# Split as number, join as string, repeat

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, base-conversion

Consider the process of:

1. Taking a non-negative integer N.
   e.g. `27`.
2. Spliting it into integers `N - floor(N/2)` and `floor(N/2)` (a 'bigger' and 'smaller' half) and writing them in that order.
   e.g.`27` becomes `14 13`.
3. Removing the space to join the integers into a new, much larger integer.
   e.g. `14 13` becomes `1413`.
4. Repeating steps 2 and 3 some desired number of times.
   e.g. `1413` → `707 706` → `707706` → `353853 353853` → `353853353853` → ...

This challenge is about doing exactly this, but not always in base 10.

## Challenge

Write a program that takes in three numbers, B, N, and S:

- B is an integer from 2 to 10 that is the base of N (binary to decimal).
- N is the non-negative integer to apply the splitting-rejoining process to. To make user input easier, it is given as a **string** in base B, not an integer.
- S is a non-negative integer that is the number of times to repeat the splitting-rejoining process.

The output of the program is the string representation of N in base B after S split-join procedures.

When S is `0`, no splits are done, so the output is always N.

When N is `0`, all splits have the form `0 0` and reduce to `0` again, so the output is always `0`.

## Examples

- `B = 10, N = 27, S = 1` → `1413`
- `B = 10, N = 27, S = 2` → `707706`
- `B = 9, N = 27, S = 1` → `1413`
- `B = 9, N = 27, S = 2` → `652651`
- `B = anything, N = anything, S = 0` → `N`
- `B = anything, N = 0, S = anything` → `0`

Table for all B with N = `1` for S = `0` to `7`:

```
B       S=0     S=1     S=2     S=3         S=4             S=5                 S=6                                 S=7
2       1       10      11      101         1110            111111              10000011111                         10000100001000001111
3       1       10      21      1110        202201          101101101100        1201201201212012012011              212100212102121002121212100212102121002120
4       1       10      22      1111        223222          111311111311        2232222232322322222322              11131111131311311111311113111113131131111131
5       1       10      32      1413        432431          213441213440        104220331443104220331442            2433241322130211014044424332413221302110140443
6       1       10      33      1514        535535          245550245545        122553122553122553122552            4125434125434125434125441254341254341254341254
7       1       10      43      2221        11111110        40404044040403      2020202202020220202022020201        10101011010101101010110101011010101101010110101011010100
8       1       10      44      2222        11111111        44444454444444      2222222622222222222226222222        11111113111111111111131111111111111311111111111113111111
9       1       10      54      2726        13581357        62851746285173      3142536758708231425367587081        15212633743485606571782880411521263374348560657178288040
10      1       10      55      2827        14141413        70707077070706      3535353853535335353538535353        17676769267676676767692676771767676926767667676769267676
```

Table for all B with random N  for S = `0` to `3`:

```
B       S=0     S=1         S=2                 S=3
2       11011   11101101    11101111110110      11101111110111110111111011
3       2210    11021101    20102012010200      1001212100121210012121001211
4       1113    230223      112112112111        2302302302323023023022
5       101     2323        11341134            31430423143042
6       120     4040        20202020            1010101010101010
7       134     5252        24612461            1230456412304564
8       22      1111        445444              222622222622
9       4       22          1111                505505
10      92      4646        23232323            1161616211616161
```

## Details

- Take input via stdin or the command line. Output to stdout.
- Instead of a program, you may write a function that takes B, N, and S and prints the result normally or returns it (as a string).
- B, N, and S may be taken in any order.
- All inputs that produce outputs whose decimal values are below 2<sup>32</sup> should work.
- N is represented in the usual way. i.e. most significant digit first and no leading zeros except in zero itself which is written `0`. (Outputting `00` instead of `0` is invalid.)
- **The shortest code in bytes wins.**

<sup>[Iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) you enjoy my challenges, consider giving [Block Building Bot Flocks!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50690/26997) some love :)</sup>

Comment: I don't know if a leaderboard for answers is really necessary.

Comment: @orlp Probably not. I'll remove it and put it back if there are a bunch of answers. I just wanted to show off my and Optimizers Stack Snippet [shenanigans](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/arbitrary-stack-snippet-loader).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
vujksmjldQc2UiGQvwz
```

Takes input in the format `N\nB\nS`. Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=vujksmjldQc2UiGQvwz&input=27%0A10%0A1&debug=0) or [Test harness](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=z+Q%23w%3Dzw%3DQvw%0AvujksmjldQc2UiGQvwz&input=Test+Cases%3A%0A%22%22%0AB+%3D+10%2C+N+%3D+27%2C+S+%3D+1%0A27%0A10%0A1%0AB+%3D+10%2C+N+%3D+27%2C+S+%3D+2%0A27%0A10%0A2%0AB+%3D+9%2C+N+%3D+27%2C+S+%3D+1%0A27%0A9%0A1%0AB+%3D+9%2C+N+%3D+27%2C+S+%3D+2%0A27%0A9%0A2%0AB+%3D+5%2C+N+%3D+141%2C+S+%3D+0%0A141%0A5%0A0%0AB+%3D+9%2C+N+%3D+0%2C+S+%3D+4%0A0%0A9%0A4&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
                      implicit: z = 1st input (N)
                                Q = 2nd input evaluated (B)
 u              vwz   reduce z (evaluated 3rd input) times by:
             iGQ         convert string from base Q to base 10
            U            create a range [0, 1, ..., ^-1]
          c2             split into 2 lists (lengths are N-[N/2] and [N/2])
     m                   map each list d to:
       ld                   their length
      j  Q                  in base Q
    s                    join both lists
  jk                     join the numbers by ""
v                     convert string to int (getting rid of leading zeros)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <strike>29</strike> 21 bytes

```
jku+j-JiGQK/J2QjKQvwz
```

Really straightforward implementation.

Takes input on stdin in the following format:

```
N
B
S
```

Comment: This gives the wrong output `00` for `N=0`.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 101 bytes

```
Nest[a~Function~(b=FromDigits)[Through@((c=IntegerString)@*Ceiling<>c@*Floor)[a/2],#],#2~b~#,#3]~c~#&
```

Uses some `Through` trickery to apply both the ceiling and floor functions. Just ignore the errors.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 24 bytes

```
q~:B;{:~Bb_)\]2f/Bfbs}*i
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AB%3B%7B%3A~Bb_)%5C%5D2f%2FBfbs%7D*i&input=%221%22%207%202) Takes input as `"N" S B`.

### Explanation

```
q~                       e# Read an eval input.
  :B;                    e# Store the base in B and discard it.
     {               }*  e# Repeat S times.
      :~                 e# Turn the string N into an array of digits.
        Bb               e# Interpret as base B.
          _)\            e# Duplicate and increment. Swap order.
             ]2f/        e# Wrap them in an array and (integer-)divide both by 2.
                 Bfb     e# Convert both to base B.
                    s    e# Flatten into a single string.
                       i e# Convert to an integer to fix the N = 0 case.
```

Comment: `"0" 1 9` outputted `00`. I tried to golf it: `q~:B;{:~Bb,2/z:,Bfbs}*`, but also invalid because it outputted empty string instead.

Comment: An `i` at the end would take care of `00`. You can get the byte back by replacing `2/:I-I]` with `)\]2f/`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 78 <s>79</s>

Recursive function. Run snippet to test (Firefox only)

**Edit** 1 byte saved thx @DocMax

```js
F=(b,n,s,S=x=>x.toString(b),m=parseInt(n,b))=>m*s?F(b,S(-~m>>1)+S(m>>1),s-1):n

// Ungolfed

U=(b,n,s)=>
{
  var S=x=>x.toString(b) // function to convert in base b
  var m=parseInt(n,b) // string in base b to integer
  if (m==0 || s==0)
    return n
  else  
    return F(b,S((m+1)>>1) + S( m>>1 ),s-1)
}

// Test
test=[
  {B: 10, N: '0', S:3, K: '0' }, {B: 10, N: '27', S: 1, K: '1413' }, {B: 10, N: '27', S: 2, K: '707706' }, {B: 9, N: '27', S: 1, K: '1413' }, {B: 9, N: '27', S: 2, K: '652651' }
];

test2=[[2, '11011', '11101101', '11101111110110', '11101111110111110111111011'],[3, '2210', '11021101', '20102012010200', '1001212100121210012121001211'],[4, '1113', '230223', '112112112111', '2302302302323023023022'],[5, '101', '2323', '11341134', '31430423143042' ]  ,[6, '120', '4040', '20202020', '1010101010101010'],[7, '134', '5252', '24612461', '1230456412304564'],[8, '22', '1111', '445444', '222622222622'],[9, '4', '22', '1111', '505505'],[10, '92', '4646', '23232323', '1161616211616161' ]
]
test2.forEach(r=>test.push(
  {B:r[0],N:r[1],S:1,K:r[2]}, {B:r[0],N:r[1],S:2,K:r[3]}, {B:r[0],N:r[1],S:3,K:r[4]}
))  

test.forEach(t => (
  r=F(t.B, t.N, t.S), 
  B.innerHTML += '<tr><th>'+(r==t.K?'Ok':'Failed')
      +'</th><td>'+t.B +'</td><td>'+t.N
      +'</td><td>'+t.S +'</td><td>'+r +'</td><td>'+t.K +'</td></tr>'
))
```

```css
th,td { font-size: 12px; padding: 4px; font-family: helvetica }
```

```html
<table><thead><tr>
  <th>Test<th>B<th>N<th>S<th>Result<th>Check
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody id=B></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I truly love how elaborate your proofs of success are. Also, you can save 1 by replacing `m&&s` with `m*s`.

Comment: @DocMax it's a real and useful unit test. It's too easy to break everything while golfing.

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 6, 90 bytes

```
var f=(B,N,S)=>((n,s)=>S?f(B,s(n+1>>1)+s(n>>1),S-1):s(n))(parseInt(N,B),x=>x.toString(B))
```

Defining a recursive function using a variable is not really good style, but it is the shortest code I could come up with in ECMAScript 6.

Getting the corner case `"00" => "0"` right wastes three bytes (`s(n)` instead of simply `N`).

To try it out, you can use [Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/): copy/paste the code and print example invocation results like so: `console.log(f(9, "27", 2))`.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp - 113 characters

```
(lambda(b n s)(dotimes(i s)(setf n(format ()"~vR~vR"b (- #1=(parse-integer n :radix b)#2=(floor #1# 2))b #2#)))n)
```

## Ungolfed

```lisp
(lambda(b n s)
  (dotimes(i s)
    (setf n (format () "~vR~vR" b (- #1=(parse-integer n :radix b)
                                     #2=(floor #1# 2))
                                b #2#)))
  n)
```

- The `~vR` format directive outputs integer in base `v`, where `v` is provided as an arguments to `format`.
- `parse-integer` accepts a `:radix` argument for converting from a specified base.
- `#1=` and `#1#` (respectively assign and use) are reader variables which allow to share common sub-expressions. When expanded, they give the following code:

  ```lisp
  (lambda (b n s)
    (dotimes (i s)
      (setf n
              (format nil "~vr~vr" b
                      (- (parse-integer n :radix b)
                         (floor (parse-integer n :radix b) 2))
                      b (floor (parse-integer n :radix b) 2))))
    n)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 27 bytes

```
Lcb:+J[(bFB:a)%2i]+b//2TBab
```

Takes base, integer, and number of repetitions as command-line arguments. The algorithm is straightforward, but uses a couple interesting language features:

```
                             a, b, c initialized from cmdline args, and i = 0 (implicit)
Lc                           Do c times:
        bFB:a                Convert b from base a to decimal and assign back to b
      [(     )%2i]           Construct a list containing b%2 and 0 (using i to avoid
                               scanning difficulties)
                  +b//2      Add floor(b/2) to both elements of list; the list now contains
                               b-b//2 and b//2
                       TBa   Convert elements of list back to base a
     J                       Join list
    +                        Coerce to number (necessary to turn 00 into plain 0)
  b:                         Assign back to b
                          b  Print b at the end
```

Pip's scalar type, which represents both numbers and strings, is handy here, as are item-wise operations on lists; unfortunately, parentheses and the two-character operators `FB`, `TB`, and `//` negate any advantage.

Alternate solution, without the intermediate assignment but still 27 bytes:

```
Lcb:+J[bFBa%2i]+bFBa//2TBab
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 245 bytes

```
int b,z,n,f,r;c(char*t,n){return n?((z=c(t,n/b)),z+sprintf(t+z,"%d",n%b)):0;}main(){char t[99],*p;gets(t);b=atoi(t);f=n=strtol(p=strchr(t,32)+1,0,b);if(!(r=atoi(strchr(p,32)+1)))f=0;while(r--)n=strtol(t+c(t+c(t,n-n/2),n/2)*0,0,b);puts(f?t:"0");}
```

This isn't going to win *anything*, but it was fun to make!

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>115</del> 112 bytes

```php
function($b,$n,$s){while($s--)$n=($c=base_convert)(ceil($n=$c($n,$b,10)/2),10,$b).$c(floor($n),10,$b);return$n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZAxa8MwEIXn@FccRoNElDb2EowiCoVCh9IGuhZMLaTaYCQhOe0Q/NvdU3BCW5pMd7r3vnuHfOun7Z1vPegQXKiD9i4Mnf2gayaAGDmZvVVD5ywlDSeWk8gOX23Xa0riasWIlZQo2bxHXStnP3UYGFW66ykqRNFENLxYs9uSYcEHu8Gx6Z0LKJ5mIuhhHyyxYpxEplXrIL8HCajCM9Zyw@E1vd@GnONZFAWcFYzD7nFXP7w8XaPK31T5P1VdiKquJFUXgqo/OT/gzLgAFEiT/CLVbbo4dcslMDhki@N@/DbIcZ/IFjMRQSZbTMAmNSf/DBh6hAqePOxMj/PC8wXj9A0)

Ungolfed:

```php
function split_join_repeat( $b, $n, $s ) {
    // repeat S times
    for( $x=0; $x < $s; $x++ ) {
        // convert N from base B to base 10 for arithmetic
        $n = base_convert( $n, $b, 10 );
        // divide and split in base 10, convert back to base B and join
        $n = base_convert( ceil( $n / 2 ), 10, $b ) .
            base_convert( floor( $n / 2 ), 10, $b );
    }
    return $n;
}
```

Output

```php
B = 10, N = 27, S = 1   1413
B = 10, N = 27, S = 2   707706
B = 9, N = 27, S = 1    1413
B = 9, N = 27, S = 2    652651

2   1   10  11  101 1110    111111  10000011111 10000100001000001111    
3   1   10  21  1110    202201  101101101100    1201201201212012012011  212100212102121002121212100212102121002120  
4   1   10  22  1111    223222  111311111311    2232222232322322222322  11131111131311311111311113111113131131111131    
5   1   10  32  1413    432431  213441213440    104220331443104220331442    12141204110401030043301214120411040103004330    
6   1   10  33  1514    535535  245550245545    122553122553122553122552    131022143412311313533131022143412311313533  
7   1   10  43  2221    11111110    40404044040403  2020202202020220202022020201    40556522600645213204055652260064521320  
8   1   10  44  2222    11111111    44444454444444  2222222622222222222226222222    76650460747555347665046074755534    
9   1   10  54  2726    13581357    62851746285173  3142536758708231425367587081    4861155667688600048611556676886000  
10  1   10  55  2827    14141413    70707077070706  3535353853535335353538535353    17676769267677271767676926767727
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 17 bytes

```
_nW o ó ®ÊsWÃq}gV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/Pz4vXCFf4fBmhUPrDncVhx9uLqxND/v/35ArWsnIXCmWy9AAAA)

Takes input in the order S, N, B with N as a [singleton list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/71434). Accepting N without a singleton list costs [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/Pz4vXCFf4fBmhUPrDncVhx9uLqxNjw6L/f/fkEvJyFyJy9AAAA).

Explanation:

```
_             }g     #Get the Sth item generated by this function...
                V    #...Starting with N as the 0th item:
 nW                  # Evaluate the previous item as a base B number
    o                # Create a list with that length
      ó              # Divide it into two lists as evenly as possible
        ®   Ã        # For each of those lists:
         Ê           #  Get the length
          sW         #  Convert it to base B
             q       # Join the two strings together
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 105 bytes

```forth
: f base ! 0 ?do 0. 2swap >number nip 2drop 2 /mod >r i + r> 0 tuck <# #s 2drop #s #> loop type decimal ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BcsIwDEX3nOLhLIE08YYBipnhAN1wghAnkCnBHicp09MHmYFp2Uj6T9KXahf68@JUxzSOa2qORVcxJWNnHVmK7m6Fx1yH9lgFro1H2@Ak8tE6iwk0zAhGNvqh/OYzIemeM1IkhouTsv/1FbYqm7a4sJFLnlSxZ4uyQ3RLQwRzDhG5H7n1x74i0w/48BHIwqDk3TKwmXQKvVTk5Bn@pfSbyln9b4kY7w)

#### Explanation

Changes the base to B, then in a loop that runs S times:

- Converts string to a number
- Splits number in 2 halves (one larger than the other if odd)
- Combines the two numbers back into a string

Prints the string when finished and sets the base back to 10 (so we can run multiple times in a row)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
:f                    \ start a new word definition
  base !              \ set the base to B
  0 ?do               \ loop from 0 to S-1 (runs S times)
    0. 2swap          \ places a double-length 0 on the stack behind the string
    >number           \ converts the string to a number in the current base
    nip 2drop         \ get rid of string remainder and second part of double
    2 /mod            \ get the quotient and remainder of dividing by 2
    >r                \ throw the quotient on the return stack
    i                 \ get a copy of the quotient from the return stack
    +                 \ add quotient and remainder
    r>                \ move quotient from return stack to stack
    0 tuck            \ convert both to double-length numbers
    <#                \ start a pictured numeric output
      #s              \ add entire number to output
      2drop           \ drop empty number
      #s              \ add second number to output
    #>                \ convert output to a string and drop number from stack
  loop                \ end loop
  type                \ print output string
  decimal             \ set base back to 10
;                     \ end word definition
```