# Compute the Resistance of a 4 Band Color Coded Resistor

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

[Resistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor) commonly have [color coded bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code#Resistor_color-coding) that are used to identify their [resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance) in [Ohms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm). In this challenge we'll only consider the normal 4-band, tan, axial-lead resistors. We'll express them as:

```
xyzt
```

Where `x` is the first band for the first significant figure, `y` is the second band for the second significant figure, `z` the third band for the multiplier, and `t` is the fourth band for the [tolerance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance).

Each of `xyzt` represents a letter that abbreviates the color of the band:

```
K = Black
N = Brown
R = Red
O = Orange
Y = Yellow
G = Green
B = Blue
V = Violet
A = Gray
W = White
g = Gold
s = Silver
_ = None
```

So, for example, `NKOg` is some particular resistor.

The resistance can be calculated with the help of this table:

[image: Resistor color code table]

As the table suggests:

- `x` and `y` can be any letters except `g`, `s`, and `_`.
- `z` can be anything except `_`.
- We'll restrict `t` to only be `g`, `s`, or `_`.

([Here's a handy resistance calculator that deals with exact same set of resistors we are.](http://www.dannyg.com/examples/res2/resistor.htm))

The resistance is `10 * x + y` times the `z` multiplier, to a tolerance of the `t` percentage.

> For example, to calculate the resistance of `NKOg`, we see that:
>
> 1. `N` means Brown for 1.
> 2. `K` means Black for 0.
> 3. `O` means Orange for 10<sup>3</sup>.
> 4. `g` means Gold for ±5%.
>
> So the resistance is `(10*1 + 0)*10^3` → `10000 Ω ±5%`.

## Challenge

Write a program or function that takes in a 4 character string of the form `xyzt` and prints or returns the resistance in the form `[resistance] Ω ±[tolerance]%`.

- **The resistor may be "upside-down", i.e. in the reverse order `tzyx`. For example, both `NKOg` and `gOKN` should produce `10000 Ω ±5%`.**
- The resistance is always in plain ohms, never kilohms, megohms, etc.
- [`Ω`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a9/index.htm) may be replaced with `ohms`, e.g. `10000 ohms ±5%`.
- [`±`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm) may be replaced with `+/-`, e.g. `10000 Ω +/-5%`.
- Having trailing zeros to the right of a decimal point is fine. (e.g. `10000.0 Ω +/-5%`)
- You can assume input is always valid (`x` and `y` never `gs_`; `z` never `_`; `t` only `gs_`).
- All 10×10×12×3 = 3600 possible resistors (2×3600 possible inputs) need to be supported even if some color band combinations aren't produced in real life.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

## Examples

1. `gOKN` → `10000 ohms +/-5%`
2. `KKR_` → `0 Ω +/-20%`
3. `ggKN` → `1 ohms ±5%`
4. `ggGO` → `3.5 Ω ±5%`
5. `ssGO` → `0.350 Ω ±10%`
6. `GOOs` → `53000 ohms +/-10%`
7. `YAK_` → `48.0 ohms +/-20%`
8. `_WAV` → `78000000000 Ω ±20%`
9. `gBBB` → `66000000.000 ohms ±5%`
10. `_RYR` → `2400.00 ohms ±20%`

<sup>[Iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) you enjoy my challenges, consider checking out [Block Building Bot Flocks!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50690/26997)</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CJam, <s>59</s> <s>58</s> <s>56</s> 50 bytes

```
r_W%e>"sgKNROYGBVAW"f#2f-~A*+A@#*" Ω ±"@[KA5]='%
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r_W%25e%3E%22sgKNROYGBVAW%22f%232f-~A*%2BA%40%23*%22%20%CE%A9%20%C2%B1%22%40%5BKA5%5D%3D'%25&input=ggGO).

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
" Ω ±"l_W%e<)iB%5*F-'%@"gKNROYGBVAW"f#:(2/'e*s~o
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%20%CE%A9%20%C2%B1%22l_W%25e%3C%29iB%255*F-'%25%40%22gKNROYGBVAW%22f%23%3A%282%2F'e*s~o&input=_RYR).

*(Thanks to @user23013 for a byte)*

---

I started out in Python, but

```py
eval("%d%de%d"%tuple("gKNROYGBVAW".find(x)-1for x in L))
```

was too expensive...

Comment: ``:(2/'e*s~`` saves the `[`.

Comment: @user23013 Ah thanks, I've been trying a bunch of ways of inserting the `e` where it's necessary, but I never thought of `/` and `*`

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, <s>130</s> 114 bytes

```python
def f(v):
 a,b,c,d=["_sgKNROYGBVAW".index(x)-3for x in v[::(1,-1)[v[0]in'sg_']]]
 return "%s Ω ±%s%%"%((10*a+b)*10**c,2.5*2**-d)
```

*edit:* @Sp3000 points out that the ordering can be better detected with `min(v,v[::-1])` rather than `v[::(1,-1)[v[0]in'sg_']]` (saving 10 bytes), not check the index of `_` and remove some unnecessary whitespace.

```python
def f(v):a,b,c,d=["sgKNROYGBVAW".find(x)-2for x in min(v,v[::-1])];return"%s Ω ±%s%%"%((10*a+b)*10**c,2.5*2**-d)
```

Comment: Thanks - I realised about concatenating the lines, but I missed the trick of using `min()` to detect the correct ordering - nice.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 93 bytes

```
#!perl -lp
ord>90and$_=reverse;s/./-3+index zsgKNROYGBVAW,$&/ge;$_=s/..\K/e/*$_." Ω ±"./.$/*5*$&."%"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>135 132</s> 130 bytes

```haskell
r y|y<"["=p[k|j<-y,(c,k)<-zip"_ sgKNROYGBVAW"[-4..],c==j]
r y=r.reverse$y
p[a,b,c,d]=show((a*10+b)*10**c)++" Ω ±"++show(-5*d)++"%"
```

**Explanation:**

```
r y|y<"["=            If first letter of argument is a capital
p[..]                 Call p on the list created
[k|                   Make a list of all k
   j<-y               Draw character j from input
       ,(c,k)<-       With (c,k) being a pair from
               zip    A list of pairs of corresponding elements from the lists:
"_ sgKNROYGBVAW"       The space at 2nd position is to match '_' with -4, but 's' with -2
[-4..]                 An infinite list starting at -4
,c==j]                Only use element k if j equals the character c

r y=r.reverse$y       If first call fails, call again with reversed argument.

p[a,b,c,d]=           Assign the first four elements of the argument to a,b,c,d respectively.
show                  Turn (number) into string
10**c                 10 to the power of c
++                    Concatenate strings
-5*d                  This works for the tolerance because '_' makes d=-4
```

*Thanks to nimi, I shaved off another 2 bytes.*