# Formic Functions - Ant Queen of the Hill Contest

Tags: grid, game, king-of-the-hill, javascript

**[Watch live](https://trichoplax.github.io/formic-functions/) | [Active answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest?answertab=active#tab-top) | [Add new answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest#footer) | [Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62666/formic-functions) | [Source code](https://github.com/trichoplax/formic-functions) | [Leaderboard](https://github.com/trichoplax/formic-functions/blob/master/README.md#leaderboard)**

*New tournaments whenever needed. New players and new updates very welcome.*

[image: Queen ant on a dance floor with changing coloured tiles]

<sup>Not actual game footage.</sup>

Each player starts with one ant - a queen, who collects food. Each piece of food can be held or used to produce a worker. Workers also collect food to be brought back to the queen.

16 players compete in one arena. The winner is the queen holding the most food after she has taken 30,000 turns. The catch is that the ants can only communicate by changing the colors of the arena squares, which may also be changed by rival ants...

## Watching the game

This is a JavaScript competition, which means you can watch the game play out live in your browser by clicking the link below.

#### [Click here to watch the game being played live](https://trichoplax.github.io/formic-functions/)

*Many thanks to **[Helka Homba](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26997/helka-homba)** for the original Stack Snippet King of the Hill contests, **[Red vs. Blue - Pixel Team Battlebots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48353/20283)**, and **[Block Building Bot Flocks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50690/20283)**, which provided the idea of a web browser hosted KotH and heavily informed the code for this one.*

*Huge thanks also for all the feedback and testing from the wonderful people in the Sandbox and in Chat.*

## Leaderboard

[image: Picture of top places of leaderboard]

*(Click the image to see the full leaderboard and joint places explanation - only a few players are showing here to save space.)*

This leaderboard is based on the players as they were on Sunday 2<sup>nd</sup> September 2018.

## Screenshots

Some images of how the arena looks towards the end of a game. Click images to view full size.

[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]
[image: image of the arena]

To get an idea of what is happening in the arena and how all these patterns form, you can run the game and hover the mouse over the arena to zoom in and see the ants at work. Also see the fascinating explanations in the answers.

## The arena

The arena is a toroidal (edge wrapping) grid of square cells. It has width 2500 and height 1000. All cells start as color 1.

Initially exactly 0.1% of cells will contain food. The 2500 pieces of food will be scattered uniformly randomly. No new food will be introduced during the game.

The queens will be placed randomly on empty cells, with no guarantee that they will not be adjacent to each other (although this is very unlikely).

## Ant abilities

- **Sight:** Each ant sees the 9 cells in its 3 by 3 neighbourhood. It has no knowledge of any other ants outside this neighbourhood. It sees the contents of each of the 9 cells (other ants and food), and also each cell's *color*.
- **No memory:** Each ant makes its decisions based on what it sees - it does not remember what it did in the previous turn and has no way of storing state other than in the colors of the arena cells.
- **No orientation:** An ant does not know where it is or which way it faces - it has no concept of North. The 3 by 3 neighbourhood will be presented to it at a randomly rotated orientation that changes each turn so it cannot even walk in a straight line unless it has colors to guide it. *(Making the same move every turn will result in a random walk rather than a straight line.)*
- **Moving, color marking and producing workers:** See **Output** below.
- **Immortality:** These are highland ants that cannot die. You can confuse rival ants by changing the colors around them, or constrain them from moving by surrounding them with 8 ants of your own, but they cannot be harmed apart from this.
- **Carrying food:** A worker can carry up to 1 piece of food. A queen can carry an arbitrary amount of food.
- **Transferal of food:** If a worker is adjacent to a queen (in any of the 8 directions), food will be automatically transferred in one of the following ways:

  - A laden worker adjacent to its own queen will transfer its food to its queen.
  - An unladen worker adjacent to an enemy queen will steal 1 piece of food, if present.

A worker cannot steal from a worker, and a queen cannot steal from a queen. Also a worker cannot take food from its own queen, and a queen cannot steal from an enemy worker.

*Note that ants take turns sequentially and food transferral occurs at the end of each ant's individual turn and does not take up a turn. It happens regardless of whether a worker moves next to a queen or a queen moves next to a worker, and still happens if both ants involved stand still for their move.*

## Coding

#### Provide a function body

Each ant is controlled by an ant function. ***Each turn the player's ant function is called separately for each ant (not just once per player, but once for the queen and once for each worker that player controls).*** Each turn, the ant function will receive its input and return a move for that particular ant.

Post an answer containing a code block showing the body of a JavaScript function, and it will be automatically included in the [controller](https://trichoplax.github.io/formic-functions/) (just refresh the controller page). The name of the player forms the title of the answer, in the form `# PlayerName` (which will be truncated to a maximum of 40 characters in the controller tables).

#### No state, no time, no random

A function must not access global variables and must not store state between turns. It may use built in functions that do not involve storing state. For example, the use of `Math.abs()` is fine, but `Date.getTime()` must not be used.

**An ant function may only use a pseudo random number generator that it supplies itself, that does not store state.** For example, it may use the colors/food/ants visible as the seed each turn. `Math.random()` is explicitly forbidden, since like nearly all pseudorandom number generators, it stores state in order to progress to the next number in sequence.

A simple random strategy is still possible due to the random orientation of the input - an ant that always chooses the same direction will perform a random walk rather than a straight line path. See the example answers for simple ways of [using this randomness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135103/20283) and [avoiding this randomness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135104/20283).

An ant function is permitted to contain further functions within its body. See the [existing answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest?answertab=active#tab-top) for examples of how this can be useful.

#### Console.log

You can log to the console during testing a new challenger player, but once posted as an answer here the player will have no access to `console.log`. Attempting to use it will result in an error and disqualification until edited. This should help to keep leaderboard tournaments fast, while still allowing debugging code pasted into the new challenger text area.

## Input and output

#### Input

The orientation of the input will be chosen at random for each ant and for each turn. The input will be rotated by 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees, but will never be reflected.

Cells are numbered in English reading order:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

The ant function will receive an array called `view`, containing an object for each of the 9 visible cells. Each object will have the following:

```
color: a number from 1 to 8
food: 0 or 1
ant: null if there is no ant on that cell, or otherwise an ant object
```

If a cell contains an ant, the ant object will have the following:

```
food: 0 or more (maximum 1 for a worker)
type: 1 to 4 for a worker, or 5 for a queen
friend: true or false
```

The ant can determine its own details by looking at the ant in the central cell, `view[4].ant`. For example, `view[4].ant.type` is 5 for a queen, or a number from 1 to 4 for a worker (indicating its type).

#### Output

Output is returned as an object representing the action to take. This can have any of the following:

```
cell: a number from 0 to 8 (mandatory)
color: a number from 1 to 8 (optional)
type: a number from 1 to 4 (optional)
```

If `color` and `type` are omitted or zero, then `cell` indicates the cell to move to.

If `color` is non-zero, the indicated cell is set to that color.

If `type` is non-zero, a worker ant of that type is created on the indicated cell. Only a queen can create a new worker, and only if she has food, as this costs one piece of food per worker.

Example outputs:

```
{cell:0}: move to cell 0
{cell:4}: move to cell 4 (that is, do nothing, as 4 is the central cell)
{cell:4, color:8}: set own cell to color 8
{cell:6, type:1}: create a type 1 worker on cell 6
{cell:6, color:1}: set cell 6 to color 1
{cell:6, color:0}: equivalent to just `{cell:6}` - move rather than set color
{cell:6, type:0}: equivalent to just `{cell:6}` - move rather than create worker
{cell:6, color:0, type:0}: move to cell 6 - color 0 and type 0 are ignored
```

Invalid outputs:

```
{cell:9}: cell must be from 0 to 8
{cell:0, color:9}: color must be from 1 to 8
{cell:0, type:5}: type must be from 1 to 4 (cannot create a new queen)
{cell:4, type:1}: cannot create a worker on a non-empty cell
{cell:0, color:1, type:1}: cannot set color and create worker in the same turn
```

An ant moving onto a cell containing food will automatically pick up the piece of food.

## Worker type

Each worker has a *type*, a number from 1 to 4. This has no meaning to the controller, and is for the player to do with as they wish. A queen could produce all her workers as type 1, and give them all the same behaviour, or she could produce several types of workers with different behaviours, perhaps type 1 as foragers and type 2 as guards.

The worker type number is assigned by you when a worker is created, and cannot be changed thereafter. Use it however you see fit.

## Turn order

Ants take turns in a set order. At the start of a game the queens are assigned a random order which does not change for the rest of the game. When a queen creates a worker, that worker is inserted into the turn order at the position before its queen. This means that all other ants belonging to all players will move exactly once before the new worker takes its first turn.

## Limit on number of players

Obviously an unlimited number of players cannot fit into the arena. Since there are now more than 16 answers, each game will feature a randomly chosen 16 of them. The average performance over many games will give a leaderboard featuring all the players, without ever having more than 16 in a single game.

## Time limit per turn

Each time the ant function is called, it should return within 15 milliseconds. Since the time limit may be exceeded due to fluctuations outside the ant function's control, an average will be calculated. If at any point the average is above 15 milliseconds and the total time taken by that particular ant function across all calls so far is more than 10 seconds, the relevant player will be disqualified.

## Disqualification

This means the player will not be eligible to win and their ant function will not be called again during that game. They will also not be included in any further games. If a player is disqualified on the tournament machine during a leaderboard game then it will be excluded from all future leaderboard games until edited.

A player will be disqualified for any of the following for any of its ants (queen or worker):

- Exceeding the time limit as described (averaged over 10 seconds).
- Returning an invalid move as described under Output.
- The cell to move to contains an ant.
- The cell to move to contains food and the ant is already a laden worker.
- The cell to produce a worker on is not empty (contains food or an ant).
- A worker is trying to produce a worker.

It may seem harsh to disqualify for invalid moves, rather than simply interpreting this as no move. However, I believe that enforcing correct implementations will lead to more interesting strategies over time. This is not intended to be an additional challenge, so a clear reason will be displayed when a player is disqualified, with the specific input and output alongside to aid in fixing the code.

## Multiple answers and editing

You may provide multiple answers, provided that they do not team up against the others. Provided each answer is working solely towards its own victory, you are permitted to tailor your strategy to take advantage of weaknesses in specific other strategies, including changing the color of the cells to confuse or manipulate them. Bear in mind that as more answers come in, the likelihood of meeting any particular player in a given game will diminish.

You may also edit your answers whenever you choose. It is up to you whether you post a new answer or edit an existing one. Provided the game is not flooded with many near-identical variations, there should be no problem.

If you make a variation of another person's answer, please remember to give them credit by linking to their answer from yours.

## Scoring

At the end of each game, a player's score is the number of other players who have less food carried by their queen. Food carried by workers is not counted. This score is added to the leaderboard, which is displayed in order of average score per game.

Joint places indicate that the order of players is not yet consistent between 6 subsets of the games played so far. The list of games is split into 6 subsets because this is the minimum number that will give a probability of less than 5% that a given pair of players will be assigned distinct places in the wrong order.

## Chat

To keep the comments section clear here, please use the [dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62666/formic-functions) for any questions and discussion. Comments on this post are likely to be cleared after a while, whereas messages in the chat room will be kept permanently.

Just to let you know, I'll be more inclined to upvote answers that include a clear and interesting explanation of how the code works.

Comment: if an ant is adjacent to two queens, what happens?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon for the sake of anyone reading through these comments, [I've answered that in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38953498#38953498)

Comment: @Draco18s I want to be able to find the Forensic Ant queen. How do I do that with your page?

Comment: @Draco18s Ah, I see the problem, it's incompatible with the "Fit canvas to width" option.

Comment: @Neil Oh interesting. So it is. I hadn't used it myself so I hadn't noticed. Huh. It should be drawing things immediately after the zoom view is drawn...Well, I'll admit I don't really know how it works.

Comment: Bug: The left 60% or so of the zoom view does not appear. Chrome 59 Mac.

Comment: Oh wait that's not a bug. I think a semitansparent overlay would be better than an opaque halfscreen.

Comment: Suggestion: If `cell` is omitted in the output, assume a value of `4`.

Comment: If I put a worker next to an enemy queen, and my queen next to that worker, the worker steals 1 food from the enemy queen but never gives it to my queen. Is this intentional? The rules imply that the worker should pick up food and give up food on alternate turns… (I *may* be working on a vampire bot…)

Comment: Nevermind, I found a way around it.

Comment: @Dave I've been waiting for the first vampire... Yes a laden worker should give its food to its queen regardless of whether there is another queen adjacent. Provided there are no enemy workers taking it straight back from your queen the turn after it arrives, this should work. If you have an example of it not working I'd be very interested in seeing it in in case the controller needs fixing. You can post details, images, log output in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62666/formic-functions).

Comment: @Dave I've found the problem - it was only checking for passing food when an ant moved (changed location) since under normal circumstances that's the only way a laden worker and its queen could end up adjacent. However, stealing food from another queen is an exception to this so I've corrected the controller to check for passing food at the end of every turn regardless of whether the location changed. You'll need to refresh the controller to pick up this change. Thanks for spotting this, and sorry for slowing down the development of the vampire...

Comment: @trichoplax well I was just about to say I'd tracked it down to movement but it looks like you got it first! I've posted the vampire bot with it's workaround (thief worker jiggles back-and-forth). Sadly it's not very good yet; even with the opponents who make large blotches on the board, it's hard to find anybody! In fairness I'm only targeting one specific player so far; should have better luck extending it to target multiple enemies (first-come-first-sapped)

Comment: [Modified controller for developers](https://draco18s.github.io/formic-functions/)! Now with [real testing capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXxIL.png)!

Comment: [Some debugging tools](https://gist.github.com/gilad905/bd30b5c3e5dd8c0165fc47c173ac0a54)

Comment: @giladmayani Just added those (and a third) to my modified controller. Good stuff.

Comment: @Draco18s Nice! I've been using your controller, which is also good. My next step - build a custom chrome extension, so I can write the answer's code in a local file, save it, and the page will automatically update with the answer.

Comment: Hey, I [made a thing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13891/8927)! You might find it interesting since it's inspired by this challenge and includes a [Formic Functions test implementation](https://davidje13.github.io/koth-webplayer/formic.htm).

Comment: @Dave Your controller is blazingly fast :) - but let me mention that its scoring seems to differ from the original in cases where queens are tied for food at the end of a game. The score should be the number of other participants whose queens hold (strictly) *less* food. E.g., if three players have 0 food at the end, they should all score zero for this game, not three.

Comment: @GNiklasch thanks; fixed. Also I see that your ant dominates the game now. Impressive!

Comment: @Dave View-locking feature of your controller is broken in Firefox.

Comment: @Alion fixed! Thanks for reporting. Feel free to raise issues like this in GitHub; we shouldn't steal trichoplax's comment thread!

Answer (score 20):

## Forensic Ants

*All my answers are sharing the same set of low-level helper functions.
 Search for "High-level logic begins here" to see the code specific to this answer.*

```js
// == Shared low-level helpers for all solutions ==

var QUEEN = 5;

var WHITE = 1;
var COL_MIN = WHITE;
var COL_LIM = 9;

var CENTRE = 4;

var NOP = {cell: CENTRE};

var DIR_FORWARDS = false;
var DIR_REVERSE = true;
var SIDE_RIGHT = true;
var SIDE_LEFT = false;

function sanity_check(movement) {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  if(!movement || movement.cell < 0 || movement.cell > 8) {
    return false;
  }
  if(movement.type) {
    if(movement.color) {
      return false;
    }
    if(movement.type < 1 || movement.type > 4) {
      return false;
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].ant || view[movement.cell].food) {
      return false;
    }
    if(me.type !== QUEEN || me.food < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if(movement.color) {
    if(movement.color < COL_MIN || movement.color >= COL_LIM) {
      return false;
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].color === movement.color) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if(view[movement.cell].ant) {
    return false;
  }
  if(view[movement.cell].food + me.food > 1 && me.type !== QUEEN) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function as_array(o) {
  if(Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o;
  }
  return [o];
}

function best_of(movements) {
  var m;
  for(var i = 0; i < movements.length; ++ i) {
    if(typeof(movements[i]) === 'function') {
      m = movements[i]();
    } else {
      m = movements[i];
    }
    if(sanity_check(m)) {
      return m;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function play_safe(movement) {
  // Avoid disqualification: no-op if moves are invalid
  return best_of(as_array(movement)) || NOP;
}

var RAND_SEED = (() => {
  var s = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    s += view[i].color * (i + 1);
    s += view[i].ant ? i * i : 0;
    s += view[i].food ? i * i * i : 0;
  }
  return s % 29;
})();

var ROTATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [6, 3, 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2],
  [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 6],
];

function try_all(fns, limit, wrapperFn, checkFn) {
  var m;
  fns = as_array(fns);
  for(var i = 0; i < fns.length; ++ i) {
    if(typeof(fns[i]) !== 'function') {
      if(checkFn(m = fns[i])) {
        return m;
      }
      continue;
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < limit; ++ j) {
      if(checkFn(m = wrapperFn(fns[i], j))) {
        return m;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function identify_rotation(testFns) {
  // testFns MUST be functions, not constants
  return try_all(
    testFns,
    4,
    (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]) ? ROTATIONS[r] : null,
    (r) => r
  );
}

function near(a, b) {
  return (
    Math.abs(a % 3 - b % 3) < 2 &&
    Math.abs(Math.floor(a / 3) - Math.floor(b / 3)) < 2
  );
}

function try_all_angles(solverFns) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    4,
    (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function try_all_cells(solverFns, skipCentre) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    9,
    (fn, i) => ((i === CENTRE && skipCentre) ? null : fn(i)),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function try_all_cells_near(p, solverFns) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    9,
    (fn, i) => ((i !== p && near(p, i)) ? fn(i) : null),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function ant_type_at(i, friend) {
  return (view[i].ant && view[i].ant.friend === friend) ? view[i].ant.type : 0;
}

function friend_at(i) {
  return ant_type_at(i, true);
}

function foe_at(i) {
  return ant_type_at(i, false);
}

function foe_near(p) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    if(foe_at(i) && near(i, p)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function move_agent(agents) {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  var buddies = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    ++ buddies[friend_at(i)];
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < agents.length; i += 2) {
    if(agents[i] === me.type) {
      return agents[i+1](me, buddies);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function grab_nearby_food() {
  return try_all_cells((i) => (view[i].food ? {cell: i} : null), true);
}

function go_anywhere() {
  return try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i}), true);
}

function colours_excluding(cols) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = COL_MIN; i < COL_LIM; ++ i) {
    if(cols.indexOf(i) === -1) {
      r.push(i);
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function generate_band(start, width) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < width; ++ i) {
    r.push(start + i);
  }
  return r;
}

function colour_band(colours) {
  return {
    contains: function(c) {
      return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1;
    },
    next: function(c) {
      return colours[(colours.indexOf(c) + 1) % colours.length];
    }
  };
}

function random_colour_band(colours) {
  return {
    contains: function(c) {
      return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1;
    },
    next: function() {
      return colours[RAND_SEED % colours.length];
    }
  };
}

function fast_diagonal(colourBand) {
  var m = try_all_angles([
    // Avoid nearby checked areas
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[5]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[0]};
      }
    },

    // Go in a straight diagonal line if possible
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[8]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[0]};
      }
    },

    // When in doubt, pick randomly but avoid doubling-back
    (rot) => (colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) ? null : {cell: rot[0]}),

    // Double-back when absolutely necessary
    (rot) => ({cell: rot[0]})
  ]);

  // Lay a colour track so that we can avoid doubling-back
  // (and mess up our foes as much as possible)
  if(!colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)) {
    var prevCol = m ? view[8-m.cell].color : WHITE;
    return {cell: CENTRE, color: colourBand.next(prevCol)};
  }

  return m;
}

function follow_edge(obstacleFn, side) {
  // Since we don't know which direction we came from, this can cause us to get
  // stuck on islands, but the random orientation helps to ensure we don't get
  // stuck forever.

  var order = ((side === SIDE_LEFT)
    ? [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0]
    : [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 0]
  );
  return try_all(
    [obstacleFn],
    order.length - 1,
    (fn, i) => (fn(order[i+1]) && !fn(order[i])) ? {cell: order[i]} : null,
    sanity_check
  );
}

function start_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => ((
      !protectedCols.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color)
    )
      ? {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3], color: colourBand.next(WHITE)}
      : null)
  ]);
}

function lay_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => {
      var ahead = rot[right ? 2 : 0];
      var behind = rot[right ? 8 : 6];
      if(
        colourBand.contains(view[behind].color) &&
        !protectedCols.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: ahead, color: colourBand.next(view[behind].color)};
      }
    }
  ]);
}

function follow_dotted_path(colourBand, side, direction) {
  var forwards = (direction === DIR_REVERSE) ? 7 : 1;
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);

  return try_all_angles([
    // Cell on our side? advance
    (rot) => {
      if(
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
        // Prevent sticking / trickery
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[2]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[forwards]};
      }
    },

    // Cell ahead and behind? advance
    (rot) => {
      var passedCol = view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color;
      var nextCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        colourBand.contains(passedCol) &&
        nextCol === colourBand.next(passedCol) &&

        // Prevent sticking / trickery
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 0 : 2]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[forwards]};
      }
    }
  ]);
}

function escape_dotted_path(colourBand, side, newColourBand) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  if(!newColourBand) {
    newColourBand = colourBand;
  }

  return try_all_angles([
    // Escape from beside the line
    (rot) => {
      var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color) ||
        !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
      ) {
        // not oriented, or in a corner
        return null;
      }
      return best_of([
        {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2], color: newColourBand.next(approachingCol)},
        {cell: rot[right ? 3 : 5]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 6 : 8]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 2 : 0]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 8 : 6]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]}
      ]);
    },

    // Escape from inside the line
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      return best_of([
        {cell: rot[3]},
        {cell: rot[5]},
        {cell: rot[0]},
        {cell: rot[2]},
        {cell: rot[6]},
        {cell: rot[8]}
      ]);
    }
  ]);
}

function latch_to_dotted_path(colourBand, side) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);

  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => {
      var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        colourBand.contains(approachingCol) &&
        view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color === colourBand.next(approachingCol) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color)
      ) {
        // We're on the wrong side; go inside the line
        return {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]};
      }
    },

    // Inside the line? pick a side
    (rot) => {
      var passedCol = view[rot[7]].color;
      var approachingCol = view[rot[1]].color;
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(passedCol) ||
        !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      if((approachingCol === colourBand.next(passedCol)) === right) {
        return best_of([{cell: rot[3]}, {cell: rot[6]}, {cell: rot[0]}]);
      } else {
        return best_of([{cell: rot[5]}, {cell: rot[2]}, {cell: rot[8]}]);
      }
    }
  ]);
}


// == High-level logic begins here ==


var PARTNER = 1;
var SENTINEL = 2;

var COL_DANCING1 = 8;
var COL_DANCING2 = 7;
var SAFE_COLOURS = random_colour_band(colours_excluding([WHITE, COL_DANCING1]));

function pass_time() {
  // Wait patiently for the blockage to go away by setting
  // random cell colours (unless we're near the sentinel)
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    if(i !== 4 && friend_at(i) === SENTINEL) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return {cell: 0, color: SAFE_COLOURS.next()};
}

function move_sentinel(me, buddies) {
  // Our job is to be a sentinel showing when the queen has wrapped around.
  // We are created first, so will move first.
  // We won't find any food.

  if(!buddies[QUEEN] && !buddies[PARTNER]) {
    // No ongoing dance; make sure our state is good for when they arrive
    return try_all_angles([
      {cell: CENTRE, color: WHITE},
      (rot) => ({cell: rot[1], color: COL_DANCING2}),
      (rot) => ((view[rot[0]].color === COL_DANCING1)
        ? {cell: rot[0], color: SAFE_COLOURS.next()}
        : null)
    ]);
  }

  // Dance when queen passes
  var danceStage = view[CENTRE].color;

  if(danceStage === WHITE) {
    // Dance has not begun yet, but queen & partner are nearby
    return try_all_angles((rot) => {
      if(friend_at(rot[5]) === QUEEN && friend_at(rot[8]) === PARTNER) {
        return {cell: CENTRE, color: COL_DANCING1};
      }
    });
  }

  if(danceStage === COL_DANCING1) {
    if(buddies[PARTNER]) {
      return null; // Wait for partner to see us
    }
    // Partner saw us @8 and moved down, queen followed.
    // We must also move down (will end up on a COL_DANCING2)
    return try_all_angles((rot) =>
      ((friend_at(rot[8]) === QUEEN) ? {cell: rot[7]} : null));
  }

  // Move towards queen counter-clockwise when she's diagonally connected
  return try_all_angles((rot) =>
    ((friend_at(rot[2]) === QUEEN) ? {cell: rot[1]} : null));
}

function move_partner(me, buddies) {
  // Our job is to travel with the queen and keep her oriented.
  // We are created second, so move after the sentinel.
  // Any food we find will immediately go to the queen, since
  // we are adjacent at all times.

  // Queen will be N of us; orient ourselves
  var rot = identify_rotation((rot) => friend_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN);

  if(!rot) {
    // Queen is lagging or lost;
    return null;
  }

  var danceStage = view[rot[0]].color;
  if(
    friend_at(rot[0]) === SENTINEL &&
    (danceStage === COL_DANCING1 || danceStage === COL_DANCING2)
  ) {
    // Dance down (queen will follow)
    return {cell: rot[7]};
  }

  if(view[rot[0]].ant) {
    // Queen is blocked
    return null;
  }

  // Lead queen if both can move
  return {cell: rot[3]};
}

function move_queen(me, buddies) {
  // Our job is to travel over the entire level collecting food.
  // We move last.

  if(buddies[PARTNER]) {
    // Partner will be S or SW of us; follow if they are ahead
    return try_all_angles((rot) =>
      (friend_at(rot[6]) === PARTNER) ? {cell: rot[3]} : null);
  }

  var rot = identify_rotation((rot) => friend_at(rot[3]) === SENTINEL);
  if(rot && view[rot[0]].color >= 7) {
    // Dance down (follow partner)
    return {cell: rot[7]};
  }

  // We're on our own, or the buddy strategy failed. Start again.

  rot = identify_rotation((rot) => friend_at(rot[5]) === SENTINEL);
  if(rot && me.food >= 1) {
    // Already have a sentinel; just need a partner
    return best_of([
      {cell: rot[7], type: PARTNER},
      {cell: rot[6], type: PARTNER},
    ]);
  } else if(me.food >= 2) {
    // Create sentinel first so that we'll know to create the partner next.
    // (ensure the sentinel is created on a white cell so that it won't
    // think it's dancing)
    return try_all_angles(
      (rot) => ((view[rot[5]].color === WHITE)
        ? {cell: rot[5], type: SENTINEL} : null),
      (rot) => ({cell: rot[5], color: WHITE})
    );
  }

  // Not able to start yet; fall back to lone behaviour:
  // Random-walk until we find or make a buddy
  return best_of([
    grab_nearby_food,
    fast_diagonal.bind(null, SAFE_COLOURS),
    go_anywhere
  ]);
}

return play_safe([move_agent([
  PARTNER, move_partner,
  SENTINEL, move_sentinel,
  QUEEN, move_queen,
]), pass_time]);
```

The forensic ants take a scientific approach to sweeping the grid. After an initial frantic scramble for food, 2 worker ants will be created. The roles are:

### Queen

The queen will team-up with the partner to travel in a straight line at the speed of light. Neither of them will diverge to fetch food; they're just grabbing whatever they stumble over.

### Partner

The partner moves with the queen, keeping her facing in the same direction. Because both ants can move 1 square each turn, they're able to stay in a straight line without wasting time painting the ground.

If the partner ever finds any food, it will immediately go to the queen, since they're adjacent at all times.

### Sentinel

The most important ant. This one stays put until the queen and partner reach it, then tells them to move 2 pixels along, and moves 2 pixels itself. This causes the queen and partner to gradually sweep over the whole board (well, about 30 pixels of it anyway). It only moves when the queen is nearby, so any food it finds will be handed over immediately.

In its spare time, the sentinel's hobbies include painting the ground around it at random to hopefully mess up any competitors.

---

These perform very consistently; between them they can sweep 2 cells each frame, which over 30000 frames means 60000 cells, and with 0.1% containing food, that means a final score of 60, which they pretty consistently achieve.

Comment: (and here's the other one I prepared while the question was beta! — that's me done for now; I'm sure these will get beaten pretty quickly!)

Comment: The score is remarkably consistent. Will be interesting to see how that's affected as the arena fills up with more competitors...

Comment: I wonder if adding another partner on the other side of the queen would help?

Comment: @KZhang I think it would (theoretically it would boost the score to ~90), but it's hard enough keeping the two of them in sync along with the sentinel! The "move everybody up 2 pixels" dance took me a while to figure out. Going to 3 pixels would block one of the tricks I relied on (the sentinel preparing the spaces around itself in advance).

Comment: Top of the first leaderboard...

Comment: I wonder what happens if a trail-eraser erases the cell under the sentinel during a dance ...

Comment: @ppperry bad things, but there's only a 1-frame, 1-cell window of opportunity; it would need to erase the "7" cell while the sentinel is standing on it. Everything else in the dance is based on ant locations. (Well, there's actually 1 other frame where it could un-erase a cell to cause damage). The bigger problem for these ants is if a foe stands in front of the queen/worker and refuses to move, or is in the way during the dance.

Answer (score 19):

## Sliding Miners 6.4

```js
const DEBUG = false;
const ADD = (a,b) => a + b;
var toReturn;
var me = view[4].ant;
me.me = true; // for basedOn to know
var food = me.food;
var type = me.type;
var isQueen = type == 5;

// raw directions
const UL = 0; const U  = 1; const UR = 2;
const L  = 3; const C  = 4; const R  = 5;
const DL = 6; const D  = 7; const DR = 8;

// directions from the reference point
const ul = 16; const u  = 17; const ur = 18;
const l  = 19; const c  = 20; const r  = 21;
const dl = 22; const d  = 23; const dr = 24;
const rp = 16;

function allRots (arr) {
  return [arr,
  [arr[2], arr[5], arr[8],
   arr[1], arr[4], arr[7],
   arr[0], arr[3], arr[6]],

  [arr[8], arr[7], arr[6],
   arr[5], arr[4], arr[3],
   arr[2], arr[1], arr[0]],

  [arr[6], arr[3], arr[0],
   arr[7], arr[4], arr[1],
   arr[8], arr[5], arr[2]]];
}
var allVRots = allRots(view);

function rotateCW3([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]) {
  return [[g,d,a],[h,e,b],[i,f,c]]
}

function on (where, what) {
  if (Array.isArray(where)) return where.some(c=>on(c, what));
  if (Array.isArray(what)) return what.some(c=>on(where, c));
  return basedOn(get(where), what);
}
function find (what) {
  return view.findIndex(c=>basedOn(c, what));
}
function findAll (what) {
  return view.map((c,i)=>[c,i]).filter(c=>basedOn(c[0], what)).map(c=>c[1]);
}
function count (what) {
  return findAll(what).length;
}
function findRel (what) {
  return ref(find(what));
}
function findAllRel (what) {
  return findAll(what).map(c=>ref(c));
}
function found (what) {
  return find(what) != -1;
}
function get (dir) {
  if (Array.isArray(dir)) return dir.map(c=>get(c));
  return view[raw(dir)];
}
function deq (a, b) {
  return a==b || raw(a)==raw(b);
}

// returns a random number from 0 to 4, based on the rotation. Will always have a possibility of being 0
function random4 () {
  var scores = allRots(view.map(c=>c.color)).map((c) => {
    let cscore = 0;
    c.forEach((c) => {
      cscore*= 8;
      cscore+= c-1;
    });
    return cscore;
  });
  var bestscore = -1, bestindex = 1;
  scores.forEach((score, index) => {
    if (score > bestscore) {
      bestscore = score;
      bestindex = index;
    }
  })
  return bestindex;
}

function rotate (what, times) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) what = [2,5,8,1,4,7,0,3,6][what];
  return what;
}

function raw(dir) {
  if (dir&rp) return rotate(dir&~rp, selectedRot);
  return dir;
}

function ref(dir) {
  if (dir == -1) return -1;
  if (dir&rp) return dir;
  return rotate(dir, 4-selectedRot)|rp;
}

function move(dir, force) {
  if (Array.isArray(dir)) return dir.some(c=>move(c, force));
  dir = raw(dir);
  return result({cell:dir}, force);
}

function color(dir, col) {
  if (Array.isArray(dir)) return dir.some(cdir => !color(cdir, col));
  dir = raw(dir);
  if (view[dir].color == col) return true;
  result({cell:dir, color:Math.abs(col)});
  return false;
}

function rcolOf(what) {
  return Number.isInteger(what)? what : what.color;
}

function colOf(what) {
  return Math.abs(Number.isInteger(what)? what : what.color);
}
function sees(c1,c2) {
  c1 = raw(c1);
  c2 = raw(c2);
  return Math.abs(c1%3-c2%3)<2 && Math.abs(Math.floor(c1/3)-Math.floor(c2/3))<2;
}

function spawn(dir, t) {
  if (Array.isArray(t)) return t.some(c=>spawn(dir, c));
  if (Array.isArray(dir)) return dir.some(c=>spawn(c, t));
  dir = raw(dir);
  return result({cell:dir, type:t});
}
// repairs a single cell
function correct(dir) {
  dir = raw(dir);
  let col = colOf(selectedPt[dir]);
  if (col && view[dir].color != col) {
    color(dir, col);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
// if pattern is repaired, returns true, otherwise fixes one cell
// firstdirs is lowercase (if you do want it to be from the patterns POV)
function repair(firstdirs, onlyThose) {
  //log("FD",firstdirs);
  var found = [];
  view.forEach((v, i) => {
    let col = colOf(selectedPt[i]);
    if (col && v.color != col) {
      found.push(i);
    }
  });
  if (found.length == 0) return true;
  if (firstdirs && (firstdirs = firstdirs.map(c=>raw(c))).some(c=>found.includes(c))) {
    let dir = firstdirs.find(c=>found.includes(c));
    let col = colOf(selectedPt[dir]);
    color(dir, col);
    return false;
  }
  if (!onlyThose) {
    let dir = found[random4() % found.length];
    let col = colOf(selectedPt[dir]);
    color(dir, col);
    return false;
  } else return true;
}

function flatten (arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b));
}

var selectedHp, selectedVp, selectedPt, selectedRot;

class Pattern {
  constructor(pattern, inherit) {
    this.pt = pattern;
    if (inherit) {
      this.vp = inherit.vp;
      this.hp = inherit.hp;
      this.rot = inherit.rot;
    } else {
      this.vp = 0;
      this.hp = 0;
      this.rot = 0;
    }
  }

  rotateClockwise() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pt[0].length; i++) {
      var sarr = [];
      for (var j = this.pt.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        sarr.push(this.pt[j][i]);
      }
      arr.push(sarr);
    }
    //log(arr);
    var res = new Pattern(arr, this);
    res.rot = (this.rot+1) % 4;
    return res;
  }

  select(x, y, w, h) {
    var res = new Pattern(this.pt.slice(y, y+h).map(c=>c.slice(x, x+w)), this);
    res.hp+= x;
    res.vp+= y;
    return res;
  }

  rots(dir) {
    var pts = [];
    var pt = new Pattern(this.pt, this);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lengthIn(dir); i++) {
      pts.push(pt);
      pt = pt.rotate(dir);
    }
    return pts;
  }

  map(fn) {
    return new Pattern(this.pt.map(ln=>ln.map(fn)), this);
  }

  lengthIn(dir) {
    if (dir == U || dir == D) return this.pt.length;
    else if (this.pt.length > 0) return this.pt[0].length;
    else return 0;
  }
  rotate(dir) { // moves the center to that direction, shifting the side
    if (dir == R) {
      var res = new Pattern(this.pt.map(c=>((h,...t)=>t.concat(h))(...c)), this);
      res.hp++;
      return res;
    }
    if (dir == L) {
      var res = new Pattern(this.pt.map(a=>a.slice(-1).concat(a.slice(0,-1))), this);
      res.hp++;
      return res;
    }
    if (dir == D) {
      var res = new Pattern(((h,...t)=>t.concat([h]))(...this.pt), this);
      res.vp++;
      return res;
    }
    throw "rotate unimplemented dir!";
  }

  center(dir) { // moves the center to that direction
    if (dir == R) {
      var res = new Pattern(this.pt.map(c=>((h,...t)=>t.concat(0))(...c)), this);
      res.hp++;
      return res;
    }
    if (dir == L) {
      var res = new Pattern(this.pt.map(a=>[0].concat(a.slice(0,-1))), this);
      res.hp++;
      return res;
    }
    if (dir == D) {
      var res = new Pattern(((h,...t)=>t.concat([new Array(h.length)]))(...this.pt), this);
      res.vp++;
      return res;
    }
    throw "center unimplemented dir!";
  }

  setSize(xs, ys) {
    var arr = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < ys; y++) {
      var ca = [];
      for (let x = 0; x < xs; x++) {
        ca.push(this.pt[y % this.pt.length][x % this.pt[0].length]);
      }
      arr.push(ca);
    }
    return new Pattern(arr, this);
  }

  static add(pattern, action, scorer, presetRot) {
    if (Array.isArray(pattern)) pattern = new Pattern(pattern);
    pattern = pattern.setSize(3,3);
    var cpt = pattern.setSize(3,3);
    var orig = cpt.pt;
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      cpt = cpt.rotateClockwise();
      if (!presetRot || presetRot == cpt.rot) {
        cpt.action = action;
        cpt.scorer = scorer;
        cpt.raw = orig;
        cpt.view = allVRots[cpt.rot];
        allPatterns.push(cpt);
      }
    }
  }


  static choose() {
    var maxScore = -1e307;
    var nextScore = -1e308;
    var maxPt;
    allPatterns.forEach((c) => {
      // null  = easy
      // 0     = bad queen
      // false = no match
      // >0    = score
      var falseN = 0;
      var corrects = c.raw.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b)).map((guess, index) => {
        var bo = basedOn(c.view[index], guess, true);
        var ant = guess.ant;
        if (ant && basedOn(c.view[index], {ant})) bo+= 1;
        if (bo === 0) return 0;
        if (bo === false) return false;
        if (bo && rcolOf(guess) > 0) return bo;
        var easy = rcolOf(guess)<=0;
        if (easy) {
          falseN++;
          return null;
        }
        return bo;
      });
      var corrstring = corrects.map((chr,i)=>chr>0? (colOf(c.raw[Math.floor(i/3)][i%3])==1? "W" : "#") : chr===null? "-" : " ").join("");
      function match(pt) {
        return new RegExp(pt.replace(/@/g, "[#-W]").replace(/C/g, "[#-]")).test(corrstring);
      }
      var score = corrects.reduce(ADD)*9/(9-falseN);
      if (match(".?(...)?##.##.*")) {
        if (match("(...)?@@@@@@.*|.?@@.@@.@@.?")) score+= foundEnemy? 5 : 3;
        else score+= foundEnemy? 3 : 1;
      } else if (!foundEnemy) score = Math.min(score/2, 5);
      if (c.scorer instanceof Function) score = c.scorer(score, c, corrects, falseN, match);
      if (DEBUG && score > -1) log(
        "scored", score,
        "corr", /*corrects.map(c =>
          (c===false?"F":c===null?"N":c===true?"T":c)
        )*/corrstring,
        "pt", c.raw.map(c=>c.ant? "A"+c.ant.type : c), c.hp, c.vp);
      if (score >= maxScore) {
        nextScore = maxScore;
        maxScore = score;
        c.corrstr = corrstring;
        maxPt = c;
      }
    });
    var flattened = maxPt.pt.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b));
    Pattern.hardcorr = flattened.map((guess, index) => rcolOf(guess)<2? 0 : basedOn(view[index], guess)).reduce(ADD);
    Pattern.corrstr = maxPt.corrstr;
    Pattern.corr = flattened.map((guess, index) => basedOn(view[index], guess)).reduce(ADD);
    Pattern.incorr = 9-Pattern.corr;
    Pattern.confidence = maxScore-nextScore;
    selectedRot = maxPt.rot;
    Pattern.action = maxPt.action;
    selectedPt = flattened;
    selectedHp = maxPt.hp;
    Pattern.raw = maxPt.raw;
    Pattern.view = maxPt.view;
    selectedVp = maxPt.vp;
    Pattern.score = maxScore;
    if (DEBUG) log("score", maxScore, "confidence", Pattern.confidence, "corr", Pattern.corr, "hardc", Pattern.hardcorr, "pt", maxPt.pt);//, "fn", maxPt.action+""
  }
}
var allPatterns = [];
function clear() {
  allPatterns = [];
}
function adds(raw, action, scorer, presetRot) { // must get a 3x3 arr
  var pt = raw;
  var hp = raw.hp;
  var vp = raw.vp;
  for (let rot = 0; rot < 4; rot++) {
    let view = allVRots[rot];
    allPatterns.push({pt, action, scorer, rot, hp, vp, view, raw});
    if (rot!=4) pt = rotateCW3(pt);
  }
}
function refPt(...args) {
  clear();
  if (Array.isArray(args[0])) {
    if (args[0].length != 3) args[0] = args[0].slice(0,3);
    if (args[0][0].length != 3) args[0] = args[0].map(c=>c.slice(0,3));
    adds(...args);
  }
  else Pattern.add(...args);
  Pattern.choose();
}

/*
is the 2nd param a subset of the 1st param.
guess can be a number (color), or an object ({color:..,ant:..,..})
guess.ant can be "worker", "queen", "enemy", "enemyworker", "enemyqueen" with obvious meanings. Note that "friend" ≠ me
guess.ant.type can be an array, ORing

true - correct!
false - not correct
0 - notqueen doesn't match (aka very bad)

negativesEqual makes this always return true for negative colors, otherwise it treats negatives as regular colors
*/
function basedOn(real, guess, negativesEqual) {
  if (Array.isArray(real)) return real.some(c=>basedOn(c, guess, negativesEqual));
  if (Number.isInteger(guess)) guess = {color:guess};
  if (guess.notqueen && real.ant && real.ant.friend && real.ant.type==5) return 0;
  if (guess.not) {
    var bo = basedOn(real, guess.not, negativesEqual);
    if (bo) return 0;
  } 
  if (guess.color && Math.abs(guess.color) != real.color && !(negativesEqual && guess.color<0)) return false; // 0 handles itself
  if (guess.obstacle !== undefined) {
    if (guess.obstacle && !real.ant && !(food && real.food && !isQueen)) return false;
    if (!guess.obstacle && (real.ant || (food && real.food && !isQueen))) return false;
  }
  if (guess.badobstacle !== undefined) {
    if (guess.badobstacle && !(real.ant && !real.ant.friend) && !(food && real.food && !isQueen)) return false;
    if (!guess.badobstacle && ((real.ant && !real.ant.friend) || (food && real.food && !isQueen))) return false;
  }
  if (guess.ant) {
    if (!real.ant) return false;
    if (guess.ant == "worker"      &&!( real.ant.friend && real.ant.type!=5)) return false;
    if (guess.ant == "queen"       &&!( real.ant.friend && real.ant.type==5)) return false;
    if (guess.ant == "enemyqueen"  &&!(!real.ant.friend && real.ant.type==5)) return false;
    if (guess.ant == "enemyworker" &&!(!real.ant.friend && real.ant.type!=5)) return false;
    if (guess.ant == "friend" && (!real.ant.friend || real.ant.me)) return false;
    if (guess.ant == "enemy"  &&  real.ant.friend) return false;
    if (Number.isInteger(guess.ant) && real.ant.type != guess.ant) return false;
    if (guess.ant.friend !== undefined && guess.ant.friend !== real.ant.friend) return false;
    if (guess.ant.type !== undefined && !(Array.isArray(guess.ant.type)? guess.ant.type.some(c=>c == real.ant.type) : guess.ant.type == real.ant.type)) return false;
    if (guess.ant.food !== undefined && guess.ant.food !== real.ant.food) return false;
  }
  if (guess.food !== undefined && guess.food !== real.food) return false;
  // log("matched");
  return true;
}

function result (action, force) {
  if (!force) if (toReturn !== undefined) return 0;
  var color = action.color;
  var type = action.type;
  var cell = action.cell;
  if (type < 1 || type > 4) return false;
  if (!(cell >= 0 && cell <= 8)) return false;
  if (color < 1 || color > 8) return false;
  if (!color && ((view[cell].ant && cell != 4) || (isQueen? (view[cell].food && type) : (food && view[cell].food)))) return false; // can't walk onto ant, can't spawn on food, can't move to food with food
  if (!isQueen && type) return false;
  if (!isQueen && !color && food && view[cell].food) return false;
  if (isQueen && !food && type) return false;
  if (type && cell==C) return false;
  if (color && type) return false;

  toReturn = action;
  return true;
}

const WH = 1; // white   
const C1 = 6; // green   HW
const C2 = 5; // red     
const C3 = 8; // black   
const C4 = 2; // yellow  HW
const C5 = 4; // cyan    HW
const C6 = 7; // blue    HW
const C7 = 3; // purple  HW
// C1=GR,C2=BL,C4=YL,C5=DK
const ENEMY = {ant:"enemy"};
const foundEnemy = found(ENEMY);
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------- MAIN CODE ---------------------------------------------------------------------\\
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\

function log(...args) {
  if (!DEBUG) return;
  toLogRaw.push(args);
  // for (let i of args) {
  //   if (i === undefined) i = "undefined";
  //   var res = "";
  //   if (typeof i === 'string') res = i;
  //   else res = JSON.stringify(i);
  //   toLog+= res + " ";
  // }
  // toLog+= "\n";
}
if (DEBUG) {
  var toLog = "";
  var logMyLogs = false;
  var toLogRaw = [];
  log(type, view.map(c=>c.ant? "A"+c.ant.type : c.color));
}

const Ut = 1;
const Dt = 2;
const Ht = 4;
const Uo = {ant:{type:Ut,friend:true}};
const Do = {ant:{type:Dt,friend:true}};
const Ho = {ant:{type:Ht,friend:true}};
const Mo = {ant:{type:[Ut,Dt],friend:true}};
const Fo = {food:1};
const Qo = {ant:{type:5,friend:true}};
const EQo = {ant:{type:5,friend:false}};
const FRIEND = {ant:"friend"};
const OBSTACLE = {obstacle:true};
const FREE = {obstacle:false};
const BADOBSTACLE = {badobstacle:true};
const STARTINGFOOD = 6;
const LESSENFOOD = 160;
const ENDINGFOOD = 160;
const isMiner = type==Ut || type==Dt;
var friendCount = count(FRIEND);
if (isMiner) {
  var Mu = type==Ut? u : d;
  var Md = type==Ut? d : u;
  var Mur = Mu+1;
  var Mul = Mu-1;
  var Mdr = Md+1;
  var Mdl = Md-1;
}

const foodExt = [C3, C7, WH];
const rawRail = [
  [WH,-1,C7,-1], // 43 03 13 23
  [C6,WH,WH,-1], // 42 02 12 22

  [C4,C1,C2,C2],
  [C2,C4,C5,C5],
  [C3,C5,C1,C3],


//[C3,C1,C4,C4],
//[C4,C4,C5,C2],
//[C5,C2,C1,C3],

//[C3,C1,C2,C5],
//[C3,C3,C1,C5],
//[C2,C4,C5,C2],


//[C2,C1,C3,C5], // 41 01 11 21
//[C1,C5,C5,C4], // 40 00 10 20
//[C5,C4,C2,C3], // 41 01 11 21
  [C6,WH,WH,-1], // 42 02 12 22
  [WH,-1,C7,-1]  // 43 03 13 23
]
.map((ln,row)=>(row<2||row>4)? ln.map(c=>({not:{ant:{friend:true, type:[Ht, 5]}},color:c})) : ln); // queen can't be in the top & bottom 2 rows

function section(ln, action, scorer) {
  if (ln > 0) section(-ln, action, scorer);
  var sct = rawRail.slice(ln+2, ln+5);
  var parts;
  if (Math.abs(ln) != 2) {
    parts = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var cpt = sct.map(([a,b,c,d])=>[a,b,c]);
      cpt.hp = i;
      cpt.vp = ln;
      parts.push(cpt);
      if (i!=4) sct = sct.map(([a,b,c,d])=>[b,c,d,a]);
    }
  } else {
    var o = sct.map(c=>c.slice(0,3));
    o.vp = ln;
    o.hp = 0;
    parts = [o];
  }
  parts.map(c=>adds(c, action, scorer));
}

function sabotage(where) {
  if (on(where, 1)) repair([where], true);
  else color(where, 1);
}


section(0, ()=>{
  if (isMiner) {
    if (on([r,ur,dr], Fo)  ||  on([u,d], Fo) && on([l,ul,dl], Mo)) { // FAKE RAIL
      color(on([dr,d],Fo)? [dr,u,ul] : [dr,d,dl], C7);
    }
    else if ([l,ul,dl].every(c=>on(c,{ant:{}})) && !random4()) move([r,u,d,ur,dr]); // peer pressure
    /* AV */ else if (found(EQo)) sabotage(find(EQo));
    else if (repair()) {
      if (on(r,Mo) && (random4() > 1 || random4() && friendCount > 3)) move([l,Mul,Mu,Mdl,Md]);
      if (on([Mu,Mur], ENEMY)) move([R, D, DR]); // move somewhere away from enemy
      else if (on(r, Qo) && on([l,ul,dl], {ant:{type:[Ut,Dt],food:1,friend:true}})) move([Mu, Mul, l, Mdl]); // make place for miners with food; Possibly stuck
      else if (on(r, Qo)) move([Mu, Mul]); // don't do stupid things around queen
      else if (on(l, Qo) && !foundEnemy) move([Mul, Mdl, Mu, Md]); //.. I've done stupid things around queen
      else if (on([Mu,Mur], OBSTACLE)) { // up is blocked :/
        if (random4()) move(on(Mu, FRIEND)? [Mur, r] : r);
        else move([r, Mul, Md, Mul, l, Mdl]);
      }
      else move([Mu, r, Mur, Md, Mdr]); // move along
    }
  } else if (isQueen) {
    var HM = Pattern.view.map(c=>+basedOn(c, Ho));
    var helperRows = [HM.slice(0,3),HM.slice(6,9)].map(c=>c.lastIndexOf(1)).map((c,i) => (c==0 && on(i==0? u : d, OBSTACLE)) ? -1 : c);
    var minH = Math.min(helperRows[0],helperRows[1]);
    var maxH = Math.max(helperRows[0],helperRows[1]);
    if (on(r, FRIEND) && [ur,dr].every(c=>on(c, ENEMY))) move([l,ul,dl]);
    if (found(EQo)) { // vampire?
      move(random4()%2? [ur,dr] : [dr,ur]);
      var eQueenRel = (findRel(EQo)-rp)%3;
      if (eQueenRel == 0) move(r,ur,dr);
      spawn(Mu, [u,d,r,ur,dr]);
    }
    if (foundEnemy) // spawn helpers against enemies
      if (food && minH == -1 && count(Ho) < 2) {
        if (helperRows[0] == -1) spawn([u,ur,ul],Ht);
        else                     spawn([d,dr,dl],Ht);
      }
    if ([r,ur,dr].every(c=>on(c, ENEMY))) move([ul,dl,l,u,d]); // OH GOD NO WHY
    if ((minH == -1 || maxH == 2) && on(r, [ENEMY,Ho]) && Pattern.incorr < 2 && count({ant:{}})-1 != count(Ho))
      move(on(ur, ENEMY)? [d,u,dr,ur,ul,dl,l] : [u,d,ur,dr,ul,dl,l]); // initialize transporting around enemy
    if ((!random4() && on(l, OBSTACLE) && on([ul, dl], OBSTACLE)) && Pattern.corr >= 7) move(r); // move forward sometimes if left is 2/3s full
    else if ([r,ur,dr].every(c=>c.ant && !c.ant.friend)) move([l,ul,dl]);
    else if (food && minH > 0 && (
        count(Mo) == 0 && selectedHp != 1 && Pattern.corr != 9 && food < LESSENFOOD
      ||
        //Pattern.corr === 9 && [u,d].every(c=>on(c,Ho)) && selectedHp === 1 && food >= LESSENFOOD && food < ENDINGFOOD && random4() < 2
        Pattern.corr === 9 && selectedHp == 0 && count(Mo) === 0 && food >= LESSENFOOD && food < ENDINGFOOD && random4() < 2
      )) { // spawn miners
      if (random4()%2) spawn([u,ul], Ut);
      else             spawn([d,dl], Dt);
    } else if (repair()) {
      if (food && minH == -1 && count(Ho) < 2) { // spawn helpers
        if (helperRows[0] == -1) spawn([u,ur,ul],Ht);
        else                     spawn([d,dr,dl],Ht);
      }
      else if (selectedHp != 1  ||  selectedHp==1 && /*(*/(maxH==2 || minH == -1 && helperRows.includes(2)) && (!random4() || food < LESSENFOOD || found(Mo))  ||  foundEnemy) move(r); // move forwards
      else if (on(ul, Do) && on(dl,Uo) && on(l, {ant:{}})) move(r); // miners are in wrong places
    }
  } else { // helper
    var repaired = repair();
    var queenRel = (findRel(Qo)-rp)%3;
    var dir = queenRel==0? 0 : 1;
    if (repair()) {
      if (on(r, EQo) && [u,d,ur,dr].map(c=>on(c, ENEMY)? 1 : 0).reduce(ADD) >= 3) move(c); // protect the queen from the evils ahead
      else if (on(r, Qo)) move([u,d,ur,dr,ul,dl,l]);
      else move((on([d,dr,dl], Ho)? [u+dir,d+dir] : [d+dir,u+dir]).concat([u+(1-dir), d+(1-dir)]), !random4());
    }
  }
})

section(1, ()=>{
  const A = selectedVp > 0? d : u; // away
  const I = selectedVp > 0? u : d; // in
  const AR = A+1;
  const AL = A-1;
  const IR = I+1;
  const IL = I-1;

  if (isMiner) {
    var queenRel = (findRel(Qo)-rp)%3;
    if (on([r,IR], Fo)) color([r,IR, I], C7); // FAKE RAIL
    else if ([l,IL].every(c=>on(c,{ant:{}})) && !random4()) move([r,IR]); // peer pressure
    /* AV */ else if (found(EQo)) sabotage(find(EQo));
    else if ((found(EQo) && random4() && Pattern.dist <= 1 && on(find(EQo), 1)) || repair()) {
      if (on(I, Qo)) move(l); // what am I doing here?
      else if (A == Mu) { // my dir!
        if (!food && selectedHp == 0 && (on(r,Ho) && on(IR, Qo)  ||  count(Mo) >= 6)) move(A); // move out!
        else if (on(IR,Qo) && on([l,IL], {ant:{type:[Mu,Md],friend:true,food:1}})) move(C); // waiting in line :D
        else if (on(IR,Qo)) move(C); // waiting in line :D
        else if (random4()) move([r, I, IR]);
        else move([r, I, IR, l, IL]);
      } else { // not my dir
        // TODO fix \\ if (selectedHp == 0 && count(Mo) >= 6 && food) move(A); // fake rail escape
        if (random4()) {
          move([I, IR, IL, l]);
        } else {
          move([r, I, IR, IL, l]);
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (isQueen) {
    if (found(EQo)) { // vampire?
      var eQueenRel = (findRel(EQo)-rp)%3;
      if (eQueenRel==0) move(r, IR);
      spawn(Mu, [r,IR]);
      spawn(Md, I);
    }
    /* AV */ if (food > 70 && (
      [IR,IL,I,l,r].every(c=>on(c,ENEMY)) // completely encased
      || on(IR, EQo) && [r,I].every(c=>on(c, ENEMY)) // getting leeched
      || on(I, EQo) && [r,l,IL,IR].map(c=>get(c)).map(c=>c.ant? (c.ant.friend? 1 : -1) : 0).reduce(ADD) < 0 // leeched
    )) move([A,AR,AL]); // BAD NEWS COMPLETELY DEAD
    if (!random4() || found(EQo) || repair())
      move(random4()? [IR,r,I,l] : [IR,r,I]);
  } else { // helper
    var queenRel = (findRel(Qo)-rp)%3;
    /* AV */ if (on(r,Qo) && on([I,IR], EQo)) move([IR,I,l,IL]);
    if (on(l, Qo)) { if (!random4() || repair()) move(r) } // queen's transporting
    if (on(I, Qo) && on(IR, {ant:"enemyworker"})) { if (!random4() || repair()) move(r) } // queen needs to transport
    // what was this? if ([l,IL,I].every(c=>on(c,OBSTACLE)) && (count(ENEMY) > 1 || find(EQo)) && !random4()) move([r,ur]);
    if ((selectedVp < 0? /...[#-W]{6}/ : /[#-W]{6}.../).test(Pattern.corrstr) && queenRel == 2 && count(Ho) == 1) move(r); // move forward without repairing
    if (!random4() && queenRel == 1 && selectedHp == 1 && on(AL, {ant:{}})) move(r); // something is out; don't repair
    else if (repair([r,l,A,AR,AL])) {
      if (on(r, ENEMY) && on(I, Qo) && [l,IL].every(c=>on(c,FRIEND))) move(IR); // protect from vampire
      if (on(r, ENEMY) && on(IL, Qo) && [l,IR].every(c=>on(c,FRIEND))) move(I);
      if (on(r, ENEMY) && !get(r).ant.food && on(I, Qo)) move(IR);
      if (queenRel == 1 && selectedHp == 1 && on(AL, {ant:{}})) move(r); // something is out
      else if (on([l,r], Ho)) { // move to the other side
        if (found(Qo)) move([I]); // TODO integrate ,IL,IR
        else move([l,r]);
      }
      else if (queenRel == 2) move(r); // move forward
    }
  }
}, (pscore, pt, corrects, falseN, match) => {
  if (match(".?(...)?@@.@@.*") && !foundEnemy) {
    if (!match(pt.vp>0? ".?@@.@@.*" : ".?...@@.@@.*")) pscore/=2;
  }
  return pscore;
})

if (isMiner) {
  section(2, () => {
    const A = selectedVp > 0? d : u; // away
    const I = selectedVp > 0? u : d; // in
    if (on(A,OBSTACLE)) move(I);
    else if (repair()) move(food? I: Mu);
  }, (pscore, pt, corrects, falseN, match) => match(pt.vp>0? "@@@.@...." : "....@.@@@")? match("@@@@@@@@@")? 100 : ((pt.vp>0) == (type==Dt)? 13 : 10) : 0);
  if (type==Dt) foodExt.reverse();
  if (!found(Ho) && !found(Qo)) {
    var lns = [rawRail[0], rawRail[1]].map(c=>c.slice(0,3));
    [[lns[0],lns[1],lns[0]], [lns[1],lns[0],lns[1]]].map(c=>{
      adds(c, () => {
        var onL;
        if (!food && ((onL = on(l, Fo)) || on(r, Fo))) {
          var foodpt = Pattern.raw.map((ln, i) => [ln[0], foodExt[i], ln[2]]);
          refPt(foodpt,undefined,undefined,selectedRot);
          if (repair()) move(onL? l : r);
        }
        else if (repair([l,r,ul,ur,dl,dr], on([Mul, Mur, Mdl, Mdr, l, r], {ant:{friend:true,type:[Ut,Dt],food:1}}) ||  on([Mu, Md], Mo))) {
          move(food? [Md, Mu] : [Mu, Md]);
        }
      }, (pscore, pt, corrects, falseN, match) => {
        var score = 0;
        var dMatch = match("...@.@@@@");
        var uMatch = match("@.@@.@...");
             if ((type==Ut ^ food) && dMatch) score = 15;
        else if ((type==Dt ^ food) && uMatch) score = 15;
        else if (uMatch || dMatch) score = 6;
        if ([0,2,3,5,6,8].some(c=>basedOn(pt.view[c], FRIEND) && !pt.view[c].ant.food)) score = 0;
        return score;
      });
      if (food) {
        var extp = c.map((ln, i) => [ln[0], foodExt[i], ln[2]]);
        [extp.map(([a,b,c])=>[0,a,b]), extp.map(([a,b,c])=>[b,c,0])].forEach((pt,i) => adds(pt, () => {
          move(i? l : r);
        }, (pscore, pt, corrects, falseN, match) => match("@@@@@@@@@")? 100 : 0));
      }
    });
  }
}

Pattern.choose();
var confident = ((Pattern.confidence >= 1 && (Pattern.score > 4 || Pattern.corr >= 4)) || (Pattern.score >= 9 && Pattern.confidence > 0.05)); // && (selectedHp !=  || !found(Qo));
var failAction = () => {
  if (foundEnemy) {
    log(view);
    log("dead around enemy :/");
    logMyLogs = true;
  }
  if (isQueen) {
    if (found(EQo)) {
      move([8-(find(EQo)-rp) + rp]);
      move(random4()%2? U : UR);
    }
    if (foundEnemy) move(random4()%2? U : UR);
  } else {
    // if (!found(Qo) && found(Fo)) move(find(Fo));
    var enemyPlace = find(ENEMY);
    if (enemyPlace !== -1) color(enemyPlace, get(enemyPlace).color==1? C3 : WH);
  }
}
if (!confident) Pattern.action = failAction;

if (isMiner) {
  if ((Pattern.hardcorr >= 4 || Pattern.score > 5) && confident) Pattern.action();
  else {
    failAction();
  }
} else if (isQueen) {
  if ((Pattern.hardcorr >= 6 || food > STARTINGFOOD+2 || friendCount>1 || found(Mo) || Pattern.score > 6 || (false)) && confident) Pattern.action();
  else if (food >= STARTINGFOOD && friendCount == 1) {
    clear();
    Pattern.add([[1,{ant:Ho.ant,color:1},1],
                 [1,1,1],
                 [1,1,1]], ()=>spawn([ur,ul],Ht));
    Pattern.add([[1,1,{ant:Ho.ant,color:1}],
                 [1,1,1],
                 [1,1,1]], ()=>spawn([ur,u],Ht));
    Pattern.choose();
    if (repair()) Pattern.action();
  } else if (food == 0 && friendCount == 0) { // diagonal search
    if (found(Fo)) {
      move(find(Fo));
    } else {
      clear();
      Pattern.add([[WH,WH,WH],
                   [WH,C1,WH],
                   [C1,WH,WH]], ()=>move(ur));
      Pattern.add([[WH,WH,WH],
                   [WH,WH,WH],
                   [C1,WH,WH]], ()=>color(C, C1));
      Pattern.add([[WH,WH,WH],[WH,WH,WH],[WH,WH,WH]], ()=>color(DL, C1));
      Pattern.choose();
      if (Pattern.corr == 9) Pattern.action();
      else move(random4()? [DL,UL,DR,UL] : [D,L,U,R]);
    }
  } else if (food == 1 && friendCount == 0) spawn([U,L,D,R,UL,DL,UR,DR], Ht);
  else if (friendCount == 1) lightSpeed();
  else if (friendCount > 0) {
    var pt = new Pattern(rawRail).select(0,2,4,3).rotate(L).rotate(L).pt;
    pt[1][2] = {color:pt[1][2], ant:{type:Ht, friend:true}};
    refPt(pt);
    repair([c,u,d,ur,dr]);
  } // TODO wtf to do after this
  else Pattern.action(); // eh fuck it
} else if (type == Ht) {
  if (confident && (Pattern.score >= 4 || Pattern.hardcorr >= 5 || friendCount>1)) Pattern.action();
  else if (found(Qo)) lightSpeed();
  else if (Pattern.hardcorr >= 3 && confident) repair();
}

function lightSpeed() {
  var other = find(isQueen? Ho : Qo);
  var orth = other%2;
  if (isQueen || (view[other].ant.food < STARTINGFOOD && count(Ho) == 1)) { // LS
    if (orth && found(Fo)) { // grab easy food
      var fp = find(Fo);
      if (sees(other, fp)) move(fp);
      else {
        refPt([[0,FRIEND,0],
                     [0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0]]);
        move(l);
      }
    }
    clear();
    // Pattern.when(U,find(FRIEND), ()=>isQueen? move(ul) : move(ur)); when I'm not lazy imma make this a replacement of the below
    Pattern.add([[0,FRIEND,0],
                 [0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0]], ()=>isQueen? move(ul) : move(ur));
    Pattern.add([[0,0,FRIEND],
                 [0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0]], ()=>move(u));
    Pattern.choose();
    Pattern.action();
  }
}

if (DEBUG) log("END", type, view.map(c=>c.ant? "A"+c.ant.type : c.color));
if (DEBUG && logMyLogs) {
  //for (let i = 0; i < toLog.length; i+=800)
  //  console.log(toLog.substring(i,i+800));
  for (let i of toLogRaw) console.log(...i);
}
if (toReturn) return toReturn;
else return {cell:4};
```

Previously this was Miners on a Rail (see the revision history), but has been changed to Sliding Miners as it performs better and MoaR would just get in the way of its success if this were an another entry.

Comment: First on the leaderboard again this time...

Comment: Hang on, I just realized - you're using *regular expressions to generate regular expressions to scan the environment?!* And here I thought *I* was the madder scientist all this time...

Comment: @Alion :D i've completely forgotten that myself too. i wonder how differently i'd make this, two years later..

Answer (score 14):

## Glider

[image: Glider in action][image: Glider turning left][image: Glider turning right]

```
//console.log(JSON.stringify(view))
var TRAIL = 6;
var SPAWN = 3;
var IDLE = 4;
var FOOD_THRESHOLD = 150;
var SPAWN_MIN = 3;
var HIGHWAY_COLORS = [7,6,4,2,3];
var HIGHWAY_THRESHOLD = 70;
var ret = {cell:4};
if(isOnHighway()) {
    var cont = true;
    //== Make best guess to if in a glider formation ==//
    if(view[4].ant.type == 5) {
        if((findWorker(1) >= 0 && findWorker(4) >= 0) || view[4].ant.food < HIGHWAY_THRESHOLD) {
            cont = false;
        }
    }
    else if(view[4].ant.type == 4) {
        if(findWorker(1) >= 0 && findWorker(5) >= 0) {
            cont = false;
        }
    }
    else if(view[4].ant.type == 3) {
        if(findWorker(2) >= 0 && findWorker(5) >= 0) {
            cont = false;
        }
    }
    else if(view[4].ant.type == 2) {
        if(findWorker(5) < 0) {
            var pos3 = findWorker(3);
            if(pos3 >= 0 && view[pos3].ant.food == 0) {
                cont = false;
            }
        }
        else if(findWorker(3) >= 0 || (findWorker(1) >= 0 && view[findWorker(5)].color == SPAWN))
            cont = false;
    }
    else if(view[4].ant.type == 1) {
        if(findWorker(5) < 0) {
            var pos4 = findWorker(4);
            if(pos4 >= 0 && view[pos4].ant.food == 0) {
                cont = false;
            }
        }
        else if(!isHighwayCenter())
            cont = false;
    }
    if(findWorker(5) >= 0) {
        for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == 5) {
                if(view[i].ant.food > 10 || view[i].ant.food == 0)
                    cont = true;
                else
                    cont = false;
            }
        }
    }
    //== End guesswork ==//
    if(cont) {
        ret = highwayRobbery();
        if(view[4].ant.type == 1) {
            //try to repair
            var curIndex = HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[4].color);
            var prvCol = HIGHWAY_COLORS[(curIndex+1)%HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];
            var nxtCol1 = HIGHWAY_COLORS[(curIndex+HIGHWAY_COLORS.length-1)%HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];
            var nxtCol2 = HIGHWAY_COLORS[(curIndex+HIGHWAY_COLORS.length-2)%HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];
            var nxtCol3 = HIGHWAY_COLORS[(curIndex+HIGHWAY_COLORS.length-3)%HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];
            var prevAt = -1;
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(i%2 == 1 && view[i].color == prvCol && view[deRotate(i,1)].color == nxtCol1 && view[deRotate(i,-1)].color == nxtCol1) prevAt = i;
            }
            if(prevAt >= 0) {
                // yep, brute force it. Because I'm lazy.
                var goNxt = 8-prevAt;
                if(view[deRotate(goNxt,1)].color == nxtCol3 && view[deRotate(goNxt,-1)].color == prvCol) ret = {cell:goNxt};
                else if(view[deRotate(goNxt,1)].color == prvCol && view[deRotate(goNxt,-1)].color == nxtCol3) ret = {cell:goNxt};
                else if(view[goNxt].color != nxtCol1) ret = {cell:goNxt,color:nxtCol1};
                else if(view[deRotate(goNxt,2)].color != nxtCol2) ret = {cell:deRotate(goNxt,2),color:nxtCol2};
                else if(view[deRotate(goNxt,-2)].color != nxtCol2) ret = {cell:deRotate(goNxt,-2),color:nxtCol2};
                else if(view[deRotate(goNxt,1)].color != nxtCol3) ret = {cell:deRotate(goNxt,1),color:nxtCol3};
                else if(view[deRotate(goNxt,-1)].color != nxtCol3) ret = {cell:deRotate(goNxt,-1),color:nxtCol3};
                else ret = {cell:goNxt};
                ret = sanityCheck(ret);
                return ret;
            }
        }
        if(view[4].ant.type == 5 && isHighwayCenter()) {
            if(ret.cell >= 0) {
                ret = {cell:8-ret.cell};
                if(view[4].color == SPAWN && (view[4].ant.food > 90 || view[4].ant.food % 7 == 0) && getHighestWorker() == 0 && (view[4].ant.food < 140 || view[4].ant.food % 9 == 0) && view[0].color == 2 && view[4].ant.food > 50 && view[4].ant.food < 200) {
            //fine
                    if(view[4].ant.food % 10 < 5)
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(ret.cell,3),type:3};
                }
                if(view[ret.cell].ant != null && !view[ret.cell].ant.friend && view[ret.cell].ant.food == 0 && view[4].ant.food > 0) {
                    if(view[deRotate(ret.cell,1)].ant == null)
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(ret.cell,1),type:3};
                    if(view[deRotate(ret.cell,-1)].ant == null)
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(ret.cell,1),type:3};
                }
            }
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == 5) {
                    ret = {cell:8-i};
                }
            }
        }
        if(ret.cell >= 0) {
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == 5) {
                    var rr = basicHighwayMove();
                    if(rr.cell >= 0 && view[4].ant.type != 5)
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(rr.cell,-2)};
                }
            }
            if(view[ret.cell].ant != null) {
                var n = HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[4].color) + 1;
                var nextMove = HIGHWAY_COLORS[n % HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];
                for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                    if(view[i].color == nextMove) {
                        if(view[i].ant == null) {
                            ret = {cell:i};
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(view[4].ant.type == 5) ret = {cell:8-ret.cell};
            }
        }
        if(view[4].ant.type == 5) {
            var foodedEnemy = false;
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(getNumWorkers(3) >= 2) break;
                if(i != 4 && view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.type == 5 && view[i].ant.food > 25) {
                    if(view[deRotate(i,1)].ant == null) {
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(i,1),type:3};
                    }
                    else if(view[deRotate(i,-1)].ant == null) {
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(i,-1),type:3};
                    }
                    else if(i%2 == 1 && view[deRotate(i,2)].ant == null) {
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(i,2),type:3};
                    }
                    else if(i%2 == 1 && view[deRotate(i,-2)].ant == null) {
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(i,-2),type:3};
                    }
                }
                if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == 3 && view[8-i].ant == null) {
                    if(i == ret.cell) {
                        ret = {cell:deRotate(i,1)}
                    }
                    else {
                        return {cell:8-i};
                    }
                }
                if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.food == 0) {
                    foodedEnemy = true;
                }
            }
        }
        var numAnts = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(view[i].ant != null)
                numAnts++;
        }
        if(numAnts > 2 && sanityCheck(ret).cell == 4) {
            ret = {cell:findOpenSpace(0,1)};
        }
        if(view[4].ant.type == 3) {
            if(getNumWorkers(5) > 0) {
                for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                    if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == 5) {
                        ret = {cell:4};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(view[4].ant.type == 4 && getNumWorkers(1) && isHighwayCenter()) {
            var workerPos = findWorker(1);
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(!areAdjacent(i,workerPos)) ret = {cell:i};
            }
        }
        if(ret.cell == -1) {
            if(isHighwayCenter()) {
                for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                    var p1 = deRotate(i,3);
                    var p2 = deRotate(i,-3);
                    if(view[i].color == view[p1].color && view[i].color == view[p2].color) {
                        ret = {cell:8-i};
                    }
                }
                if(view[4].ant.type == 1 || view[4].ant.type == 5) {
                    ret = {cell:8-ret.cell};
                }
            }
        }
        if(ret.cell >= 0)
            return sanityCheck(ret);
    }
}

switch(view[4].ant.type) {
    case 5:
        ret = doQueen();
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        ret = doSweep();
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        ret = doGuide();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
//basic sanity check
ret = sanityCheck(ret);
return ret;

function sanityCheck(ret) {
    if(!ret || ret.cell < 0 || ret.cell > 8) {
        return {cell:4};
    }
    if(ret.color) {
        return ret;
    }
    if((ret.cell != 4 && view[ret.cell].ant != null) || (view[ret.cell].food > 0 && (view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[4].ant.type < 5))) {
        return {cell:4};
    }
    if(ret.type && (view[ret.cell].ant != null || view[ret.cell].food > 0 || view[4].ant.food == 0 || view[4].ant.type < 5)) {
        return {cell:4};
    }
    return ret;
}

function doQueen() {
    if((view[4].ant.food == SPAWN_MIN || (view[4].ant.food >= SPAWN_MIN && view[4].ant.food < FOOD_THRESHOLD && (view[4].ant.food % 3 == 1 || isOnHighway()))) && getHighestWorker() <= 1 ) {
        //prep for first ant
        var s0 = view[0].ant;
        var s1 = view[1].ant;
        var s2 = view[2].ant;
        var s3 = view[3].ant;
        var s5 = view[5].ant;
        var s6 = view[6].ant;
        var s7 = view[7].ant;
        var s8 = view[8].ant;
        var nullCount = 0 + (s0 == null?1:0) + (s1 == null?1:0) + (s2 == null?1:0) + (s3 == null?1:0) + (s5 == null?1:0) + (s6 == null?1:0) + (s7 == null?1:0) + (s8 == null?1:0);
        var nullCount2 = 0 + (s0 == null || s0.friend?1:0) + (s1 == null || s1.friend?1:0) + (s2 == null || s2.friend?1:0) + (s3 == null || s3.friend?1:0) + (s5 == null || s5.friend?1:0) + (s6 == null || s6.friend?1:0) + (s7 == null || s7.friend?1:0) + (s8 == null || s8.friend?1:0);
        if(nullCount >= 7 && nullCount2 >= 8 && view[1].food == 0 && view[3].food == 0 && view[5].food == 0 && view[7].food == 0) {
            var high = getHighestWorker();
            if (high <= 1 && view[4].color != SPAWN && !isOnHighway()) {
                // 50% chance of delaying the respawn by 1 additional move away from where we exploded
                // reduces the chance of a second, immediate explosion
                var pos1 = findWorker(1);
                if(findFirstTrail() < 2 && view[4].ant.food > SPAWN_MIN+1 && pos1 < 0) return foreverAlone();
                if(pos1 >= 0) {
                    var space = deRotate(pos1,2);
                    if(view[space].ant != null) return {cell:findOpenSpace(0,1)};
                }
                return {cell:4,color:SPAWN};
            }
            //spawn first ant
            else if(view[4].color == SPAWN) {
                var pos1 = findWorker(1);
                if(pos1 < 0)  {
                    pos1 = findFirstTrail();
                    if(pos1 % 2 == 0) pos1 = deRotate(pos1,1);
                    else pos1 = deRotate(pos1,4);
                }
                var space = findOpenSpace(pos1,2);
                var high = getHighestWorker();
                if(space < 0) return {cell:4,color:TRAIL}
                if(high == 0) { //no workers
                    return {cell:space,type:1};
                }
                else if(high < 4) { //1 worker of type:high
                    return {cell:space,type:high+1};
                }
                else { //1 worker of type 4
                    //we have all workers, skip!
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return foreverAlone();
        }
    }
    else if(view[4].ant.food == 1 && getHighestWorker() == 0 ) {
        var space = findOpenSpace(1,2);
        return {cell:space,type:1};
    }
    else if(view[4].ant.food >= 1 && getHighestWorker() < 4 && findWorker(1) >= 0) {
        //spawn remaining ants
        if(view[4].color == SPAWN && !isHighwayCenter()) {
            var pos1 = findWorker(getHighestWorker());
            var space = deRotate(pos1,2);
            var high = getHighestWorker();
            if(space < 0 || view[space].ant != null) return {cell:findOpenSpace(0,1)};
            if(high == 0) { //no workers
                return {cell:space,type:1};
            }
            else if(high < 4) { //1 worker of type:high
                return {cell:space,type:high+1};
            }
            else { //1 worker of type 4
                //we have all workers, skip!
            }
        }
    }
    if(view[4].color == SPAWN && getNumWorkers(3) == 1 && getNumWorkers(4) == 1) {
        var one = getNumWorkers(1);
        var two = getNumWorkers(2);
        if((one ^ two) == 1 && (findWorker(1) % 2 == 0 || findWorker(2) % 2 == 0))
            return {cell:4,color:1};
    }
    if(getNumWorkers(1) == 0 && getNumWorkers(2) == 0) {
        if(getNumWorkers(4) == 1 && getNumWorkers(3) == 0) {
            var pos4 = findWorker(4);
            if(view[deRotate(pos4,1)].ant == null && view[deRotate(pos4,2)].ant == null && findWorker(4) % 2 == 1) {
                //finish rotate with only one glider arm
                return {cell:4};
            }
        }
        return foreverAlone();
    }
    else if(getNumWorkers(1) >= 1 && getNumWorkers(2) >= 1 && getNumWorkers(3) >= 1 && getNumWorkers(4) >= 1) {
        if(view[4].color != 2 && findWorker(1)%2 == 1 && findWorker(2)%2 == 1) {
            return {cell:4,color:TRAIL};
        }
        //move diagonally
        var pos = findWorker(4);
        pos = deRotate(pos,1);
        var checkpos = view[deRotate(pos,4)];
        if(checkpos.ant != null && checkpos.ant.friend) {
            if(checkpos.ant.type == 2)
                return {cell:4};
            if(checkpos.ant.type == 1)
                return {cell:4};
        }
        if(view[pos].ant) return {cell:4,color:1};
        return {cell:pos};
    }
    else {
        var pos = findWorker(4);
        if(pos < 0) {
            //if gliding along with only a buddy
            pos = findWorker(1);
            if(pos >= 0 && view[deRotate(pos,2)].food > 0 && view[deRotate(pos,1)].food == 0) {
                return {cell:4};
            }
        }
        if(pos < 0) {
            var s1 = view[1].ant;
            var s3 = view[3].ant;
            var s5 = view[5].ant;
            var s7 = view[7].ant;
            //return {cell:999}
            if(s1 == null) {
                if(s3 == null) {
                    return {cell:0};
                }
                if(s5 == null) {
                    return {cell:2};
                }
            }
            if(s7 == null) {
                if(s3 == null) {
                    return {cell:6};
                }
                if(s5 == null) {
                    return {cell:8};
                }
            }
            return {cell:4};
        }
        pos = deRotate(pos,1);
        var checkpos1 = view[pos];
        for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(i != 4 && view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.type == 5 && view[i].ant.food > 2) {
                if(i%2==0) {
                    if(view[deRotate(i,1)].ant == null) return {cell:deRotate(i,1),type:3};
                    if(view[deRotate(i,-1)].ant == null) return {cell:deRotate(i,-1),type:3};
                }
                else {
                    if(view[deRotate(i,1)].ant == null) return {cell:deRotate(i,1),type:3};
                    if(view[deRotate(i,-1)].ant == null) return {cell:deRotate(i,-1),type:3};
                    if(view[deRotate(i,2)].ant == null) return {cell:deRotate(i,2),type:3};
                    if(view[deRotate(i,-2)].ant == null) return {cell:deRotate(i,-2),type:3};
                }
                return {cell:4};
            }
        }
        if(checkpos1.ant != null && view[deRotate(pos,1)].ant != null && !view[deRotate(pos,1)].ant.friend) {
            return foreverAlone();
        }

        var checkpos2 = view[deRotate(pos,4)];
        var checkpos3 = view[deRotate(checkpos,1)];
        if(checkpos1.ant != null && checkpos1.ant.friend && checkpos1.ant.type == 1 && checkpos2.ant != null && checkpos2.ant.friend && checkpos2.ant.type == 2 && checkpos3.ant != null && checkpos3.ant.friend && checkpos3.ant.type == 3) {
            //move out of spawn orientation
            return {cell:4};
        }
        if(view[pos].ant != null) {
            if(checkpos2.ant == null && checkpos1.ant == null) {
                return {cell:8-pos};
            }
            if(!view[pos].ant.friend) {
                return foreverAlone();
            }
            if(view[4].color == TRAIL) return foreverAlone();
            return {cell:4,color:TRAIL};
        }
        if(8 - findWorker(3) == findWorker(4)) {
            //finish rotate to the right
            return {cell:4};
        }
        if((view[deRotate(pos,1)].food > 0 || view[deRotate(pos,2)].food > 0) && view[deRotate(pos,1)].ant == null && view[4].color != TRAIL) {
            if(findWorker(1) < 0 || view[deRotate(findWorker(1),1)].food == 0) {
                return {cell:4};
            }
        }
        return {cell:pos};
    }
    return {cell:100+view[4].ant.type}; //oh god
}

//guides sit next to the queen
function doGuide() {
    var queenPos = findWorker(5);
    var ty = view[4].ant.type==3?2:1;
    var dir = view[4].ant.type==3?1:-1;
    if(queenPos >= 0 && queenPos%2 == 1 && view[queenPos].color == SPAWN) {
        if(view[deRotate(queenPos,dir*2)].ant == null) {
            return {cell:4};
        }
    }
    if(queenPos < 0 || findWorker(ty) < 0) {
        if(findWorker(ty) >= 0 && view[0].color != IDLE) return {cell:0,color:IDLE}
        return firebreak();
    }
    var checkpos = view[deRotate(queenPos,-2*dir)];
    if(view[4].ant.type==4 && checkpos.ant != null && checkpos.ant.friend && checkpos.ant.type == 1) {
        //attempt rotate
        return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,-dir)};
    }
    checkpos = view[deRotate(queenPos,4)];
    if(checkpos.ant != null && checkpos.ant.friend && checkpos.ant.type == ty) {
        //attempt rotate
        if(getNumWorkers(ty) == 1) {
            return {cell:4};
        }
    }
    var pos = deRotate(queenPos,dir);
    if(pos >= 0 && view[4].ant.type==3 && findWorker(4) < 0) {
        //wait for rotate
        if(view[4].color == TRAIL) {
            return {cell:4};
        }
    }
    if(pos >= 0 && findWorker(2) >= 0 && view[deRotate(findWorker(2),1)].ant != null) {
        //rotate
        return {cell:4,color:TRAIL};
    }
    if(pos < 0) pos = 4;
    else if(view[pos].ant != null) return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,4)};
    if(pos == 4 && view[queenPos].color == TRAIL) return {cell:queenPos,color:1};
    return {cell:pos};
}

//sweepers sit next to guides
function doSweep() {
    var queenPos = findWorker(5);
    var followType = view[4].ant.type==1?4:3;
    var pos = findWorker(followType);
    if(pos % 2 == 0 && getNumWorkers(followType) > 1) {
        //if there's more than one worker #4, we want to use the best one
        for(var i=pos+1;i<9;i++) {
            if(i != 4 && view[i].ant != null) {
                if(view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == followType) {
                    pos = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(queenPos >= 0 && queenPos%2 == 1 && view[queenPos].color == SPAWN) {
        var p = findWorker(view[4].ant.type);
        if(p >= 0 && (deRotate(p,1) == queenPos || deRotate(p,-1) == queenPos)) {
            return {cell:8-queenPos};
        }
        return {cell:4};
    }
    if(queenPos >= 0 && pos < 0) {
        //if Worker #1 is the only ant besides the queen:
        //TODO
    //good
        if(view[queenPos].ant.food <= SPAWN_MIN || !(view[queenPos].ant.food < FOOD_THRESHOLD && view[queenPos].ant.food % 3 == 1 && !isOnHighway())) {
            var go = deRotate(queenPos,-1);
            if((view[deRotate(queenPos,-2)].food > 0 || view[deRotate(queenPos,-3)].food > 0 || (queenPos %2 == 1 && view[deRotate(queenPos,-3)].food > 0)) && view[go].food == 0) {
                go = deRotate(queenPos,2);
                //return {cell:4};
            }
            return {cell:go};
        }
        else if(view[queenPos].ant.food < FOOD_THRESHOLD && view[queenPos].ant.food % 3 == 1) {
            return {cell:4};
        }
    }
    if(queenPos >= 0) {
        var dir = view[4].ant.type==1?1:-1;
        //var checkpos = view[deRotate(pos,-dir)];
        var moveTo = deRotate(pos,dir);
        if(moveTo >= 0 && view[moveTo].ant != null && view[moveTo].ant.friend && view[moveTo].ant.type == 5) {
            moveTo = deRotate(pos,-dir);
        }
        if(view[4].ant.type == 2 && findWorker(1) < 0 && view[queenPos].color != TRAIL) {
            moveTo = 4;
        }
        return {cell:moveTo};
    }
    else {
        if(pos < 0) return {cell:4}; //firebreak();
        var dir = view[4].ant.type==1?-1:1;
        var moveTo = deRotate(pos,dir);
        if(view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[moveTo].food > 0) {
            //have food, attempt to give to queen
            moveTo = deRotate(pos,-dir);
        }
        if(view[4].ant.type==1 && pos >= 0 && (view[deRotate(pos,dir*2)].food > 0 || view[deRotate(pos,dir*3)].food > 0)) {
            //attempt rotate
            moveTo = deRotate(pos,-dir);
        }
        if(view[4].ant.type==2 && pos >= 0 && (view[deRotate(pos,dir*2)].food > 0 || view[deRotate(pos,dir*3)].food > 0)) {
            //attempt rotate
            moveTo = deRotate(pos,-dir);
        }
        if(moveTo >= 0 && view[moveTo].ant != null && view[moveTo].ant.type == 5) {
            if(view[moveTo].ant.friend)
                moveTo = deRotate(moveTo,dir*2);
            else
                moveTo = deRotate(pos,-dir);
        }
        return {cell:moveTo};
    }
    return {cell:100+view[4].ant.type};//oh god
}

function foreverAlone() {
    var s0 = view[0].ant;
    var s1 = view[1].ant;
    var s2 = view[2].ant;
    var s3 = view[3].ant;
    var s5 = view[5].ant;
    var s6 = view[6].ant;
    var s7 = view[7].ant;
    var s8 = view[8].ant;
    //good
    if(!(s0 == null && s1 == null && s2 == null && s3 == null && s5 == null && s6 == null && s7 == null && s8 == null) && view[4].color == TRAIL) {
        if (view[0].color == TRAIL && !view[8].ant && view[8].color != TRAIL) return {cell: 8};
        else if (view[2].color == TRAIL && !view[6].ant && view[6].color != TRAIL) return {cell: 6};
        else if (view[6].color == TRAIL && !view[2].ant && view[2].color != TRAIL) return {cell: 2};
        else if (view[8].color == TRAIL && !view[0].ant && view[0].color != TRAIL) return {cell: 0};
        //Can't find color, or path is blocked? try diagonals regardless of color
        else if (!view[0].ant) return {cell: 0};
        else if (!view[2].ant) return {cell: 2};
        else if (!view[6].ant) return {cell: 6};
        else if (!view[8].ant) return {cell: 8};
        //Everything else failed? Stay put.
        else return {cell: 4};
    }
    //good
    if (view[4].color == TRAIL) { //If on colored square, try to move
        var totGreen = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) { //Look for food
            if (view[i].food) {
                return {cell: i};
            }
            if(view[i].color == TRAIL) totGreen++;
        }
        var ret = getTrailMove();
        if(view[deRotate(ret.cell,1)].color == TRAIL && totGreen <= 4) ret.cell = deRotate(ret.cell,-1);
        else if(view[deRotate(ret.cell,-1)].color == TRAIL && totGreen <= 4) ret.cell = deRotate(ret.cell,1);
        return ret;
    } else { //If not on colored square, look for food, or set current color to 2.
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) { //Look for enemies
            if (i != 4 && view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend) {
                var r = findOpenSpace(8-i,1);
                if(view[r].color == TRAIL) r = deRotate(r,1);
                return {cell: r};
            }
        }
        return {cell: 4, color:TRAIL};
    }
}

function getTrailMove() {
    if (view[0].color == TRAIL && !view[8].ant && view[8].color != TRAIL) return {cell: 8};
    else if (view[2].color == TRAIL && !view[6].ant && view[6].color != TRAIL) return {cell: 6};
    else if (view[6].color == TRAIL && !view[2].ant && view[2].color != TRAIL) return {cell: 2};
    else if (view[8].color == TRAIL && !view[0].ant && view[0].color != TRAIL) return {cell: 0};
    //Can't find color, or path is blocked? try diagonals regardless of color
    else if (!view[0].ant) return {cell: 0};
    else if (!view[2].ant) return {cell: 2};
    else if (!view[6].ant) return {cell: 6};
    else if (!view[8].ant) return {cell: 8};
    //Everything else failed? Stay put.
    else return {cell: 4};
}

function firebreak() {
    var ret = -1;
    if(findWorker(5) >= 0) {
        return {cell:8-findWorker(5)};
    }
    if(view[4].color != 5) {
        var myView = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            myView[i] = view[i].color
            if(view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[i].food > 0) {
                myView[i] = 8;
            }
            if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend) return {cell:findOpenSpace(deRotate(i,2),1)};
        }
        var ret = clearAhead(myView);
        if(ret == null)
            return {cell:4,color:5};
        else {
            if(!(view[ret.cell].ant != null && view[ret.cell].ant.friend == false) && (view[4].ant.food == 0 || view[ret.cell].food == 0))
                return ret;
            return {cell:4,color:5};
        }
    }
    if(view[1].color == 5 && view[3].color == 5 && view[5].color == 5 && view[7].color == 5) {
        if(view[0].color != 8) return {cell:0,color:8};
        if(view[1].color != 8) return {cell:1,color:8};
    }
    if(view[1].color == 5 && view[7].color != 5) ret = {cell:7};
    if(view[3].color == 5 && view[5].color != 5) ret = {cell:5};
    if(view[5].color == 5 && view[3].color != 5) ret = {cell:3};
    if(view[7].color == 5 && view[1].color != 5) ret = {cell:1};
    if(view[1].color != 5 && view[3].color != 5 && view[5].color != 5 && view[7].color != 5) ret = {cell:1};
    if((view[1].color == 5 && view[7].color == 5) || (view[3].color == 5 && view[5].color == 5)) ret = {cell:0};
    var loop = 0;
    while(ret.cell >= 0 && ((view[ret.cell].food > 0 && view[4].ant.food > 0) || view[ret.cell].ant != null) && loop < 9) {
        loop++;
        ret.cell = (ret.cell + 2) % 9;
    }
    if(loop < 9 && ret.cell >= 0) return ret;
    return {cell:4};
}

//7,6,4,2,3
//O7,D2

function highwayRobbery() {
    var move = basicHighwayMove();
    if(move.cell >= 0 && view[move.cell].ant != null) {
        var n = HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[4].color) + (view[4].color%2==0?1:HIGHWAY_COLORS.length);
        var nextMove = HIGHWAY_COLORS[n % HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];
        for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(view[i].color == nextMove) {
                return {cell:i};
            }
        }
    }
    return move;
}

function basicHighwayMove() {
    var isQueen = view[4].ant.type == 5;
    if(isHighwayCenter()) {
        var n = HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[4].color) + 1;
        var nextMove = HIGHWAY_COLORS[n % HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];
        for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(view[i].color == nextMove) {
                if(view[i].ant == null)
                    return {cell:i};
                else {
                    return {cell:deRotate(i,1)};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if(view[4].color == 7) {
            //move diagonal to yellow (2)
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(i != 4 && i % 2 == 0 && view[i].color == 2) {
                    return {cell:i};
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //move orthogonal to blue (7)
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(i % 2 == 1 && view[i].color == 7) {
                    //try ortho yellow first
                    for(var j=0;j<9;j++) {
                        if(j % 2 == 1 && view[j].color == 2 && areAdjacent(i,j))
                            return {cell:j};
                    }
                    return {cell:i};
                }
            }
            //if orthogonal blue doens't exist...
            //...try diagonal to magenta
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(i != 4 && i % 2 == 0 && view[i].color == 3) {
                    return {cell:i};
                }
            }
            if(view[4].color != 2) {
                //...try diagonal blue
                for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                    if(i % 2 == 0 && view[i].color == 7)
                        return {cell:i};
                }
            }
            //...and orthogonal yellow
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(i % 2 == 1 && view[i].color == 2)
                    return {cell:i};
            }
        }
        var n = HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[4].color) + 1;
        var nextMove = HIGHWAY_COLORS[n % HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];
        for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(view[i].color == nextMove) {
                return {cell:i};
            }
        }
    }
    return {cell:-1};
}

function isOnHighway() {
    var match = 0;
    var nxt = HIGHWAY_COLORS[(HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[4].color)+1) % HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];//4
    var prv = HIGHWAY_COLORS[(HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[4].color)+HIGHWAY_COLORS.length-2) % HIGHWAY_COLORS.length];//6
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[i].color) >=0 && (i == 4 || view[i].color != view[4].color))
            match++;
    }
    if(match >= 5) {
        //7,6,4,2,3


        if((view[1].color == nxt && view[7].color == prv)||(view[1].color == prv && view[7].color == nxt) || 
            (view[3].color == nxt && view[5].color == prv)||(view[3].color == prv && view[5].color == nxt)) {
            return true;
        }
        if((view[1].color == view[8].color && (view[1].color == nxt || view[1].color == prv))||(view[1].color == view[6].color && (view[1].color == nxt || view[1].color == prv)) || 
            (view[3].color == view[2].color && (view[3].color == nxt || view[3].color == prv))||(view[3].color == view[8].color && (view[3].color == nxt || view[3].color == prv))) {
            return true;
        }
        if((view[0].color == view[7].color && (view[0].color == nxt || view[0].color == prv))||(view[2].color == view[7].color && (view[2].color == nxt || view[2].color == prv)) || 
            (view[0].color == view[5].color && (view[0].color == nxt || view[0].color == prv))||(view[6].color == view[5].color && (view[6].color == nxt || view[6].color == prv))) {
            return true;
        }
        if(isHighwayCenter()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function isHighwayCenter() {
    if(HIGHWAY_COLORS.indexOf(view[4].color) >=0 && (((view[0].color != view[8].color || view[2].color != view[6].color) && view[4].ant.type == 1) || (view[0].color != view[8].color && view[2].color != view[6].color))){
        var m1 = view[1].color == view[7].color;
        var m2 = view[2].color == view[8].color;
        var m3 = view[0].color == view[6].color;
        var m4 = view[0].color != 1 && view[2].color != 1;
        if((m1?1:0)+(m2?1:0)+(m3?1:0) >= 2 && m4) {
            if(view[3].color != view[5].color && ((view[2].color != view[5].color && view[8].color != view[5].color) || view[4].ant.type == 1) && ((view[3].color != view[0].color && view[3].color != view[6].color) || view[4].ant.type == 1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        m1 = view[3].color == view[5].color;
        m2 = view[0].color == view[2].color;
        m3 = view[6].color == view[8].color;
        m4 = view[0].color != 1 && view[6].color != 1;
    //good
        if((m1?1:0)+(m2?1:0)+(m3?1:0) >= 2 && m4) {
            m1 = view[1].color != view[7].color;
            m2 = (view[0].color != view[1].color && view[1].color != view[2].color);
            m3 = (view[6].color != view[7].color && view[7].color != view[8].color);
            if(m1 && m2 && m3) {
                return true;
            }
            if(view[4].ant.type == 1 && ((m1?1:0)+(m2?1:0)+(m3?1:0)) >= 2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function deRotateSide(m, amt) {
    return deRotate(m,amt*2);
}

/**Positive amount is clockwise**/
function deRotate(m, amt) {
    var rotationsCW = [1,2,5,8,7,6,3,0];
    var rotationsCCW = [3,6,7,8,5,2,1,0];
    if(m == 4 || m < 0 || m > 8 || amt == 0) return m;
    if(amt > 0)
        return rotationsCW[(rotationsCW.indexOf(m)+amt)%8];
    amt = -amt;
    return rotationsCCW[(rotationsCCW.indexOf(m)+amt)%8];
}

function areAdjacent(A, B) {
    if(A == 4 || B == 4 || A == B) return true;
    if(A % 2 == 0 && B % 2 == 0) return false;
    if(A % 2 == 1 && B % 2 == 0) return areAdjacent(B,A);
    if(A % 2 == 1 && B % 2 == 1) return !(8-A == B || 8-B == A);
    if(A == 0 && (B == 1 || B == 3)) return true;
    if(A == 2 && (B == 1 || B == 5)) return true;
    if(A == 6 && (B == 3 || B == 7)) return true;
    if(A == 8 && (B == 5 || B == 7)) return true;
    return false;
}

function findFirstTrail() {
    var pos = 0;
    var b = 0;
    while(view[pos].color != TRAIL && b < 8) {
        pos=deRotate(pos,1);
        b++;
    }
    return pos;
}

function clearAhead(sides) {
    var c=0;
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(view[i].color == 5) c++;
        if(view[i].color == 5 && i%2 == 0) c+=10;
    }
    if(c == 2) {
        if(view[0].color == 5 || view[2].color == 5 || view[6].color == 5 || view[8].color == 5) {
            return {cell:4,color:5};
        }
        if(view[0].ant == null)
            return {cell:0};
        if(view[2].ant == null)
            return {cell:2};
        if(view[6].ant == null)
            return {cell:6};
        if(view[8].ant == null)
            return {cell:8};
    }
    c = 0;
    sides[4] = 0;
    var toMatch =[{state:[1,1,1,
                          2,0,2,
                          0,1,0]},
                 {state:[0,2,1,
                         1,0,1,
                         0,2,1]},
                 {state:[0,1,0,
                         2,0,2,
                         1,1,1]},
                 {state:[1,2,0,
                         1,0,1,
                         1,2,0]}];
    for(var m=0;m<4;m++) {
        var score=0;
        for(var j=0;j<9;j++) {
            if(j!=4) {
                if(sides[j] == 5 && toMatch[m].state[j] == 1) {
                    score++;
                }
                if(sides[j] != 5 && (toMatch[m].state[j] == 0 || toMatch[m].state[j] == 2)) {
                    score++;
                }
                if(sides[j] == 5 && toMatch[m].state[j] == 2) {
                    score--;
                }
            }
        }
        if(score >= 6) {
            var clearOrder=[1,0,2];
            for(var r=0;r<clearOrder.length;r++) {
                var s = deRotateSide(clearOrder[r],m);
                if(view[s].color == 5) {
                    if(view[s].ant == null)
                        return {cell:s,color:8};
                    else
                        return {cell:4};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function findOpenSpace(pos, dir) {
    if(pos > 8 || pos < 0) return pos;
    var b = 0;
    while(view[pos].ant != null && b < 8) {
        pos=deRotate(pos,dir);
        b++;
    }
    return pos;
}

function getHighestWorker() {
    var r=0;
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(i != 4 && view[i].ant != null) {
            if(view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type > r) r = view[i].ant.type;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

function getNumWorkers(type) {
    var r=0;
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(i != 4 && view[i].ant != null) {
            if(view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == type) r++;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

function findWorker(type) {
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(i != 4 && view[i].ant != null) {
            if(view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == type) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**422% Complete**
<sup><sup>422% because the update was on 4/22<sub><sub>This joke has gone on too long</sub></sub></sup></sup>

Invalid move detection: check
Turning: check
Respawning workers when they get trimmed: mostly check
Avoiding stuck on other ants leeching food: ...

**Update 8/1**

Turns twice as often, resulting in ~15% more food collected

**Update 8/2**

Added robustness vs. getting stuck.

**Update 9/9**

Added code to respawn workers 2 and 3 when that arm is missing.

**Update 9/12**

Revert prior update. The glider could move forward with the newly spawned arm, but workers would act out of order when trying to turn and it would blow apart.

In addition to fixing that, reconfigured the respawn-all-workers code to be more discriminatory: it reduce collisions with nearby "lost" workers as well as preventing the respawn entirely above 60 food: 60 food is sufficient to score in the top 3 spots most of the time, which is better than spending 4 food on workers that are likely to just get stripped off again in short order: very few ants ever score more than 60 except when they out-strip Glider's capabilities anyway. Also added some code to let lost workers run about messing up other ants trails.

Few other fixes relating to situations in which the glider could get stuck even when there was a valid move it could make (e.g. having the queen ditch a stuck arm and respawn them later).

Reconfigured the color to use a defined variable and changed the trail color from yellow to green to avoid getting "trapped" in Miners on a Rail's rail system (solo queen would get constantly redirected).

Some of the new code is incorporated from my other entry, [Black Hole](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135157/8927).

**Update 9/13**

Fixed a bug in the move-out-of-spawn-orrientation code. Couple of `2`s handle gotten converted to `TRAIL`s.

**Update 1/21**

- Glider can now turn to the left (animation pending).
- Early game accelerated by spawning one worker as soon as food is available.
- One-arm gliding can turn both directions as well.
- "Don't respawn workers" threshold raised
- "Don't waste food trying to respawn and failing" reduced from `%5` to `%3`

**Update 1/25**

- Fixed some deadlock scenarios, boosting efficiency a few points in some matches.

**Update 2/20**

- Addressed several edge-case explosion / deadlock scenarios, making both the 5-and and 3-ant configurations more stable. Several arrangements of food could result in the Glider becoming confused and either deadlocking (repeatedly rotating back and forth) or exploding.

  - One explosion was the result of the sweeper ant moving onto food during the last step of a rotation, then assuming "shit, I have food, sacrifice myself to get it to the queen" when it didn't need to (standard move was valid).
  - One explosion was the result of the cell under the queen already being `TRAIL` (green), causing one of the queen's "stay still" moves (handled by the fallback to `foreverAlone()` making the queen move away from the group. Fixed this by making a stationary guard modify the queen's cell's color just before the queen takes her action.
  - More desirable than fixing the queen's code, as this allows us to escape deadlocks that may otherwise occur by retaining the fallback to `foreverAlone()`, getting the queen out, even if we can't save her wings.
- `foreverAlone()` function updated to only move onto food if the cell under the queen is `TRAIL` (green). Very slight efficiency loss.
- Glider rebuild morebetter locates an adjacent green cell, a change in `findFirstYellow()` and its usage. This, combined with the previous bullet results in better avoidance of previously seen cells and/or the site of a recent explosion: a newly formed glider will--in a large majority of cases--move off in a direction not along the queen's incoming trajectory.

  - Function renamed: Yellow has not been the queen's trail color in a long, long time.
  - Function was also *incorrectly* locating the "first cell of trail" due to an inverted logic check: `while ==` instead of `while !=`

**Update 2/25**

- More edge-case explosion/crash/deadlock fixes, overall improving performance.
- Some alterations to LightSpeed-like behavior, suggested by Alion (from his [own entry's behavior](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153688/47990)). Generally increases food collection, but also avoids certain deadlock scenarios.

**Update 3/11:**
Broken Glider wings that find themselves on the Highway switch behavior to a Vampire-like "steal food" system. Predominantly this won't mean much unless the queen *herself* is alone inside the Highway, which with its vast amounts of green, make this an impossible space to escape from.

Worker 1 will attempt to enact repairs on the Highway central corridor and performing a best-guess abort if it finds itself on a spot of Highway that is NOT rail (rather than repairing a false center). Travels in the same direction as the queen (counter to workers 2, 3, and 4).

Workers 2, 3, and 4 attempt to perform drive-by theft on the Highway queen, then return to their own queen, who spawns workers when she...

- cannot see any of her own workers
- is sitting on magenta
- has food between thresholds (with soft boundaries on both sides)
- modified by a simple random

This avoids creating too many workers (works out to ~100) and when a string of laden workers return, there is net food income (due to the no-spawning while seeing own workers) eventually pushing Glider above the top threshold and spawning (massively reduced) new workers.

This was a tactic I had been planning on writing into Vampire, but Vampire's first attempt at blocking the Highway queen and just bleeding her dry worked, so there was no incentive to create this behavior.  On-highway detection code is written from scratch and is distinct from Vampire, although the mirror-detection (IsHighwayCenter) is very similar, just due to the simplicity of the pattern.

**Update 3/16**

Aside from two minor bug fixes (see edit history) an optimization was made to the Forever Alone function (stolen from...? originally) as to avoid back tracking, allowing the queen to observe more cells on average when by herself.

Fallback movement method added when the `highwayRobbery()` function failed to return a valid move when the ant is in the highway center (and no other logic had adjusted this to a sensible value). If *that* fails, the ants perform their standard gliding logic.

Minor tweaks

- Queen no longer attempts to start spawning when she detects that she is on the highway
- Queen no longer burns through Calories trying to complete a glider formation that will never complete (spawns a worker 4, worker 4 doesn't see worker 1, worker 4 moves away, repeat)
- Adjusted the food modulo values to be coprime with the Highway color cycle.
- Fixed a "finish rotate with 1 arm" that was causing a deadlock
- Minor fixes to the `isOnHighway()` check
- Made ants move onto an orthogonal yellow before moving onto an orthogonal blue cell when in the highway (saves 1 turn finding the center after becoming detatched).

**Update 3/26**

More minor tweaks.

**Update 4/21**

Minor fixes.

---

Loosely based on [Steamroller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135154/47990).

Gathers 4 food leaving behind a yellow trail. Once it has four food, it produces one of each worker type around itself. It then begins gliding along at maximum thrust.  Moving animation at the top takes 1 game turn to complete: as worker 1 is produced first, it executes first, then 2, 3, and 4, before finishing the turn with the queen.  Turning animation takes 2 turns, the short pauses are when the queen performs `{cell:4}` and the food moves when workers 3, 4, and the queen all perform `{cell:4}` in order to prepare for continued gliding.

Comment: I like this bot idea

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Thanks! I was thinking about Steamroller/Piercer and thought to myself "hold on, queen goes last, surely I can get *five* ants to play nice..." grabbed a piece of paper, tore off some squares, and started moving them around. It worked so I wrote up some code. Had to do a lot of error handling and bug fixing for edge cases (the initial bot would get stuck or consume all the food it could and be done, adding the turn operation introduced a lot of edge case scenarios where it would break formation and crash).

Comment: @trichoplax until it crashes into another ant?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon eeeehhhh...maybe. It doesn't get *disqualified* at least...

Comment: I had the idea of doing this 5 ant setup, but it just seemed too hard. If you can figure out how to make the ants deviate from their looping path, I think that you have this whole tournament in the bag.

Comment: @KZhang Oh I did. Look for the comments "//attempt rotate"

Answer (score 13):

## Windmill

Here's a windmill... waiting for the Man from la Mancha (or Vampire from la Mancha?) who will ride up to bring it down.

[image: Windmill, early middle stage of the game]

I tried to explore how much further the design of [Miners on a Rail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/136694#136694) - now relegated to that answer's edit history - could be pushed, prompted by the observation that the stepping stones had better be painted onto *alternate* walls of the mine shafts. And then it just grew and evolved...

While our heavyweight rail plus lightweight shaft geometry is almost the same and the rail patterns look similar enough to cause some ants to mistake either one for the other, the implementation is written from scratch and much more pedestrian in coding style, and introduces one new key idea. Zoom into the hub to watch it *milling*.

```
var AJM=1;var ASM=2;var AE=3;var ASF=4;var AQ=5;var RW=true;var EFCO=false;var THC=1;var TH0=0;var TH1=15;var TH2=17;var TH3=67;var TH4=120;var TH5=390;var THX=15;var THFCO1=9;var THFCO2=26;var THFCO3=75;var RM1=7;var RD1=4;var RM2=19;var RD2=THX;var PW=1;var PY=2;var PP=3;var PC=4;var PR=5;var PG=6;var PB=7;var PK=8;var LN=0;var LCLR=PW;var LT=PB;var LLSF=PP;var LA=PP;var LRL0=PC;var LRL1=PG;var LRL2=LRL0;var LRM0=PR;var LRM1=PB;var LRM1_WRP=PK;var LRM2=PG;var LRR0=PG;var LRR1=PW;var LRR1U=PR;var LRR1V=PY;var LRR1X=PK;var LRR2=PY;var LMX_M0=LCLR;var LMX_M1IN=PC;var LMX_M1OUT=PY;var LMX_M2IN=PP;var LMX_M2OUT=PR;var LMX_M3IN=PB;var LMX_M3OUT=PK;var LMS_WRP=PK;var LMR0=PK;var LML1=PY;var LMR2=PR;var LML3=PC;var LMMF=PG;var LMMH=PP;var LG3=PK;var LG4=PR;var LG5=PK;var LG6=PB;var LP0=LCLR;var LPB=PC;var LPG=PY;var LPG1=PR;var LPX=PP;var FALSE_X9=[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
var UNDEF_X9=[undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined];
var QCPERD=6;var LCL_QC_RESET=LCLR;var LCRQC=[PY,PP,PC,PR,PG,PK];var LCRQCVAL=Array.from(FALSE_X9);var LCRQC_VALUE=Array.from(UNDEF_X9);for (var i=0; i<QCPERD; i++){LCRQCVAL[LCRQC[i]]=true;LCRQC_VALUE[LCRQC[i]]=i;}var SCPERD=7;var LCL_SC_RESET=LCLR;var LCRSC=[PY,PP,PC,PR,PG,PB,PK];var LCRSCVAL=Array.from(FALSE_X9);var LCRSC_VALUE=Array.from(UNDEF_X9);for (i=0; i<SCPERD; i++){LCRSCVAL[LCRSC[i]]=true;LCRSC_VALUE[LCRSC[i]]=i;}var LCRPHR=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRPHR[LPG]=true;LCRPHR[LPG1]=true;var LCRPHASES=Array.from(LCRPHR);LCRPHASES[LPX]=true;var LCRGRM1=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRGRM1[LRM1]=true;LCRGRM1[LRM1_WRP]=true;var LCRGRM_ALL=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRGRM_ALL[LRM0]=true;LCRGRM_ALL[LRM1]=true;LCRGRM_ALL[LRM1_WRP]=true;LCRGRM_ALL[LRM2]=true;var LCRGRR1_OUT=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRGRR1_OUT[LRR1V]=true;LCRGRR1_OUT[LRR1X]=true;var LCRGRR1B=Array.from(LCRGRR1_OUT);LCRGRR1B[LRR1U]=true;var LCRGRR1=Array.from(LCRGRR1B);LCRGRR1[LRR1]=true;var LCRMX_IO=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRMX_IO[LMX_M1IN]=true;LCRMX_IO[LMX_M1OUT]=true;LCRMX_IO[LMX_M2IN]=true;LCRMX_IO[LMX_M2OUT]=true;LCRMX_IO[LMX_M3IN ]=true;LCRMX_IO[LMX_M3OUT]=true;var LCRMX=Array.from(LCRMX_IO);LCRMX[LMX_M0]=true;var LCRMX_IN=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRMX_IN[LMX_M1IN]=true;LCRMX_IN[LMX_M2IN]=true;LCRMX_IN[LMX_M3IN ]=true;var LCRMX_OUT=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRMX_OUT[LMX_M1OUT]=true;LCRMX_OUT[LMX_M2OUT]=true;var LCRMM_FOOD=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRMM_FOOD[LCLR]=true;LCRMM_FOOD[LMMF]=true;var LCRMM_HOME=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRMM_HOME[LCLR]=true;LCRMM_HOME[LMMH]=true;var LCRMS=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRMS[LCLR]=true;LCRMS[LMS_WRP]=true;var LCRFRLL0=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRFRLL0[LCLR]=true;LCRFRLL0[LMR0]=true;LCRFRLL0[LMR2]=true;LCRFRLL0[LRM0]=true;LCRFRLL0[LRM2]=true;var LCRFRLL1=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRFRLL1[LCLR]=true;LCRFRLL1[LMR0]=true;LCRFRLL1[LMR2]=true;LCRFRLL1[LRR0]=true;LCRFRLL1[LRM1]=true;LCRFRLL1[LRR2]=true;var LCRFRLL2=Array.from(FALSE_X9);LCRFRLL2[LCLR]=true;LCRFRLL2[LMR0]=true;LCRFRLL2[LMR2]=true;LCRFRLL2[LRM0]=true;LCRFRLL2[LRR1V]=true;var TN=8;var POSC=4;var NOP={cell:POSC};var AIMU=1;var AIML=3;var AIMR=5;var AIMD=7;var FWD_CELLS=[[ true,true,false,true,true,false,false,false,false ],[ true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false ],[ false,true,true,false,true,true,false,false,false ],[ true,true,false,true,true,false,true,true,false ],[ true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true ],[ false,true,true,false,true,true,false,true,true ],[ false,false,false,true,true,false,true,true,false ],[ false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true ],[ false,false,false,false,true,true,false,true,true ]];var PTNOM=-9;var PTHOME=[LRM0,LRL0,LRM0,LRL0,LN,LRL0,LN,LN,LRM0];var PTGARDEN=[LG6,LG5,LG4,LN,LN,LG3,LN,LRL0,LRL1];var PTFRM0=[LRL1,LRM1,LCRGRR1,LRL0,LRM0,LRR0,LRL2,LRM2,LRR2];var PTFRM1=[LRL2,LRM2,LRR2,LRL1,LCRGRM1,LCRGRR1,LRL0,LRM0,LRR0];var PTFRM2=[LRL0,LRM0,LRR0,LRL2,LRM2,LRR2,LRL1,LCRGRM1,LCRGRR1];var PTGRM0=[LRL1,LCRGRM1,LCRGRR1,LRL0,LRM0,LRR0,LRL2,LRM2,LRR2];var PTGRM1=PTFRM1;var PTGRM2=PTFRM2;var PTGRM2B=[LRL0,LRM0,LRR0,LRL2,LRM2,LRR2,LRL1,LCRGRM1,LCRGRR1B];var PTGRM1_WRP=[LRL2,LRM2,LRR2,LRL1,LRM1_WRP,LRR1X,LRL0,LRM0,LRR0];var PTFRL0=[LCRFRLL1,LRL1,LRM1,LCRFRLL0,LRL0,LRM0,LCRFRLL2,LRL2,LRM2];var PTFRL1=[LCRFRLL2,LRL2,LRM2,LCRFRLL1,LRL1,LCRGRM1,LCRFRLL0,LRL0,LRM0];var PTFRL0H=[LN,LRL1,LRM1,LN,LRL0,LRM0,LN,LN,LN];var PTFRL1G=[LCRFRLL2,LRL2,LRM2,LG3,LRL1,LCRGRM1,LCRPHASES,LRL0,LRM0];var PTFRL2=[LCRFRLL0,LRL0,LRM0,LCRFRLL2,LRL2,LRM2,LCRFRLL1,LRL1,LCRGRM1];var PTGRL0=[LCRFRLL1,LRL1,LCRGRM1,LCRFRLL0,LRL0,LRM0,LCRFRLL2,LRL2,LRM2];var PTGRL1=PTFRL1;var PTGRL2=PTFRL2;var PTGRR0=[LCRGRM1,LCRGRR1,LCLR,LRM0,LRR0,LMR0,LRM2,LRR2,LCRMX];var PTGRR2=[LRM0,LRR0,LMR0,LRM2,LRR2,LCRMX,LCRGRM1,LCRGRR1,LCLR];var PTGRR1=[LRM0,LCRGRM1,LRM2,LRR0,LCRGRR1,LRR2,LMR0,LCLR,LCRMX];var PTMS0R_IN=[LRR0,LRR1U,LRR2,LMR0,LCLR,LCRMX_IN,LCLR,LCLR,LML1];var PTMS0R_OUT=[LRR0,LRR1U,LRR2,LMR0,LCLR,LCRMX_IO,LCLR,LCLR,LML1];var PTMS0R_OUT1=[LRR0,LCRGRR1_OUT,LRR2,LMR0,LCLR,LCRMX,LCLR,LCLR,LML1];var PTMS0=[LCLR,LCRMM_HOME,LML3,LMR0,LCRMM_FOOD,LCLR,LCLR,LCLR,LML1];var PTMS1=[LMR0,LCRMM_HOME,LCLR,LCLR,LCRMM_FOOD,LML1,LMR2,LCLR,LCLR];var PTMS2=[LCLR,LCRMM_HOME,LML1,LMR2,LCRMM_FOOD,LCLR,LCLR,LCLR,LML3];var PTMS3=[LMR2,LCRMM_HOME,LCLR,LCLR,LCRMM_FOOD,LML3,LMR0,LCLR,LCLR];var PTMS1_IN=[LMR0,LCRMM_HOME,LCRMX_IN,LCLR,LCRMM_FOOD,LML1,LMR2,LCLR,LCLR];var PTMS1_IO=[LMR0,LCRMM_HOME,LCRMX_IO,LCLR,LCRMM_FOOD,LML1,LMR2,LCLR,LCLR];var PTMS0_OUT=[LCLR,LCLR,LML3,LMR0,LCLR,LCRMX_IO,LCLR,LCLR,LML1];var PTMS0_WRAPPING=[LCLR,LCRMM_HOME,LML3,LMR0,LCRMM_FOOD,LCRMS,LRL0,LRL1,LRL2];var PTGRL1_WRP=[LMR0,LCLR,LMS_WRP,LRL0,LRL1,LRL2,LRM0,LRM1_WRP,LRM2];var PTMS0FL=[LMMH,LML3,LN,LMMF,LCLR,LN,LCLR,LML1,LN];var PTMS1FL=[LMMH,LCLR,LN,LMMF,LML1,LN,LCLR,LCLR,LN];var PTMS2FL=[LMMH,LML1,LN,LMMF,LCLR,LN,LCLR,LML3,LN];var PTMS3FL=[LMMH,LCLR,LN,LMMF,LML3,LN,LCLR,LCLR,LN];var PTMS0FR=[LN,LCLR,LMMH,LN,LMR0,LMMF,LN,LCLR,LCLR];var PTMS1FR=[LN,LMR0,LMMH,LN,LCLR,LMMF,LN,LMR2,LCLR];var PTMS2FR=[LN,LCLR,LMMH,LN,LMR2,LMMF,LN,LCLR,LCLR];var PTMS3FR=[LN,LMR2,LMMH,LN,LCLR,LMMF,LN,LMR0,LCLR];var CCW=[6,7,8,5,2,1,0,3,6,7,8,5,2,1,0,3,6,7,8,5,2,1];
var xn=-1;var fwdWrong=[];var rearWrong=[];var here=view[POSC];var mC=here.color;var myself=here.ant;var mT=myself.type;var mF=myself.food;var mS=(mT==AE||(mT!=AQ&&mF>0));if (EFCO&&(mT==AQ)){if (mF<=THFCO1){QCPERD=5;} else if (mF<=THFCO2){QCPERD=4;} else if (mF<=THFCO3){QCPERD=5;}}var dOK=[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true];
var uo=true;var sL=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];var sD=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];var sN=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];var sT=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];var fdL=0;var fdD=0;var fdT=0;sT[mC]++;for (i=0; i<TN; i+=2){var cell=view[CCW[i]];sD[cell.color]++;sN[cell.color]++;sT[cell.color]++;if (cell.food>0){fdD++;fdT++;if (mS){dOK[CCW[i]]=false;uo=false;}}}for (i=1; i<TN; i+=2){var cell=view[CCW[i]];sL[cell.color]++;sN[cell.color]++;sT[cell.color]++;if (cell.food>0){fdL++;fdT++;if (mS){dOK[CCW[i]]=false;uo=false;}}}var aF=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var aLF=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var aUF=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var fT=0;var mQ=0;var aE=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var aLE=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var aUE=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var eT=0;for (i=0; i<TN; i++){var cell=view[CCW[i]];if (cell.ant){if (cell.ant.friend){aF[cell.ant.type]++;fT++;if (cell.ant.type==AQ){xn=i&6;mQ=i&1;}if (cell.ant.food>0){aLF[cell.ant.type]++;} else {aUF[cell.ant.type]++;}} else {aE[cell.ant.type]++;eT++;if (cell.ant.food>0){aLE[cell.ant.type]++;} else {aUE[cell.ant.type]++;}}dOK[CCW[i]]=false;uo=false;}}switch (mT){case AQ:return (rQSs());case ASF:if (mQ==1){return (rSSs());} else if (aF[AQ]>0){return (rGSs());} else {return (rLSSy());}case AE:return (rESs());case AJM:case ASM:if (aE[AQ]>0){return (rDSs());} else if (mF>0){return (rLSs());} else {return (rUSs());}default:return NOP;}function rQSs (){switch (aF[ASF]){case 0:return (rQScrSy());case 1:for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){var cell=view[CCW[i]];if (cell.ant&&cell.ant.type==ASF){xn=i&6;if (i&1){if (mF<=THX){return (rQLsSy());} else {return (rQLvSy());}} else {return (rQSgSy());}}}break;case 2:for (i=0; i<TN; i+=2){var cell0=view[CCW[i]];var cell1=view[CCW[i+1]];if ((cell0.ant&&(cell0.ant.type==ASF))&&(cell1.ant&&(cell1.ant.type==ASF))){xn=i;return (rQOSy());}}return (rQCSy());default:return (rQCSy());}return NOP;}function rSSs (){if (view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.type==ASF)){return (rSOSy());} else if (view[CCW[xn+1]].ant.food<=THX){return (rSLSy());} else {return (rSESy());}}function rGSs (){var secCell=view[CCW[xn+7]];if (secCell.ant&&(secCell.ant.friend==1)&&(secCell.ant.type==ASF)){return (rGOSy());} else {return (rGSSy());}return NOP;}function rESs (){if (aF[AQ]>0){return (rEHyS());} else if (aF[AJM] +aF[ASM]>0){return (rEBRSy());} else {return (rEASy());}return NOP;}function rDSs(){if (aF[AQ]>0){return (rDHSy());} else {for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==AQ)){if (i&1){if ((view[CCW[i+1]].ant&&view[CCW[i+1]].ant.friend&&view[CCW[i+2]].ant&&view[CCW[i+2]].ant.friend)||(view[CCW[i-1]].ant&&view[CCW[i-1]].ant.friend&&view[CCW[i+6]].ant&&view[CCW[i+6]].ant.friend)||(view[CCW[i+2]].ant&&view[CCW[i+2]].ant.friend&&view[CCW[i+6]].ant&&view[CCW[i+6]].ant.friend)){if (dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+3]]){return {cell:CCW[i+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+5]]){return {cell:CCW[i+5]};}}} else {if (view[CCW[i+1]].ant&&view[CCW[i+1]].ant.friend&&
view[CCW[i+7]].ant&&view[CCW[i+7]].ant.friend){if (dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+3]]){return {cell:CCW[i+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+5]]){return {cell:CCW[i+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+6]]){return {cell:CCW[i+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+2]]){return {cell:CCW[i+2]};}}if ((i<=2)&&dOK[CCW[i+7]]){return {cell:CCW[i+7]};}if ((i>=4)&&dOK[CCW[i+1]]){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};}}if (fT==0){if (view[CCW[i]].color!=PP){return {cell:CCW[i],color:PP};} else if (mC!=LCLR){return {cell:POSC,color:LCLR};}}}}}return NOP;}function rUSs (){if ((aF[AQ]>0)&&!LCRQCVAL[view[CCW[xn+mQ]].color]){return (rUHSy());} else if ((fT+eT>=4)&&(aF[AJM]+aF[ASM] +aF[AE]>=3)){return (rUCRSy());} else if (aF[AQ]>0){return (rUHSy());} else if (aF[ASF]>0){if (aF[ASF]>1){return (rM2R1Sy());} else {return (rURHSy());}} else if (aF[AE]>0){return (rUBRSy());} else if (spcRL1()){return (rULRL1Sy());} else if (spcRR0()){return (rULRR0Sy());} else if (spcRR2()){return (rULRR2Sy());} else if (spcMS()){return (rUDSSy());} else if (spcRL02()){return (rULRL02Sy());} else if (spcRM()){return (rUTRRSy());} else if (spcRR1()){return (rUPSSy());} else if (spcMS0R()){return (rUESSy());} else if (spcMS0W()){return (rUSWSy());}return (rLostMSy(true));}function rLSs (){if ((fT>=3)&&(fT+eT>=4)){return (rLCRSy());} else if (aF[ASF]>0){if (aF[ASF]>1){return (rM2R1Sy());} else {return (rLRHSy());}} else if (spcMFL()){return (rLLLWSy());} else if (spcMFR()){return (rLLRWSy());} else if (spcRL1()){return (rLLRL1Sy());} else if (spcRR0()){return (rLLRR0Sy());} else if (spcRR2()){return (rLLRR2Sy());} else if (spcMS0R()){return (rLLSSy());} else if (spcMS0ROut()){return (rLLVSSy());} else if (spcMS()&&(aF[AE]==0)){return (rLASSy());} else if (spcRL02()){return (rLLRL02Sy());} else if (spcRM()){return (rLTRRSy());} else if (spcRR1()){return (rLDSSy());} else if (aF[AE]>0){return (rLFRSy());}return (rLostMSy(true));}function rQScrSy(){if (uo){if (fdT>0){return (rQSETc());} else if (mF>=THC){for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LT)||(view[CCW[i+1]].color==LT)){return {cell:CCW[i+1],type:ASF};}}return {cell:1,type:ASF};} else if (mC!=LT){if ((mC==LCLR)||(sN[LCLR]>=TN-1)){return {cell:POSC,color:LT};} else {return (rQSTCTc());}} else if ((sN[LCLR]>=4)&&(sN[LT]==1)){for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LT)||(view[CCW[i+1]].color==LT)){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};}}} else if (sN[LCLR]==TN){return {cell:0};} else {return (rQSATc());}} else {if ((fdT>0)&&(eT>0)&&(eT==aE[AQ])){return (rQSSTc());} else {return (rQSEvTc());}}return NOP;}function rQSgSy(){if (fdT>0){if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else {for (var i=2; i<TN-1; i++){if (dOK[CCW[xn+i]]&&(view[CCW[xn+i]].food>0)){return {cell:CCW[xn+i]};}}for (var i=2; i<TN-1; i++){if (dOK[CCW[xn+i]]){     return {cell:CCW[xn+i]};}}return NOP;}} else if ((mF>TH0)&&(mC==LCL_QC_RESET)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return { cell:CCW[xn+7],type:AE};} else if (view[CCW[xn]].color==LPB){if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return { cell:CCW[xn+3],type:AE};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return { cell:CCW[xn+5],type:AE};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return { cell:CCW[xn+6],type:AJM};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return { cell:CCW[xn+2],type:AJM};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return { cell:CCW[xn+4],type:AJM};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return { cell:CCW[xn+1],type:ASF};}}}return NOP;}function rQOSy(){if ((aE[AQ]>0)&&(mF>0)){for (var i=2; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[xn+i]].ant&&(view[CCW[xn+i]].ant.type==AQ)&&!view[CCW[xn+i]].ant.friend){var j=(xn&4) ? 1 : -1;if (dOK[CCW[xn+i-j]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+i-j],type:AJM};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+i+j]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+i+j],type:AJM};} else if (i==5){var i1=5-2*j;var i2=5+2*j;if (dOK[CCW[xn+i1]]&&!(view[CCW[xn+4]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+4]].ant.friend&&
view[CCW[xn+6]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+6]].ant.friend&&
view[CCW[xn+i2]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+i2]].ant.friend)){return {cell:CCW[xn+i1],type:AJM};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+i2]]&&!(view[CCW[xn+4]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+4]].ant.friend&&
view[CCW[xn+6]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+6]].ant.friend&&
view[CCW[xn+i1]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+i1]].ant.friend)){return {cell:CCW[xn+i2],type:AJM};}} else if ((i==3)&&dOK[CCW[xn+5]]&&!(view[CCW[xn+2]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+2]].ant.friend&&
view[CCW[xn+4]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+4]].ant.friend)){return {cell:CCW[xn+5],type:AJM};} else if ((i==7)&&dOK[CCW[xn+5]]&&!(view[CCW[xn+6]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+6]].ant.friend)){return {cell:CCW[xn+5],type:AJM};}}}} else if ((mF>0)&&(view[CCW[xn+7]].color==LA)&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7],type:AJM};} else if (view[CCW[xn+1]].ant.food>0){if ((mF>0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2],type:AJM};}} else if ((aLF[AJM]+aLF[ASM]>0)&&(mF>0)&&(sN[LA]>0)){for (var i=2; i<TN; i++){var c=CCW[xn+i];if (dOK[c]&&(view[c].color==LA)){return {cell:c,type:AJM};}}} else if (eT>0){var bandits=aUE[1]+aUE[2]+aUE[3]+aUE[4];if ((mF>THX)&&((bandits>=2)||((bandits>=1)&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.friend&&(view[CCW[xn+5]].color==LA)&&(view[CCW[xn+7]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+7]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[xn+7]].color==LA))||(view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[xn+3]].color==LA))))){if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};}}if (mF<RD1){if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};}} else if ((bandits>=1)&&(mF>0)){if ((mF>THX)&&(mF % RM2==RD2+xn/2)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};}}for (var i=2; i<TN; i++){var c=CCW[xn+i];var c1,c2;if ((xn==2)||isSc0(view[CCW[xn+1]].color)){c1=CCW[xn+i-1];c2=CCW[xn+i+1];} else if ((xn==6)||isSc1(view[CCW[xn+1]].color)){c1=CCW[xn+i+1];c2=CCW[xn+i-1];} else {break;}if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.food==0)){if (dOK[c1]&&!(view[c2].ant&&view[c2].ant.friend&&view[c2].ant.food>0)){return {cell:c1,type:AJM};} else if (dOK[c2]&&!(view[c1].ant&&view[c1].ant.friend&&view[c1].ant.food>0)){return {cell:c2,type:AJM};}break;}}}}if (!(LCRQCVAL[mC])){return {cell:POSC,color:LCRQC[1]};} else if ((view[CCW[xn]].color==LPX)&&isSc0(view[CCW[xn+1]].color)){if ((mF<=TH0)||(mF % RM1==RD1)){return (rQHTc());} else if (mF<=TH2){if (dOK[CCW[0]]){return {cell:CCW[0],type:AJM};} else {return (rQHTc());}} else {var destCycle=[2,4,6,4,6,2,6,2,4];var destination=destCycle[mF % 9];if (!dOK[CCW[xn+destination]]){destination=destination % 6+2;}if (!dOK[CCW[xn+destination]]){destination=destination % 6+2;}if (!dOK[CCW[xn+destination]]){return (rQHTc());}if (mF<=TH3){if (xn<=2){return {cell:CCW[xn+destination],type:AJM};} else {return (rQHTc());}} else if (mF<=TH4){if (xn<=2){return {cell:CCW[xn+destination],type:((xn>0) ? AJM : ASM)};} else {return (rQHTc());}} else if (mF<=TH5){if (xn==0){return {cell:CCW[xn+destination],type:ASM};} else {return (rQHTc());}} else {return (rQHTc());}}} else {return {cell:POSC,color:incQc(mC)};}return NOP;}function rQLsSy(){if (mF>=TH1){if (mC!=LCLR){return {cell:POSC,color:LCLR};} else {for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if (view[CCW[i]].color!=LCLR){return {cell:CCW[i],color:LCLR};}}}if ((eT==0)&&(fT==1)){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};}}if ((eT==0)&&(fT==1)){if (view[CCW[xn+2]].food>0){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if ((view[CCW[xn+3]].food +view[CCW[xn+4]].food>0)&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].color!=LLSF)){return NOP;} else {return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};}} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]&&(dOK[CCW[xn+3]]||(view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend))){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else {return NOP;}}function rQLvSy(){if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};}return NOP;}function rQCSy(){return NOP;}function rSOSy(){if (!(LCRSCVAL[mC])){return {cell:POSC,color:LCRSC[1]};} else if (isSc0(mC)&&isQc0(view[CCW[xn+1]].color)&&
(view[CCW[xn+3]].color==LPG)){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LPX};} else {return {cell:POSC,color:incSc(mC)};}return NOP;}function rSLSy(){if ((eT==0)&&(fT==1)){if (view[CCW[xn]].food>0){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (view[CCW[xn+7]].food +view[CCW[xn+6]].food>0){return {cell:POSC,color:LLSF};} else {return {cell:CCW[xn]};}} else if ((eT>0)&&view[CCW[xn+2]].ant&&!view[CCW[xn+2]].ant.friend){return {cell:POSC,color:LLSF};} else {if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};}}return NOP;}function rSESy(){if (view[CCW[xn+5]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.friend&&(view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.type==ASF)){if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};}} else if ((mC==LRR0)&&(view[CCW[xn+5]].color==LG6)){if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};}} else {if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};}}return NOP;}function rGSSy(){if (view[CCW[xn]].color!=LCL_QC_RESET){return {cell:CCW[xn],color:LCL_QC_RESET};}if (mC!=LPB){return {cell:POSC,color:LPB};}return (rGGTc());}function rGOSy(){if (aE[AQ]>0){var c=CCW[xn+2];if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.type==AQ)&&(view[c].ant.food>0)&&!view[CCW[xn+1]].ant){return {cell:CCW[xn+1],color:LA};}c=CCW[xn+3];if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.type==AQ)&&(view[c].ant.food>0)&&!view[CCW[xn+1]].ant){return {cell:CCW[xn+1],color:LA};}}if (!LCRPHR[mC]){if ((mC==LPX)&&isSc0(view[CCW[xn+7]].color)){return NOP;} else if (eT==0){return {cell:POSC,color:LPG};}} else if (isSc1(view[CCW[xn+7]].color)&&isQc2(view[CCW[xn]].color)){switch (mC){case LPG:return {cell:POSC,color:LPG1};case LPG1:return {cell:POSC,color:LPG};default:return {cell:POSC,color:LPG};}}if ((eT>0)&&!LCRPHR[mC]&&(xn&4)){return {cell:POSC,color:LPG};} else {return (rGGTc());}}function rLSSy(){if (mC!=LCLR){return {cell:POSC,color:LCLR};}return NOP;}function rEHyS(){if (mQ==1){var ptrn=PTFRL0H;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,0,1);if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if (LCRQCVAL[view[CCW[xn+mQ]].color]&&dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};}}return NOP;}function rEBRSy(){if (aF[ASF]>0){return (rELGTc());} else {return (rEBRTc());}}function rEASy(){return NOP;}function rUHSy(){if ((mQ==0)&&(view[CCW[xn]].ant.food<RD1)&&view[CCW[xn+1]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+1]].ant.friend&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].ant.type==ASF)){var cc=[5,6,7,4,2];for (var i=0; i<cc.length; i++){var c=CCW[xn+cc[i]];if (dOK[c]){return {cell:c};}}return NOP;}if ((eT>0)&&(aE[AQ]+aUE[1]+aUE[2] +aUE[3]+aUE[4]>0)){var common;if (mQ==0){common=[1,7];} else {common=[0,2,3,7];}for (var i=0; i<common.length; i++){var c=CCW[xn+common[i]];if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&((view[c].ant.type==AQ)||(view[c].ant.food==0))){if ((aE[AQ]==0)&&(mC!=LA)){return {cell:POSC,color:LA};} else {return NOP;}}}}if (mQ==0){if (mC!=LRM0){return {cell:POSC,color:LRM0};} else if (view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LRR0){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LRR0};} else if (view[CCW[xn+7]].color!=LRL0){return {cell:CCW[xn+7],color:LRL0};} else if (view[CCW[xn+5]].color!=LRM1){return {cell:CCW[xn+5],color:LRM1};} else if (view[CCW[xn+6]].color!=LRL1){return {cell:CCW[xn+6],color:LRL1};} else if ((!LCRGRR1[view[CCW[xn+4]].color])&&!(view[CCW[xn+4]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+4]].ant.friend)){return {cell:CCW[xn+4],color:LRR1};}if (LCRQCVAL[view[CCW[xn]].color]||(view[CCW[xn+5]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.food>0))||(view[CCW[xn+6]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+6]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[xn+6]].ant.food>0))){if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};}}} else {var ptrn=PTFRL0H;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,0,1);if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if (LCRQCVAL[view[CCW[xn+mQ]].color]){if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend&&dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};}}}return NOP;}function rUBRSy(){if (spcRL1()){return (rULRL1Sy());} else if (spcRL02()){return (rULRL02Sy());} else if (spcRM()){return (rUFCRTc());}for (var i=TN-1; i>=0; i--){if (view[CCW[i+1]].ant&&view[CCW[i+1]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i+1]].ant.type==AE)&&dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}function rUTRRSy(){return (rUCRTc());}function rULRL1Sy(){var ptrn=PTGRL1;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,0,1);if (xn>=0){if ((view[CCW[xn+6]].color==LMS_WRP)&&(view[CCW[xn+7]].color==LCLR)&&(view[CCW[xn]].color==LMR0)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LRM1_WRP)){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LRM1_WRP};} else if ((view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LRM1_WRP)&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend&&dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else {return NOP;}} else if (spcRM()){return (rUTRRSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rULRL02Sy(){var ptrn;var msm;if (sL[LRM0]>0){ptrn=PTGRL0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,1);}if (xn<0){ptrn=PTGRL2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,1);}if (xn>=0){if (view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend&&dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else {return NOP;}} else if (spcRM()){return (rUTRRSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rULRR0Sy(){var ptrn=PTGRR0;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIML,2,1);if (xn>=0){return (runUMLeaveRRTactic());} else if (spcRM()){return (rUTRRSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rULRR2Sy(){var ptrn=PTGRR2;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIML,2,1);if (xn>=0){return (runUMLeaveRRTactic());}    return (rLostMSy(false));}function rUPSSy(){var ptrn=PTGRR1;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);if (xn>=0){var c=CCW[xn+1];if (view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.food>0)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else {return NOP;}}if ((view[CCW[xn+2]].color==LMX_M3OUT)&&(view[CCW[xn]].color==LMR0)&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].color==LCLR)&&(mC!=LRR1X)){return {cell:POSC,color:LRR1X};} else if ((mT==AJM)&&(mC==LRR1U)&&(view[CCW[xn]].color==LMR0)&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].color==LCLR)&&LCRMX_OUT[view[CCW[xn+2]].color]){return {cell:POSC,color:LRR1V};} else if ((mC==LRR1X)||((mT==AJM)&&(mC==LRR1V))||((mC==LRR1U)&&(view[CCW[xn]].color==LMR0)&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].color==LCLR)&&LCRMX_IN[view[CCW[xn+2]].color])){if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (view[CCW[xn+4]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+4]].ant.friend&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else {return NOP;}} else if (mC!=LRR1U){return {cell:POSC,color:LRR1U};} else if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else {if (dOK[c]){return {cell:c};} else if (view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend){if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else {return NOP;}} else {return NOP;}}}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rUESSy(){var ptrn=PTMS0R_IN;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,4,2);if (xn>=0){return (rUESTc(ptrn,msm));}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rUDSSy(){var ptrn;var msm;if ((sL[LML3]>=1)&&(sD[LMR2]+sD[LMR0]>=1)){ptrn=PTMS3;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(sL[LMR2]>=1)&&(sD[LML1]+sD[LML3]>=1)){ptrn=PTMS2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}if (xn>=0){if ((msm<0)&&(view[CCW[xn]].color==LRM0)&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].color==LRR0)&&(view[CCW[xn+2]].color==LMR0)){if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else {return NOP;}}return (rUDSTc(ptrn,msm));}if ((xn<0)&&(sL[LML1]>=1)&&(sD[LMR0]+sD[LMR2]>=1)){ptrn=PTMS1_IN;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,4);if (xn<0){ptrn=PTMS1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}}if (xn>=0){return (rUDSTc(ptrn,msm));}if ((sD[LML3]+sL[LMR0]>=2)&&(sD[LRL0] >=2)&&(sD[LML1]==0)){ptrn=PTMS0_WRAPPING;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rUWRTc(ptrn,msm));}}if ((sL[LMR0]>=1)&&(sD[LML3]+sD[LML1]>=1)){ptrn=PTMS0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);if (xn>=0){return (rUDSTc(ptrn,msm));}}if (spcRR1()){ptrn=PTGRR1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);if (xn>=0){if (mC==LRR1){return {cell:POSC,color:LRR1U};}return NOP;}}if (spcMS0R()){ptrn=PTMS0R_IN;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,4,2);if (xn>=0){return (rUESTc(ptrn,msm));}}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rUSWSy(){var ptrn=PTMS0_WRAPPING;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rUWRTc(ptrn,msm));}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rURHSy(){return (rMNGTc());}function rUCRSy(){for (var i=TN; i>=1; i--){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&dOK[CCW[i-1]]){return {cell:CCW[i-1]};}}return NOP;}function rLLLWSy(){var ptrn;var msm;if (mC==LML1){ptrn=PTMS1FL;msm=patC(ptrn,AIML,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLLLWTc());}} else if (mC==LML3){ptrn=PTMS3FL;msm=patC(ptrn,AIML,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLLLWTc());}} else if (sL[LML1]+sL[LML3]>=2){ptrn=PTMS0FL;msm=patC(ptrn,AIML,0,1);if (xn<0){ptrn=PTMS2FL;msm=patC(ptrn,AIML,0,1);}if (xn>=0){return (rLLLWTc());}} else if (spcMFR()){return (rLLRWSy());} else if (spcMS()){return (rLASSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLLRWSy(){var ptrn;var msm;if (mC==LMR0){ptrn=PTMS0FR;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLLRWTc());}} else if (mC==LMR2){ptrn=PTMS2FR;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLLRWTc());}} else if (sL[LMR0]+sL[LMR2]>=2){ptrn=PTMS1FR;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,0,1);if (xn<0){ptrn=PTMS3FR;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,0,1);}if (xn>=0){return (rLLRWTc());}} else if (spcMS()){return (rLASSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLASSy(){var ptrn;var msm;if ((sL[LML3]>=1)&&(sD[LMR2]+sD[LMR0]>=1)){ptrn=PTMS3;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,3,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(sL[LMR2]>=1)&&(sD[LML1]+sD[LML3]>=1)){ptrn=PTMS2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,3,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(sL[LML1]>=1)&&(sD[LMR0]+sD[LMR2]>=1)){ptrn=PTMS1_IO;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,0,1);if (xn<0){ptrn=PTMS1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,3,2);}}if (xn>=0){return (rLASTc(ptrn,msm));}if ((sD[LML3]+sL[LMR0]>=2)&&(sD[LRL0] >=2)&&(sD[LML1]==0)){ptrn=PTMS0_OUT;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,0,1);if (xn>=0){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LCLR};}ptrn=PTMS0_WRAPPING;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLWRTc(ptrn,msm));}}if ((sL[LMR0]>=1)&&(sD[LML3]+sD[LML1]>=1)){ptrn=PTMS0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,3,2);if (xn>=0){return (rLASTc(ptrn,msm));}}if (spcRM()){return (rLTRRSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLLSSy(){var ptrn=PTMS0R_OUT;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,0,1);if (xn>=0){} else {ptrn=PTMS0R_IN;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);if (xn>=0){ptrn=PTMS0R_OUT;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,0,1);}}if (xn>=0){return (rLLSTc(ptrn,msm));} else if (spcMS()){return (rLASSy());} else {return (rLostMSy(false));}return NOP;}function rLLVSSy(){var ptrn=PTMS0R_OUT1;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,0,1);if (xn>=0){if (view[CCW[xn+3]].color==LCLR){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:((mT==ASM) ? LMX_M2OUT : LMX_M1OUT)};
} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (view[CCW[xn+5]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.friend&&
dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else {return NOP;}} else if (spcMS()){return (rLASSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLDSSy(){var ptrn=PTGRR1;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,1,1);if (xn>=0){if ((view[CCW[xn]].color==LMR0)&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].color==LCLR)){if ((mC==LRR1X)&&(view[CCW[xn+2]].color!=LMX_M3OUT)){return {cell:CCW[xn+2],color:LMX_M3OUT};}if ((view[CCW[xn+2]].color==LMX_M3OUT)&&(mC!=LRR1X)){return {cell:POSC,color:LRR1X};} else if ((LCRMX_OUT[view[CCW[xn+2]].color])&&
(mC!=LRR1V)){return {cell:POSC,color:LRR1V};} else if ((LCRMX_IN[view[CCW[xn+2]].color])&&(mC!=LRR1U)){return {cell:POSC,color:LRR1U};} else if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};}}if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else {return NOP;}}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLTRRSy(){return (rLCRTc());}function rLFRSy(){for (var i=1; i<TN; i+=2){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==AE)&&dOK[CCW[i+2]]){return {cell:CCW[i+2]};}}return NOP;}function rLRHSy(){var ptrn=PTFRL1G;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLRLTc());}return (rMNGTc());}function rLLRL1Sy(){var ptrn=PTGRL1;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,0,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLRLTc());} else if (spcRM()){return (rLTRRSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLLRL02Sy(){var ptrn;var msm;if (sL[LRM0]>0){ptrn=PTGRL0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,1);}if (xn<0){ptrn=PTGRL2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,1);}if (xn>=0){return (rLRLTc());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLLRR0Sy(){var ptrn=PTGRR0;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIML,2,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLRRTc());} else if (spcRM()){return (rLTRRSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLLRR2Sy(){var ptrn=PTGRR2;var msm=patC(ptrn,AIML,2,1);if (xn>=0){return (rLRRTc());} else if (spcRM()){return (rLTRRSy());}return (rLostMSy(false));}function rLCRSy(){for (var i=TN; i>=1; i--){if (!dOK[CCW[i]]&&dOK[CCW[i-1]]){return {cell:CCW[i-1]};}}return NOP;}function rM2R1Sy(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==ASF)&&view[CCW[i+1]].ant&&view[CCW[i+1]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i+1]].ant.type==ASF)){if (i&1){} else {}if (dOK[CCW[i+7]]){return {cell:CCW[i+7]};} else {return NOP;}}}return (rLostMSy(true));}function rLostMSy(totally){if ((fdT>0)&&(mF==0)){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].food>0)&&dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}}if (totally&(fT==0)){if (((mC==PY)&&(sN[PY]==0))||((mC==PR)&&(sN[PR]==0))){return {cell:POSC,color:PP};}if (((mC==PG)&&(sN[PG]==0))||((mC==PC)&&(sN[PC]==0))||((mC==PB)&&(sN[PB]==0))||((mC==PP)&&(sN[PP]==0))){return {cell:POSC,color:PW};} else if ((sT[PG]==0)&&(((mC==PK)&&(sN[PK]==0))||((mC==PY)&&(sN[PY]==0))||((mC==PR)&&(sN[PR]==0)))){return {cell:POSC,color:PW};} else if ((mC!=PW)&&(sN[mC]>=4)){return {cell:POSC,color:PW};}}if ((mC==PG)&&(sL[PG]>=2)){return {cell:POSC,color:PW};} else if (((mC==PK)||(mC==PR))&&(sN[PK]+sN[PR]>=3)){return {cell:POSC,color:PW};}if (sN[PW]<=4){var preferredColors =[PG,PB,PC,PP,PY,PR,PK];for (var ci=0; ci<preferredColors.length; ci++){var c=preferredColors[ci];if (mC==c){break;}if (sN[c]>0){for (var i=1; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==c)&&dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}}}}if (RW){for (var i=1; i<TN; i+=2){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}for (i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;} else {return NOP;}}function rDHSy(){if (mQ==0){var c=CCW[xn+2];if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.type==AQ)&&(view[c].ant.food>0)&&!view[CCW[xn+1]].ant){return {cell:CCW[xn+1],color:LA};}c=CCW[xn+6];if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.type==AQ)&&(view[c].ant.food>0)&&!view[CCW[xn+7]].ant){return {cell:CCW[xn+7],color:LA};}} else {var c=CCW[xn+4];if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.type==AQ)&&(view[c].ant.food>0)&&!view[CCW[xn+3]].ant){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LA};}c=CCW[xn+6];if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.type==AQ)&&(view[c].ant.food>0)&&!view[CCW[xn+7]].ant){return {cell:CCW[xn+7],color:LA};}c=CCW[xn+5];if (view[c].ant&&!view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.type==AQ)&&(view[c].ant.food>0)){if (!view[CCW[xn+3]].ant){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LA};} else if (!view[CCW[xn+7]].ant){return {cell:CCW[xn+7],color:LA};}}}return NOP;}function rQSETc(){if (mC!=LT){return {cell:POSC,color:LT};}for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].food>0){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}function rQSSTc(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].food>0)&&(dOK[CCW[i]])){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}function rQSTCTc(){if ((mC!=LCLR)&&(sN[mC]>=4)){if (sN[LT]==0){return {cell:POSC,color:LT};} else if (sN[LT]>=3){return {cell:POSC,color:LT};} else {for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LT)&&(view[CCW[i+2]].color!=LT)){return {cell:CCW[i+2],color:LT};}}return NOP;}} else if (sN[LT]==1){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LT)&&(view[CCW[i+4]].color!=LCLR)){if (view[CCW[i+1]].color==LCLR){return { cell:CCW[i+1]};} else if (view[CCW[i+7]].color==LCLR){return { cell:CCW[i+7]};} else {return {cell:POSC,color:LT};}}}return {cell:POSC,color:LT};} else {return {cell:POSC,color:LT};}return NOP;}function rQSATc(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LCLR)&&(view[CCW[i+1]].color==LCLR)&&(view[CCW[i+2]].color==LCLR)){if ((view[CCW[i+3]].color==LCLR)&&(view[CCW[i+4]].color==LCLR)){return {cell:CCW[i+2]};}return {cell:CCW[i+1]};}}for (i=TN-1; i>=0; i--){if (view[CCW[i]].color!=LT){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}for (i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].color!=LT){return {cell:CCW[i],color:LCLR};}}return {cell:0,color:LCLR};}function rQSEvTc(){if (sN[LT]>0){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].color==LT){xn=i&6;}}if ( dOK[CCW[xn+7]]&&dOK[CCW[xn]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+1]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+2]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]] ){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+6]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]&&dOK[CCW[xn]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+4]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+6]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+2]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]&&dOK[CCW[xn]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else {for (i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}} else {for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]&&dOK[CCW[i+1]]&&dOK[CCW[i+2]]&&dOK[CCW[i+3]]&&dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+2]};}}for (i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]&&dOK[CCW[i+1]]&&dOK[CCW[i+2]]){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};}}for (i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}return NOP;}function rQHTc(){var ptrn=PTHOME;var msm=patC(ptrn,POSC,0,1);if (msm!=0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:ptrn[cc.p]};} else {return NOP;}}function rGGTc(){var ptrn=PTGARDEN;var msm=patC(ptrn,POSC,0,1);if (msm!=0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:ptrn[cc.p]};} else {return NOP;}}function rUFCRTc(){var ptrn;var msm;if (mC==LRM0){ptrn=PTFRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRM2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);}} else if (mC==LRM2){ptrn=PTFRM2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);}} else if (mC==LRM1){ptrn=PTFRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRM2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,1);}} else if (mC==LRM1_WRP){ptrn=PTGRM1_WRP;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,1);}if ((xn<0)&&spcRR1()){return (rUPSSy());}if (xn<0){return (rLostMSy(false));}if (msm==0){if (fdL>0){if ((view[CCW[xn+7]].food>0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else if ((view[CCW[xn+3]].food>0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};}}if ((mC==LRM1)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LRR1X)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LRR1U)&&!((mT==AJM)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color==LRR1V))&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};}if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};}return NOP;}for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){var ce=CCW[xn+i];if (view[ce].ant&&view[ce].ant.friend&&(view[ce].ant.type==AE)){if ((2<=i)&&(i<=4)){var msmSaved=msm;var fwdWrongSaved=Array.from(fwdWrong);var rearWrongSaved=Array.from(rearWrong);xn=xn % 4+4;msm=patC(ptrn,POSC,0,1);if (msm<msmSaved){xn=xn % 4+4;msm=msmSaved;fwdWrong=fwdWrongSaved;rearWrong=rearWrongSaved;} else {}break;}}}if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else {var cc=rearWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};}return NOP;}function rUCRTc(){var ptrn;var msm;if (mC==LRM0){ptrn=PTGRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);if ((xn<0)&&spcRR1()){return (rUPSSy());}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);}} else if (mC==LRM2){ptrn=PTGRM2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);}} else if (mC==LRM1){ptrn=PTGRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,4,2);}} else if (mC==LRM1_WRP){ptrn=PTGRM1_WRP;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,1);}if ((xn<0)&&spcRR1()){return (rUPSSy());}if (xn<0){return (rLostMSy(true));}if (msm==0){if (fdL>0){if ((view[CCW[xn+7]].food>0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else if ((view[CCW[xn+3]].food>0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};}}if ((mC==LRM1)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LRR1X)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LRR1U)){if ((((mT==AJM)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color==LRR1))||((mT==ASM)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color==LRR1V)))&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};}}if (mC==LRM0&&(view[CCW[xn+5]].color==LRM1_WRP)&&!(view[CCW[xn+5]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.friend)){return {cell:CCW[xn+5],color:LRM1};}var c=CCW[xn+5];if (dOK[c]){return {cell:c};} else if (view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend){var evade=false;if (view[c].ant.food>0){evade=true;} else if (view[CCW[xn+1]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+1]].ant.friend&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].ant.food==0)){evade=true;}if (evade){if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else {return NOP;}} else {return NOP;}}} else if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else {var cc=rearWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};}return NOP;}function rUESTc(ptrn,msm){switch (view[CCW[xn+3]].color){case LMX_M0:return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LMX_M1IN};case LMX_M1OUT:if (mT==ASM){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LMX_M2IN};}break;case LMX_M2OUT:if (mT==ASM){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LMX_M3IN};}break;case LMX_M3OUT:break;case LMX_M1IN:case LMX_M2IN:case LMX_M3IN:if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if ((msm==0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else {break;}default:break;}if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};}return NOP;}function runUMLeaveRRTactic(){if (view[CCW[xn+7]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+7]].ant.friend&&dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else {return NOP;}}function rUDSTc(ptrn,msm){var c=CCW[xn+1];if ((msm==0)&&(fdL>0)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].food+view[CCW[xn+7]].food>0)){if (mC!=LMMF){return {cell:POSC,color:LMMF};} else if (view[CCW[xn+5]].color!=LMMH){return {cell:CCW[xn+5],color:LMMH};} else if ((view[CCW[xn+3]].food>0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if ((view[CCW[xn+7]].food>0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};}} else if ((msm<0)&&!(view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend)){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if (msm>=0){if (dOK[c]){return {cell:c};} else {if (view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend){if (view[c].ant.food>0){if ((view[CCW[xn]].color==LCLR)&&dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if ((view[CCW[xn+2]].color==LCLR)&&dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else {return NOP;}} else {var c=CCW[xn+5];if (view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend&&(view[c].ant.food==0)){if (view[c].color==LMMH){if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else {return NOP;}} else if (mC!=LMMH){return {cell:POSC,color:LMMH};} else {return NOP;}} else {return NOP;}}} else {return NOP;}}}return NOP;}function rUWRTc(ptrn,msm){if (view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LMS_WRP){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LMS_WRP};} else if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};}return NOP;}function rLLLWTc(){if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else {return NOP;}}function rLLRWTc(){if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else {return NOP;}}function rLWRTc(ptrn,msm){if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else {return NOP;}}function rLASTc(ptrn,msm){var c=CCW[xn+5];if ((msm<0)&&!(view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend)){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if (mC==LMMF){return {cell:POSC,color:LCLR};} else if (view[CCW[xn+5]].color==LMMH){return {cell:CCW[xn+5],color:LCLR};} else if (msm>=0){if (dOK[c]){return {cell:c};} else if ((view[c].food>0)&&(eT==0)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};}}}return NOP;}function rLLSTc(ptrn,msm){if (msm<0){if (view[CCW[xn+5]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.friend){return NOP;}var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};}switch (view[CCW[xn+3]].color){case LMX_M1IN:return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LMX_M1OUT};case LMX_M2IN:return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LMX_M2OUT};case LMX_M3IN:default:return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LMX_M3OUT};case LMX_M1OUT:case LMX_M2OUT:case LMX_M3OUT:if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};}break;}return NOP;}function rLCRTc(){var ptrn;var msm;var trust=(aF[AE]>0 ? 1 : 0);if (mC==LRM0){ptrn=PTGRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2-trust);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM2B;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}} else if (mC==LRM2){ptrn=PTGRM2B;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2-trust);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}} else if (mC==LRM1){ptrn=PTGRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2-trust);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM2B;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTGRM0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);}} else if (mC==LRM1_WRP){ptrn=PTGRM1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMD,3,2);if (xn>=0){if (view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=LRR1X){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:LRR1X};} else if (!(view[CCW[xn+7]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+7]].ant.friend)){return {cell:POSC,color:LRM1};}}}if (xn<0){if (spcRR1()){return (rLDSSy());}return (rLostMSy(true));}if (msm==0){var c=CCW[xn+1];if (dOK[c]){return {cell:c};} else if (view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend){var evade=false;if (view[c].ant.food==0){evade=true;} else if (view[CCW[xn+5]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.friend&&(view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.food>0)){evade=true;}if (evade){if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else {return NOP;}} else {return NOP;}}} else if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else {var cc=rearWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};}return NOP;}function rLRLTc(){if (view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend&&
dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else {return NOP;}}function rLRRTc(){if (view[CCW[xn+7]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+7]].ant.friend&&dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else {return NOP;}}function rMNGTc(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==ASF)){if (view[CCW[i]].color==LCLR){if (i&1){if ((view[CCW[i+3]].color==LG5)&&dOK[CCW[i+3]]){return {cell:CCW[i+3]};}} else {if ((view[CCW[i+4]].color==LG6)&&dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};} else if ((view[CCW[i+3]].color==LG5)&&dOK[CCW[i+3]]){return {cell:CCW[i+3]};}}return (rLostMSy(true));} else if (dOK[CCW[i+1]]){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};}}}return NOP;}function rELGTc(){var ptrn=PTFRL1G;var msm;for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==ASF)){xn=i;break;}}msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,0,1);if (xn<0){return NOP;} else if ((msm==0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+5]]&&((view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend)||
(view[CCW[xn+4]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+4]].ant.friend))){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if (msm>0){var cc=rearWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else {return NOP;}return NOP;}function rEBRTc(){var ptrn;var msm;if (mC==LRL0){for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){var c=CCW[i];if ((view[c].color==LRM0)&&view[c].ant&&view[c].ant.friend&&((view[CCW[i]].ant.type==AJM)||(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==ASM))){ptrn=PTFRL2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,1,1);if (xn>=0){break;}}}if (xn<0){ptrn=PTFRL0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,1,1);}if (xn<0){ptrn=PTFRL2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,1,1);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRL1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,1,1);}if (xn<0){return rECLRETc();}} else if (mC==LRL1){ptrn=PTFRL1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,1,1);if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRL2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,1,1);}if ((xn<0)&&(eT>0)){ptrn=PTFRL0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMU,1,1);}if (xn<0){return rECLRETc();}} else if ((mC==LRR2)&&(sL[LRL1]>=1)&&(sL[LRL0]==0)){return {cell:POSC,color:LRL0};}if ((msm==0)&&dOK[CCW[xn+5]]&&((view[CCW[xn+3]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+3]].ant.friend)||
(view[CCW[xn+4]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+4]].ant.friend))){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (msm<0){var cc=fwdWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else if (msm>0){var cc=rearWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};} else {return NOP;}return NOP;}function rECLRETc(){var ptrn;var msm;for (var i=3; i<TN+2; i+=2){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
((view[CCW[i]].ant.type==AJM)||(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==ASM))){xn=i-3;if (mC==LRL0){ptrn=PTFRL0;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,0.3);if (msm==PTNOM){ptrn=PTFRL2;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,0.3);}} else if (mC==LRL1){ptrn=PTFRL1;msm=patC(ptrn,AIMR,1,0.3);}if (msm>0){var cc=rearWrong[0];return {cell:cc.v,color:fixup(ptrn[cc.p])};}return NOP;}}return NOP;}function patC(ptrn,targetCell,qG,wt){if (xn>=0){return (patCO(ptrn,targetCell,qG,wt,xn));} else {var msm;for (var o=0; o<TN; o+=2){msm=patCO(ptrn,targetCell,qG,wt,o);if (xn>=0){return msm;}}return PTNOM;}}function patCO(ptrn,targetCell,qG,wt,ortn){var fwdFCs=FWD_CELLS[targetCell];var totDscs=0;fwdWrong=[];rearWrong=[];if ((Array.isArray(ptrn[POSC])&&!ptrn[POSC][mC])||
((ptrn[POSC]>0)&&(mC!=ptrn[POSC]))){if (fwdFCs[POSC]){fwdWrong.push({p:POSC,v:POSC});totDscs+=1;} else {rearWrong.push({p:POSC,v:POSC});totDscs+=wt;}}if ((xn<0)&&(totDscs>qG)){return PTNOM;}var jFrom=0;switch (targetCell){case AIMU:jFrom=4;break;case AIML:jFrom=6;break;case AIMR:jFrom=2;break;case AIMD:case POSC:default:break;}for (var j=jFrom; j<TN+jFrom; j++){var posP=CCW[j];var posV=CCW[ortn+j];var c=view[posV].color;if ((Array.isArray(ptrn[posP])&&!ptrn[posP][c])||
((ptrn[posP]>0)&&(c!=ptrn[posP]))){if (fwdFCs[posP]){fwdWrong.push({p:posP,v:posV});totDscs+=1;} else {rearWrong.push({p:posP,v:posV});totDscs+=wt;}}if ((xn<0)&&(totDscs>qG)){return PTNOM;}}if ((xn<0)){xn=ortn;}if (fwdWrong.length==0){return (totDscs);} else {return (-totDscs);}}function isQc0(color){return (LCRQCVAL[color]&&(LCRQC_VALUE[color]==0));
}function isQc2(color){return (LCRQCVAL[color]&&(LCRQC_VALUE[color]==2));
}function incQc(color){if (LCRQCVAL[color]){if (LCRQC_VALUE[color]>=QCPERD){return LCRQC[0];} else {return (LCRQC[(LCRQC_VALUE[color]+1) % QCPERD]);
}} else {return undefined;}}function isSc0(color){return (LCRSCVAL[color]&&(LCRSC_VALUE[color]==0));
}function isSc1(color){return (LCRSCVAL[color]&&(LCRSC_VALUE[color]==1));
}function incSc(color){if (LCRSCVAL[color]){return (LCRSC[(LCRSC_VALUE[color]+1) % SCPERD]);
} else {return undefined;}}function spcMS(){return (((mC==LCLR)||((mF+fdL>0)&&(mC==LMMF))||((mF>0)&&(mC==LMMH)))&&(sN[LMR0]+sN[LML1] +sN[LMR2]+sN[LML3]>=2)&&(sN[LCLR]>=3)&&(sN[LMMF] +sN[LMMH] +sN[PB]<=3)); }function spcRM(){return (LCRGRM_ALL[mC]&&(sT[LRL0]+sT[LRL1]>=3)&&(sN[LRL0]>=1)&&(sN[LRR0]+sN[LRR2]>=2)&&(sT[LRM0]+sT[LRM1_WRP] +sT[LRM1]+sT[LRM2]>=2)&&(sT[LCLR]<=4));}function spcRL1(){return ((mC==LRL1)&&(sL[LRL0]>=2)&&(sD[LRM0]>=1)&&(sL[LRM1_WRP]+sL[LRM1]>=1)&&(sD[LRM2]>=1));}function spcRL02(){return ((mC==LRL0)&&(sL[LRL1]+sL[LRL2]>=2)&&(sN[LRM0]>=1)&&(sD[LRM1_WRP]+sD[LRM1]>=1));}function spcRR0(){return ((mC==LRR0)&&(sL[LRM1]==0)&&(sD[LRM1]+sD[LRM1_WRP]>=1)&&(sL[LMR0]>=1)&&(sL[LRR2]>=1));}function spcRR1(){return (LCRGRR1[mC]&&(sN[LRR0]>=2)&&(sL[LRR2]>=1)&&(sD[LRM0]>=1)&&(sN[LCLR]<=3)&&(sL[LRM1] +sL[LRM1_WRP]>=1));}function spcRR2(){return ((mC==LRR2)&&(sD[LCLR]>=1)&&(sD[LRM0]>=1)&&(sD[LRM1]+sD[LMR0]>=2)&&(sL[LRR0]>=2));}function spcMS0R(){return((mC==LCLR)&&(sL[LMR0]>=1)&&(sL[LRR1U]>=1)&&(sD[LRR2]>=1)&&(sD[LRR0]>=1));}function spcMS0ROut(){return ((mC==LCLR)&&(sL[LMR0]+sL[LRR1V]>=2)&&(sD[LRR2]>=2)&&(sD[LRR0]>=1));}function spcMS0W(){return ((mC==LCLR)&&(sD[LRL0]>=3)&&(sL[LRL1]>=1)&&(sL[LMS_WRP]>=2)&&(sN[LCLR]>=2));}function spcMFL(){return ((sL[LMMF]>=1)&&(sD[LMMH]>=1)&&(sT[LCLR]>=2)&&(sT[LML1]+sT[LML3]>=1));}function spcMFR(){return ((sL[LMMF]>=1)&&(sD[LMMH]>=1)&&(sT[LCLR]>=2)&&(sT[LMR0]+sT[LMR2]>=1));}function fixup(ptrnCell){if (Array.isArray(ptrnCell)){for (var i=1; i<=9; i++){if (ptrnCell[i]){return i;}}return LCLR;} else {return ptrnCell;}}
```

(On trichoplax's and dzaima's advice - for which many thanks! - this has been uglified to fit within the PPCG size limits, at the expense of readability. **Edit:** The unabridged original, amply commented and with meaningful variable and function names, is now [available on GitHub](https://github.com/GNiklasch/formic-windmill).)

After the usual initial scramble, the Windmill Queen launches *three* rails, aiming to have an area closer to it scoured more thoroughly and reduce rail travel times, and adding redundancy. There's a little garden on the fourth side, with berries red and blue and black.

We dispense with Miners on a Rail's Repairer. (Their very long rail is a mixed blessing... it tends to attract vampires.) Instead, we have an Engineer on each rail. Their original purpose was to tell miners whether they are extending the rail (viz. when they can see the engineer) versus repairing it (when they can't), but this got somewhat buried as the code evolved. They now look after a few minor tasks, such as helping to prevent rails from sprouting upside-down continuations.

A shaft 3 cells wide by 1000 cells deep is expected to contain 3 food on average, and only 4% of all shafts of this depth won't contain any. Once we estimate from the amount of hoarded food that the rails have grown long enough to make it worthwhile, the queen will therefore begin to spawn senior miners who will re-inspect shafts previously explored by a junior miner. As in Miners on a Rail, we're prepared to handle shafts which wrap around the arena to the back (left) side of a rail.

The Windmill Queen also employs two other staff: A Gardener, and a Secretary. They're the same ant type, doing one thing or the other depending on their locations relative to the queen and to each other. They help the queen to orchestrate the creation of the engineers and of the first few junior miners, and then assist the queen in running a clock: an oscillator that will ring every 85 moves (when undisturbed).

This master clock, together with the amount of hoarded food and the random 1-of-4 orientations we receive, decouples the creation of miners from the arrival of food, and regulates the rate at which further miners will be spawned. When the queen has just settled, all incoming food is quickly converted into more miners until the rate of incoming food reaches about 9 per 1000 moves (which requires about a dozen productive miners). Then the clock cycle becomes the limiting factor and we start hoarding food. Later as the amount of food increases, we throttle down the spawning rate to at most 6 new miners per 1000 moves and later at most 3, and finally stop procreating altogether. A ratchet mechanism prevents the queen from expending too much food on spawning when all rails are blocked or damaged.

Even without any major damage, the mining efficiency will decrease a lot as each game unfolds. Initially, we expect a miner drilling at half light speed and returning at light speed to deliver 1 food every 1000 moves on average. Towards the end, it's more like 0.12-0.14 food per miner per 1000 moves. Travelling the longer rails, painting the mostly white shaft pattern onto a no longer mostly white canvas, and repairing shafts and rails all take time; miners get stuck, or lost, or tied up in paintball skirmishes with opponents.

Our miners make an effort to extract themselves from any major traffic jams.

And there's a rudimentary immune system to deal with unfriendly intruders.

Trying to steamroll our backyard is not recommended. Our staff won't be amused.

The main drawback is that the Windmill queen needs 8 food to afford her initial staff out of pocket, so the scrambling phase is rather long, giving other similar contenders a head start. If our nest gets overrun and the rails wiped out before we have hoarded any food, the day will end badly for us. Later, and with at least one rail running or repairable, we can usually keep going, or at least hold on to (most of) what we already have.

The implementation treats neighbor cells as numbered counter-clockwise, starting at a corner, with an array (`CCW`) to translate these numbers into the controller's `view` subscripts. When we have a need (and are able) to pin down our sense of North, we set our compass, a base subscript into `CCW`. The ant function always starts by taking stock of its surroundings, in particular recording a spectrum (how often each color occurs), and then branches out by ant type and situation along a multi-level decision tree of strategies and tactics. This makes it feasible to handle a host of weird special cases whilst dealing with the most common situations very quickly. The tree has almost 200 leaves which paint a cell or take a step or create an ant, and more than 70 which do nothing - distilled from the 2^27 possible view color patterns multiplied by possible ants in view, food in view, and food carried.

Here's an ASCII rendering of the hub geometry:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   | ^ |MR2|   | v |MR2|   | ^ |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   | i |   |   | a | r |  rail 2   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+-n-+---+---+-c-+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |ML1|   |   |ML1| a |   |RL0|RM0|RR0|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   | y | u |   | y | t |   | c | r | g |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+-s-+---+---+-e-+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |MX | e |MR0|MX | d |MR0|RL2|RM2|RR2|MX |ML1|   |ML3|   |ML1|   |
|   |   |   | c |   | k | y |   | k | c | g | y | c | y |   | c |   | y |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |RR1|RR0|RR2|RR1|RR0|RR2|RR1|RR0|RL1|RM1|RR1|   | shaft in use  |  >|   |
|  r|   | g | y | r | g | y | y | g | g | b | r |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+--a+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| <i|RM1|RM0|RM2|RM1|RM0|RM2|RM1|RM0|RL0|RM0|RR0|MR0|   |MR2|   |MR0|   |   |
|  l| b | r | g | b | r | g | b | r | c | r | g | k |   | r |   | k |   |   |
+-- +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  3|RL1|RL0|RL2|RL1|RL0|RL2|RL1|RL0|*Q*|RL0|RL1|RL2|RL0|RL1|RL2|RL0|RL1|   |
|   | g | c | c | g | c | c | g | c |clk| c | g | c | c | g | c | c | g |r  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+a--+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |G3 |Grd|Sec|RM0|RM1|RM2|RM0|RM1|RM2|RM0|RM1|i >|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | k |r/y|clk| r | b | g | r | b | g | r | b |l  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ --+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |G4 |G5 |G6 |RR0|RR1|RR2|RR0|RR1|RR2|RR0|RR1|1  |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | r | k | b | g | y | y | g | r | y | g |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |MR0|   |MX |MR0|   |MX |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | k |   | y | k |   | c |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

(showing MX and RR1 colors during and after the first descent by a junior miner).

There are dozens of loose ends. (E.g., we do clean food off the rail because it could become an obstacle to laden miners, but some food just off the rail won't be eaten since the extra complexity just didn't seem worth it.) The good-enough is the enemy of the better...

**v1.1** fixes a cause for disqualification and adds a few minor enhancements.

**v1.2** adds a few more fixes and enhancements.

**v1.3** adds previously mixing `var` declarations to make this work on strict-mode controllers like [Dave's](https://davidje13.github.io/koth-webplayer/formic.htm); no functional changes.

**v1.4** fixes a misunderstanding between queen and gardener about the use of garlic (as Vampires arriving along rail3 are going to find out), cures a stupid pattern-definition bug, and improves a few edge cases.

**v1.5** teaches the Windmill a new trick - wanna see an ant-elope?

**v1.6** lets miners scribble patterns into vast greenish expanses, refines the burglar alarm at home, and deals with enemy queens elsewhere in a slightly more elastic way, plus minor touch-ups.

**v1.7** aside from minor resilience fixes uses a [Lightspeed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/153688#153688)-style startup phase, not to settle earlier but to settle with a larger stock of food. (We need 7 miners to exceed the expected food return rate of a lightspeed tandem, so no point in switching to mining before we can afford them.)

**v1.8** fixes a deadlock in the Lightspeed-phase logic and, more importantly, cures a spawning bug introduced in v1.6 which had resulted in disqualification.

**v1.9** fixes another exotic disqualifying bug, tentatively addresses some congestion cases in shafts, and attempts to deal with the latest vampiric inventions.

**v2.0** enables the queen to abandon an existing hub altogether when in dire need, resorting to Lightspeed-style scrambling, and with luck re-settling later to found a new mill elsewhere, far from the original site.
Experiments with a variable-speed Food Controlled Oscillator, on the other hand, did not result in convincing improvements. Sending out more miners earlier would somewhat increase some competitors' accident rates, but also our own. The FCO code remains in place but has been disabled for now.

**v2.1** addresses three edge cases where workers had better move than stay put.

Comment: The reason why Miners' shafts are how they are is because of trail-eraser: with my design it's very unlikely that a trail-eraser finding a shaft would result in it tracing back to the rail, while yours has at least a 50% chance of leading a trail-eraser to the rail. I was searching for a better shaft pattern for at least half an hour without finding one..

Comment: Yeah, that's a point. On the other hand, Trail-erasers can get bored with the rail and walk *away* along the zigzag back-to-back shaft walls... The alternating pattern is more robust when drilling into difficult terrain (though not infallible).

Comment: Miners on a Rail sometimes actually benefits from Trail-eraser: It enables the rail'd miners to re-explore shafts without really intending to.- And rails and shafts can be repaired. Accidents can and will happen. Recovery options are important. MoaR's are already impressive!

Comment: That would be the case if there were actually things in place for that - miners can get stacked up if there's some food blocking the way of multiple ants. It should be possible to fix that though

Comment: I love the explanation. Particularly using one worker type to produce two different behaviours depending on local context.

Comment: You sure you need both the gardener and secretary? Is there something I'm missing? The oscillator could be run by an [8-ary Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code) for up to 512 cycle length with 3 colors allocated.

Comment: It's what emerged from my tinkering... It started with a 2-cell oscillator run by queen and secretary and a 3rd cell holding additional state encoded by a restricted number of colors for bootstrap sequencing. It then turned out convenient (and more robust!) to have an ant occupy the third cell, and the 2-cell clock was running too fast. So the gardener was added, and then took on the extra task of a clock divider, from period (6x7)+1 to (2x6x7)+1, in her spare time. But you're right, the secretary alone *could* run a 3-cell Gray code clock and the queen could just watch it.

Comment: That said, when you look at it in terms of individual ants' turns, *everything* is done Gray-code style in any case. One ant changes one color at a time!- And careful thought was needed elsewhere (esp. at the shaft heads) which ant is responsible for which color at which time. Occupying a cell can be thought of as owning a mutex, leading to code where my ants mostly refrain from changing the color of a cell hosting a friend, with rare and carefully controlled exceptions.

Comment: @trichoplax Whoops - thanks for the heads-up! Cause known (subscript off by two), cf [issue#6](https://github.com/GNiklasch/formic-windmill/issues/6). I'll use the occasion to check in a couple other little fixes. Will update my answer after some regression testing and re-minifying the code.

Answer (score 12):

## Black Hole

```
var COLOR=8
var COLOR2=7
var COLOR3=2
var LOCKDOWN=8
var orthogonals = [1, 3, 7, 5]
var isQueen = view[4].ant.type==5
var rotationsCW = [1,2,5,8,7,6,3,0]
var rotationsCCW = [3,6,7,8,5,2,1,0]
var matchStates = [
    {state:[0,0,0,
            0,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:0,back:0,fill:true},
    {state:[1,0,0,
            0,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:1,back:3,fill:true},
    {state:[0,1,0,
            1,0,0,
            0,0,0],move:0,back:0,fill:false},
    {state:[0,1,0,
            0,0,1,
            0,0,0],move:2,back:2,fill:false},
    {state:[0,0,1,
            0,0,1,
            0,1,0],move:8,back:2,fill:false},
    //5:
    {state:[1,0,0,
            1,0,0,
            0,1,0],move:2,back:6,fill:false},
    {state:[0,1,0,
            0,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:2,back:0,fill:false},
    {state:[1,0,0,
            1,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:1,back:6,fill:false},
    {state:[0,1,1,
            0,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:5,back:0,fill:false},
    {state:[0,1,0,
            1,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:2,back:6,fill:false},
    //10:
    {state:[1,1,0,
            0,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:2,back:3,fill:false},
    {state:[1,1,0,
            1,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:2,back:6,fill:false},
    {state:[0,1,1,
            0,1,1,
            0,0,0],move:8,back:0,fill:false},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            0,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:5,back:3,fill:false},
    {state:[1,0,0,
            1,1,0,
            1,0,0],move:1,back:7,fill:false},
    //15:
    {state:[0,1,0,
            1,1,1,
            0,0,0],move:8,back:6,fill:false},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,0,
            0,0,0],move:5,back:6,fill:false},
    {state:[1,0,0,
            1,1,0,
            1,1,0],move:1,back:8,fill:false},
    {state:[1,1,0,
            1,1,0,
            1,0,0],move:2,back:7,fill:false},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            0,1,1,
            0,0,0],move:8,back:3,fill:false},
    //20:
    {state:[1,1,1,
            0,0,1,
            0,0,1],move:7,back:3,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,0,0,
            1,0,0],move:5,back:7,fill:true},
    {state:[1,0,0,
            1,0,0,
            1,1,1],move:1,back:5,fill:true},
    {state:[0,0,1,
            0,0,1,
            1,1,1],move:3,back:1,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            0,1,1,
            0,0,1],move:7,back:3,fill:true},
    //25:
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,0,
            1,0,0],move:5,back:7,fill:true},
    {state:[1,0,0,
            1,1,0,
            1,1,1],move:1,back:5,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,1,
            0,0,0],move:8,back:6,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,1,
            1,0,0],move:8,back:7,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,0,
            1,1,0],move:5,back:8,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,1,
            1,1,0],move:8,back:8,fill:true},
    //30:
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,1,
            1,0,1],move:7,back:7,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,0,
            1,1,1],move:5,back:5,fill:true},
    {state:[1,0,1,
            1,1,1,
            1,1,1],move:1,back:1,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            0,1,1,
            1,1,1],move:3,back:3,fill:true},
    {state:[1,1,1,
            1,1,1,
            1,1,1],move:9,back:9,fill:false},
    //35:
]
function matchesColor(c) {
    return c==COLOR || c==COLOR2 || c==COLOR3 || (view[4] == COLOR3 && c == LOCKDOWN)
}
function matchesNonLineColor(c) {
    return c==COLOR || c==COLOR2
}
function isAnyColor(c) {
    var r=0
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(view[i].color == c) r++
    }
    return r
}
function howManyAnts() {
    var r=0;
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(view[i].ant != null) r++
    }
    return r
}
function deRotate(m, amt) {
    if(m == 4 || m < 0 || m > 8 || amt == 0) return m
    if(amt > 0)
        return rotationsCW[(rotationsCW.indexOf(m)+amt)%8]
    amt = -amt
    return rotationsCCW[(rotationsCCW.indexOf(m)+amt)%8]
}
function deRotateSide(m, amt) {
    return deRotate(m,amt*2)
}
function matchWhileLost(sides) {
    var c=0;
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(view[i].color == COLOR3) c++
        if(view[i].color == COLOR3 && i%2 == 0) c+=10
    }
    if(c == 2) {
        if(view[0].color == COLOR3 || view[2].color == COLOR3 || view[6].color == COLOR3 || view[8].color == COLOR3) {
            return {cell:4,color:COLOR3}
        }
        if(view[0].ant == null)
            return {cell:0}
        if(view[2].ant == null)
            return {cell:2}
        if(view[6].ant == null)
            return {cell:6}
        if(view[8].ant == null)
            return {cell:8}
    }
    c = 0
    sides[4] = 0
    var toMatch =[{state:[1,1,1,
                         2,0,2,
                         0,1,0]},
                 {state:[0,2,1,
                         1,0,1,
                         0,2,1]},
                 {state:[0,1,0,
                         2,0,2,
                         1,1,1]},
                 {state:[1,2,0,
                         1,0,1,
                         1,2,0]}]
    for(var m=0;m<4;m++) {
        var score=0
        for(var j=0;j<9;j++) {
            if(j!=4) {
                if(sides[j] == COLOR3 && toMatch[m].state[j] == 1) {
                    score++
                }
                if(sides[j] != COLOR3 && (toMatch[m].state[j] == 0 || toMatch[m].state[j] == 2)) {
                    score++
                }
                if(sides[j] == COLOR3 && toMatch[m].state[j] == 2) {
                    score--
                }
            }
        }
        if(score >= 6) {
            var clearOrder=[1,0,2]
            for(var r=0;r<clearOrder.length;r++) {
                var s = deRotateSide(clearOrder[r],m)
                if(view[s].color == COLOR3) {
                    if(view[s].ant == null)
                        return {cell:s,color:COLOR}
                    else
                        return {cell:4}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
function matchBlueStyle(sides) {
    return null
}
function bestMatch(sides) {
    var c=0;
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(sides[i] > 1) c++
    }
    if(!isQueen && view[4].ant.food > 0) {
        c++
        sides[4] = 8
    }
    if(c <= 1) {
        return {state:matchStates[0],rot:0,fill:matchStates[0].fill}
    }
    c = 0
    while(!matchesColor(sides[0]) && !matchesColor(sides[1]) && c < 4) {
        var s2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        s2[0] = sides[2]
        s2[1] = sides[5]
        s2[2] = sides[8]
        s2[3] = sides[1]
        s2[5] = sides[7]
        s2[6] = sides[0]
        s2[7] = sides[3]
        s2[8] = sides[6]
        sides = s2
        c++
    }
    while(c < 8 && (matchesColor(sides[0]) || matchesColor(sides[1])) && matchesColor(sides[8])) {
        var s2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        s2[0] = sides[2]
        s2[1] = sides[5]
        s2[2] = sides[8]
        s2[3] = sides[1]
        s2[5] = sides[7]
        s2[6] = sides[0]
        s2[7] = sides[3]
        s2[8] = sides[6]
        sides = s2
        c++
    }
    var bestState = null
    var bestMatchScore = -1
    for(var i = 0; i < matchStates.length; i++) {
        var score=0
        for(var j=0;j<9;j++) {
            if(j!=4) {
                if(matchesColor(sides[j]) && matchStates[i].state[j] == 1) {
                    score++
                }
                if(!matchesColor(sides[j]) && matchStates[i].state[j] == 0) {
                    score++
                }
            }
        }
        if(score >= bestMatchScore) {
            //console.log("state " + i + ": " + score);
            bestMatchScore = score
            bestState = matchStates[i]
        }
    }
    return {state:bestState,rot:c,fill:bestState.fill,score:bestMatchScore}
}
function getHighestWorker() {
    var r=0;
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(i != 4 && view[i].ant != null) {
            if(view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type > r) r = view[i].ant.type
        }
    }
    return r
}
function pathLost() {
    var i, j
    var safe = []
    for(var q=0;q<9;q++) {
        if(q != 4 && view[q].ant != null && view[q].ant.friend && (view[q].ant.type > view[4].ant.type && view[4].ant.food == 0 && view[q].ant.type < 5)) {
            if(!matchesColor(view[4].color)) return {cell:4,color:COLOR}
            return {cell:4}
        }
    }
    if (matchesNonLineColor(view[4].color)) {
        var myView = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            myView[i] = view[i].color
            if(!isQueen && view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[i].food > 0) {
                myView[i] = COLOR;
            }
        }
        var ret = matchWhileLost(myView)
        if(ret == null)
            return {cell:4, color:COLOR3}
        else {
            if(!(view[ret.cell].ant != null && view[ret.cell].ant.friend == false) && (view[4].ant.food == 0 || view[ret.cell].food == 0 || isQueen))
                return ret
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<view.length; i++) {
        if (view[i].ant === null && (view[4].ant.food == 0 || view[i].food == 0 || isQueen)) {
            safe.push(i);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        j = (i+2) % 4
        if (matchesNonLineColor(view[orthogonals[i]].color) && view[orthogonals[j]].color == COLOR3) {
            if (view[orthogonals[i]].ant == null) {
                return {cell:orthogonals[i]}
            } else if (safe.length > 0) {
                return {cell:safe[0]}
            } else if (view[0].ant === null && (view[4].ant.food == 0 || view[0].food == 0 || isQueen)) {
                return {cell:0}
            }
        }
    }
    if (view[1].ant === null && (view[4].ant.food == 0 || view[1].food == 0 || isQueen)) {
        return {cell:1}
    } else {
        if(!matchesColor(view[4].color)) return {cell:4,color:COLOR}
        return {cell:4}
    }
}
function isAllyAdjacentTo(view, place) {
    var i = deRotate(place, 1)
    var j = deRotate(place, -1)
    if(view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type < 5) return 1
    if(view[j].ant != null && view[j].ant.friend && view[j].ant.type < 5) return 1
    if(orthogonals.indexOf(place) >= 0) {
        i = deRotate(place, 2)
        j = deRotate(place, -2)
        if(view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type < 5) return 2
        if(view[j].ant != null && view[j].ant.friend && view[j].ant.type < 5) return 2
    }
    return 0
}
function findOpenSpace(pos, dir) {
    if(pos > 8 || pos < 0) return pos
    if(view[pos].ant != null && view[pos].ant.friend && view[4].ant.food == 0) {
        pos=deRotate(pos,4)
    }
    //var inc = dir>0?1:-1
    var b = 0
    while(view[pos].ant != null && b < 8) {
        pos=deRotate(pos,dir)
        b++
    }
    return pos
}
//end functions
function getReturn() {
    var colToPlace=COLOR
    var blueAmt = isAnyColor(COLOR2)
    var myView = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        myView[i] = view[i].color
        if(!isQueen && view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[i].food > 0) {
            myView[i] = COLOR;
        }
        if(!isQueen && view[4].ant.food == 0 && view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.food > 0) {
            if(!matchesColor(view[4].color)) return {cell:4,color:COLOR}
            return {cell:4};
            //myView[i] = COLOR;
        }
        if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend) {
            myView[i] = COLOR;
        }
    }
    if(isQueen) {
        for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(i != 4 && !matchesColor(view[i].color) && view[i].ant != null) {
                myView[i] = COLOR
            }
        }
    }
    //console.log("view:")
    //console.log(myView)
    //console.log("1")
    var match = bestMatch(myView)
    if(match.state.move != 9) {
        var ctY = 0
        var lastY = -1
        var ctW = 0
        var lastW = -1
        for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(view[i].color == COLOR3) {
                myView[i] = 8
                ctY++
                lastY = i
            }
            else if(!matchesColor(view[i].color)) {
                ctW++
                lastW = i
            }
        }
        if(ctY > 0 && isQueen && view[4].ant.food > 0 && ctW >= 1) {
            if(view[4].color != COLOR3 && matchesColor(view[4].color))
                return {cell:4,color:COLOR3}
            var tt = deRotate(lastW,-1)
            if(view[tt].color != COLOR2)
                return {cell:tt,color:COLOR2}
            lastW = findOpenSpace(lastW,1)
            return {cell:lastW}
        }
        else if(ctY >= 2 && ctW >= 3)
            match = bestMatch(myView)
        else if(ctY > 0 && view[lastY].ant == null && ctW >= 3) {
            return {cell:lastY,color:1}
        }
    }
    //console.log("2")
    if(!isQueen) {
        for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.type == 5 && view[i].ant.food > 0 && view[i].ant.food <= 2) {
                if(view[4].ant.type == 4)
                    return {cell:4,color:COLOR2}
                return {cell:4}
            }
        }
    }
    //console.log("3")
    if(blueAmt > 0 && view[4].color != COLOR3 && match.state.move != 9) {
        //console.log("Some blue")
        var mb = match.state.back
        mb = deRotateSide(mb,match.rot)
        if(!isQueen || view[4].ant.food <= 2) {
            var a = deRotate(mb,1)
            var b = deRotate(mb,-1)//TODO should be -1
            //console.log("mb: " + mb + "," + a + "," + b)
            if(mb != 9 && (view[mb].color == COLOR2 || view[4].color == COLOR2 || view[a].color == COLOR2 || view[b].color == COLOR2)) {
                //blue behind
                //console.log("Blue behind")
                colToPlace = COLOR2
            }
            else {
                //console.log("No blue behind")
                //console.log(match)
                var myView2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                //construct a view without blue in it
                for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
                    myView2[i] = view[i].color == COLOR2?1:view[i].color
                }
                var match2 = bestMatch(myView2)
                if(match2.state.move == 9 || match2.state == matchStates[0]) {
                    //zero or one black
                    //console.log("<= 1 Black")
                    //console.log(myView2)
                    //console.log(match2.state)
                    colToPlace = COLOR2
                }
                else if(view[4].ant.type != 4) {
                    var mf = match2.state.move
                    mf = deRotateSide(mf,match2.rot)
                    //console.log("mf: " + mf)
                    if(mf != 9 && view[mf].color == COLOR2 && view[mf].ant == null) {
                        //about to move onto blue
                        //console.log("Moving onto blue")
                        //console.log(view)
                        //console.log(myView2)
                        return {cell:mf,color:1}
                    }
                    var clearOrder=[1,3,5,7,0,2,6,8]
                    for(var r=0;r<clearOrder.length;r++) {
                        var s = deRotateSide(clearOrder[r],0)
                        if(view[s].color == COLOR2 && (view[s].ant == null || !view[s].ant.friend || (isQueen && view[4].ant.food == 0))) {
                            //console.log("DIE BLUE SCUM")
                            //console.log(view)
                            //console.log(myView2)
                            return {cell:s,color:1}
                        }
                        else if(isQueen && view[s].ant != null && view[s].ant.friend) {
                            //console.log("Blue Queen")
                            //console.log(view)
                            //console.log(myView2)
                            return {cell:4,color:COLOR2}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //console.log("Nothing happened")
    }
    //console.log("4")
    if(view[4].ant.type <= 2) {
      for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend) {
          var canSeeAlly = isAllyAdjacentTo(view,i)
          if(canSeeAlly == 0) {
            if(view[i].color == LOCKDOWN) {
              var a = deRotate(i, 1)
              var b = deRotate(i, -1)
              if(view[a].color != LOCKDOWN) return {cell:a,color:LOCKDOWN}
              if(view[b].color != LOCKDOWN) return {cell:b,color:LOCKDOWN}
              if(orthogonals.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
                a = deRotate(i, 2)
                b = deRotate(i, -2)
                if(view[a].color != LOCKDOWN) return {cell:a,color:LOCKDOWN}
                if(view[b].color != LOCKDOWN) return {cell:b,color:LOCKDOWN}
              }
            }
            else {
              return {cell:i,color:LOCKDOWN}
            }
            if(view[4].color == LOCKDOWN || view[4].color == COLOR) {
              var ii = deRotate(i,4)
              ii = findOpenSpace(ii,1)
              return {cell:ii}
            }
            return {cell:4,color:COLOR}
          }
          else if(canSeeAlly == 2) {
            var m = deRotate(i, 2)
            var j = deRotate(i, -2)
            if(view[m].ant != null && view[m].ant.friend && view[m].ant.type < 5) return {cell:m,color:LOCKDOWN}
            if(view[j].ant != null && view[j].ant.friend && view[j].ant.type < 5) return {cell:j,color:LOCKDOWN}
          }
          else if(view[4].color == LOCKDOWN || view[4].color == 2) {

          }
          else {
            return {cell:4,color:2}
          }
        }
      }
      for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        if(view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend && (view[i].ant.type > view[4].ant.type && view[4].ant.food == 0)) {
          if(match.state.move == 9)
            return {cell:4}
          if(view[i].ant.type == 5)
            return {cell:4}
          var m = findOpenSpace(i,1)
          if(view[m].ant == null)
            return {cell:m}
          return {cell:4,color:2}
        }
      }
    }
    else if(view[4].ant.type <= 4) {
      for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend) {
          var canSeeAlly = isAllyAdjacentTo(view,i)
          if(canSeeAlly == 0) {
            if(view[i].color == LOCKDOWN) {
              var a = deRotate(i, 1)
              var b = deRotate(i, -1)
              if(view[a].color != LOCKDOWN) return {cell:a,color:LOCKDOWN}
              if(view[b].color != LOCKDOWN) return {cell:b,color:LOCKDOWN}
              if(orthogonals.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
                a = deRotate(i, 2)
                b = deRotate(i, -2)
                if(view[a].color != LOCKDOWN) return {cell:a,color:LOCKDOWN}
                if(view[b].color != LOCKDOWN) return {cell:b,color:LOCKDOWN}
              }
            }
            else {
              return {cell:i,color:LOCKDOWN}
            }
            if(view[4].color == LOCKDOWN || view[4].color == COLOR) {
              var ii = deRotate(i,4)
              ii = findOpenSpace(ii,1)
              return {cell:ii}
            }
            return {cell:4,color:COLOR}
          }
          else if(canSeeAlly == 2) {
                var m = deRotate(i, 2)
                j = deRotate(i, -2)
                if(view[m].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend && view[m].ant.type < 5) return {cell:m,color:LOCKDOWN}
                if(view[j].ant != null && view[j].ant.friend && view[j].ant.type < 5) return {cell:j,color:LOCKDOWN}
          }
          else if(view[4].color == LOCKDOWN || view[4].color == 2) {

          }
          else {
            return {cell:4,color:2}
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else if(view[4].ant.food > 4) {
        for(var i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(view[i].ant != null && !view[i].ant.friend) {
                var canSeeAlly = isAllyAdjacentTo(view,i)
                if(canSeeAlly == 0) {
                    var m = findOpenSpace(i,1)
                    if(view[m].ant == null)
                        return {cell:m,type:1}
                    return {cell:4,color:3}
                }
            }
        }
        var high = getHighestWorker()
        if(high >= 3 && view[4].ant.food % 2 == 1 && view[4].ant.food < 40) {
            var typeToSpawn = 1
            if(view[4].ant.food < 10 && high == 4 && view[4].ant.food % 4 == 1) {
                typeToSpawn = 3
            }
            var m = findOpenSpace(0,1)
            var canSeeAlly = isAllyAdjacentTo(view,m)
            if(canSeeAlly == 0 && view[m].ant == null)
                return {cell:m,type:typeToSpawn}
        }
    }
    //console.log("5")
    var m = match.state.move
    if(isQueen && view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[4].ant.food <= 2 && isAnyColor(COLOR2) == 0 && isAnyColor(COLOR3) == 0 && m < 9) {
        var high = getHighestWorker()+1
        var num = howManyAnts();
        //high += Math.max(num-2,0)
        if(high < 5) {
            m = deRotate(m,match.rot+4) //get space behind
            m = findOpenSpace(m,1) //make sure its open
            if(view[m].ant == null && view[m].food == 0)
                return {cell:m,type:high}
            return {cell:4}
        }
        else {
            //return {cell:9}
            colToPlace = COLOR2
        }
    }
    if(!isQueen && view[4].ant.food > 0 /*&& view[4].ant.type >= 3*/) {
        //console.log("type 3")
        m = match.state.back
        //console.log(m)
        colToPlace = COLOR
    }
    if(view[4].ant.type == 3) {
        colToPlace = COLOR
    }
    //console.log("6")
    if(!matchesColor(view[4].color) && !(!isQueen && view[4].ant.food)) {
        //console.log("6a")
        /*for(var j=0; j < 9; j++) {
            if(j != 4 && view[j].ant != null && view[j].ant.friend && view[j].ant.food > 0 && j != match.back) {
                m = match.state.move
                if(m < 9) {
                    m = findOpenSpace(m,1)
                    if(view[m].ant == null)
                        return {cell:m}
                    return {cell:4}
                }
                return {cell:4,color:colToPlace}
            }
        }*/
        if(isQueen && view[4].color == LOCKDOWN) {
          m = deRotateSide(m,match.rot)
          m = findOpenSpace(m,1)
          return {cell:m}
        }
        return {cell:4,color:colToPlace}
    }
    if(match.fill && !matchesColor(view[4].color)) {
        return {cell:4,color:colToPlace}
    }
    if(m >= 9) {
        if(!matchesColor(view[4].color)) {
            return {cell:4,color:COLOR}
        }
        //console.log("lost! " + view[4].ant.food);
        //console.log(pathLost());
        return pathLost()
    }
    //console.log("7")
    //console.log("m0: " + m + "+" + match.rot)
    m = deRotateSide(m,match.rot)
    //console.log("m1: " + m)
    m = findOpenSpace(m,1)
    //console.log("m2: " + m)
    if(view[4].ant.food > 0 && !matchesColor(view[4].color) /*&& (view[4].ant.type >= 3)*/) {
        var anyFood = false
        for(var x=0;x<9;x++) {
            if(view[x].food > 0) anyFood = true;
        }
        if(!anyFood)
            return {cell:4,color:colToPlace}
    }
    //console.log("m3: " + m)
    m = findOpenSpace(m,1)
    //console.log("m4: " + m)
    if((!isQueen && view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[m].food > 0) && view[m].ant == null) return {cell:4}
    return {cell:m}
}
var ret = getReturn()
ret = sanityCheck(ret)
return ret
function sanityCheck(ret) {
    if(!ret || ret.cell < 0 || ret.cell > 8 || (ret.cell != 4 && (ret.color == null || ret.color == 0) && view[ret.cell].ant != null) || (view[ret.cell].food > 0 && (view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[4].ant.type < 5))) {
        return {cell:4}
    }
    if(ret.type && (view[ret.cell].ant != null || view[ret.cell].food > 0)) {
        return {cell:4}
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This is a massive, massive ant function. It does this:

[image: The black hole]

The functionality is really quite simple. The top of the code block defines a `matchStates` object that the ants use to identify which way they're facing, and in so doing, they orbit around the known explored area.  Then a few helper functions (matching colors, counting ants, etc).

`bestMatch()` takes in the view seen by the ant (mutable) and finds the best match in the `matchStates` and returns the best match.

Queeny does one thing as she moves around, placing down black:

- Make workers until she goes to make a worker that would be a queen, then switches to placing blue. Any ant placing a color that sees blue nearby places blue instead.
- The queen, if she sees blue, hoards food.

Type 1 and 2 workers act like the queen until they find food, then they abandon placing down color until they've walked around the circle and given their food to the queen.

Type 3 and 4 workers act like queens until they find food, then they work backwards around the circle (still placing color) until they hand off their food to the queen.

Any ant that finds itself lost invokes `pathLost()` which is a smarter straight line algorithm (it's litterrally the [smart straight path function from meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13338/47990) with some tweaks).

Those tweaks are:

- Type 1 ants act randomly and attempt to erase paths (mostly not needed, but Type 1 ants aren't valuable long term, and this does clean up diagonal checkerboards)
- Non-queens won't act if they can see the queen
- Any time the ant can see and still determine orientation of its path that encounters previous paths in front of it, erases that path, ensuring ants make it back out:

[image: Crossover example]

Beyond that, most of the rest is just error handling to insure that no ants perform illegal operations (moving onto other ants, moving onto food, spawning ants *on* food...) although the biggest error handling chunk of code is down at the bottom:

```
if(view[4].ant.food > 0 && !matchesColor(view[4].color) && (view[4].ant.type >= 3) || surroundingColor > 6) {
  var anyFood = false
  for(var x=0;x<9;x++) {
    if(view[x].food > 0) anyFood = true;
  }
  if(!anyFood)
    return {cell:4,color:colToPlace}
}
```

Type 3 and 4 ants that are walking backwards won't place down color around food still on the ground (food is otherwise treated like colored tiles for the purposes of path orientation).  Additionally, Type 1 or 2 ants that think they've been hemmed in (<=2 uncolored spaces in view) will place down color.  For small 'islands' they eventually make themselves lost, rather than be permanently trapped.

The maximum food obtainable by this faction is only limited by how quickly it switches colors as well as the maximum duration of a game (10k minimum). More workers isn't necessarily beneficial, but it's essential to get several early. Type 3 and 4 workers are the most efficient (taking 6 steps closer to the queen every 6 game steps) but creating them too early leads to fewer total workers.  So initial placement has a big impact, but as the area mapped by the swarm is ever-growing with few spaces unseen, it will grab *every last piece* even though no ant will risk getting lost in order to pick a piece up.

**Update 7/23**

Noticed some issues in specific edge-cases, like this one:

[image: Queen wants to move onto an enemy]

And made very minor tweaks to account for it. Basically, treat enemy ants and laden workers as colored tiles.

**Update 7/26**

Fox, I don't even know any more.

- Tweaked lost-yellow-trail-error handling to be more robust
- Tweaked friend-path-collision handling to be more robust
- Added Trail Eraser neutralizer code
- Added "blue trails" detection and handling code [BETA]
- Made queen continue to produce workers after going into hoard mode (occasionally, at least)
- Invalid move sanitation
- Miscellaneous spaghetti code
- Removed console.log
- Removed herobrine
- Added accretion disk

[image: New accretion disk]

Without the yellow trails:

[image: Minus the yellow]

**Update 7/26 PART 2**

- Completely revamped the "what do I do with blue?" code

  - Removed accretion disk
- Added salt and pepper
- Fixed issues with "which way am I facing?" detection

  - Removed circular shape
  - Added square shape

    - Looks like boring now
- Removed immunity to Trail-Eraser
- Added smarts in "I am lost" code, reduces stuck ants

**Update 7/31**

- Re-added anti-Trail-Eraser code (it got lost in the "remove blue" update)
- Sanity check function was preventing coloring cells under other ants
- More better anti-eraser fix: no longer need 3 workers to counter a single eraser

**Update 8/4**

Minor tweaks.

- LOCKDOWN color is now black
- All ants walk "backwards" to deliver food. Those mechanics will lead to fewer ants getting trapped in "bubbles" left by Trail-Eraser
- Better handling of lost ants not getting each other stuck
- Reduced "only hoard" threshold to 40

**Weaknesses**

- Erasure.
- Color tampering.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65024/discussion-on-answer-by-draco18s-formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contes).

Answer (score 12):

## Vampire Mk.8 (Re-Vamped)

*This has been turned into a community wiki so that anybody can update it to target other victims. It uses the concept of environments to keep the different targeting code separate. If you want to make a change, please run a few tournaments to make sure your new code doesn't lower the average score!*

---

*All my answers are sharing the same set of low-level helper functions. Search for "High-level logic begins here" to see the code specific to this answer.*

```js
// == Shared low-level helpers for all solutions ==
var QUEEN = 5

var WHITE = 1
var COL_MIN = WHITE
var COL_LIM = 9

var CENTRE = 4

var NOP = {cell: CENTRE}

var DIR_FORWARDS = false
var DIR_REVERSE = true
var SIDE_RIGHT = true
var SIDE_LEFT = false

function sanity_check(movement) {
    var me = view[CENTRE].ant
    if(!movement || (movement.cell|0) !== movement.cell || movement.cell < 0 || movement.cell > 8) {
        return false
    }
    if(movement.type) {
        if(movement.color) {
            return false
        }
        if((movement.type|0) !== movement.type || movement.type < 1 || movement.type > 4) {
            return false
        }
        if(view[movement.cell].ant || view[movement.cell].food) {
            return false
        }
        if(me.type !== QUEEN || me.food < 1) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    if(movement.color) {
        if((movement.color|0) !== movement.color || movement.color < COL_MIN || movement.color >= COL_LIM) {
            return false
        }
        if(view[movement.cell].color === movement.color) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].ant && movement.cell != 4) {
        return false
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].food + me.food > 1 && me.type !== QUEEN) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

function as_array(o) {
    if(Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o
    }
    return [o]
}

function best_of(movements) {
    var m
    for(var i = 0; i < movements.length; ++ i) {
        if(typeof(movements[i]) === 'function') {
            m = movements[i]()
        } else {
            m = movements[i]
        }
        if(sanity_check(m)) {
            return m
        }
    }
    return null
}

function play_safe(movement) {
    // Avoid disqualification: no-op if moves are invalid
    return best_of(as_array(movement)) || NOP
}

var RAND_SEED = (() => {
    var s = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        s += view[i].color * (i + 1)
        s += view[i].ant ? i * i : 0
        s += view[i].food ? i * i * i : 0
    }
    return s % 29
})()

var ROTATIONS = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [6, 3, 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2],
    [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 6],
]

function areAdjacent(A, B) {
    if(A == 4 || B == 4 || A == B) return true
    if(A % 2 == 0 && B % 2 == 0) return false
    if(A % 2 == 1 && B % 2 == 0) return areAdjacent(B,A)
    if(A % 2 == 1 && B % 2 == 1) return !(8-A == B || 8-B == A)
    if(A == 0 && (B == 1 || B == 3)) return true
    if(A == 2 && (B == 1 || B == 5)) return true
    if(A == 6 && (B == 3 || B == 7)) return true
    if(A == 8 && (B == 5 || B == 7)) return true
    return false
}

function try_all(fns, limit, wrapperFn, checkFn) {
    var m
    fns = as_array(fns)
    for(var i = 0; i < fns.length; ++ i) {
        if(typeof(fns[i]) !== 'function') {
            if(checkFn(m = fns[i])) {
                return m
            }
            continue
        }
        for(var j = 0; j < limit; ++ j) {
            if(checkFn(m = wrapperFn(fns[i], j))) {
                return m
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}

function identify_rotation(testFns) {
    // testFns MUST be functions, not constants
    return try_all(
        testFns,
        4,
        (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]) ? ROTATIONS[r] : null,
        (r) => r
    )
}

function near(a, b) {
    return (
        Math.abs(a % 3 - b % 3) < 2 &&
        Math.abs(Math.floor(a / 3) - Math.floor(b / 3)) < 2
    )
}

function try_all_angles(solverFns) {
    return try_all(
        solverFns,
        4,
        (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]),
        sanity_check
    )
}

function try_all_cells(solverFns, skipCentre) {
    return try_all(
        solverFns,
        9,
        (fn, i) => ((i === CENTRE && skipCentre) ? null : fn(i)),
        sanity_check
    )
}

function try_all_cells_near(p, solverFns) {
    return try_all(
        solverFns,
        9,
        (fn, i) => ((i !== p && near(p, i)) ? fn(i) : null),
        sanity_check
    )
}

function ant_type_at(i, friend) {
    return (view[i].ant && view[i].ant.friend === friend) ? view[i].ant.type : 0
}

function friend_at(i) {
    return ant_type_at(i, true)
}

function foe_at(i) {
    return ant_type_at(i, false)
}

function foe_near() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        if(i !== 4 && view[i].ant && !view[i].ant.friend) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

function ant_type_near(p, friend) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        if(i !== 4 && ant_type_at(i, friend) && near(i, p)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

function move_agent(agents) {
    var me = view[CENTRE].ant
    var buddies = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        ++ buddies[friend_at(i)]
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < agents.length; i += 2) {
        if(agents[i] === me.type) {
            return agents[i+1](me, buddies)
        }
    }
    return null
}

function grab_nearby_food() {
    return try_all_cells((i) => (view[i].food ? {cell: i} : null), true)
}

function go_anywhere() {
    return try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i}), true)
}

function colours_excluding(cols) {
    var r = []
    for(var i = COL_MIN; i < COL_LIM; ++ i) {
        if(cols.indexOf(i) === -1) {
            r.push(i)
        }
    }
    return r
}

function generate_band(start, width) {
    var r = []
    for(var i = 0; i < width; ++ i) {
        r.push(start + i)
    }
    return r
}

function colour_band(colours) {
    return {
        contains: function(c) {
            return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1
        },
        next: function(c) {
            return colours[(colours.indexOf(c) + 1) % colours.length]
        },
        prev: function(c) {
            return colours[(colours.indexOf(c) + colours.length - 1) % colours.length]
        }
    }
}

function random_colour_band(colours) {
    return {
        contains: function(c) {
            return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1
        },
        next: function() {
            return colours[RAND_SEED % colours.length]
        }
    }
}

function fast_diagonal(colourBand) {
    var m = try_all_angles([
        // Avoid nearby checked areas
        (rot) => {
            if(
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
                colourBand.contains(view[rot[5]].color) &&
                colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color)
            ) {
                return {cell: rot[0]}
            }
        },

        // Go in a straight diagonal line if possible
        (rot) => {
            if(
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
                colourBand.contains(view[rot[8]].color)
            ) {
                return {cell: rot[0]}
            }
        },

        // When in doubt, pick randomly but avoid doubling-back
        (rot) => (colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) ? null : {cell: rot[0]}),

        // Double-back when absolutely necessary
        (rot) => ({cell: rot[0]})
    ])

    // Lay a colour track so that we can avoid doubling-back
    // (and mess up our foes as much as possible)
    if(!colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)) {
        var prevCol = m ? view[8-m.cell].color : WHITE

        var colours = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
            ++ colours[view[i].color]
        }

        return {cell: CENTRE, color: colourBand.next(prevCol)}
    }

    return m
}

function checkAllNearEnvirons(colours, buddies) {
        var nearMoves = [victims.length]
        for(var e = 0; e < victims.length; e++) {
                var env = victims[e]
                nearMoves[e] = null
                if(env.near_nest(colours)) {
                        nearMoves[e] = env.near_nest_move(colours, buddies)
                }
        }
        return best_of(nearMoves)
}

function follow_edge(obstacleFn, side) {
    // Since we don't know which direction we came from, this can cause us to get
    // stuck on islands, but the random orientation helps to ensure we don't get
    // stuck forever.

    var order = ((side === SIDE_LEFT)
        ? [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0]
        : [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 0]
    )
    return try_all(
        [obstacleFn],
        order.length - 1,
        (fn, i) => (fn(order[i+1]) && !fn(order[i])) ? {cell: order[i]} : null,
        sanity_check
    )
}

function start_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
    var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT)
    return try_all_angles([
        (rot) => ((
            !protectedCols.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
            !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
            !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color) &&
            !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color)
        )
            ? {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3], color: colourBand.next(WHITE)}
            : null)
    ])
}

function lay_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
    var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT)
    return try_all_angles([
        (rot) => {
            var ahead = rot[right ? 2 : 0]
            var behind = rot[right ? 8 : 6]
            if(
                colourBand.contains(view[behind].color) &&
                !protectedCols.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
                !colourBand.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
            ) {
                return {cell: ahead, color: colourBand.next(view[behind].color)}
            }
        }
    ])
}

function follow_dotted_path(colourBand, side, direction) {
    var forwards = (direction === DIR_REVERSE) ? 7 : 1
    var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT)

    return try_all_angles([
        // Cell on our side? advance
        (rot) => {
            if(
                colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
                // Prevent sticking / trickery
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[2]].color)
            ) {
                return {cell: rot[forwards]}
            }
        },

        // Cell ahead and behind? advance
        (rot) => {
            var passedCol = view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color
            var nextCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color
            if(
                colourBand.contains(passedCol) &&
                nextCol === colourBand.next(passedCol) &&

                // Prevent sticking / trickery
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 0 : 2]].color)
            ) {
                return {cell: rot[forwards]}
            }
        }
    ])
}

function escape_dotted_path(colourBand, side, newColourBand) {
    var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT)
    if(!newColourBand) {
        newColourBand = colourBand
    }

    return try_all_angles([
        // Escape from beside the line
        (rot) => {
            var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color
            if(
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color) ||
                !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
                colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
                colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
            ) {
                // not oriented, or in a corner
                return null
            }
            return best_of([
                {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2], color: newColourBand.next(approachingCol)},
                {cell: rot[right ? 3 : 5]},
                {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2]},
                {cell: rot[right ? 6 : 8]},
                {cell: rot[right ? 2 : 0]},
                {cell: rot[right ? 8 : 6]},
                {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]}
            ])
        },

        // Escape from inside the line
        (rot) => {
            if(
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color) ||
                colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
            ) {
                return null
            }
            return best_of([
                {cell: rot[3]},
                {cell: rot[5]},
                {cell: rot[0]},
                {cell: rot[2]},
                {cell: rot[6]},
                {cell: rot[8]}
            ])
        }
    ])
}

function latch_to_dotted_path(colourBand, side) {
    var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT)

    return try_all_angles([
        (rot) => {
            var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color
            if(
                colourBand.contains(approachingCol) &&
                view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color === colourBand.next(approachingCol) &&
                !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color)
            ) {
                // We're on the wrong side; go inside the line
                return {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]}
            }
        },

        // Inside the line? pick a side
        (rot) => {
            var passedCol = view[rot[7]].color
            var approachingCol = view[rot[1]].color
            if(
                !colourBand.contains(passedCol) ||
                !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
                colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
            ) {
                return null
            }
            if((approachingCol === colourBand.next(passedCol)) === right) {
                return best_of([{cell: rot[3]}, {cell: rot[6]}, {cell: rot[0]}])
            } else {
                return best_of([{cell: rot[5]}, {cell: rot[2]}, {cell: rot[8]}])
            }
        }
    ])
}


// == High-level logic begins here ==


var TARGET_COLOURS_ZIG = colour_band([4, 5, 7, 8])
var TARGET_COLOURS_FIREFLY = colour_band([2, 5, 8])
var GROUND_COLOURS_BH = colour_band([2, 7, 8])
var SAFE_COLOURS = random_colour_band([8])

var THIEF = 1
var BOUNCER = 2
var LANCE = 4
var LANCE_TIP = 3

var INITIAL_GATHER = 12

function colour_band_prev(band, base) {
    if(!band.contains(base)) {
        return band.next(WHITE)
    }
    var cur = band.next(base)
    var c
    while((c = band.next(cur)) !== base) {
        cur = c
    }
    return cur
}

function white_near(p) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        if(near(i, p) && view[i].color === WHITE) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

function white_near(p, min) {
    var c = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        if(near(i, p) && view[i].color === WHITE) {
            if(++c >= min) return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

var TARGET_ARRANGEMENT_RAIL = [
    [8,4,5,8,5,2,4,2,6],
    [8,5,2,4,2,6,6,4,5],
    [4,2,6,6,4,5,8,4,5],
    [6,4,5,8,4,5,8,5,2]
]
var TARGET_NEAR_RAIL = [
    [2,4,0,5,8,0,4,8,0,1], //Not Valid for Worker #1
    [2,6,0,4,5,0,4,5,0,0],
    [4,6,0,2,4,0,5,8,0,0],
    [4,8,0,4,6,0,2,4,0,0],
    [4,5,0,5,2,0,2,6,0,1], //NV 1
    [4,5,0,4,5,0,5,2,0,5], //NV Q
    [5,2,0,2,6,0,4,5,0,0],
    [5,8,0,4,8,0,4,6,0,5]  //NV Q
]
var TARGET_COLOURS_RAIL = colour_band([4,5,2,4])
var rail_miners = {
    name:function() { return "rail_miners"; },
    near_nest: function(colours) {
        var bestScore = 0
        var enemyQueen = false
        // check every rotation for each 3x3 rail possibility
        TARGET_NEAR_RAIL.forEach(function (arrangement) {
            ROTATIONS.forEach(function (rot){
                var sevenVal = 1
                var score = 0
                for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    score += arrangement[i] == view[rot[i]].color?1:0
                    score += (arrangement[i] == 0 && view[rot[i]].color == 7)?sevenVal:0
                    score += (arrangement[i] == 0 && !(view[rot[i]].color == 7 || view[rot[i]].color == 1))?-1:0
                    if(arrangement[i] == 0 && view[rot[i]].color == view[rot[i-2]].color) score -= 2
                    if(view[rot[i]].color) sevenVal = 0
                    enemyQueen |= view[i].ant && view[i].ant.type == QUEEN && !view[i].ant.friend
                    if(view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == THIEF && view[i].color == WHITE) score++
                }
                if(score > bestScore && arrangement[9] != view[4].ant.type) {
                    bestScore = score
                }
            })
        })
        if(bestScore >= (5 - (enemyQueen && view[4].ant.type == 1?1:0))) {
            if(highway.likely_nest(colours)) return false
            return true
        }
        return false
    },
    worth_leeching: function(myFood, buddies) {
        var numFours = 0
        var foodNeed = 11
        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(foe_at(i) == 4) numFours++
        }
        if(!buddies[THIEF]) return false
        if(view[4].ant.type != 5 && buddies[QUEEN] && myFood < 500 && myFood+buddies[THIEF] > (foodNeed-numFours*3)) return true
        return myFood < 500 && myFood >= (foodNeed-numFours*3)
    },
    near_nest_move: function(colours, buddies) {
        var victim_pos = -1
        var avoid_pos = -1
        var friend_pos = -1
        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(foe_at(i) == QUEEN) victim_pos = i
            if(foe_at(i) > 0 && foe_at(i) < 4) avoid_pos = i
            if(friend_at(i) == THIEF) friend_pos = i
        }
        if(victim_pos >= 0) return rail_miners.follow_victim(view[4].ant, buddies, colours, victim_pos)
        if(view[4].ant.type == THIEF && buddies[QUEEN]) return NOP
        if(view[4].ant.type == QUEEN && rail_miners.worth_leeching(view[4].ant.food, buddies)) {
            if(avoid_pos >= 0 && view[4].color != WHITE) {
                return best_of([
                    try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                        (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === THIEF ? {cell: rot[0]} : null),
                        (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === THIEF ? {cell: rot[3]} : null)
                    ]),
                    try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                        (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === THIEF ? {cell: rot[2]} : null),
                        (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === THIEF ? {cell: rot[1]} : null)
                    ]),
                    NOP
                ])
            }
            var allowed = [[8,4,8],[4,6,8],[6,8,4],[5,5,6],[6,5,2],[2,6,5]]
            var curr = [view[4].color,view[friend_pos].color,view[8-friend_pos].color]
            var found = false
            allowed.forEach(function (al) {
                if(al[0] == curr[0] && al[1] == curr[1] && al[2] == curr[2]) {
                    found = true
                }
            })
            if(!found) {
                return best_of([
                    try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                        (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === THIEF && [2,4,5].indexOf(view[rot[2]].color) >= 0 ? {cell: rot[2]} : null),
                        (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === THIEF && [2,4,5].indexOf(view[rot[0]].color) >= 0 ? {cell: rot[0]} : null)
                    ]),
                    NOP
                ])
            }
            return NOP
        }
        return null
    },
    likely_nest: function(colours) {
        var bestScore = 0
        // check every rotation for each 3x3 rail possibility
        var q = 0
        TARGET_ARRANGEMENT_RAIL.forEach(function (arrangement) {
            var j = 0
            ROTATIONS.forEach(function (rot){
                var score = 0
                for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    score += arrangement[i] == view[rot[i]].color?1:0
                    if(view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == THIEF && view[i].color == WHITE) score++
                }
                if(score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = score
                }
                j++
            })
            q++
        })
        if(view[4].ant.type == THIEF && rail_miners.near_nest(colours)) return true
        if(bestScore >= 7) {
            if(highway.likely_nest(colours)) return false
            return true
        }
        return false
    },

    likely_victim: function(victim_pos) {
        return true
    },

    follow_victim: function(me, buddies, colours, victim_pos) {
        if(me.type == QUEEN) {
            if(victim_pos % 2 == 0) {
                return best_of([
                    try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                        (rot) => (foe_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN && friend_at(rot[5]) == THIEF ? {cell: rot[2]} : null),
                        (rot) => (foe_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN /*&& friend_at(rot[7]) == THIEF*/ ? {cell: rot[6]} : null)
                    ]),
                    NOP
                ])
            }
            else {
                return best_of([
                    try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                        (rot) => (foe_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN && friend_at(rot[2]) == THIEF ? {cell: rot[5], type: THIEF} : null),
                        (rot) => (foe_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[3], type: THIEF} : null),
                        (rot) => (foe_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[5], type: THIEF} : null),
                        (rot) => (buddies[THIEF] < 4 && foe_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[2], type: THIEF} : null),
                        (rot) => (buddies[THIEF] < 4 && foe_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[0], type: THIEF} : null)
                    ]),
                    NOP
                ])
            }
        }
        return NOP
    },
    find_victim: function(me, buddies, colours) {
        var forwardCell = -1
        var current = view[CENTRE].color
        var target = TARGET_COLOURS_RAIL.next(current)
        var antitarget = TARGET_COLOURS_RAIL.prev(current)
        var queenPos = -1
        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 1 && view[i].color == target && view[8-i].color == antitarget && current != WHITE){
                forwardCell = i
            }
            if(friend_at(i) == QUEEN) queenPos = i
        }
        if(forwardCell < 0 && current == 4) {
            target = 4
            antitarget = 2
            for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if(i % 2 == 1 && view[i].color == target && view[8-i].color == antitarget){
                    forwardCell = i
                }
            }
        }
        if(me.type == QUEEN) {
            var numEn = 0
            for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if(i % 2 == 1 && friend_at(i) == THIEF && friend_at(8-i) == THIEF){
                    if(foe_at(deRotate(i,1)) > 0)
                        return {cell:forwardCell}
                    if(foe_at(deRotate(i,-1)) > 0)
                        return {cell:forwardCell}
                    return NOP
                }
                if(i % 2 == 0 && friend_at(i) == THIEF && friend_at(deRotate(i,2)) == THIEF){
                    return {cell:deRotate(i,3), type:THIEF}
                }
            }
            return wilderness.find_victim(me, buddies, colours)
        }
        else if(forwardCell >= 0) {
            if(friend_at(forwardCell) == QUEEN) {
                return best_of([
                    try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                        (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[0]} : null),
                        (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[3]} : null)
                    ]),
                    go_anywhere
                ])
            }
        }
        else if(queenPos>=0 && view[queenPos].color == WHITE && (foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,2)) && foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,-2)))) {
            return wilderness.find_victim(me, buddies, colours)
        }
        if(me.type == THIEF && forwardCell >= 0 && buddies[THIEF] == 1) {
            return wilderness.find_victim(me, buddies, colours)
        }
        return NOP
    }
}

var TARGET_ARRANGEMENT_WIND = [
        [5,4,0,7,6,0,6,4,0],
        [7,6,0,6,4,0,5,4,0],
        [6,4,0,5,4,0,7,6,0]
]
var TARGET_ARRANGEMENT_WINDCENTER = [
        [2,7,6,2,6,4,6,5,4],
        [2,6,4,6,5,4,2,7,6],
        [6,5,4,2,7,6,2,6,4]
]
var WIND_BAND = colour_band([5,6,7])
var windmill = {
    name:function() { return "windmill"; },
    near_nest: function(colours) { return false; },
    near_nest_move: function(colours, buddies) { return null; },
    likely_nest: function(colours) { // Main nest detection
        var bestScore = 0
        // check every rotation for each 3x3 rail possibility
        TARGET_ARRANGEMENT_WIND.forEach(function (arrangement) {
            ROTATIONS.forEach(function (rot){
                var score = 0
                for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    score += arrangement[i] == view[rot[i]].color?1:0
                }
                if(score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = score
                }
            })
        })
        if(bestScore >= 5 && view[4].ant.type != THIEF) {
            return true
        }

        var bestScore = 0
        // check every rotation for each 3x3 rail possibility
        TARGET_ARRANGEMENT_WINDCENTER.forEach(function (arrangement) {
            ROTATIONS.forEach(function (rot){
                var score = 0
                for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    score += arrangement[i] == view[rot[i]].color?1:0
                }
                if(score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = score
                }
            })
        })
        if(bestScore >= 8) {
            return true
        }
        var buddies = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
            ++ buddies[friend_at(i)]
        }
        return buddies[LANCE] || buddies[LANCE_TIP]
    },
    worth_leeching: function(myFood, buddies) {
        if(view[4].ant.type == THIEF && (buddies[LANCE] > 0 || buddies[LANCE_TIP] > 0)) return true
        return myFood > 5 || (myFood > 1 && buddies[LANCE])
    },
    likely_victim: function(victim_pos) {
        return false
    },

    follow_victim: function(me, buddies, colours, victim_pos) {
        // nest is chaotic and varies by direction of approach
        // We'll let the Find Victim logic handle this
        return NOP
    },

    find_victim: function(me, buddies, colours) {
        if(me.type == THIEF) {
            var queenPos = -1
            var lancePos = -1
            var tipPos = -1
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(friend_at(i) == QUEEN) queenPos = i
                if(friend_at(i) == LANCE) lancePos = i
                if(friend_at(i) == LANCE_TIP) tipPos = i
            }
            if(queenPos < 0 || (foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,1)) > 0 && foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,2)) > 0)) {
                if(queenPos < 0)
                    return go_anywhere
                return {cell:8-queenPos}
            }
            if(queenPos % 2 == 1 && tipPos % 2 == 0) {
                return go_anywhere
            }
            if(queenPos % 2 == 0 && lancePos % 2 == 1) {
                return go_anywhere
            }
            if(queenPos % 2 == 1 && foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,-2)) > 0) {
                return go_anywhere
            }
            return NOP
        }
        if(buddies[LANCE_TIP]) {
            var lancePos = -1
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(friend_at(i) == LANCE_TIP) {
                    lancePos = i
                }
            }
            if(buddies[LANCE]) {
                if(friend_at(8-lancePos) == LANCE) {
                    if(foe_at(deRotate(8-lancePos,1)) == 1 || foe_at(deRotate(8-lancePos,2)) == 1) {
                        var ret = NOP
                        if(lancePos % 2 == 1)
                            ret = {cell:deRotate(8-lancePos,-2)}
                        if(lancePos % 2 == 0)
                            ret = {cell:deRotate(8-lancePos,-3)}
                        if(!sanity_check(ret)) {
                            ret = best_of([
                                try_all_cells_near(lancePos, (i) => (ant_type_at(i) == 0 && view[i].color == 6 ? {cell: i} : null), true),
                                NOP
                            ])
                        }
                        return ret
                    }
                    if(foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,-2)) > 0) {
                        return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,2)}
                    }
                    return NOP
                }
                if(friend_at(deRotate(lancePos,3)) == LANCE) {
                    if((view[lancePos].color == 2 && view[4].color == 7) || foe_at(8-lancePos)) {
                        return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,1)}
                    }
                    return NOP
                }
                if(view[4].color == 6 && view[lancePos].color == 6 && friend_at(deRotate(lancePos,1)) == LANCE) {
                    if(foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,2)) > 0) {

                        return {cell:8-deRotate(lancePos,2)}
                    }
                    return NOP
                }
                if(view[lancePos].color == 2 && view[deRotate(lancePos,-3)].color == 5 && friend_at(deRotate(lancePos,-3)) == LANCE) {
                    return NOP
                }
                if(lancePos % 2 == 0) {
                    if(foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,-1)) > 0 && lancePos % 2 == 1) return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,2)}
                    if(view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].color != 5) return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,-1),color:5}
                    if(view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].color == 3 && view[4].color == 1) return {cell:4,color:3}
                    if(view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].color == 5 && view[4].color == 3) return {cell:4,color:2}
                    if(view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].color == 5 && view[4].color == 2) return {cell:4,color:1}
                    if(view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].color == 5 && view[4].color == 7 && view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].ant == null) return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,-1),type:THIEF}
                    if(view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].color == 5 && view[4].color == 7) return {cell:4,color:3}
                }
                return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,-1)}
            }
            if(view[4].color == WHITE && view[lancePos].color == WHITE) {
                return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,-2),type:BOUNCER}
            }
            if(view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].ant != null && view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].ant.type == 5) {
                return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,2)}
            }
            if(view[4].color == 6 && view[deRotate(lancePos,1)].color == 7) {
                return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,1)}
            }
            if(foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,-2)) > 0 || foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,-3)) > 0) {
                if(foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,-2)) > 0 && foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,3)) > 0 && (foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,-1)) > 0 || foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,4)) > 0)) {
                    return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,1)}
                }
                if(foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,3)) > 0) {
                    return NOP
                }
                return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,1)}
            }
            if(foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,2)) > 0 && view[deRotate(lancePos,-1)].color != 2) {
                return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,-1),color:2}
            }
            if(foe_at(deRotate(lancePos,-1)) > 0) {
                return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,1)}
            }
            if(lancePos % 2 == 1 && friend_at(deRotate(lancePos,-1)) == THIEF) {
                return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,-2)}
            }
            return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,-1)}
        }
        else if(buddies[LANCE]) {
            var lancePos = -1
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(view[i].ant && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == LANCE) {
                    lancePos = i
                }
            }
            if(view[4].color == 3 && lancePos % 2 == 1) return NOP
            var moveNext = lancePos % 2 == 1 ? {cell:deRotate(lancePos,2)} : {cell:deRotate(lancePos,1)}
            if(view[moveNext.cell].ant != null && !view[moveNext.cell].ant.friend) {
                moveNext = {cell:deRotate(lancePos,1),type:LANCE_TIP}
            }
            if(view[lancePos].ant.food > 0) {
                if(lancePos % 2 == 1)
                    return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,4),type:LANCE_TIP}
                else
                    return {cell:deRotate(lancePos,3),type:LANCE_TIP}
            }
            if(view[lancePos].color == 6 && view[moveNext.cell].color == 8 && view[deRotate(lancePos,2)].color == 5) {
                return {cell:moveNext.cell,type:LANCE_TIP}
            }

            return moveNext
        }
        else {
            var current = view[CENTRE].color
            var standOn = WIND_BAND.next(WIND_BAND.next(WIND_BAND.next(current)))
            var target = WIND_BAND.next(current)
            var antitarget = WIND_BAND.next(target)
            if(current != standOn) return wilderness.find_victim(me, buddies, colours)

            var ret = best_of([
                try_all_cells((i) => ((i % 2 == 1 && view[i].color == target && view[8-i].color == antitarget && ([2,5,6].indexOf(view[deRotate(i,-1)].color) >= 0) && (view[i].color != 5 || view[deRotate(i,1)].color == 4)) ? {cell: i, type: LANCE} : null), true),
                NOP
            ])
            if(ret.cell == 4) {
                return wilderness.find_victim(me, buddies, colours)
            }
            return ret
        }
        return NOP
    }
}

var TARGET_ARRANGEMENT_HIGHWAY = [
    [2,3,7,6,8,2,3,7,6],
    [2,3,7,7,6,4,4,2,3],
    [2,4,6,7,3,2,4,6,7],
    [3,2,4,4,6,7,7,3,2],
    [3,4,7,7,2,6,6,3,4],
    [3,4,7,2,6,3,4,7,2],
    [3,6,2,2,7,4,4,3,6],
    [4,7,2,2,5,6,3,4,7],
    [4,6,7,2,6,3,3,4,7],
    [4,6,7,7,3,2,2,4,6],
    [6,4,2,3,7,6,4,2,3],
    [7,3,2,2,4,6,6,7,3],
    [7,4,3,6,2,7,4,3,5]
]
var HIGHWAY_BAND = colour_band([2,7,4,3,6])
var HIGHWAY_BAND2 = colour_band([2,3,7,6,4])

var highway = {
    name:function() { return "highway"; },                                     // For debugging
    near_nest: function(colours) { return false; },                // For dodging enemy workers without getting lost
    near_nest_move: function(colours, buddies) { return null; }, // How to move when near_nest is true
    likely_nest: function(colours) { // Main nest detection
        var bestScore = 0
        // check every rotation for each 3x3 rail possibility
        TARGET_ARRANGEMENT_HIGHWAY.forEach(function (arrangement) {
            ROTATIONS.forEach(function (rot){
                var score = 0
                for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    score += arrangement[i] == view[rot[i]].color?1:0
                }
                if(score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = score
                }
            })
        })
        if(bestScore >= 7) {
            return true
        }
        if(this.isCenter(colours)) return true

        return false
    },         // Main nest detection
    isCenter: function(colours) {
        var bestScore = 0
        ROTATIONS.forEach(function (rot){
            var score = 0
            for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if(i >= 3 && i <= 5 && [2,7,4,3,6].indexOf(view[rot[i]].color) >= 0 && (i == 4 || view[rot[i]].color != view[rot[8-i]].color)) {
                    if(i != 4) {
                        score++
                    }
                    else {
                        if(view[rot[3]].color != view[rot[5]].color && view[rot[1]].color == view[rot[7]].color && (view[rot[4]].color != view[rot[1]].color && view[rot[4]].color != view[rot[3]].color && view[rot[4]].color != view[rot[5]].color && view[rot[4]].color != view[rot[7]].color)) {
                            score++
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(i >= 6) {
                    if(view[rot[i]].color == view[rot[i-6]].color && [2,7,4,3,6].indexOf(view[rot[i]].color) >= 0 && (i == 7 || view[rot[i]].color != view[rot[8-i]].color) && view[rot[i]].color != view[4].color) {
                        score += 2
                    }
                }
            }
            if(score > bestScore) {
                bestScore = score
            }
        })
        if(bestScore >= 7) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    },
    worth_leeching:function(myFood, buddies){ return myFood > 80 && myFood < 500; }, // Is this nest worth leeching?
    likely_victim: function(victim_pos) {
        return true
    },   // Identifying the target queen
    follow_victim: function(me, buddies, colours, victim_pos) {
        if(me.type == QUEEN && buddies[THIEF] < 3) {
            return best_of([
                try_all_cells((i) => (near(i, victim_pos) ? {cell: i, type: THIEF} : null), true),
                try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i, type: THIEF}), true)
            ])
        }
        if(me.type == THIEF && buddies[QUEEN])
            return NOP
        return go_anywhere
    },   // How to handle what happens when the enemy queen is found
    find_victim: function(me, buddies, colours) {
        if(me.type == THIEF && !buddies[QUEEN]) {
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
                if(foe_at(i)) return NOP
            }
            var target = HIGHWAY_BAND.prev(view[4].color)
            var followRail = best_of([
                try_all_cells((i) => (i % 2 == 1 && view[i].color == target) ? {cell:i} : null),
                NOP
            ])
        }
        else {
            var target = HIGHWAY_BAND.next(view[4].color)
            var followRail = best_of([
                try_all_cells((i) => (i % 2 == 1 && view[i].color == target) ? {cell:i} : null),
                NOP
            ])
        }
        return followRail
    }                // How to follow the nest
}

var wilderness = {
    name:function() { return "wilderness"; },
    near_nest: function(colours) { return false; },
    near_nest_move: function(colours, buddies) { return null; },
    likely_nest: function(colours) {
        return true
    },
    worth_leeching: function(myFood, buddies) {
        return true
    },
    likely_victim: function(victim_pos) {
        return true
    },

    follow_victim: function(me, buddies, colours, victim_pos) {
        // We stumbled across a random queen; make the most of it
        // TODO
        if(rail_miners.near_nest(colours)) {
            return rail_miners.follow_victim(me, buddies, colours, victim_pos)
        }

        // avoids blocking off the rail miner queen from her workers
        // (we'd like to leech her again)
        if(me.type === QUEEN && !buddies[THIEF] && me.food > 0) {

            // Make a buddy to help us steal
            return best_of([
                try_all_cells((i) => (near(i, victim_pos) ? {cell: i, type: THIEF} : null), true),
                try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i, type: THIEF}), true)
            ])
        }
        else if(me.type === QUEEN){
            var enemyCount = 0
            var allyPos = -1
            for(var a=0; a<9; a++) {
                if(a != 4 && view[a].ant != null) {
                    if(view[a].ant.friend) {
                        if(near(a,victim_pos)){
                            allyPos = a
                        }
                    }
                    else if(view[a].ant.type != 5) {
                        enemyCount++
                    }
                }
            }
            if(enemyCount >= buddies[THIEF] && allyPos >= 0) {
                //if next to the queen and we're outnumbered, move back to the center of the rail.
                var target = TARGET_COLOURS_RAIL.prev(view[allyPos].color)
                var best = best_of([
                    try_all_cells((i) => (near(i, victim_pos) && i % 2 == 0 ? {cell: i, type: THIEF} : null), true),
                    try_all_cells((i) => (near(i, victim_pos) ? {cell: i, type: THIEF} : null), true)
                ])
                if(best != null) return best

                best_of([
                    try_all_cells((i) => ((view[i].color == target && i != 4 && areAdjacent(i,a)) ? {cell: i} : null))
                ])
                if(best != null) return best

                return best_of([
                    {cell:deRotate(allyPos,1)},
                    {cell:deRotate(allyPos,-1)}
                ])
            }
        }

        return NOP
    },
    find_victim: function(me, buddies, colours) {
        if(me.type === QUEEN) {
            var in_void = true
            for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
                if(view[i].color !== WHITE && !SAFE_COLOURS.contains(view[i].color)) {
                    in_void = false
                    break
                }
            }
            if(!in_void) {
                // because of avoiding returning Miner on a Rail workers
                // we dodge sideways and this takes us back onto track
                var nearMove = checkAllNearEnvirons(colours, buddies)
                if(nearMove) return nearMove
            }
            return best_of([
                // Make a buddy once we have a reasonable stash of food so we can
                // search the board faster
                // (but avoid making buddies when there's a potential nest nearby
                // better to wait until we find their queen)
                (!buddies[THIEF] && me.food >= INITIAL_GATHER && in_void) &&
                    try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i, type: THIEF}), true),

                // Follow buddy in search of victims
                buddies[THIEF] && try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                    (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === THIEF ? {cell: rot[2]} : null),
                    (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === THIEF ? {cell: rot[1]} : null)
                ]),
                buddies[THIEF] && try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                    (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === THIEF ? {cell: rot[0]} : null),
                    (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === THIEF ? {cell: rot[3]} : null)
                ]),
                buddies[THIEF] && NOP, // Don't lose our buddy!

                // Random walk until we can make a buddy or find the victim
                grab_nearby_food,
                foe_near() ? go_anywhere : fast_diagonal.bind(null, SAFE_COLOURS),
                go_anywhere
            ])
        } else if(me.type === THIEF) {
            return best_of([
                // Lost the queen! Random walk because we have nothing better to do.
                // (don't leave lines; they could disrupt the pattern)
                !buddies[QUEEN] && go_anywhere,
                buddies[BOUNCER] && go_anywhere,
                buddies[THIEF] > 1 && go_anywhere, //untested
                // Follow queen in search of victims
                try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                    (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[0]} : null),
                    (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[3]} : null)
                ]),
                NOP // Don't lose our buddy!
            ])
        }
    }
}

var victims = [highway, rail_miners, windmill]

function guess_environment(colours, buddies) {
    var food = view[4].ant.food
    if(view[4].ant.type !== QUEEN) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(i != 4 && view[i].ant && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type === QUEEN) {
                food = view[i].ant.food
            }
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < victims.length; ++ i) {
        if(victims[i].likely_nest(colours) && victims[i].worth_leeching(food, buddies)) {
            return victims[i]
        }
    }

    return wilderness
}

function is_safe(i) {
    var nearThief = false
    var nearOfficer = false
    for(var j = 0; j < 9; ++ j) {
        if(friend_at(j) === THIEF) {
            nearThief = true
        }
        if(foe_at(j) && foe_at(j) !== QUEEN) {
            nearOfficer = true
        }
    }
    return nearThief && !nearOfficer
}

function move(me, buddies) {
    var colours = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        ++ colours[view[i].color]
    }
    var env = guess_environment(colours,buddies)
    var victim_pos = -1
    var queen_pos = -1
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        if(foe_at(i) === QUEEN && env.likely_victim(i) && view[i].ant.food > 0) {
            victim_pos = i
            if(view[i].ant.food > 0) {
                break
            }
        }
        if(friend_at(i) === QUEEN) {
            queen_pos = i
        }
    }

    var in_void = true
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        if(view[i].color !== WHITE || (i != 4 && me.type === BOUNCER && friend_at(i) === BOUNCER)) {
            in_void = false
            break
        }
    }
    if(me.type === BOUNCER) {
        if(env === wilderness && in_void) {
            // Our work is done; leave queen and wander at random
            if(buddies[QUEEN]) {
                return best_of([
                    try_all_cells((i) => (ant_type_near(i, true) ? null : {cell: i}), true),
                    go_anywhere
                ])
            }
            return NOP
        }
        else if(env === rail_miners) {
            // Our work is done; leave queen and wander at random
            if(buddies[QUEEN]) {
                var allAngles = try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                    (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[0]} : null),
                    (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[3]} : null),
                    NOP
                ])
                return best_of([
                    //if next to an enemy queen, move out of the way
                    try_all_cells((i) => (foe_at(i) == QUEEN ? {cell:9-i} : null), true),
                    try_all_cells((i) => (foe_at(i) == QUEEN ? {cell:7-i} : null), true),
                    allAngles
                ])
            }
            return NOP
        } else if(buddies[QUEEN]) {
            // Escort queen out of nest
            var allAngles = try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[0]} : null),
                (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[3]} : null),
                NOP
            ])

            return best_of([
                //if next to an enemy queen, move out of the way
                try_all_cells((i) => (foe_at(i) == QUEEN ? {cell:9-i} : null), true),
                try_all_cells((i) => (foe_at(i) == QUEEN ? {cell:7-i} : null), true),
                allAngles
            ])
        }
        else {
            return go_anywhere
        }
    } else if(buddies[BOUNCER]) {
        if(me.type === QUEEN) {
            // Be escorted out of nest
            return try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === BOUNCER ? {cell: rot[2]} : null),
                (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === BOUNCER ? {cell: rot[1]} : null),
                go_anywhere,
                NOP
            ])
        } else {
            // Get out of the way
            return try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[7]} : null),
                (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[8]} : null),
                (rot) => (friend_at(rot[1]) === BOUNCER ? {cell: rot[7]} : null),
                (rot) => (friend_at(rot[0]) === BOUNCER ? {cell: rot[8]} : null),
                go_anywhere
            ])
        }
    }
    if(victim_pos !== -1) {
        // abandon the queen if she's dry.
        // abandon rail miner's queen so she has at least 10 food (otherwise she produces workers 3:4 food she aquires)
        // value is higher than 10 because there's two to three rounds of theft (at 4 ants each) before the queen gets out of range
        // this can still leave the rail miner's queen lower than 10, but unlikely
        // other queens are abandoned if they have less than 5 food, due to the "max 4 ants stealing" and at 0 food, she's not a target.
        if(view[victim_pos].ant.food < 5 || (env == rail_miners && view[victim_pos].ant.food < 28)) {
            if(me.type == THIEF) {
                if(rail_miners.near_nest(colours)) {
                    // we'd rather reuse the workers
                    return NOP
                }
            }
            // Victim is out of food; bounce out of nest
            if(env == rail_miners) {
                if(me.type == QUEEN && me.food < 300 && !buddies[BOUNCER]) {
                    if(friend_at(deRotate(victim_pos,2)) == THIEF && foe_at(deRotate(victim_pos,3)) == 0) return {cell:deRotate(victim_pos,3),type:BOUNCER}
                    if(friend_at(deRotate(victim_pos,-2)) == THIEF && foe_at(deRotate(victim_pos,-3)) == 0) return {cell:deRotate(victim_pos,-3),type:BOUNCER}
                }
                // murder SlM
                return NOP
            }
            var m = try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i, type: BOUNCER}), true)
            if(m) {
                return m
            }
        }
        if(me.type === QUEEN && buddies[THIEF] && !is_safe(CENTRE)) {
            // Try to avoid getting food stolen back from us
            var m = try_all_cells((i) => (is_safe(i) ? {cell: i} : null), true)
            if(m) {
                return m
            }
        }
        return env.follow_victim(me, buddies, colours, victim_pos)
    } else {
        return env.find_victim(me, buddies, colours)
    }
}

// LANCE is only used by windmill targetting, easier to break this out as its own method
function moveLance(me, buddies) {
    var queenPos = -1
    var tipPos = -1
    var enQueenPos = -1
    if(buddies[BOUNCER]) {
        for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(friend_at(i) == BOUNCER) {
                return {cell:8-i}
            }
        }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(friend_at(i) == QUEEN) {
            queenPos = i
        }
        if(friend_at(i) == LANCE_TIP) {
            tipPos = i
        }
        if(foe_at(i) == QUEEN) enQueenPos = i
    }
    if(!buddies[QUEEN]) {
        for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0 && friend_at(i) == QUEEN) {
                if(view[deRotate(i,3)].ant != null && view[deRotate(i,3)].ant.friend && view[deRotate(i,3)].ant.type == LANCE_TIP) return NOP
                return {cell:deRotate(i,1)}
            }
        }
        if(!buddies[LANCE_TIP] && !buddies[THIEF] && view[4].color == 2) {
            for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
                if(view[i].color == 1) return {cell:i}
            }
        }
        if(enQueenPos >= 0 && enQueenPos % 2 == 0 && foe_at(deRotate(enQueenPos,1)) == 1) {
            return {cell:deRotate(enQueenPos,-3)}
        }
        if(enQueenPos >= 0 && enQueenPos % 2 == 1 && foe_at(deRotate(enQueenPos,2)) == 1) {
            return {cell:8-enQueenPos}
        }
        if(enQueenPos >= 0 && (me.food > 0 || foe_at(deRotate(enQueenPos,-1)) || foe_at(deRotate(enQueenPos,3)))) {
            if(enQueenPos % 2 == 0 && (foe_at(deRotate(enQueenPos,4)) || friend_at(deRotate(enQueenPos,4)) == THIEF)) {
                return {cell:deRotate(enQueenPos,-3)}
            }
        }
        return NOP
    }
    if(buddies[LANCE_TIP]) {
        if(deRotate(queenPos,-1) == tipPos && view[tipPos].color == 8) return {cell:8-tipPos}
        if(deRotate(queenPos,-1) == tipPos) return try_all_cells((i) => (areAdjacent(i,tipPos) && view[i].color == 5 ? {cell:i} : null))
        if(foe_at(8-tipPos) == QUEEN) return {cell:8-tipPos,color:6}
        if(foe_at(8-queenPos) > 0 || foe_at(deRotate(8-queenPos,1)) > 0) return NOP
        return try_all_cells((i) => (!areAdjacent(i,queenPos) && !areAdjacent(i,tipPos) ? {cell:i} : null))
    }
    if(view[4].color != 4 && view[4].color != 6) {
        if(foe_at(8-queenPos) == QUEEN) {
            var formation = try_all_angles.bind(null, [
                (rot) => (foe_at(rot[1]) === 1 && foe_at(rot[2]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[3]} : null),
                (rot) => (foe_at(rot[1]) === 1 && foe_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[7]} : null),
                (rot) => (foe_at(rot[1]) === 1 && view[rot[1]].ant.food > 0 && foe_at(rot[6]) === QUEEN && friend_at(rot[2]) === QUEEN ? {cell: rot[5]} : null),
            ])()
            if(formation != null) {
                return formation
            }
            return NOP
        }
        if(foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,1)) > 0 && foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,-1)) > 0) {
            return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,-3)}
        }
        return best_of([
            try_all_cells((i) => (enQueenPos ==-1 && i % 2 == 1 && (view[i].color == 4 || view[i].color == 6) && view[deRotate(i,1)].color != 2 && view[deRotate(i,-1)].color != 2 && areAdjacent(i,queenPos) ? {cell: i} : null), true),
            ((view[4].color != 6 || view[4].color != 4) && queenPos % 2 == 0 && view[deRotate(queenPos,-3)].color == 5) ? {cell:4,color:6} : null,
            NOP
        ])
    }
    else {
        var queenOn = view[8-queenPos].color
        var target = WIND_BAND.next(queenOn)
        var prior = WIND_BAND.next(target)
        var followRail = best_of([
            try_all_cells((i) => (view[deRotate(i,-3)].color == prior && view[deRotate(i,-1)].color == target && areAdjacent(i,queenPos) && (view[i].color == 4 || view[i].color == 6) ? {cell: i} : null), true),
            queenPos % 2 == 1 ? (view[queenPos].color == 4 || view[4].color == 4 ? NOP : {cell:deRotate(queenPos,-2)}) : (view[queenPos].color == 4 || view[queenPos].color == 6 ? {cell:deRotate(queenPos,-1)} : NOP)
        ])

        if(view[deRotate(queenPos,-1)].ant != null) {
            if(!view[deRotate(queenPos,-1)].ant.friend && view[deRotate(queenPos,-2)].ant != null && !view[deRotate(queenPos,-2)].ant.friend) {
                return NOP
            }
            if(queenPos % 2 == 0 && !view[deRotate(queenPos,-1)].ant.friend && view[deRotate(queenPos,-2)].ant == null && (view[queenPos].color == 3 || view[queenPos].color == WHITE)) {
                return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,-3)}
            }
            if(queenPos % 2 == 0 && friend_at(deRotate(queenPos,-1)) == THIEF && view[deRotate(queenPos,-2)].ant == null && (view[queenPos].color == 3 || view[queenPos].color == WHITE)) {
                return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,-3)}
            }
            return NOP
        }
        if(me.food > 0 && queenPos % 2 == 0) {
            return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,-1)}
        }
        if(foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,-3)) > 0 && (view[queenPos].color == 1 || view[deRotate(queenPos,1)].color == 1 || view[deRotate(queenPos,-1)].color == 1)) {
            if(view[queenPos].color == 3) {
                return followRail
            }
            if(view[queenPos].color == 7) return NOP
            return {cell:queenPos,color:3}
        }
        if((foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,-2)) > 0 || foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,-3)) > 0) && queenPos % 2 == 0 && view[deRotate(queenPos,-1)].color == 5) {
            if(view[queenPos].color == 7) return NOP
            return {cell:queenPos,color:3}
        }
        if(view[deRotate(queenPos,-4)].ant != null && !view[deRotate(queenPos,-4)].ant.friend && (view[queenPos].color == 1 || view[deRotate(queenPos,1)].color == 1 || view[deRotate(queenPos,-1)].color == 1)) {
            if(view[queenPos].color == 7) return NOP
            return {cell:queenPos,color:3}
        }
        if((followRail == null || followRail.cell == 4) && foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,-2)) == 1) {
            if(view[queenPos].color == 7) return NOP
            return {cell:queenPos,color:3}
        }
        if(followRail != null && followRail.cell != 4 && view[followRail.cell].color == 6 && view[deRotate(followRail.cell,1)].color == 6) {
            followRail = {cell:deRotate(followRail.cell,1)}
        }
        return followRail
    }
    return NOP
}

// LANCE_TIP never needs to move
// Unfortunately, reusing an existing worker type for this purpose is not easily possible.
// Used against Sliding Miners as a stationary blocker to prevent the queen slipping past.
function moveTip(me, buddies) {
    var queenPos = -1
    var in_void = true
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(friend_at(i) == QUEEN) {
            queenPos = i
        }
        if(view[i].color != WHITE) {
            in_void = false
        }
    }
    var colours = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    var enemies = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
        ++ colours[view[i].color]
        if(foe_at(i) > 0) enemies++
    }
    var onRails = rail_miners.near_nest(colours)
    if(buddies[QUEEN] && !buddies[LANCE]) {
        if(onRails) return NOP
        if(foe_at(8-queenPos) == 4) {
            return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,2)}
        }
        if(in_void) return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,4)}
        if(enemies == 2 && queenPos % 2 == 0 && view[deRotate(queenPos,1)].ant == null) {
            return {cell:queenPos,color:7}
        }
        if(enemies == 2 && queenPos % 2 == 1) {
            return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,-1),color:7}
        }
    }
    if(buddies[QUEEN] && buddies[LANCE]) {
        if(enemies == 0 && view[queenPos].color == 1) return NOP
        if(view[deRotate(queenPos,1)].color == 5 && friend_at(deRotate(queenPos,1)) == LANCE) return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,4)}
        return {cell:deRotate(queenPos,2)}
    }
    if(!buddies[QUEEN] && view[4].color == 2) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
            if(view[i].color == 8) return {cell:i}
        }
    }
    if(queenPos >=0 && foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,2)) > 0 && view[deRotate(queenPos,2)].ant.food == 0 && foe_at(deRotate(queenPos,4)) > 0 && view[deRotate(queenPos,4)].ant.food > 0) {
        return {cell:queenPos,color:7}
    }
    return NOP
}

function deRotate(m, amt) {
    var rotationsCW = [1,2,5,8,7,6,3,0]
    var rotationsCCW = [3,6,7,8,5,2,1,0]
    if(m == 4 || m < 0 || m > 8 || amt == 0) return m
    if(amt > 0)
        return rotationsCW[(rotationsCW.indexOf(m)+amt)%8]
    amt = -amt
    return rotationsCCW[(rotationsCCW.indexOf(m)+amt)%8]
}

return play_safe(move_agent([
    THIEF, move,
    QUEEN, move,
    BOUNCER, move,
    LANCE, moveLance,
    LANCE_TIP, moveTip
]))
```

Nobody had posted any answers exploiting the rule "An unladen worker adjacent to an enemy queen will steal 1 piece of food, if present.", so I decided to fix that!

This vampire seeks out specific targets to leech off of, which are continually updated (since this is a Community Wiki), and are sometimes disabled (via `worth_leeching` function) when they are no longer profitable enough.

*Note that the `worth_leeching` function mentioned, in addition to its use in disabling targets (if it returns false), allows for control over a given targeting object to maximize decision making, e.g. preventing Vampire from going after likely traps (Ziggurat creates little pockets that have no queen at the center) until Vampire has collected a sufficient quantity of food that getting stuck won't completely waste the round (i.e. only score 12 food). Parameters passed make the method very flexible without having to query the `view` object.*

Descriptions of the targets follow, in the order they appear in the code:

### Black Hole (target disabled)

When this finds Black Hole, it's pretty random whether we'll end up finding their queen, or their workers will drain our own food, or we'll bounce off and carry on searching. Turns out Black Hole is pretty hard to target.

### Ziggurat (target disabled)

Once at the centre of Ziggurat, the queen spawns thieves to extract as much food as possible as quickly as possible. It has to be fast since the colony now defends against us by spawning an army of workers (wasting their own food). Once all the food is gone, we make a "bouncer" and escort ourselves out, off in search of the next victim.

For Black Hole, this uses a worker sitting on the surface to wait for the target queen to pass by, while our queen sits deeper so that passing workers won't mug her. When the target queen eventually passes by, we follow her as much as possible.

For Miners on a rail, it uses a brute-force search to see if the queen is sitting on the center of the miner's main rail system. It then follows it back to its source (letting miner's workers step around). Once at the queen it spawns a thief as normal and drains the queen down to 9 food. Under 10 food the miner queen generates 3 workers for every 4 food she is given, making sticking around a low-return prospect.  Bounce out and return later. (Thanks go to Draco18s for providing this environment's code!)

When this finds Ziggurat, it does pretty well, and causes interesting explosions, as seen in this early prototype (before bouncing was added):

[image: exploded ziggurat]

### FireFly (target disabled)

The block targeting Firefly uses the Ziggurat code as a baseline, but overrides the colors used. This makes it easy for any author to create a new Vampire target with ease while keeping byte-count low. Firefly code was disabled when Firefly didn't collect food, but was re-enabled in Mk. 5.

Not related to FIrefly, but Mk.4 also added in some additional object methods to handle side-stepping the target's workers (used by the anti-rail-miners code) which allows the Vampire queen to safely encounter a working rail miner repairer, instead of causing the two ants to get permanently stuck.

### Miners on a Rail (MoaR) / Sliding Minders (SlM)

When this finds Miners on a Rail, it tracks the rail in the outbound direction (the same direction unladen rail workers move) to avoid having its food stolen. When it finds the end of the rail, it acts like the Miners on a Rail's own worker 4 (the repairer). We know where the rail is, may as well follow that direction and loop back to start!

But the most common result is that we never find anything. This still does OK in that case; about middle of the scoreboard.

### Windmill

The development of the Don Quixote (Windmill targetting) code (in Mk. 5) was [fraught with challenges](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42449225#42449225) and went through many iterations, including one that would have been a new Ant type) before an acceptable strategy was developed.  When the queen notices that she's standing on the middle rail of Windmill's main arms it spawns a new type of worker (code-named `LANCE`) in order to run down the *side* of the rail to avoid enemy workers (as if an enemy worker spots the vampire queen, they'll attempt to deadlock her), until eventually encountering the Windmill queen.

Two approaches to the queen are relatively clear and we can attempt to rely on the Lance arriving first (the Vampire queen will observe her worker holding food) and use that moment to spawn in a `THIEF` rather than stepping in and letting the Windmill queen spawn a worker adjacent to the Vampire Queen (resulting in a net-zero flow of food). The third approach ends up running into the gardeners, so the queen spawns a `LANCE_TIP` worker in order to do some political maneuvering to end up with a net-positive flow of food.

These attacks come at the cost of being unable to determine how much food the Windmill queen has and thus unable to predict when to spawn a `BOUNCER` and leave for better victims. However, this works in Vampire's favor as the Windmill is such a fat, juicy cow that it's more valuable to just stick around until the end: Windmill can easily gather several hundred food in only a few thousand moves, much much more than Vampire can acquire by trying to find a new target to leech.

The Garlicked (Mk6) update changes how the queen approaches slightly. The rail approach is identical, but upon reaching the queen, there are some slight changes, which result in only a single worker being adjacent to the Windmill queen, keeping the Vampire queen as far away as possible (to avoid Windmill workers, and most importantly, the garlic). The change was due to the fact that when two workers were adjacent to the Windmill queen, she would pack her bags and relocate.

Renewable Energy (Mk 7) revises the Windmill targetting logic, largely undoing the changes of Mk 6, as there were changes to Windmill that was causing the code to fail to leech 100% of the time. Revised success rate is about 70%, remaining 30% is due to dumb luck that is unavoidable. Approach vector slighly altered.

### Highway

Highway is easy to find. It is an ever-expanding greenish blob of doom. So, waiting to find and smash the dreams of Miners and Windmill *first* before going after Highway means that Vampire doesn't target too soon.

Finding the queen is simple: find the center of the highway and wait. She'll eventually come by. Worker arrangements will determine whether or not she gets stopped or we have to wait for another loop, but the delay doesn't make that big of a difference: eventually we'll catch her and steal *ALL* of her food.

If Vampire has 1000 food or more, she ignores Highway, because at that point, it doesn't matter any more.

Comment: Sorry about the error in the controller requiring movement in order to keep stealing. That wasn't my intention, and now that the controller is fixed any updates you make to this strategy won't need to keep the worker moving, if that helps fine tune things. Nice to finally see this opportunity being taken - I was wondering how long it would take before players started using stealing as a strategy...

Comment: @trichoplax no problem; when I get time to have a second look at it I'll see what I can improve now that the worker doesn't need to jiggle around. As for how long until this was made, I think the main thing was waiting for an opponent to be easy to find!

Comment: this is really mean.

Comment: trichoplax explicitly allowed such weakness-exploit strategies

Comment: I upvoted "this is really mean" because I agree, and it's one of the mean things I specifically wanted to see in this contest...

Comment: Yup. Super-mean. If it's any consolation: it hardly ever works in real games (with other players than this & its victim), because line-eraser keeps mucking up the target pattern.

Comment: [Yes I'm seeing over 300 in a game against just Ziggurat, but scoring lower than Ziggurat on average in a game against all players](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39048338#39048338)

Comment: I can't ping you in the chat room since you haven't been there yet, but I posted an apology there because [an error in my random selection disadvantaged the 4 most recent entrants](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39134429#39134429) (yours included). I'm sorry about this - it is now fixed and a new tournament being run without this bias against Vampire.

Comment: Would you be interested in a vampiric method for Miners on a Rail?

Comment: @Draco18s it certainly seems targetable (and zigurat's become rather immune to the vampire lately). I might have a go at some point, but I've mostly stopped working on these answers now. In the meantime if you want to make your own vampire or adapt this one, go ahead!

Comment: What I meant was: I wrote the code for it already, as one of Vampire's environment objects. It's a bit rough, but I'm more than happy to share. I figured it would be better as an addition, rather than spun off as a separate bot (on account of it being 99% identical). I just thought you might want to give it a look-over before I just edited it into your answer. https://pastebin.com/tQpXcnSV There may also be some optimizations that could be utilized (I tweaked the code to not abandon the rail-queen at 0 food, but it might be best to instead abandon her at 9 food; less lost to new worker ants).

Comment: @Draco18s ah I see. Looks good to me! You might want to double-check some of the comments (e.g. "Random walk to avoid getting stuck" doesn't seem to apply now), but yeah, go for it!

Comment: Heh, yeah, I hadn't done that yet :P  Would there be a better way of matching against the rail miner's primary rail? I kind of brute-forced it, not quite sure how your `try_for_cells()` method worked. If you're good with it, otherwise though, I'll fix up the comments to make sense and add it in.

Comment: I'll probably be updating this again soon, I found some areas where the rail-targeting code is either insufficient or where it causes Vampire to get stuck. I've got a working copy, but it screws with code all over the place. Want to see if I can isolate the changes so it fits with the abstraction of the original more cleanly again. As-is though, it *wrecks* Miners on a Rail in tournaments.

Comment: @Draco18s sure. Don't worry about changes being too big; I'm all for making this one into a community-wiki framework for people to hang vampires from. If your changes make it easier to do that, then post away!

Comment: Well, for example, if Vampire bumps into Rail's "main rail creator" ant, that ant ends up with food and they deadlock. I had to write a new method called "near_nest" and reference it from wilderness to determine if Vampire had stepped 1 cell off from the center of the rail and avoid starting an undirected search again. Wasn't extensible (lit. `if(rail_miners.near_nest(colors)) { /*get back on rail*/ }`.  Want to clean it up first.

Comment: Vampire cleaned up. Only thing now is, I don't think its worth targetting Ziggurat any more; Ziggurat gets corrupted so easily these days that it is impossible to find the center, including workers that have somehow become so lost they start construct a new pyramid wholly disconnected from the original. The *code* is worth keeping (as it can be extended to target like-bots such as Firefly, although Firefly doesn't collect food yet). Thoughts?

Comment: @Draco18s good point. The options as I see them: 1: Remove targeting of any competitor which isn't reliable enough, 2: Multiple vampires, each targeting one or two competitors, 3: Food-based decisions on whether to target competitors (only target ziggurat if our food > (e.g.) 20 would make it a "bonus" catch, after we've already hit one opponent, or a fallback if we've been scouring the board for a long time). I'm leaning towards #3, because it avoids reducing the pool of potential victims, but offers some sort of prioritisation. And maybe there are smarter ways to do that.

Comment: #3 is kind of what I was thinking too. Partially because hitting Miners on a Rail twice in quick succession doesn't make much sense (usually after it's leeched 50+ food). Easy enough to add though.

Comment: Aaand updated! Whew. Firefly's object includes comments about what each function is for, based on what I know. Feel free to tweak them if you feel they aren't accurate, Dave.

Comment: @Draco18s cool; looks good. A quick comment is that the new "areAdjacent" function is the same as the existing "near" function. And the descriptions you added to the functions look accurate from what I remember. Also I see you found my bug in the sanity checking function! Sorry about that!

Comment: I don't think I ever *saw* the near function, heh. As for the sanity check, was one of those things that didn't matter until it did. :P I know *my own* sanity check (Glider) had a similar flaw when I updated it last.

Comment: @Draco18s nice update. I'm not sure the black hole targeting is worth keeping any more (I noticed you made it less likely to apply), since it seems to often get stuck lying in wait under random black branches when it could be out looking for a better target. When this hits windmill in the right circumstances, it does phenomenally well!

Comment: @Dave I ran several tests to see if it was worth removing entirely and it seemed to perform less-well on average when it was disabled entirely. 30-45 food seemed to be a sweet spot (average leaderboard points of 8.5 to 9 compared with 7.5 with Black Hole completely disabled). Feel free to run some tests yourself, though. And  yes, if it hits Windmill it leeches all of the food Windmill collects...all 600 ;)

Comment: I think that should finally do it for Vampire. Both logic bugs were my fault, from back when I added MoaR code, no idea how they didn't adversely affect the bot until trying to target Windmill. Funny how everything seems fine until the bot suddenly spawns 70 workers after leeching MoaR when it's never done that before and you dig into why and find a badly written `if` statement (why yes, "if I have 0 food, that is not a valid queen to steal from"...what? How did this not completely screw over Vampire before!?)

Comment: @Draco18s I saw that spawn-a-hundred-workers bug and had just started looking into why it happened. Glad you found it! Also I've made this community wiki now, so feel free to make any more changes you want!

Comment: Yeah, it was the Thieves sitting next to the two queens, failing to find a victim (because the THIEF had no food!) and it would wander off. It'd still done its job stealing food from MoaR, but it definitely impacted Vampire's own performance. The fixes probably won't make it rank too much higher, but it will be better.

Comment: @Dave Did some further analysis, BH isn't worth leeching afterall. Your assessment was ultimately correct. The deadlocks against "things that aren't black hole" prevents vampire from finding the ultimately juicy target of Windmill, which is much easier to identify unambiguously.

Comment: "If Vampire has 1000 food or more" I never thought I'd see a dead-serious sentence like this.

Comment: [For Dave's benefit] Error was due to a duplication of a variable that collapsed back to a single (e.g. obj -> obj1, obj2 -> obj1) with one instance of usage that didn't get updated. Known and will be fixed when I get to updating Sliding Miners targeting... ***again.***

Comment: Any ideas about hyperwave?

Answer (score 11):

## Langton's ant

*All of my answers will contain similar low-level logic in the form of the Formic Functions Framework. "HIGH-LEVEL LOGIC STARTS HERE" marks the end of the Framework's code.*

```js
// FORMIC FUNCTIONS FRAMEWORK //
// Version 1.0                //

var WHITE = 1;
var QUEEN = 5;
var HERE = 4;
var MY_VO = view[HERE];
var ME = MY_VO.ant;
var NOP = move(HERE);

var ORTHOGONALS = [1, 3, 5, 7];
var DIAGONALS = [0, 2, 6, 8];
var DIRECTIONS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var ALL_CELLS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var VIEW_ORIENTATIONS = [
  [0,1,2,
   3,4,5,
   6,7,8],

  [6,3,0,
   7,4,1,
   8,5,2],

  [8,7,6,
   5,4,3,
   2,1,0],

  [2,5,8,
   1,4,7,
   0,3,6]
];

function rotateCW(cell, amount) {
  if (cell === HERE) return cell;
  var order = [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3];
  return order[(order.indexOf(cell) + amount + 8) % 8];
}

function isDiagonal(cell) {
  return DIAGONALS.includes(cell);
}
function isOrthogonal(cell) {
  return ORTHOGONALS.includes(cell);
}

function move(cell) {
  return {cell: cell};
}
function moveMany(cells) {
  var p = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) p.push(move(cells[i]));
  return p;
}

function color(cell, col) {
  return {cell: cell, color: col};
}
function colorMany(cells, col) {
  var p = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) p.push(color(cells[i], col));
  return p;
}

function spawn(cell, type) {
  return {cell: cell, type: type};
}
function spawnMany(cells, type) {
  var p = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) p.push(spawn(cells[i], type));
  return p;
}

function isSane(action, ant) {
  // TODO: Minimize this
  if (ant === undefined || !ant.isObject) ant = ME;
  if (action === undefined || action.cell < 0 || action.cell >= 9) return false;
  if (action.color !== undefined) {
    if (action.color < 1 || action.color > 8) return false;
    return true;
  }
  else if (action.type !== undefined) {
    if (action.type < 1 || action.type > 4) return false;
    if (ant.type !== QUEEN || ant.food === 0) return false;
    if (isOccupied(action.cell, ant) || view[action.cell].food !== 0) return false;
    return true;
  }
  else {
    if (isOccupied(action.cell, ant) && action.cell !== HERE) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
function isOccupied(cell, ant) {
  if (ant === undefined || !ant.isObject) ant = ME;
  return view[cell].ant !== null || (view[cell].food > 0 && ant.type !== QUEEN && ant.food === 1);
}
function isColoringMeaningful(action) {
  return isSane(action) && action.color !== undefined && view[action.cell].color !== action.color;
}

function test(cell, test) {
  var vo = view[cell];
  return (test.color === undefined || test.color === vo.color) &&
         (test.food === undefined || test.food === vo.food) &&
         (test.ant === undefined || test.ant === vo.ant || (
           (test.ant !== null && vo.ant !== null) &&
           (test.ant.food === undefined || test.ant.food === vo.ant.food) &&
           (test.ant.type === undefined || test.ant.type === vo.ant.type) &&
           (test.ant.friend === undefined || test.ant.friend === vo.ant.friend)
         ));
}

function findOrientation(tests) {
  var best = {orientation: null, matches: []};
  for (var o = 0; o < VIEW_ORIENTATIONS.length; o++) {
    var matches = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
      if (test(VIEW_ORIENTATIONS[o][tests[i].cell], tests[i])) {
        matches.push(tests[i]);
      }
    }
    if (matches.length > best.matches.length) {
      best.orientation = o;
      best.matches = matches;
    }
  }

  return best;
}

function orientCells(orientation, cells) {
  if (orientation === null || orientation < 0 || orientation >= 4) orientation = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i] = VIEW_ORIENTATIONS[orientation][cells[i]];
  }
  return cells;
}

function findFirst(func, cells) {
  if (cells === undefined) cells = ALL_CELLS;
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (func(cells[i])) return cells[i];
  }
  return null;
}
function findAll(func, cells) {
  if (cells === undefined) cells = ALL_CELLS;
  var found = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (func(cells[i])) found.push(cells[i]);
  }
  return found;
}

// HIGH-LEVEL LOGIC STARTS HERE //
var ROAD_COL = 3;
var SIM_COLS = [ 1, 8, 5, 6, 4, 2, 7, 3]; // SIM_COLS.length must be greater or equal to SIM_ROTS.length
var SIM_ROTS = [-1,-1,+1,-1,-1,+1,-1,-1];
// Here are some additional rulesets to play around with:
// [+1,-1,+1,-1,+1,-1,+1,-1] // Classic Langton's ant, extended to use all 8 colors cyclically
// [+1,+1,-1,+1,-1,+1,+1]    // Produces a very interesting highway
// [-1,-1,+1,-1,-1,+1,-1,-1] // The default one -- chosen because it produces a highway nearly instantly, and the highway itself is pretty efficient
// [-1,+1,-1,-1,-1,+1,+1,-1]
// [-1,-1,+1,-1,-1,+1,-1,-1]
// [-1,+1,-1,-1,-1,+1,+1,-1]
// [+1,-1,+1,+1,+1,-1]

var ANCHOR = 1;
var TAIL = 2;

var DEBUG_MODE = false;

function getSimColIndex(cell) {
  return Math.max(SIM_COLS.lastIndexOf(view[cell].color, SIM_ROTS.length - 1), 0);
}
function getNextSimCol(simColIndex) {
  return SIM_COLS[(simColIndex + 1) % SIM_ROTS.length];
}
function getSimRot(simColIndex) {
  return SIM_ROTS[simColIndex];
}

function run() {
  switch (ME.type) {
    case QUEEN: {
      var anch = findFirst(c => test(c, {ant: {type: ANCHOR, friend: true}}), DIRECTIONS);
      if (anch !== null) {
        if (isOrthogonal(anch)) {
          var tail = findFirst(c => test(c, {ant: {type: TAIL, friend: true}}), DIAGONALS);
          if (tail !== null) {
            return [move(rotateCW(anch, -2 * getSimRot(getSimColIndex(HERE))))].filter(isSane)[0] || NOP;
          } else {
            var nanch = rotateCW(anch, -getSimRot(getSimColIndex(anch)));
            return color(nanch, getNextSimCol(getSimColIndex(nanch)));
          }
        } else {
          return NOP;
        }
      } else {
        var tailO;
        if (ME.food === 2) {
          return spawnMany(ORTHOGONALS, TAIL).filter(isSane)[0] || NOP;
        } else if (ME.food === 1 && (tailO = findOrientation([{cell: 1, ant: {type: TAIL, friend: true}}])).orientation !== null) {
          return spawnMany(orientCells(tailO.orientation, [3, 5]), ANCHOR).filter(isSane)[0] || NOP;
        }

        var f;
        if ((f = findFirst(c => test(c, {food: 1})))) {
          return move(f);
        }

        if (test(HERE, {color: ROAD_COL})) {
          return moveMany(orientCells(findOrientation([{cell: 0, color: ROAD_COL}]).orientation, [8, 6, 2])).filter(a => isSane(a) && !test(a.cell, {color: ROAD_COL}))[0] || moveMany(DIAGONALS).filter(isSane)[0] || NOP;
        } else {
          return color(HERE, ROAD_COL);
        }
      }
      break;
    }
    case ANCHOR: {
      var queen = findFirst(c => test(c, {ant: {type: QUEEN, friend: true}}), DIAGONALS);
      var tail = findFirst(c => test(c, {ant: {type: TAIL, friend: true}}), ORTHOGONALS);
      var qp = [rotateCW(queen, -1), rotateCW(queen, +1)];
      var tp = [rotateCW(tail, -2), rotateCW(tail, +2)];
      for (var i = 0; i < qp.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tp.length; j++) {
          if (qp[i] === tp[j]) return [move(qp[i])].filter(isSane)[0] || NOP;
        }
      }
      return NOP;
      break;
    }
    case TAIL: {
      var anch = findFirst(c => test(c, {ant: {type: ANCHOR, friend: true}}), DIAGONALS);
      if (anch !== null) {
        var rot = getSimRot(getSimColIndex(anch));
        var nanch = rotateCW(anch, rot);
        if (test(nanch, {ant: {type: QUEEN, friend: true}})) return [move(rotateCW(anch, -rot))].filter(isSane)[0] || NOP;
        return [move(nanch)].filter(isSane)[0] || NOP;
      } else {
        return NOP;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

var output = run();
if (isSane(output)) return output;
else {
  if (DEBUG_MODE) {
    return;
  } else {
    return NOP;
  }
}
```

[image: Langton's ant ("RL")]
[image: Langton's ant ("LLRLLRLL")]

---

## Introduction

This is an implementation of **[Langton's ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant)** within the confines of the Formic Functions QOTH challenge. As an added bonus, it supports **multi-color variants** of Langton's ant. I also managed to utilize the full palette of **up to *8 colors.*** Furthermore, this ant completes ***one* step** of the simulation **in *two* steps** of in-game time.

Unfortunately, the more interesting variants of Langton's ant take more than 8 colors, so I settled on an efficient one instead. I wrote a supplementary program to find the ants that cover the largest amount of land within a specified time limit, and stumbled across multiple variations of the "RRL" ruleset. They all cover **4168 cells within 15000 steps.**

Now, 4000 cells is ***abysmal!*** This means that, on average, this entry will end the game with ***FOUR*** food. *And that's on an empty board!* Frankly, the ***[Brownian Jig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135103/74965%20Brownian%20Jig)*** does better than this. In short, this isn't a serious contender when it comes to position on the scoreboard. What it can do, however, is *mess other entries up.* And that's the sole reason why I even bothered to submit this. Very complex interactions often emerge between this entry and ones that rely heavily on colors. And those that rely on colors *usually suffer.*

---

## Explanation

The colors (`SIM_COLS`) have a corresponding rotation (`SIM_ROTS`) that the Queen uses to change the direction she's heading. `+1` means clockwise rotation ("R"), `-1` means counterclockwise rotation ("L"). The classic Langton's ant would be `SIM_COLS = [ 1, 8]`, `SIM_ROTS = [+1,-1]`. The `SIM_COLS` array effectively discards all elements that don't have a matching element in the `SIM_ROTS` array. All colors that are not contained within the truncated `SIM_COLS` array are treated as color 0 and will never be produced by the ant itself.

Like any other proper ant, this one starts by gathering enough food so it can start *actually doing things.* It requires **2 food**.

After finishing the initial scramble, the Queen spawns two ants, named **Anchor** and **Tail**. The Queen spawns the Tail first, adjacent orthogonally (cells 1, 3, 5, 7) to the Queen. Then, she spawns the Anchor, adjacent orthogonally to the Queen and diagonally (cells 0, 2, 6, 8) to the Tail.

The behavior consists of an ever-repeating cycle of two different steps.

### Step 1

Tail: Searches for the cell that the Queen occupied 2 simulation steps ago and goes there. Note that it uses the color from under the Anchor and the presence of the Queen (or lack thereof) to accurately determine the target cell. This is prone to disasters that I will address in a future update.

Anchor: Doesn't do anything.

Queen: Finds the Anchor and treats it as the inverse of the direction the ant is going. The direction is then rotated according to the color under the Queen. The Queen moves to the cell indicated by the rotated direction.

### Step 2

Tail: Doesn't do anything.

Anchor: Searches for a cell that is diagonally adjacent to the Tail and orthogonally adjacent to the Queen and goes there. There's at most one such cell.

Queen: Similarly to the Tail in step 1, she searches for the cell that she occupied 2 simulation steps ago and changes its color in a cyclical fashion. Note that she uses the color from under the Anchor to accurately determine the target cell. The worst disaster that could happen is coloring the wrong cell, and while it would alter the trajectory of the ant, it's not really an issue because the trajectory is going to be altered by the presence of other ants anyway.

### Determining what to do

The Queen determines the current step by searching for the Tail orthogonally. If she finds it, she's on step 1. Otherwise, she's on step 2. In rare cases, she might find the Anchor adjacent diagonally to herself. In that case, she will not do anything.

The Anchor does not have any logic to determine its step. It always strives to be orthogonally adjacent to the Queen and diagonally adjacent to the Tail. If there is no such cell, it simply doesn't move.

The Tail determines the current step by searching for the Anchor diagonally. If it finds it, it's on step 1. Otherwise, it's on step 2.

The previously mentioned disaster during the movement of the Tail can be triggered by an ant altering the color under the Anchor. If the altered color indicates a different rotation than the original and the Queen is not in sight of the Tail, the resulting position after the Tail's movement is a straight line of the 3 ants. I am currently working on a remedy to this situation.

---

While this is definitely *not* a serious contender for first place, it's bound to spice things up on the arena and shift the meta a bit towards the colorless ants. I've got a couple of submissions cooking (and one of them is looking *really* spicy), so expect some more entries from me in the coming weeks.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 10):

## Ziggurat v3.0

```
var clockwise = [1,2,5,0,4,8,3,6,7];
var opposite = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0];
var cyclic_cw = [0,1,2,5,8,7,6,3,0];
var worker_colors = [4,5,7,8];
var next_worker_color = [1,1,1,1,5,7,1,8,4];
var prev_worker_color = [1,1,1,1,8,4,1,5,7];
var diags = [0,2,6,8];
var orthos = [1,3,5,7];
var cleaning_color = 6;


// Borrowed from Medusa
function clean(move) {
    if (move["color"] == undefined) {
        if (view[move["cell"]].ant != null) {
            move = {cell: 4};
        }
        if (move["type"] == undefined) {
            if (view[move["cell"]].food == 1 && view[4].ant.type < 5 && view[4].ant.food > 0) {
                move = {cell: 4};
            }
        } else if (view[4].ant.type != 5 || view[4].ant.food == 0 || view[move["cell"]].food == 1) {
            move = {cell: 4};
        }
    }
    return move;
}

function worker_blank(cel) {
    return (worker_colors.indexOf(view[cel].color) < 0);
}

// Own status
var my_color = view[4].color;
var my_food = view[4].ant.food;
var my_type = view[4].ant.type;

// Random free cell
var free_cell = 4;
for (var cel = 0; cel < 9; cel++) {
    if (view[cel].ant == null) {
    free_cell = cel;
    }
}

// Check surroundings
var blanks = 0;
var outer_edge = 0;
var inner_edge = 0;
var next_edge = -1;
var prev_nonblank = -1;
var some_nonblank = -1;
var prev_cell = -1;
var next_cell = -1;
var food_cell = -1;
var nonblank_color = 0;
var cleaning_marker = -1;
var uniform = 1;
var low_type = -1;
var friend_workers = 0;
var guards = 0;
var enemies = 0;
var enemy_queens = 0;
var my_queen = -1;

if (!worker_blank(4)) {
    nonblank_color = view[4].color;
}
for (var ix = 0; ix < 8; ix++) {
    var cel = cyclic_cw[ix];
    var cel2 = cyclic_cw[ix+1];
    if (view[cel].food == 1) {
    food_cell = cel;
    }
    if (worker_blank(cel)) {
    blanks++;
    if (!worker_blank(cel2)) {
        if (worker_blank(4)) {
        outer_edge = 1;
        } else {
        inner_edge = 1;
        }
        next_edge = cel;
            prev_nonblank = cel2;
    }
    if (view[cel].color == cleaning_color) {
        cleaning_marker = cel;
    }
    } else {
    some_nonblank = cel;
    if (nonblank_color == 0) {
        nonblank_color = view[cel].color;
    } else if (view[cel].color != nonblank_color) {
        uniform = 0;
    }
    }
    if ((!worker_blank(4) && view[cel2].color == prev_worker_color[my_color] && view[cel2].ant == null) || (worker_blank(4) && !worker_blank(cel2))) {
    prev_cell = cel2;
    }
    if (!worker_blank(4) && view[cel2].color == next_worker_color[my_color] && view[cel2].ant == null) {
    next_cell = cel2;
    }
    if (view[cel].ant != null) {
    var the_ant = view[cel].ant;
    if (the_ant.friend) {
        if (low_type < 0 || the_ant.type < low_type) {
        low_type = the_ant.type;
        }
        if (the_ant.type == 4) {
        guards++;
        } else if (the_ant.type == 5) {
        my_queen = cel;
        } else {
        friend_workers++;
        }
    } else {
        enemies++;
        if (the_ant.type == 5) {
        enemy_queens++;
        }
    }
    }
}

// Queen before finding food (motile)
if (my_type == 5 && worker_blank(4)) {
    if (my_food > 1) {
    return {cell:4, color:worker_colors[1]};
    }
    if (food_cell >= 0 && my_color != 1) {
    return clean({cell:food_cell});
    }
    if (my_color == 2) {
    for (var ix = 0; ix < 4; ix++) {
        var cel = diags[ix];
        var oppo = opposite[cel];
        if (view[cel].color == 2) {
        if (view[oppo].color == 1 && worker_blank(oppo) && view[oppo].ant == null) {
            return clean({cell:oppo});
        }
                if (view[oppo].color != 2) {
            return {cell:oppo, color:1};
                }
        }
    }
        for (var ix = 0; ix < 4; ix++) {
        var cel = diags[ix];
        if (view[cel].color != 2) {
        return {cell:cel, color:2};
        }
    }
    }
    if (my_color == 1) {
    return {cell:4, color:2};
    }
    return clean({cell:free_cell});
}

// Queen after finding food (sessile)
if (my_type == 5) {
    for (var ix = 0; ix < 8; ix++) {
        cel = cyclic_cw[ix];
    if (worker_blank(cel)) {
            return {cell:cel, color:worker_colors[1]};
    }
    }

    if (my_color != worker_colors[0]) {
        if (my_food > 0) {
        return clean({cell:free_cell, type:1});
        } else {
            return {cell:4, color:worker_colors[0]};
        }
    }
    if (my_food > 0) {
    if (my_food > 3 && guards < 2) {
        return clean({cell:free_cell, type:4});
    }
    if (0 < low_type && low_type < 3) {
        return clean({cell:free_cell, type:(low_type + 1)});
    }
    }
    return {cell:4};
}

// Queen's guard

if (my_type == 4) {
    // Queen is a nbor
    if (my_queen >= 0) {
    if (enemy_queens > 0) {
        return {cell:4};
    }
    if (my_queen == 1) {
        return clean({cell:5});
    }
    return clean({cell:clockwise[my_queen]});
    }
    // Try to get to queen
    if (prev_cell >= 0) {
    return clean({cell:prev_cell});
    }
    // Wander
    return clean({cell:free_cell});
}

// Worker

// Create new ziggurat
if (blanks == 8 && cleaning_marker < 0 && my_color != cleaning_color) {
    if (worker_colors.indexOf(my_color) >= 0) {
    return {cell:free_cell, color:my_color};
    }
    return {cell:free_cell, color:worker_colors[0]};
}

var front = view[1].color;
if (!worker_blank(4) && !worker_blank(1) && my_color != front) {
    if (view[7].color == front || (view[6].color == front && view[8].color == front)) {
        return {cell:4, color:front};
    }
}

if (my_food == 0) {
    // Grab food
    if (food_cell >= 0 && (!worker_blank(4) || !worker_blank(food_cell))) {
        return clean({cell:food_cell});
    }

    // Clear marked uniform region
    if (my_color == cleaning_color && uniform) {
    if (blanks < 7) {
        return {cell:some_nonblank, color:1};
    } else if (blanks == 7) {
        return {cell:some_nonblank, color:cleaning_color};
    }
    }

    // Follow cleaning color
    if (blanks == 8) {
    if (cleaning_marker < 0 || my_color == cleaning_color) {
        return {cell:4, color:1};
    } else if (cleaning_marker >= 0) {
        return clean({cell:cleaning_marker});
    }
    }

    // Dive into uniform region
    if (blanks > 3 && worker_blank(4) && worker_blank(1) && !worker_blank(2) && view[2].color == view[5].color && view[2].color == view[8].color) {
    return clean({cell:2});
    }

    // Mark uniform region for clearing
    if (!worker_blank(4) && uniform && (blanks < 4 || (blanks < 7 && ((worker_blank(1) && worker_blank(7)) || (worker_blank(3) && worker_blank(5)))))) {
    return {cell:4, color:cleaning_color};
    }

    // Extend edge
    if (outer_edge) {
    var new_color = 0;
    var cl = clockwise[next_edge];
    var cl2 = clockwise[cl];
    if (!worker_blank(1) && view[7].color == view[1].color) {
        new_color = view[1].color;
    } else if (!worker_blank(3) && view[5].color == view[3].color) {
        new_color = view[3].color;
        } else if (!worker_blank(cl2) && view[cl].color == next_worker_color[view[cl2].color]) {
        if (cl > 1) {
        new_color = view[cl].color;
        } else {
        new_color = next_worker_color[view[cl].color];
        }
    } else if (!worker_blank(cl)) {
        new_color = next_worker_color[view[cl].color];
        } else if (prev_nonblank >= 0) {
            new_color = next_worker_color[prev_nonblank];
    }
    if (new_color == 0 && blanks < 2) {
        new_color = worker_colors[0];
    }
        if (new_color > 0) {
            return {cell:4, color:new_color};
        } else {
            return clean({cell:next_edge});
        }
    }

    // Escape from hole
    if (worker_blank(4) && blanks == 0) {
        return {cell:4, color:next_worker_color[nonblank_color]};
    }

    // Go outside or fill it
    if (inner_edge && next_edge >= 0) {
    if (friend_workers > 1) {
        return clean({cell:free_cell});
    }
        if (blanks == 4 && prev_nonblank >= 0) {
            return {cell:next_edge, color:next_worker_color[view[prev_nonblank].color]};
        }
    if (view[next_edge].ant == null) {
            return clean({cell:next_edge});
    }
    return {cell:4};
    }

    // Go toward border
    if (!worker_blank(4) && next_cell >= 0 && next_cell != 1) {
    return clean({cell:next_cell});
    }

    // Wander
    return clean({cell:free_cell});
}

if (my_food > 0) {
    // Take food to queen
    if ((prev_cell >= 0 && prev_cell != 1) || (prev_cell >= 0 && worker_blank(4))) {
    return clean({cell:prev_cell});
    }

    // Wander
    if (worker_blank(free_cell) && !worker_blank(4)) {
    return {cell:4};
    }
    return clean({cell:free_cell});
}

return clean({cell:free_cell});
```

### How it works

This ant is a combination of [Black Hole](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135157/32014) and [Medusa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135271/32014).
The queen begins by searching for food diagonally.
Once it has two units of food, it becomes sessile and makes two workers.
The workers circle around the queen and make a growing striped region (the "ziggurat") using four colors.
When a worker finds food, it follows the stripes and takes it to the queen, who sits at the center of the square.
If the worker was one of the original two, the queen makes a new worker; otherwise, she stores the food.

### Comments

**Version 2.0** uses four colors, which hopefully prevents the ants from getting lost so easily.
The worker creation scheme has also been revamped to first make lots of workers and grow the region, then stash food to make it to the leaderboard.
There are also more checks against illegal moves.

**Version 2.1** features an improved ziggurat construction routine.
Workers are sometimes able to choose their color from two options, which makes the stripe pattern more random, hopefully fooling the Vampire.
Workers sometimes lay down two colors before moving, which makes the ziggurat grow faster.
When inside the ziggurat, workers sometimes make a random move to escape infinite loops, and try to correct certain local inconsistencies.
The queen is smarter about avoiding trails in her motile phase.
Finally, if the sessile queen is attacked, she fights back by creating a burst of new workers, which should also help her recover if the attacker was a Trail-eraser that cut her off from all existing workers.

**Version 3.0** has more tweaks to the construction routine. As a (largely untested) countermeasure against Black Hole and Wildfire, workers that discover uniform colored regions will try to erase them. The queen no longer spawns dozens of workers when attacked; instead, she has a dedicated pair of guardian ants orbiting around her. She will also wait longer before starting to hoard food.

I don't really know JS, so the code is a horrid mess.

Here's a picture of the striped region:

[image: Ziggurat]

Comment: This is beautiful to watch. It's interesting that there are occasional imperfections in the stripes, like defects in a growing crystal, but they are still arranged leading to the queen so it doesn't seem to cause the workers any problems.

Comment: I love watching this one work, especially when the pattern gets some imperfect [anomalies](http://i.imgur.com/H27z9zT.png) (due to workers being unable to return to the place where they found food)

Comment: @trichoplax I hope it's fixed now.

Comment: How does this one do when it gets hit by trail-eraser?

Comment: @pperry Badly. Once the queen is cut off from her workers, it's really hard to recover.

Comment: @trichoplax I've just updated the bot. It should never make an illegal move now, and is overall a bit smarter.

Comment: And, the newer version seems like it can survive an attack by one trail-eraser with some difficulty. Not sure what happens if more than one invade, though

Comment: This bot interacts with black hole in very interesting ways if they happen to build their bases close to each other.

Comment: @trichoplax Thanks, I'll fix that later.

Comment: @trichoplax Should be fixed now. I added other improvements as well.

Answer (score 9):

## Wildfire Mk.3

*All my answers are sharing the same set of low-level helper functions. Search for "High-level logic begins here" to see the code specific to this answer.*

```js
// == Shared low-level helpers for all solutions ==

var QUEEN = 5;

var WHITE = 1;
var COL_MIN = WHITE;
var COL_LIM = 9;

var CENTRE = 4;

var NOP = {cell: CENTRE};

var DIR_FORWARDS = false;
var DIR_REVERSE = true;
var SIDE_RIGHT = true;
var SIDE_LEFT = false;

function sanity_check(movement) {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  if(!movement || (movement.cell|0) !== movement.cell || movement.cell < 0 || movement.cell > 8) {
    return false;
  }
  if(movement.type) {
    if(movement.color) {
      return false;
    }
    if((movement.type|0) !== movement.type || movement.type < 1 || movement.type > 4) {
      return false;
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].ant || view[movement.cell].food) {
      return false;
    }
    if(me.type !== QUEEN || me.food < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if(movement.color) {
    if((movement.color|0) !== movement.color || movement.color < COL_MIN || movement.color >= COL_LIM) {
      return false;
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].color === movement.color) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if(movement.cell !== CENTRE && view[movement.cell].ant) {
    return false;
  }
  if(view[movement.cell].food + me.food > 1 && me.type !== QUEEN) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function as_array(o) {
  if(Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o;
  }
  return [o];
}

function best_of(movements) {
  var m;
  for(var i = 0; i < movements.length; ++ i) {
    if(typeof(movements[i]) === 'function') {
      m = movements[i]();
    } else {
      m = movements[i];
    }
    if(sanity_check(m)) {
      return m;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function play_safe(movement) {
  // Avoid disqualification: no-op if moves are invalid
  return best_of(as_array(movement)) || NOP;
}

var RAND_SEED = (() => {
  var s = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    s += view[i].color * (i + 1);
    s += view[i].ant ? i * i : 0;
    s += view[i].food ? i * i * i : 0;
  }
  return s % 29;
})();

var ROTATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [6, 3, 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2],
  [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 6],
];

function try_all(fns, limit, wrapperFn, checkFn) {
  var m;
  fns = as_array(fns);
  for(var i = 0; i < fns.length; ++ i) {
    if(typeof(fns[i]) !== 'function') {
      if(checkFn(m = fns[i])) {
        return m;
      }
      continue;
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < limit; ++ j) {
      if(checkFn(m = wrapperFn(fns[i], j))) {
        return m;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function identify_rotation(testFns) {
  // testFns MUST be functions, not constants
  return try_all(
    testFns,
    4,
    (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]) ? ROTATIONS[r] : null,
    (r) => r
  );
}

function near(a, b) {
  return (
    Math.abs(a % 3 - b % 3) < 2 &&
    Math.abs(Math.floor(a / 3) - Math.floor(b / 3)) < 2
  );
}

function try_all_angles(solverFns) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    4,
    (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function try_all_cells(solverFns, skipCentre) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    9,
    (fn, i) => ((i === CENTRE && skipCentre) ? null : fn(i)),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function try_all_cells_near(p, solverFns) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    9,
    (fn, i) => ((i !== p && near(p, i)) ? fn(i) : null),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function ant_type_at(i, friend) {
  return (view[i].ant && view[i].ant.friend === friend) ? view[i].ant.type : 0;
}

function friend_at(i) {
  return ant_type_at(i, true);
}

function foe_at(i) {
  return ant_type_at(i, false);
}

function ant_type_near(p, friend) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    if(i !== 4 && ant_type_at(i, friend) && near(i, p)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function move_agent(agents) {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  var buddies = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    ++ buddies[friend_at(i)];
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < agents.length; i += 2) {
    if(agents[i] === me.type) {
      return agents[i+1](me, buddies);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function grab_nearby_food() {
  return try_all_cells((i) => (view[i].food ? {cell: i} : null), true);
}

function go_anywhere() {
  return try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i}), true);
}

function colours_excluding(cols) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = COL_MIN; i < COL_LIM; ++ i) {
    if(cols.indexOf(i) === -1) {
      r.push(i);
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function generate_band(start, width) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < width; ++ i) {
    r.push(start + i);
  }
  return r;
}

function colour_band(colours) {
  return {
    contains: function(c) {
      return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1;
    },
    next: function(c) {
      return colours[(colours.indexOf(c) + 1) % colours.length];
    }
  };
}

function random_colour_band(colours) {
  return {
    contains: function(c) {
      return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1;
    },
    next: function() {
      return colours[RAND_SEED % colours.length];
    }
  };
}

function fast_diagonal(colourBand, avoidedColours) {
  if(!avoidedColours) {
    avoidedColours = colourBand;
  }
  var m = try_all_angles([
    // Avoid nearby checked areas
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !avoidedColours.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        avoidedColours.contains(view[rot[5]].color) &&
        avoidedColours.contains(view[rot[7]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[0]};
      }
    },

    // Go in a straight diagonal line if possible
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !avoidedColours.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        avoidedColours.contains(view[rot[8]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[0]};
      }
    },

    // When in doubt, pick randomly but avoid doubling-back
    (rot) => (avoidedColours.contains(view[rot[0]].color) ? null : {cell: rot[0]}),

    // Double-back when absolutely necessary
    (rot) => ({cell: rot[0]})
  ]);

  // Lay a colour track so that we can avoid doubling-back
  // (and mess up our foes as much as possible)
  if(!avoidedColours.contains(view[CENTRE].color)) {
    var prevCol = m ? view[8-m.cell].color : WHITE;
    return {cell: CENTRE, color: colourBand.next(prevCol)};
  }

  return m;
}

function follow_edge(obstacleFn, side, resultFn) {
  // Since we don't know which direction we came from, this can cause us to get
  // stuck on islands, but the random orientation helps to ensure we don't get
  // stuck forever.

  if(!resultFn) {
    resultFn = (i) => ({cell: i});
  }

  var order = ((side === SIDE_LEFT)
    ? [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0]
    : [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 0]
  );
  return try_all(
    [obstacleFn],
    order.length - 1,
    (fn, i) => ((fn(order[i+1]) && !fn(order[i])) ? resultFn(order[i]) : null),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function start_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => ((
      !protectedCols.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color)
    )
      ? {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3], color: colourBand.next(WHITE)}
      : null)
  ]);
}

function lay_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => {
      var ahead = rot[right ? 2 : 0];
      var behind = rot[right ? 8 : 6];
      if(
        colourBand.contains(view[behind].color) &&
        !protectedCols.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: ahead, color: colourBand.next(view[behind].color)};
      }
    }
  ]);
}

function follow_dotted_path(colourBand, side, direction) {
  var forwards = (direction === DIR_REVERSE) ? 7 : 1;
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);

  return try_all_angles([
    // Cell on our side? advance
    (rot) => {
      if(
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
        // Prevent sticking / trickery
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[2]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[forwards]};
      }
    },

    // Cell ahead and behind? advance
    (rot) => {
      var passedCol = view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color;
      var nextCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        colourBand.contains(passedCol) &&
        nextCol === colourBand.next(passedCol) &&

        // Prevent sticking / trickery
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 0 : 2]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[forwards]};
      }
    }
  ]);
}

function escape_dotted_path(colourBand, side, newColourBand) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  if(!newColourBand) {
    newColourBand = colourBand;
  }

  return try_all_angles([
    // Escape from beside the line
    (rot) => {
      var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color) ||
        !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
      ) {
        // not oriented, or in a corner
        return null;
      }
      return best_of([
        {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2], color: newColourBand.next(approachingCol)},
        {cell: rot[right ? 3 : 5]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 6 : 8]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 2 : 0]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 8 : 6]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]}
      ]);
    },

    // Escape from inside the line
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      return best_of([
        {cell: rot[3]},
        {cell: rot[5]},
        {cell: rot[0]},
        {cell: rot[2]},
        {cell: rot[6]},
        {cell: rot[8]}
      ]);
    }
  ]);
}

function latch_to_dotted_path(colourBand, side) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);

  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => {
      var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        colourBand.contains(approachingCol) &&
        view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color === colourBand.next(approachingCol) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color)
      ) {
        // We're on the wrong side; go inside the line
        return {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]};
      }
    },

    // Inside the line? pick a side
    (rot) => {
      var passedCol = view[rot[7]].color;
      var approachingCol = view[rot[1]].color;
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(passedCol) ||
        !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      if((approachingCol === colourBand.next(passedCol)) === right) {
        return best_of([{cell: rot[3]}, {cell: rot[6]}, {cell: rot[0]}]);
      } else {
        return best_of([{cell: rot[5]}, {cell: rot[2]}, {cell: rot[8]}]);
      }
    }
  ]);
}


// == High-level logic begins here ==


var groundCol = 5;
var poisonCol = 8;

var DIRECTOR = 1;
var FORAGER0 = 2;
var FORAGER1 = 3;
var FORAGER2 = 4;
var MAX_FORAGER_TYPES = 3; // Worker creation throttle
var MIN_FOOD = 3; // Don't embarrass ourselves when things go bad
var MAX_FOOD_SPAWN = 80; // If we're doing well, don't spoil it all

var GROUND_COLOURS = colour_band([groundCol, poisonCol]);
var POISON_COLOURS = colour_band([poisonCol]);
var SAFE_COLOURS = random_colour_band(colours_excluding([WHITE, groundCol, poisonCol]));
var INITIAL_OBSTACLES = random_colour_band(colours_excluding([WHITE]));

function ground_at(i) {
  return GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[i].color);
}

function unlaiden_friend_at(i) {
  return friend_at(i) && (friend_at(i) === QUEEN || !view[i].ant.food);
}

function obstacle_at(i) {
  // foes are unpredictable, so don't consider them obstacles
  return view[i].food || unlaiden_friend_at(i) || GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[i].color);
}

function wait_if_blocked(i) {
  return friend_at(i) ? {cell:CENTRE} : {cell: i};
}

function move_director(me, buddies) {
  if(!buddies[QUEEN]) {
    // Lost the queen!
    return go_anywhere();
  }

  var rot = identify_rotation((rot) => (
    friend_at(rot[0]) === QUEEN || friend_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN
  ));

  var ready = (friend_at(rot[1]) === QUEEN && view[rot[1]].color === groundCol);
  var shift = (view[rot[2]].color === groundCol && GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[5]].color));

  return best_of([
    // Ensure we never end up underground unless we mean to, and provide a
    // base poison layer to help workers find the right side if lost
    {cell: CENTRE, color: poisonCol},
//    {cell: rot[5], color: poisonCol},
    {cell: rot[3], color: poisonCol},

    // Move up to avoid own line after wrapping (us being underground is a signal)
    (ready && shift) && {cell: rot[2]},

    // Advance
    (ready && !shift) && {cell: rot[5]},

    // Make the poison layer more solid if we have extra time
    {cell: rot[7], color: poisonCol},
    {cell: rot[6], color: poisonCol},
    {cell: rot[8], color: poisonCol},

    // Don't lose the queen
    NOP
  ]);
}

function move_forager(me, buddies) {
  var underground = GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[CENTRE].color);
  var buried = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    if(i !== 4 && GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[i].color)) {
      ++ buried;
    }
  }
  var travelCol = underground ? POISON_COLOURS : SAFE_COLOURS;

  if(buddies[DIRECTOR]) {
    // We've somehow got in the way of the line; get out of the way
    return try_all_angles((rot) =>
      ((friend_at(rot[6]) === DIRECTOR || friend_at(rot[7]) === DIRECTOR) &&
      best_of([{cell: rot[0]}, {cell: rot[1]}, {cell: rot[2]}])));
  }

  if(me.food) {
    // We have food for the queen; run ahead to find her as fast as we can

    return best_of([
      // Identify confusing pinch points and close them (don't get stuck on islands)
      try_all_angles((rot) => (
        obstacle_at(rot[1]) && obstacle_at(rot[7]) &&
        !obstacle_at(rot[5]) && !GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) && {cell: CENTRE, color: groundCol}),

      // We're enclosed; mark this as a dead-end
      (buried >= 7) && {cell: CENTRE, color: poisonCol},

      // Race to queen, but don't climb over each other and cause a blockage
      follow_edge(obstacle_at, SIDE_RIGHT, wait_if_blocked),

      // Lost? Travel quickly to find the surface again
      fast_diagonal.bind(null, travelCol),

      // Totally lost
      go_anywhere
    ]);
  }

  if(buddies[QUEEN]) {
    // Don't overtake the queen!
    return NOP;
  }

  // Paint the ground
  if(!underground) {
    return {cell: CENTRE, color: groundCol};
  }

  return best_of([
    // Unpaint small islands which would confuse us or our buddies
    (buried >= 3) && try_all_angles((rot) => (
      !view[rot[0]].ant &&
      GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
      !GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[1]].color) &&
      !GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[3]].color)
    ) && {cell: rot[0], color: SAFE_COLOURS.next(WHITE)}),

    (buried >= 3) && try_all_angles((rot) => (
      !view[rot[1]].ant &&
      GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[1]].color) &&
      !GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
      !GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[2]].color)
    ) && {cell: rot[1], color: SAFE_COLOURS.next(WHITE)}),

    // Follow line
    follow_edge(ground_at, SIDE_RIGHT, wait_if_blocked),

    // Disoriented; find the surface again
    fast_diagonal.bind(null, travelCol),

    // Totally lost; random walk
    {cell: 0}
  ]);
}

function move_queen(me, buddies) {
  if(buddies[DIRECTOR]) {
    var rot = identify_rotation((rot) => (
      (friend_at(rot[7]) === DIRECTOR && view[rot[7]].color !== groundCol) ||
      (friend_at(rot[5]) === DIRECTOR && view[rot[5]].color === groundCol) ||
      friend_at(rot[8]) === DIRECTOR
    ));

    var rand14 = rot === ROTATIONS[0];
    var existing = friend_at(rot[0]);
    var nextType = existing ? (existing + 1) : FORAGER0;
    var workerSpawn = (
      me.food > MIN_FOOD && me.food < MAX_FOOD_SPAWN &&
      view[rot[3]].color === groundCol && // Don't spawn if disrupted
      view[rot[0]].color === WHITE && // Don't spawn while stuck in a nest
      view[rot[1]].color === WHITE &&
      !friend_at(rot[1]) && !friend_at(rot[3]) && !friend_at(rot[6]) &&
      (existing || rand14) // reduce likelihood of spawning new chains
    );

    return best_of([
      // Paint ground
      {cell: CENTRE, color: groundCol},

      // Follow director up slopes
      (friend_at(rot[5]) === DIRECTOR) && {cell: rot[2]},
      (friend_at(rot[5]) === DIRECTOR) && {cell: rot[1]},

      // Recognise likely erasure issues and correct
      view[rot[2]].color === groundCol && GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[8]].color) &&
        {cell: CENTRE, color: groundCol},

      // Clear cells which could confuse workers
      GROUND_COLOURS.contains(view[rot[2]].color) && {cell: rot[2], color: SAFE_COLOURS.next(WHITE)},

      // Spawn new workers when ready (throttle probabilistically)
      (workerSpawn && nextType < FORAGER0 + MAX_FORAGER_TYPES) && {cell: rot[1], type: nextType},

      // Follow director along flat planes
      (friend_at(rot[8]) === DIRECTOR) && {cell: rot[5]},

      // Don't lose director
      NOP
    ]);
  }

  return best_of([
    // Begin wildfire
    (me.food >= MIN_FOOD + MAX_FORAGER_TYPES + 1) && try_all_angles((rot) =>
      (view[rot[5]].color !== groundCol && sanity_check({cell: rot[5]}) &&
        {cell: rot[8], type: DIRECTOR})),

    // Hungry or too crowded to begin; frantically find food
    grab_nearby_food,
    fast_diagonal.bind(null, SAFE_COLOURS, INITIAL_OBSTACLES),
    go_anywhere,
    {cell: 1, color: SAFE_COLOURS.next(WHITE)}
  ]);
}

return play_safe(move_agent([
  DIRECTOR, move_director,
  FORAGER0, move_forager,
  FORAGER1, move_forager,
  FORAGER2, move_forager,
  QUEEN, move_queen,
]));
```

Wildfire ants sweep the board, devouring everything in their path. This was inspired by mixing the concepts of [Black Hole (by Draco18s)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135157/8927) with [my Forensic Ants](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135108/8927).

The queen will start by quickly gathering a stash of food. Once she has enough, she'll start moving in a straight line and spawn some helpers. These helpers will follow behind her in an orderly line, running to catch up if they find food.

Mk.2 uses a specialist ant to help the queen maintain her direction, and this ant also lays down a trail of black to help lost workers find the correct side of the band. Combined with better worker navigation, it now performs much better when mixed with competing ants. It even (eventually) recovers after hitting nests of red dots.

Mk.2c uses probability to control the worker population and seems to manage it fairly well. The workers are still getting lost inside the fire more often than I'd like, but despite that it manages to take over impressive amounts of the board when on its own.

Mk.3 adds protection against diagonal red lines produced by the "single queen" entry, which also helps out in some similar situations. The workers are much less likely to get distracted by random detours now, and it seems to be performing better.

Here's the result of one of the prototypes:

[image: FIRE]

(yes, that's 865 worker ants… and er, 5 food)

---

Here's a screenshot with competition:

[image: Cleansing fire]

---

And here's how I imagine the ants in my mind (plus the corresponding music):

[image: Paprika Parade]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65025/discussion-on-answer-by-dave-formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest).

Comment: can't hear your music...

Comment: @NH. the frogs / chaos / general insanity are from the film Paprika. If you want to know the music, watch that!

Answer (score 9):

## Lightspeed

*All of my answers will contain similar low-level logic in the form of the Formic Functions Framework. "HIGH-LEVEL LOGIC STARTS HERE" marks the end of the Framework's code.*

```js
 //  FORMIC FRAMEWORK  //
// Version 6.1.10     //
const WHITE = 1;
const QUEEN = 5;
const CENTER = 4;
const HERE = view[CENTER];
const ME = HERE.ant;
const ORTHOGONALS = [1, 3, 5, 7];
const DIAGONALS = [0, 2, 6, 8];
const DIAGONALS_ORTHOGONALS = [0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7];
const DIRECTIONS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS = [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3];
const CELLS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const ROTATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2,
   3, 4, 5,
   6, 7, 8],

  [6, 3, 0,
   7, 4, 1,
   8, 5, 2],

  [8, 7, 6,
   5, 4, 3,
   2, 1, 0],

  [2, 5, 8,
   1, 4, 7,
   0, 3, 6]
];
const NEIGHBORS = [
  [1, 4, 3],
  [2, 5, 4, 3, 0],
  [5, 4, 1],
  [0, 1, 4, 7, 6],
  [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3],
  [8, 7, 4, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 7],
  [6, 3, 4, 5, 8],
  [7, 4, 5]
];
const HORIZONTAL_FLIP = [2, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6];
const VERTICAL_FLIP = [6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2];

const DEBUG_MODE = false;
function dump() {
  if (DEBUG_MODE) {
    throw "dump() not implemented";
  }
}
function log(...args) {
  if (DEBUG_MODE) {
    console.log(...args);
  }
}
function error(...args) {
  log("Transformed view state:", view);
  log(...args);
  throw "A critical error has occurred!";
}

function createArray(func, length) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr.push(func(i, arr));
  }
  return arr;
}

class Test {
  run(cell) {
    error("No run method defined for this instance of Test:", this);
  }
  find(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.find((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  findIndex(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.findIndex((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  filter(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.filter((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  every(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.every((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  some(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.some((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  count(cells = CELLS) {
    return this.filter(cells).length;
  }
  invert() {
    return new InverseTest(this);
  }
  and(test) {
    return new EveryTest(this, test);
  }
  or(test) {
    return new SomeTest(this, test);
  }
}

class InverseTest extends Test {
  constructor(test) {
    super();
    this.test = test;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return !this.test.run(cell);
  }
  invert() {
    return this.test;
  }
}

class CombinedTest extends Test {
  constructor(...tests) {
    super();
    this.tests = tests;
  }
  append(test) {
    this.tests.push(test);
    return this;
  }
}
class EveryTest extends CombinedTest {
  run(cell) {
    return this.tests.every((test) => test.run(cell));
  }
  and(test) {
    return this.append(test);
  }
}
class SomeTest extends CombinedTest {
  run(cell) {
    return this.tests.some((test) => test.run(cell));
  }
  or(test) {
    return this.append(test);
  }
}

class ColorTest extends Test {
  constructor(color) {
    super();
    this.color = color;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return view[cell].color === this.color;
  }
}
class ColorBandTest extends SomeTest {
  constructor(colorBand) {
    super(...colorBand.map((color) => new ColorTest(color)));
  }
}

class FoodTest extends Test {
  constructor(hasFood = true) {
    super();
    this.food = hasFood ? 1 : 0;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return view[cell].food === this.food;
  }
}

class AntTest extends Test {
  constructor(friend, type, food) {
    super();
    this.friend = friend;
    this.type = type;
    this.food = food;
  }
  run(cell) {
    const ant = view[cell].ant;
    return ant !== null && (this.type === undefined || ant.type === this.type) && (this.friend === undefined || ant.friend === this.friend) && (this.food === undefined || (this.food ? ant.food > 0 : ant.food === 0));
  }
}

class NeighborTest extends Test {
  constructor(test) {
    super();
    this.test = test;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return this.test.some(NEIGHBORS[cell]);
  }
}

class MatchTest extends Test {
  constructor(matches) {
    super();
    this.matches = matches;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return this.matches[cell];
  }
}

class CustomTest extends Test {
  constructor(func, ...args) {
    super();
    this.func = func;
    this.args = args;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return this.func(cell, ...this.args);
  }
}

class Action {
  constructor(cell, test) {
    this.cell = cell;
    this.test = test;
  }

  valid() {
    return this.cell >= 0 && this.cell < 9 && (!this.test || this.test.run(this.cell));
  }
  attempt() {
    return this.valid() ? this : null;
  }
  static tryAll(...actions) {
    return actions.find((action) => action instanceof this && action.valid()) || null;
  }
}
class Move extends Action {
  constructor(cell, test) {
    super(cell, test);
  }

  valid() {
    return super.valid() && view[this.cell].ant === null && (view[this.cell].food === 0 || ME.food === 0 || ME.type === QUEEN);
  }
  static many(cells, test) {
    return cells.map((cell) => new this(cell, test));
  }
}
class Paint extends Action {
  constructor(cell, color, test) {
    super(cell, test);
    this.color = color;
  }

  valid() {
    return super.valid() && view[this.cell].color !== this.color && this.color >= 1 && this.color <= 8;
  }
  static many(cells, colors, test) {
    return cells.map((cell, i) => new this(cell, colors[i % colors.length], test));
  }
}
class Spawn extends Action {
  constructor(cell, type, test) {
    super(cell, test);
    this.type = type;
  }

  valid() {
    return super.valid() && view[this.cell].ant === null && view[this.cell].food === 0 && ME.food > 0 && ME.type === QUEEN && this.type >= 1 && this.type <= 4;
  }
  static many(cells, type, test) {
    return cells.map((cell, i) => new this(cell, type, test));
  }
}
class NOP extends Action {
  constructor() {
    super(CENTER);
  }

  valid() {
    return true;
  }
}

class Context {
  apply(func, ...args) {
    const hiddenView = view;
    if (this.viewTranslator) {
      view = this.viewTranslator(hiddenView);
    }

    let output = func(...args);
    if (output instanceof Action && this.outputTranslator) {
      this.outputTranslator(output);
    }

    view = hiddenView;
    return output;
  }
}

class TranslationContext extends Context {
  constructor(translationArray) {
    super();
    this.translationArray = translationArray;
  }

  viewTranslator(oldView) {
    const newView = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      newView.push(oldView[this.translationArray[i]]);
    }
    return newView;
  }

  outputTranslator(out) {
    out.cell = this.translationArray[out.cell];
  }
}
class RotationContext extends TranslationContext {
  constructor(orientation) {
    super(ROTATIONS[orientation]);
    this.orientation = orientation;
  }
}
class OffsetContext extends TranslationContext {
  constructor(centerCell) {
    throw "OffsetContext not implemented";
  }
}
class HorizontalReflectionContext extends TranslationContext {
  constructor() {
    super(HORIZONTAL_FLIP);
  }
}
class VerticalReflectionContext extends TranslationContext {
  constructor() {
    super(VERTICAL_FLIP);
  }
}

class ColorMapContext extends Context {
  constructor(map, unmap) {
    super();
    this.map = map;
    this.unmap = unmap;
  }

  viewTranslator(oldView) {
    return oldView.map((cell) => ({color: this.map[cell.color - 1], food: cell.food, ant: cell.ant}));
  }

  outputTranslator(out) {
    out.color = this.unmap[out.color - 1];
  }
}

class XY {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  static fromTuples(...xyTuples) {
    return xyTuples.map((xy) => new this(xy[0], xy[1]));
  }
}

class WrapProperties {
  constructor(horizontal, vertical, size, wrapOffsets) {
    this.horizontal = !!horizontal;
    this.vertical = !!vertical;
    this.size = size;
    this.wrapOffsets = wrapOffsets || {};
  }
}

class ScoredTest {
  constructor(test, score = 1) {
    this.test = test;
    this.score = score;
  }

  run(cell) {
    return this.test.run(cell) ? this.score : 0;
  }
}

class Environment {
  constructor(tests, wrapping) {
    this.tests = tests.map((test) => test instanceof Test ? new ScoredTest(test) : test);
    this.wrapping = wrapping;
  }

  at(x, y) {
    const w = this.wrapping;
    while ((w.horizontal && (x < 0 || x >= w.size.x)) || (w.vertical && (y < 0 || y >= w.size.y))) {
      if (w.horizontal) {
        if (x < 0) {
          x += w.size.x;
          y += w.wrapOffsets.left || 0;
        } else if (x >= w.size.x) {
          x -= w.size.x;
          y += w.wrapOffsets.right || 0;
        }
      }

      if (w.vertical) {
        if (y < 0) {
          y += w.size.y;
          x += w.wrapOffsets.up || 0;
        } else if (y >= w.size.y) {
          y -= w.size.y;
          x += w.wrapOffsets.down || 0;
        }
      }
    }

    if ((!w.horizontal || (x >= 0 && x < w.size.x)) && (!w.vertical || (y >= 0 || y < w.size.y))) {
      return this.tests[x + y * w.size.x];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  around(x, y) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let oy = -1; oy <= 1; oy++) {
      for (let ox = -1; ox <= 1; ox++) {
        arr.push(this.at(x + ox, y + oy));
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }

  detect(...positions) {
    return createArray((i) => new RotationContext(i), 4).reduce((best, context) => {
      const next = context.apply(() => {
        return positions.reduce((best, pos, i) => {
          let score = 0;
          const matches = this.around(pos.x, pos.y).map((test, i) => {
            if (test && (test.test instanceof Test)) {
              const result = test.run(i);
              if (result) {
                score += result;
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          });
          if (score > best.score) {
            return {position: pos, positionIndex: i, orientation: context.orientation, environment: this, matches: matches, score: score, confidence: score - best.score};
          } else {
            best.confidence = Math.min(best.score - score, best.confidence);
            return best;
          }
        }, {position: positions[0], positionIndex: 0, orientation: 0, environment: this, matches: [], score: 0, confidence: 0});
      });
      if (next.score > best.score) {
        next.confidence = next.score - best.score;
        return next;
      } else {
        best.confidence = Math.min(best.score - next.score, best.confidence);
        return best;
      }
    }, {position: positions[0], positionIndex: 0, orientation: 0, environment: this, matches: [], score: 0, confidence: 0});
  }

  static chooseBest(...detectionResults) {
    const r = detectionResults.reduce((best, result, i) => {
      if (result.score > best.score) {
        result.index = i;
        result.confidence = result.score - best.score;
        return result;
      } else {
        best.confidence = Math.min(best.score - result.score, best.confidence);
        return best;
      }
    });
    r.index = r.index || 0;
    return r;
  }
}

class ColoredEnvironment extends Environment {
  constructor(colors, wrapping) {
    super(colors.map((color) => new ColorTest(color)), wrapping);
  }

  getPainter(detectionResult) {
    return new (class Painter {
      constructor(loc) {
        this.pos = loc.position;
        this.matches = loc.matches;
        this.colors = loc.environment.around(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).map((test) => test && test.test instanceof ColorTest ? test.test.color : null);
        this.test = new MatchTest(loc.matches).invert();
        this.orient = loc.orientation;
      }

      paint(...cells) {
        return cells.map((cell) => new Paint(cell, this.colors[cell], this.test));
      }
      cleanup(eraseColor, eraseTargets, ...cells) {
        const eraseQual = this.test.and(new ColorBandTest(eraseTargets));
        return cells.map((cell) => new Paint(cell, eraseColor, eraseQual));
      }
    })(detectionResult);
  }
}

// HIGH-LEVEL LOGIC STARTS HERE //
const PARTNER = 1;

// TODO: Do a 180 when 3 workers are in front of us
function logicOrthogonal(frontC, sideC, backC, backCells, moveCells) {
  const a = [frontC, sideC, backC, backCells, moveCells];
  const f = new FoodTest;
  return Action.tryAll(
    ...Move.many([frontC, sideC], f),
    f.some(backCells) ? new Move(backC) : null,
    ...Move.many(moveCells),
    new NOP
  );
}
function logicDiagonal(adjacentC) {
  return Action.tryAll(...Move.many(adjacentC), new NOP);
}
function logic(partnerTest, partnerOrthC, partnerDiagC, frontC, sideC, backC, backCells, moveCells, adjacentC) {
  function detectEnv(c) {
    return new Environment(createArray((i) => i === c ? partnerTest : undefined, 9), new WrapProperties(false, false, new XY(3, 3), null)).detect(new XY(1, 1));
  }
  const orth = detectEnv(partnerOrthC);
  const diag = detectEnv(partnerDiagC);
  return orth.score === 1 ? new RotationContext(orth.orientation).apply(() => logicOrthogonal(frontC, sideC, backC, backCells, moveCells)) : 
    diag.score === 1 ? new RotationContext(diag.orientation).apply(() => logicDiagonal(adjacentC)) : 
    error("How did we get here?");
}

if (ME.type === QUEEN) {
  const partner = new AntTest(true, PARTNER);
  if (partner.some(DIRECTIONS)) {
    return logic(partner, 5, 8, 2, 1, 7, [0, 3, 6, 7], [2, 7, 1, 8], [5, 7]);
  } else {
    const COLOR = 5;
    const bgTest = new ColorTest(WHITE);
    if (bgTest.run(CENTER)) {
      return new Paint(CENTER, COLOR).attempt() || error("Something went terribly wrong while painting own cell");
    }

    const food = new FoodTest().find(DIRECTIONS);
    if (food !== undefined) {
      return new Move(food);
    }

    const det = new ColoredEnvironment([
      WHITE, WHITE, WHITE, 
      WHITE, undefined, undefined,
      WHITE, undefined, COLOR
    ], new WrapProperties(false, false, new XY(3, 3))).detect(new XY(1, 1));
    return (ME.food > 0 ? Action.tryAll(...Spawn.many(ORTHOGONALS, PARTNER)) : null) ||
      (det.score === 6 ? new RotationContext(det.orientation).apply(() => Action.tryAll(...Move.many([0, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8]))) : null) ||
      Action.tryAll(...Move.many(DIAGONALS_ORTHOGONALS), new NOP);
  }
} else {
  return logic(new AntTest(true, QUEEN), 1, 0, 2, 5, 3, [8, 7, 6, 3], [2, 3, 5, 0], [1, 3]);
}
```

---

## Explanation

*This is such a simple ant that I'm stunned nobody has ever thought of it...*

This ant produces a Partner after gathering 1 food with the classic approach. After this, the Queen and the Partner travel in a **straight, diagonal line at the highest speed possible** (one cell per turn) using each other's position. They don't paint any cells. They survey an average of **6 cells per turn**, netting them a theoretical total of ***180* food per game** on an empty map, which they consistently achieve.

**Version 2.0+ is out! Features comments in code that explain the specifics of this entry.**

---

## Changelog

#### Version 1.0

- initial release

#### Version 2.0

- completely revamped maneuvers

  - now utilizes diagonal adjacency for more movement options
  - changed behavior for grabbing food

    - average collection rate remains unchanged, but the system is more robust
    - prevents deadlock when more than one piece of food present, significantly increasing consistency
    - reduced the rate of changing direction
    - can grab food behind itself
  - changed behavior for avoiding obstacles

    - reduced the chance of deadlock, further increasing consistency
    - doesn't U-turn unless absolutely necessary, increasing average total area covered
- cleaned up code
- added comments

#### Version 2.1

- resolved an exotic deadlock

#### Version 2.2

- resolved another exotic deadlock

#### Version 2.3

- avoiding enemies is now significantly more effective

#### Version 2.3.1

- avoiding enemies is slightly more effective still

#### Version 2.4

- Formic Framework updated to version 5.0.4 (from 1.0)
- refactored code (behavior nearly identical to version 2.3.1)

#### Version 2.5

- Formic Framework updated to version 6.1.10 (from 5.0.4)
- refactored code to match new coding standard (behavior nearly identical to version 2.4)
- removed code comments :(

#### Version 2.5.0.1

- minor fixes

#### Version 2.5.0.2

- fixed disqualification bug with the help of [dzaima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima) in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44153850#44153850)

#### Version 2.5.0.3

- disabled debugging

Answer (score 8):

## Trail-eraser

```
var i, j
var orthogonals = [1, 3, 7, 5]  // These are the non-diagonal cells
if(view[4].ant.type == 5) {
//Queen moves straight to get food
// Color own cell if white
if (view[4].color != 6) { 
    return {cell:4, color:6}
}
var specified = null;
// Otherwise move to a white cell opposite a colored cell
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    j = (i+2) % 4
    if (view[orthogonals[i]].color !== 6 &&
        view[orthogonals[j]].color == 6 && !view[orthogonals[i]].ant) {
        specified = {cell:orthogonals[i]}
    } else if (view[4].ant.food < 8 && view[4].ant.food && view[orthogonals[i]].color !== 6 && !view[orthogonals[i]].ant && !view[orthogonals[i]].food && view[orthogonals[i]].color !== 1) {
        //create workers once I encounter a trail
        return {cell:orthogonals[i], type:(view[orthogonals[i]].color%4)+1};
    } else if (view[orthogonals[i]].food) {
        return {cell:orthogonals[i]}
    }
}
if(specified) { return specified; }
// Otherwise move to one of the vertical or horizontal cells if not occupied
for (i=1; i<9; i+=2) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move to one of the diagonal cells if not occupied
for (i=0; i<9; i+=2) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i};
    }
}

// Otherwise don't move at all
return {cell:4};
}
//workers erase their trails
//Follow the trail to erase
var move, color, enemyAnt = false;
var nearbyColoredCells = 0;
if(view[4].color != 1){
   color =  {cell:4, color:1}
}
for(i=0;i<9;i++) {
    if(i != 4 && view[i].color != 1 && !view[i].ant && (!view[4].ant.food || !view[i].food) && (!move || (view[i].color % 4 + 1) == view[4].type || (view[move.cell].color == 6 && view[i].color != 6))) {
        move = {cell:i}
    }
    if(view[i].ant && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type == 5){
       return {cell:4}
    }
    if(i != 4 && view[i].color != 1 && view[i].color != 6){
        nearbyColoredCells += 1;
    }
    if(view[i].ant && !view[i].ant.friend) {
         enemyAnt = i;
    }
}
if(nearbyColoredCells <= 1 || enemyAnt > 1) {
    // Either I'm following a standard trail or there are enemy workers; possibly decolor own cell and move
    if(color && (!move || !enemyAnt)) { return color; }
    if(move) { return move; }
} else if (nearbyColoredCells > 1){
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
       if(view[i].color != 1){ return {cell:i, color:1} }
   }
}
// uh-oh, our trail ended or we got lost -- random walk
// find a safe place to move
for (i=0;i<9;i+=1) {
    if (!view[i].ant && (!view[4].ant.food || !view[i].food)) {
       return {cell:i}
    }
}
return {cell:4}
```

This ant, while moderately good at finding food (but not as good as Roman Ants or Forensic ants) attempts to confuse other ants. It does so by creating a worker whose sole purpose is to erase trails whenever it encounters a crossing path of color. Workers who hit the end of their trail uselessly random walk until they find another trail. In order to preserve food and possibly do better, this ant will switch strategies to one of not producing more workers once it hits eight food, which should be in the late game just because it tends to require a specific combo to preserve food and not just use it all.

Comment: Sabotage!  What did the Romans ever do to you?

Comment: This entry is having a lot of fun messing with the black holes...

Comment: Now that it's been edited to remove `console.log`, this player does an excellent job of sabotaging the others. It seems to produce several of 3 different types of worker, but doesn't save any food, so scores zero and stays at the bottom of the leaderboard.

Comment: @Dave They submitted a competing entry to this challenge ...

Comment: I ran another game and this player gathered food and didn't score zero so maybe it was just unfortunate in the first game.

Comment: Yah, this player sometimes wastes all of its food, as it gets confused by Roman ants

Comment: Update: Now hoards three food, which should place it above some of the other bad ant strategies some of the time and not simply fall all the way to the bottom

Comment: Second update: no longer hoards food at beginning, instead starts collecting food instead of sabotaging later

Comment: I just realized that this answer is technically subject to deletion for not being a serious contender for the winning criteria. However, given that this was essentially a cornerstone of the challenge, deleting it wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 8):

## Hyperwave

*All of my answers will contain similar low-level logic in the form of the Formic Functions Framework. "HIGH-LEVEL LOGIC STARTS HERE" marks the end of the Framework's code.*

```js
 //  FORMIC FRAMEWORK  //
// Version 6.1.10     //
const WHITE = 1;
const QUEEN = 5;
const CENTER = 4;
const HERE = view[CENTER];
const ME = HERE.ant;
const ORTHOGONALS = [1, 3, 5, 7];
const DIAGONALS = [0, 2, 6, 8];
const DIAGONALS_ORTHOGONALS = [0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7];
const DIRECTIONS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS = [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3];
const CELLS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const ROTATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2,
   3, 4, 5,
   6, 7, 8],

  [6, 3, 0,
   7, 4, 1,
   8, 5, 2],

  [8, 7, 6,
   5, 4, 3,
   2, 1, 0],

  [2, 5, 8,
   1, 4, 7,
   0, 3, 6]
];
const NEIGHBORS = [
  [1, 4, 3],
  [2, 5, 4, 3, 0],
  [5, 4, 1],
  [0, 1, 4, 7, 6],
  [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3],
  [8, 7, 4, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 7],
  [6, 3, 4, 5, 8],
  [7, 4, 5]
];
const HORIZONTAL_FLIP = [2, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6];
const VERTICAL_FLIP = [6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2];

const DEBUG_MODE = true;
function dump() {
  if (DEBUG_MODE) {
    throw "dump() not implemented";
  }
}
function log(...args) {
  if (DEBUG_MODE) {
    console.log(...args);
  }
}
function error(...args) {
  log("Transformed view state:", view);
  log(...args);
  throw "A critical error has occurred!";
}

function createArray(func, length) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr.push(func(i, arr));
  }
  return arr;
}

class Test {
  run(cell) {
    error("No run method defined for this instance of Test:", this);
  }
  find(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.find((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  findIndex(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.findIndex((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  filter(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.filter((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  every(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.every((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  some(cells = CELLS) {
    return cells.some((c) => this.run(c));
  }
  count(cells = CELLS) {
    return this.filter(cells).length;
  }
  invert() {
    return new InverseTest(this);
  }
  and(test) {
    return new EveryTest(this, test);
  }
  or(test) {
    return new SomeTest(this, test);
  }
}

class InverseTest extends Test {
  constructor(test) {
    super();
    this.test = test;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return !this.test.run(cell);
  }
  invert() {
    return this.test;
  }
}

class CombinedTest extends Test {
  constructor(...tests) {
    super();
    this.tests = tests;
  }
  append(test) {
    this.tests.push(test);
    return this;
  }
}
class EveryTest extends CombinedTest {
  run(cell) {
    return this.tests.every((test) => test.run(cell));
  }
  and(test) {
    return this.append(test);
  }
}
class SomeTest extends CombinedTest {
  run(cell) {
    return this.tests.some((test) => test.run(cell));
  }
  or(test) {
    return this.append(test);
  }
}

class ColorTest extends Test {
  constructor(color) {
    super();
    this.color = color;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return view[cell].color === this.color;
  }
}
class ColorBandTest extends SomeTest {
  constructor(colorBand) {
    super(...colorBand.map((color) => new ColorTest(color)));
  }
}

class FoodTest extends Test {
  constructor(hasFood = true) {
    super();
    this.food = hasFood ? 1 : 0;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return view[cell].food === this.food;
  }
}

class AntTest extends Test {
  constructor(friend, type, food) {
    super();
    this.friend = friend;
    this.type = type;
    this.food = food;
  }
  run(cell) {
    const ant = view[cell].ant;
    return ant !== null && (this.type === undefined || ant.type === this.type) && (this.friend === undefined || ant.friend === this.friend) && (this.food === undefined || (this.food ? ant.food > 0 : ant.food === 0));
  }
}

class NeighborTest extends Test {
  constructor(test) {
    super();
    this.test = test;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return this.test.some(NEIGHBORS[cell]);
  }
}

class MatchTest extends Test {
  constructor(matches) {
    super();
    this.matches = matches;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return this.matches[cell];
  }
}

class CustomTest extends Test {
  constructor(func, ...args) {
    super();
    this.func = func;
    this.args = args;
  }
  run(cell) {
    return this.func(cell, ...this.args);
  }
}

class Action {
  constructor(cell, test) {
    this.cell = cell;
    this.test = test;
  }

  valid() {
    return this.cell >= 0 && this.cell < 9 && (!this.test || this.test.run(this.cell));
  }
  attempt() {
    return this.valid() ? this : null;
  }
  static tryAll(...actions) {
    return actions.find((action) => action instanceof this && action.valid()) || null;
  }
}
class Move extends Action {
  constructor(cell, test) {
    super(cell, test);
  }

  valid() {
    return super.valid() && view[this.cell].ant === null && (view[this.cell].food === 0 || ME.food === 0 || ME.type === QUEEN);
  }
  static many(cells, test) {
    return cells.map((cell) => new this(cell, test));
  }
}
class Paint extends Action {
  constructor(cell, color, test) {
    super(cell, test);
    this.color = color;
  }

  valid() {
    return super.valid() && view[this.cell].color !== this.color && this.color >= 1 && this.color <= 8;
  }
  static many(cells, colors, test) {
    return cells.map((cell, i) => new this(cell, colors[i % colors.length], test));
  }
}
class Spawn extends Action {
  constructor(cell, type, test) {
    super(cell, test);
    this.type = type;
  }

  valid() {
    return super.valid() && view[this.cell].ant === null && view[this.cell].food === 0 && ME.food > 0 && ME.type === QUEEN && this.type >= 1 && this.type <= 4;
  }
  static many(cells, type, test) {
    return cells.map((cell, i) => new this(cell, type, test));
  }
}
class NOP extends Action {
  constructor() {
    super(CENTER);
  }

  valid() {
    return true;
  }
}

class Context {
  apply(func, ...args) {
    const hiddenView = view;
    if (this.viewTranslator) {
      view = this.viewTranslator(hiddenView);
    }

    let output = func(...args);
    if (output instanceof Action && this.outputTranslator) {
      this.outputTranslator(output);
    }

    view = hiddenView;
    return output;
  }
}

class TranslationContext extends Context {
  constructor(translationArray) {
    super();
    this.translationArray = translationArray;
  }

  viewTranslator(oldView) {
    const newView = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      newView.push(oldView[this.translationArray[i]]);
    }
    return newView;
  }

  outputTranslator(out) {
    out.cell = this.translationArray[out.cell];
  }
}
class RotationContext extends TranslationContext {
  constructor(orientation) {
    super(ROTATIONS[orientation]);
    this.orientation = orientation;
  }
}
class OffsetContext extends TranslationContext {
  constructor(centerCell) {
    throw "OffsetContext not implemented";
  }
}
class HorizontalReflectionContext extends TranslationContext {
  constructor() {
    super(HORIZONTAL_FLIP);
  }
}
class VerticalReflectionContext extends TranslationContext {
  constructor() {
    super(VERTICAL_FLIP);
  }
}

class ColorMapContext extends Context {
  constructor(map, unmap) {
    super();
    this.map = map;
    this.unmap = unmap;
  }

  viewTranslator(oldView) {
    return oldView.map((cell) => ({color: this.map[cell.color - 1], food: cell.food, ant: cell.ant}));
  }

  outputTranslator(out) {
    out.color = this.unmap[out.color - 1];
  }
}

class XY {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  static fromTuples(...xyTuples) {
    return xyTuples.map((xy) => new this(xy[0], xy[1]));
  }
}

class WrapProperties {
  constructor(horizontal, vertical, size, wrapOffsets) {
    this.horizontal = !!horizontal;
    this.vertical = !!vertical;
    this.size = size;
    this.wrapOffsets = wrapOffsets || {};
  }
}

class ScoredTest {
  constructor(test, score = 1) {
    this.test = test;
    this.score = score;
  }

  run(cell) {
    return this.test.run(cell) ? this.score : 0;
  }
}

class Environment {
  constructor(tests, wrapping) {
    this.tests = tests.map((test) => test instanceof Test ? new ScoredTest(test) : test);
    this.wrapping = wrapping;
  }

  at(x, y) {
    const w = this.wrapping;
    while ((w.horizontal && (x < 0 || x >= w.size.x)) || (w.vertical && (y < 0 || y >= w.size.y))) {
      if (w.horizontal) {
        if (x < 0) {
          x += w.size.x;
          y += w.wrapOffsets.left || 0;
        } else if (x >= w.size.x) {
          x -= w.size.x;
          y += w.wrapOffsets.right || 0;
        }
      }

      if (w.vertical) {
        if (y < 0) {
          y += w.size.y;
          x += w.wrapOffsets.up || 0;
        } else if (y >= w.size.y) {
          y -= w.size.y;
          x += w.wrapOffsets.down || 0;
        }
      }
    }

    if ((!w.horizontal || (x >= 0 && x < w.size.x)) && (!w.vertical || (y >= 0 || y < w.size.y))) {
      return this.tests[x + y * w.size.x];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  around(x, y) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let oy = -1; oy <= 1; oy++) {
      for (let ox = -1; ox <= 1; ox++) {
        arr.push(this.at(x + ox, y + oy));
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }

  detect(...positions) {
    return createArray((i) => new RotationContext(i), 4).reduce((best, context) => {
      const next = context.apply(() => {
        return positions.reduce((best, pos, i) => {
          let score = 0;
          const matches = this.around(pos.x, pos.y).map((test, i) => {
            if (test && (test.test instanceof Test)) {
              const result = test.run(i);
              if (result) {
                score += result;
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          });
          if (score > best.score) {
            return {position: pos, positionIndex: i, orientation: context.orientation, environment: this, matches: matches, score: score, confidence: score - best.score};
          } else {
            best.confidence = Math.min(best.score - score, best.confidence);
            return best;
          }
        }, {position: positions[0], positionIndex: 0, orientation: 0, environment: this, matches: [], score: 0, confidence: 0});
      });
      if (next.score > best.score) {
        next.confidence = next.score - best.score;
        return next;
      } else {
        best.confidence = Math.min(best.score - next.score, best.confidence);
        return best;
      }
    }, {position: positions[0], positionIndex: 0, orientation: 0, environment: this, matches: [], score: 0, confidence: 0});
  }

  static chooseBest(...detectionResults) {
    const r = detectionResults.reduce((best, result, i) => {
      if (result.score > best.score) {
        result.index = i;
        result.confidence = result.score - best.score;
        return result;
      } else {
        best.confidence = Math.min(best.score - result.score, best.confidence);
        return best;
      }
    });
    r.index = r.index || 0;
    return r;
  }
}

class ColoredEnvironment extends Environment {
  constructor(colors, wrapping) {
    super(colors.map((color) => new ColorTest(color)), wrapping);
  }

  getPainter(detectionResult) {
    return new (class Painter {
      constructor(loc) {
        this.pos = loc.position;
        this.matches = loc.matches;
        this.colors = loc.environment.around(this.pos.x, this.pos.y).map((test) => test && test.test instanceof ColorTest ? test.test.color : null);
        this.test = new MatchTest(loc.matches).invert();
        this.orient = loc.orientation;
      }

      paint(...cells) {
        return cells.map((cell) => new Paint(cell, this.colors[cell], this.test));
      }
      cleanup(eraseColor, eraseTargets, ...cells) {
        const eraseQual = this.test.and(new ColorBandTest(eraseTargets));
        return cells.map((cell) => new Paint(cell, eraseColor, eraseQual));
      }
    })(detectionResult);
  }
}

// HIGH-LEVEL LOGIC STARTS HERE //
// TODO:
// - more food checkpoints (no disadvantages because it's illogical for WFW to "premanently lose" workers)
// - randomly shifting 1 up (5% chance? watch out for hoarding stealing your randomness!)
// - randomly skip painting a tiny bit of local cells (prevent deadlock against ants outside of view)
// - escape routine when situation is dire (many workers near the queen/partner)

const COLOR_BAND = [4, 7, 3, 2, 8];

const PARTNER = 2;
const WORKER = 1;

const START_FOOD = 6;
const MIN_CONFIDENCE = 2;

const PATTERN = new ColoredEnvironment(COLOR_BAND, new WrapProperties(true, true, new XY(COLOR_BAND.length, 1), {up: 2, down: -2})).detect(...createArray((i) => new XY(i, 0), COLOR_BAND.length));

function checkpoint(val, tolerance) {
  return ME.food >= val - tolerance && ME.food <= val;
}
function shouldSpawn() {
  return PATTERN.orientation === 0 && PATTERN.positionIndex % 3 === 0 &&
    ME.food < 400 &&
    (ME.food < 75 || PATTERN.positionIndex === 0) && 
    !checkpoint(300, 4) &&
    !checkpoint(200, 5) &&
    !checkpoint(160, 3) &&
    !checkpoint(130, 2) &&
    !checkpoint(100, 2) &&
    !checkpoint(75, 2) &&
    !checkpoint(50, 2) &&
    !checkpoint(35, 1) &&
    !checkpoint(20, 1) &&
    !checkpoint(10, 0);
}

function lightspeed() {
  // TODO: Do a 180 when 3 workers are in front of us
  function logicOrthogonal(frontC, sideC, backC, backCells, moveCells) {
    const a = [frontC, sideC, backC, backCells, moveCells];
    const f = new FoodTest;
    return Action.tryAll(
      ...Move.many([frontC, sideC], f),
      f.some(backCells) ? new Move(backC) : null,
      ...Move.many(moveCells),
      new NOP
    );
  }
  function logicDiagonal(adjacentC) {
    return Action.tryAll(...Move.many(adjacentC), new NOP);
  }
  function logic(partnerTest, partnerOrthC, partnerDiagC, frontC, sideC, backC, backCells, moveCells, adjacentC) {
    function detectEnv(c) {
      return new Environment(createArray((i) => i === c ? partnerTest : undefined, 9), new WrapProperties(false, false, new XY(3, 3), null)).detect(new XY(1, 1));
    }
    const orth = detectEnv(partnerOrthC);
    const diag = detectEnv(partnerDiagC);
    return orth.score === 1 ? new RotationContext(orth.orientation).apply(() => logicOrthogonal(frontC, sideC, backC, backCells, moveCells)) : 
      diag.score === 1 ? new RotationContext(diag.orientation).apply(() => logicDiagonal(adjacentC)) : 
      error("How did we get here?");
  }

  if (ME.type === QUEEN) {
    const partner = new AntTest(true, PARTNER);
    if (partner.some(DIRECTIONS)) {
      return logic(partner, 5, 8, 2, 1, 7, [0, 3, 6, 7], [2, 7, 1, 8], [5, 7]);
    } else {
      const COLOR = 5;
      const bgTest = new ColorTest(WHITE);
      if (bgTest.run(CENTER)) {
        return new Paint(CENTER, COLOR).attempt() || error("Something went terribly wrong while painting own cell");
      }

      const food = new FoodTest().find(DIRECTIONS);
      if (food !== undefined) {
        return new Move(food);
      }

      const det = new ColoredEnvironment([
        WHITE, WHITE, WHITE, 
        WHITE, undefined, undefined,
        WHITE, undefined, COLOR
      ], new WrapProperties(false, false, new XY(3, 3))).detect(new XY(1, 1));
      return (ME.food > 0 ? Action.tryAll(...Spawn.many(ORTHOGONALS, PARTNER)) : null) ||
        (det.score === 6 ? new RotationContext(det.orientation).apply(() => Action.tryAll(...Move.many([0, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8]))) : null) ||
        Action.tryAll(...Move.many(DIAGONALS_ORTHOGONALS), new NOP);
    }
  } else {
    return logic(new AntTest(true, QUEEN), 1, 0, 2, 5, 3, [8, 7, 6, 3], [2, 3, 5, 0], [1, 3]);
  }
}

function queen() {
  const partnerTest = new AntTest(true, PARTNER);
  if (PATTERN.confidence < MIN_CONFIDENCE && (ME.food < START_FOOD || partnerTest.some(DIAGONALS))) return lightspeed();
  return new RotationContext(PATTERN.orientation).apply(() => {
    const partnerCell = new AntTest(true, PARTNER).find(DIRECTIONS);
    const p = PATTERN.environment.getPainter(PATTERN);
    const e = new AntTest(false);
    const enemy = e.some(DIRECTIONS);
    return Action.tryAll(
      ...!PATTERN.matches[8] ? [
        ...!enemy ? [...p.paint(7, 4, 5, 1, 2), ...shouldSpawn() && PATTERN.score === 8 ? Spawn.many([0, 2], WORKER) : []] : [],
        ...partnerCell === 1 ? Move.many(e.run(5) ? [0, 2] : PATTERN.orientation === 1 && PATTERN.positionIndex % 3 === 1 ? [2, 0, 5] : [5, 2, 0]) : 
          partnerCell === 0 ? Move.many(e.run(1) ? [3] : enemy ? [1, 3] : []) :
          partnerCell === 2 ? Move.many(e.run(1) ? [5] : []) :
          []
      ] : [
        ...!enemy ? p.paint(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0) : [],
        ...Move.many(partnerCell === 1 ? [2, 0] : partnerCell === 0 ? [1, 3] : partnerCell === 2 && e.run(1) ? [5] : [])
      ],
      new NOP
    )
  });
}
function partner() {
  const queenTest = new AntTest(true, QUEEN)
  const queenCell = queenTest.find(DIRECTIONS);
  if (queenCell === undefined) {
    return new NOP; // TODO: What do we do if we've lost our queen?
  }
  if (PATTERN.confidence < MIN_CONFIDENCE && (view[queenCell].ant.food < START_FOOD || DIAGONALS.includes(queenCell))) return lightspeed();
  return PATTERN.confidence >= MIN_CONFIDENCE ? new RotationContext(PATTERN.orientation).apply(() => {
    const queenCell = queenTest.find(DIRECTIONS);
    const e = new AntTest(false);
    const enemy = e.some(DIRECTIONS);
    return Action.tryAll(
      ...!enemy ? PATTERN.environment.getPainter(PATTERN).paint(...CELLS) : [],
      ...Move.many([
        [1],
        [0, 2],
        [1],
        [0, 1],
        [], // Queen can't be on cell 4 - I'm here, after all!
        [2, 1],
        [3],
        [],
        [5]
      ][queenCell]),
      new NOP
    )
  }) : new NOP;
}
function worker() {
  const m = new MatchTest(PATTERN.matches);
  const n = m.invert();
  const u = new AntTest(true, WORKER, false);
  const l = new AntTest(true, WORKER, true);
  const q = new AntTest(true, QUEEN);
  const pt = new AntTest(true, PARTNER);
  const p = PATTERN.environment.getPainter(PATTERN);
  return new RotationContext(PATTERN.orientation).apply(() => { // TODO: Unique (random?) behavior when confidence low
    if (ME.food === 0) {
      const f = new FoodTest();
      const count = n.count([6, 7, 8]);
      return Action.tryAll(
        ...PATTERN.confidence >= 2 ? p.paint(4, 0, 1, 2) : [],
        //...p.cleanup(WHITE, COLOR_BAND, ...CELLS),
        ...((food) => food !== undefined ? [...p.paint(...NEIGHBORS[food], food), new Move(food)] : [])(f.find(DIRECTIONS)),
        ...q.or(pt).some(DIRECTIONS) || u.some([6, 7, 8, 5, 2]) ? Move.many([0, 1, 3], m) : [],
        ...count > 1 ? p.paint(...[6, 7, 8]) : [],
        ...count === 1 ? [...p.paint(...[3, 5]), ...Move.many([7, 8, 6, 3], m)] : [],
        /*n.run(6) ? new Move(3, m) : null,
        ...n.run(7) ? Move.many([6, 3], m) : [],
        n.run(8) ? new Move(7, m) : null,*/
        n.run(5) ? new Move(5) : null,
        ...Move.many([2, 1, 0, 3], m),
        new NOP
        /*
        ...(PATTERN.confidence >= 2 ? [...(PATTERN.score < 8 || new AntTest(false).some(DIRECTIONS) ? p.paint(4, 3, 0, 1, 2, 5) : []), ...p.cleanup(WHITE, COLOR_BAND, ...CELLS)] : []),
        ...((food) => food !== undefined ? [...p.paint(...NEIGHBORS[food]), new Move(food)] : [])(f.find(DIRECTIONS)), ...(
          w ? Move.many([1, 0, 2]) :
          m.some([4, 3]) ? p.paint(4, 3) :
          m.some([0, 1, 2]) ? Move.many([1, 5]) :
          m.run(6) ? [new Move(3)] :
          m.run(7) ? Move.many([6, 3]) :
          m.run(8) ? [new Move(7)] :
          m.run(5) ? Move.many([5, 7]) :
          Move.many([2, 1, 5])
        )
        new NOP*/
      );
    } else {
      return Action.tryAll(
        //...Move.many(new AntTest(true, WORKER).some([2, 5, 8, 7]) || PATTERN.score < 9 ? [8, 7, 6, 3] : [5, 8, 2], m.invert()),
        ...((test) => createArray((i) => new Move(CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS[(6 - i) % 8], test), 5))(new CustomTest((cell, moveTest, blockTest) => {
          const i = CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS.findIndex((c) => c === cell);
          return moveTest.run(CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS[i]) && blockTest.run(CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS[((i - 1) + 8) % 8]);
        }, m, n.or(new AntTest().and(l.invert())))),
        ...Move.many([2, 5, 1, 8], m),
        //...Move.many([...(PATTERN.score === 9 && !new AntTest(true, WORKER).some(DIRECTIONS) ? [2] : []), 5, 8, 7, 6, 3], m),
        new NOP
      );
    }
  });
}

switch (ME.type) {
  case QUEEN: {
    return queen();
  }
  case PARTNER: {
    return partner();
  }
  case WORKER: {
    return worker();
  }
}
```

---

#### I have temporarily removed all description of this entry because of time pressure. I will add a thorough description of this major update at a later date.

---

## Changelog

#### Version 1.0

- initial release

#### Version 2.0

- replaced Highway with Hyperwave

#### Version 2.0.1

- hotfixed hoarding mechanism

Comment: This one starts out beautiful to watch, then turns terrifying...

Comment: Time to enact the vampiric edict against roads.

Comment: And I'm only going to be feeding the Vampire more as time goes on @Draco18s - there are lots of improvements I wish to make.

Comment: First entry I've seen which can entirely subsume the board within the standard game time. Very impressive.

Comment: One of the longest answers I've ever seen, but worth it - this is crazy!

Answer (score 7):

## Roman Ants Mk.2

*All my answers are sharing the same set of low-level helper functions.
 Search for "High-level logic begins here" to see the code specific to this answer.*

```js
// == Shared low-level helpers for all solutions ==

var QUEEN = 5;

var WHITE = 1;
var COL_MIN = WHITE;
var COL_LIM = 9;

var CENTRE = 4;

var NOP = {cell: CENTRE};

var DIR_FORWARDS = false;
var DIR_REVERSE = true;
var SIDE_RIGHT = true;
var SIDE_LEFT = false;

function sanity_check(movement) {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  if(!movement || movement.cell < 0 || movement.cell > 8) {
    return false;
  }
  if(movement.type) {
    if(movement.color) {
      return false;
    }
    if(movement.type < 1 || movement.type > 4) {
      return false;
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].ant || view[movement.cell].food) {
      return false;
    }
    if(me.type !== QUEEN || me.food < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if(movement.color) {
    if(movement.color < COL_MIN || movement.color >= COL_LIM) {
      return false;
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].color === movement.color) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if(view[movement.cell].ant) {
    return false;
  }
  if(view[movement.cell].food + me.food > 1 && me.type !== QUEEN) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function as_array(o) {
  if(Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o;
  }
  return [o];
}

function best_of(movements) {
  var m;
  for(var i = 0; i < movements.length; ++ i) {
    if(typeof(movements[i]) === 'function') {
      m = movements[i]();
    } else {
      m = movements[i];
    }
    if(sanity_check(m)) {
      return m;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function play_safe(movement) {
  // Avoid disqualification: no-op if moves are invalid
  return best_of(as_array(movement)) || NOP;
}

var RAND_SEED = (() => {
  var s = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    s += view[i].color * (i + 1);
    s += view[i].ant ? i * i : 0;
    s += view[i].food ? i * i * i : 0;
  }
  return s % 29;
})();

var ROTATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [6, 3, 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2],
  [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 6],
];

function try_all(fns, limit, wrapperFn, checkFn) {
  var m;
  fns = as_array(fns);
  for(var i = 0; i < fns.length; ++ i) {
    if(typeof(fns[i]) !== 'function') {
      if(checkFn(m = fns[i])) {
        return m;
      }
      continue;
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < limit; ++ j) {
      if(checkFn(m = wrapperFn(fns[i], j))) {
        return m;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function identify_rotation(testFns) {
  // testFns MUST be functions, not constants
  return try_all(
    testFns,
    4,
    (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]) ? ROTATIONS[r] : null,
    (r) => r
  );
}

function near(a, b) {
  return (
    Math.abs(a % 3 - b % 3) < 2 &&
    Math.abs(Math.floor(a / 3) - Math.floor(b / 3)) < 2
  );
}

function try_all_angles(solverFns) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    4,
    (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function try_all_cells(solverFns, skipCentre) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    9,
    (fn, i) => ((i === CENTRE && skipCentre) ? null : fn(i)),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function try_all_cells_near(p, solverFns) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    9,
    (fn, i) => ((i !== p && near(p, i)) ? fn(i) : null),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function ant_type_at(i, friend) {
  return (view[i].ant && view[i].ant.friend === friend) ? view[i].ant.type : 0;
}

function friend_at(i) {
  return ant_type_at(i, true);
}

function foe_at(i) {
  return ant_type_at(i, false);
}

function foe_near(p) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    if(foe_at(i) && near(i, p)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function move_agent(agents) {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  var buddies = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    ++ buddies[friend_at(i)];
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < agents.length; i += 2) {
    if(agents[i] === me.type) {
      return agents[i+1](me, buddies);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function grab_nearby_food() {
  return try_all_cells((i) => (view[i].food ? {cell: i} : null), true);
}

function go_anywhere() {
  return try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i}), true);
}

function colours_excluding(cols) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = COL_MIN; i < COL_LIM; ++ i) {
    if(cols.indexOf(i) === -1) {
      r.push(i);
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function generate_band(start, width) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < width; ++ i) {
    r.push(start + i);
  }
  return r;
}

function colour_band(colours) {
  return {
    contains: function(c) {
      return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1;
    },
    next: function(c) {
      return colours[(colours.indexOf(c) + 1) % colours.length];
    }
  };
}

function random_colour_band(colours) {
  return {
    contains: function(c) {
      return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1;
    },
    next: function() {
      return colours[RAND_SEED % colours.length];
    }
  };
}

function fast_diagonal(colourBand) {
  var m = try_all_angles([
    // Avoid nearby checked areas
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[5]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[0]};
      }
    },

    // Go in a straight diagonal line if possible
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[8]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[0]};
      }
    },

    // When in doubt, pick randomly but avoid doubling-back
    (rot) => (colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) ? null : {cell: rot[0]}),

    // Double-back when absolutely necessary
    (rot) => ({cell: rot[0]})
  ]);

  // Lay a colour track so that we can avoid doubling-back
  // (and mess up our foes as much as possible)
  if(!colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)) {
    var prevCol = m ? view[8-m.cell].color : WHITE;
    return {cell: CENTRE, color: colourBand.next(prevCol)};
  }

  return m;
}

function follow_edge(obstacleFn, side) {
  // Since we don't know which direction we came from, this can cause us to get
  // stuck on islands, but the random orientation helps to ensure we don't get
  // stuck forever.

  var order = ((side === SIDE_LEFT)
    ? [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0]
    : [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 0]
  );
  return try_all(
    [obstacleFn],
    order.length - 1,
    (fn, i) => (fn(order[i+1]) && !fn(order[i])) ? {cell: order[i]} : null,
    sanity_check
  );
}

function start_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => ((
      !protectedCols.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color)
    )
      ? {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3], color: colourBand.next(WHITE)}
      : null)
  ]);
}

function lay_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => {
      var ahead = rot[right ? 2 : 0];
      var behind = rot[right ? 8 : 6];
      if(
        colourBand.contains(view[behind].color) &&
        !protectedCols.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: ahead, color: colourBand.next(view[behind].color)};
      }
    }
  ]);
}

function follow_dotted_path(colourBand, side, direction) {
  var forwards = (direction === DIR_REVERSE) ? 7 : 1;
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);

  return try_all_angles([
    // Cell on our side? advance
    (rot) => {
      if(
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
        // Prevent sticking / trickery
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[2]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[forwards]};
      }
    },

    // Cell ahead and behind? advance
    (rot) => {
      var passedCol = view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color;
      var nextCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        colourBand.contains(passedCol) &&
        nextCol === colourBand.next(passedCol) &&

        // Prevent sticking / trickery
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 0 : 2]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[forwards]};
      }
    }
  ]);
}

function escape_dotted_path(colourBand, side, newColourBand) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  if(!newColourBand) {
    newColourBand = colourBand;
  }

  return try_all_angles([
    // Escape from beside the line
    (rot) => {
      var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color) ||
        !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
      ) {
        // not oriented, or in a corner
        return null;
      }
      return best_of([
        {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2], color: newColourBand.next(approachingCol)},
        {cell: rot[right ? 3 : 5]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 6 : 8]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 2 : 0]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 8 : 6]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]}
      ]);
    },

    // Escape from inside the line
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      return best_of([
        {cell: rot[3]},
        {cell: rot[5]},
        {cell: rot[0]},
        {cell: rot[2]},
        {cell: rot[6]},
        {cell: rot[8]}
      ]);
    }
  ]);
}

function latch_to_dotted_path(colourBand, side) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);

  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => {
      var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        colourBand.contains(approachingCol) &&
        view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color === colourBand.next(approachingCol) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color)
      ) {
        // We're on the wrong side; go inside the line
        return {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]};
      }
    },

    // Inside the line? pick a side
    (rot) => {
      var passedCol = view[rot[7]].color;
      var approachingCol = view[rot[1]].color;
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(passedCol) ||
        !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      if((approachingCol === colourBand.next(passedCol)) === right) {
        return best_of([{cell: rot[3]}, {cell: rot[6]}, {cell: rot[0]}]);
      } else {
        return best_of([{cell: rot[5]}, {cell: rot[2]}, {cell: rot[8]}]);
      }
    }
  ]);
}


// == High-level logic begins here ==


var QUEEN_COL = colour_band(generate_band(3, 3));
var WORKER_COL = colour_band(generate_band(6, 3));
var AVOID_COL = colour_band([2]);
var INVERT_COL = colour_band([WHITE, 2]);

var MIN_FOOD = 5;
var MAX_WORKER_FOOD = 10;

function decide() {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  var queen = me.type === QUEEN;

  if(queen && me.food > MIN_FOOD && me.food < MAX_WORKER_FOOD) {
    var m = try_all_cells((i) => {
      if(view[i].food && !foe_near(i)) {
        // Try to spawn a worker next to the food;
        // the worker will pick up the food on the next turn
        return try_all_cells_near(i, (j) => ({cell: j, type: 1}));
      }
    }, true);
    if(sanity_check(m)) {
      return m;
    }
  }

  if(!queen && me.food) {
    return best_of([
      // Look for queen
      follow_dotted_path.bind(null, QUEEN_COL, SIDE_RIGHT, DIR_FORWARDS),
      latch_to_dotted_path.bind(null, QUEEN_COL, SIDE_RIGHT),

      // Failed to find queen's trail; try following worker trails backwards
      follow_dotted_path.bind(null, WORKER_COL, SIDE_RIGHT, DIR_REVERSE),
      latch_to_dotted_path.bind(null, WORKER_COL, SIDE_RIGHT),

      // Failed to find any trail; cover ground as quickly as possible
      fast_diagonal.bind(null, AVOID_COL)
    ]);
  }

  var myCol = queen ? QUEEN_COL : WORKER_COL;
  return best_of([
    grab_nearby_food,

    // Disperse workers away from queen
    !queen && escape_dotted_path.bind(null, QUEEN_COL, SIDE_RIGHT, WORKER_COL),

    // Follow our own path
    follow_dotted_path.bind(null, myCol, SIDE_RIGHT, DIR_FORWARDS),

    // If our path looks suspicious, it could have wrapped; try to escape it
    escape_dotted_path.bind(null, myCol, SIDE_RIGHT),

    // Explore
    // Laying a path causes us to move at 2/3 c, so workers can catch up.
    lay_dotted_path.bind(null, myCol, SIDE_RIGHT, QUEEN_COL),
    start_dotted_path.bind(null, myCol, SIDE_RIGHT, QUEEN_COL),

    // Fall-back to white dots if we're inside a colour block
    lay_dotted_path.bind(null, myCol, SIDE_RIGHT, INVERT_COL),
    start_dotted_path.bind(null, myCol, SIDE_RIGHT, INVERT_COL),

    // Stuck for some reason; try to escape
    fast_diagonal.bind(null, AVOID_COL)
  ]);
}

return play_safe([
  decide,

  // No valid moves; try to find *anywhere* we can go.
  go_anywhere,

  // Try changing a nearby cell's colour for the heck of it.
  {cell: 1, color: view[1].color % 8 + 1}
]);
```

Roman ants like to build roads, straight and fast. Because they build dotted roads, they are able to move at 2/3 the speed of light! Their roads also use cycling colours so that they know whether they're following the road forwards or in reverse, and the worker ants use a different set of colours than the queen (workers start getting spawned once the queen has a non-embarrassing amount of food available). Put together, this means that once a worker ant finds food, it can trace its own path backwards then trace the queen's path forwards to return the food (while tracing a path the ants move at the speed of light).

If you're wondering how the ants are able to follow a dotted line despite only being able to see a 3x3 grid at any time and not knowing their own direction: they draw the line to their right, not on their actual line of travel. So if (for example) the ant sees a filled square to the North, it knows the path must be above it, which means the direction of travel must be West (to keep the path on the right). If the ant sees a filled square to the North-East but not to the North-West or South-East, it must have gone past the end of the line, so paints the cell to the North-West and travels West. There's more complication around switching direction once food has been found, but that's the gist of it.

One other point worth mentioning is that when a worker ant sees food, they will jump at the opportunity to grab it without thinking about how they'll get back home (after all, an enemy ant could be ready to grab it!). So if a worker ant ever gets lost while carrying food, it will switch behaviour to a random-walk-ish pattern, leaving a yellow trail behind it to avoid retracing its steps. This helps the ants rediscover their trails and introduces enough randomness to avoid some of the infinite-loops which can otherwise occur.

It doesn't perform amazingly, and the ants have a habit of re-tracing their own footsteps (they're dumb enough not to know whether the path they're following is an old one, or one which they are in the process of drawing!), which occasionally leads to infinite loops.

Finally, there's a sanity checking method applied to any output which makes sure this can't get disqualified (hopefully!)

---

The updated version switches out the random walking for fast diagonal travel, fixes a bunch of bugs, and adds some attempts at walking using white roads if any ant gets stuck inside a large coloured area. Most of the bugs were found while converting it to use a high-level-thinking / low-level-abilities separation.

Comment: (here's one I prepared while this was in [beta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13324/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest))

Comment: For a rough order-of-magnitude: I just ran this and got 30 food + 6 worker ants. That's about consistent with the numbers I saw while developing it.

Comment: That's a neat trick leaving gaps in the road for a 50% speed boost. Also means the roads are hard to spot at first - took me a while to find your ant... But it easily outperforms the example players, especially once the workers start returning. Some of the workers end up building expanses of yellow and white checkerboard pattern - not sure if that's part of the plan?

Comment: @trichoplax oops; I forgot to put that in the explanation (forgot they did that!). I've updated the explanation. In short: it is part of the plan, but it's not a great plan.

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 7):

## Monorail

Still a work in progress, but I want to push something out now just because I'm paranoid that the competition will end before I finish otherwise.

```
var c0=5 //red
var c1=4 //cyan
var c2=6 //green
var c3=3 //magenta
var c4=7 //blue
var c5=8 //black
var c6=2 //yellow
var cN=1 //white

var ws=4 //support
var wb=3 //bodyguard
var wg=1 //gather
var wq=5 //queen

var v=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [6, 3, 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2],
       [2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 6]]

var x1=[0,2,6,8]
var x2=[8,6,2,0]

var r1=[1,7,3,5]
var r2=[5,3,7,1]

switch(view[4].ant.type)
{
 case 5: return queen()
 case 4: return support()
 case 3: return bodyguard()
 case 1: return gather()
 default: return {cell:4}
}

function queen()
{
 if(fAlly(ws)<0)
 {
  if(view[4].color==c1&&view[4].ant.food>0)
  {
   var o=findOrient(c1,c2,c3)
   if(sOpen(v[o][7])) return {cell:v[o][7],type:ws}
   return doThing()
  }
  else if(view[4].color==c0&&view[4].ant.food>=6)
  {
   var o=findOrient(c1,c2,c3)
   if(view[v[o][1]].color!=c1) return {cell:v[o][1],color:c1}
   if(view[v[o][0]].color!=c2) return {cell:v[o][0],color:c2}
   if(view[v[o][2]].color!=c3) return {cell:v[o][2],color:c3}
   if(sOpen(v[o][7])) return {cell:v[o][7],type:ws}
  }
  return wander(c0)
 }
 else
 {
  if(view[4].color==c0&&view[4].ant.food<7)
  {
   if(view[4].ant.food >=5)
   {
    var o=findOrient(c1,c2,c3)
    if(sOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1],type:wb}
    if(sOpen(v[o][0])) return {cell:v[o][0],type:wb}
    if(sOpen(v[o][2])) return {cell:v[o][2],type:wb}
   }
   if(view[4].ant.food>0)
   {
    var op=fOpen()
    if(op>=0) return {cell:op,type:wg}
   }
  }
  return doThing()
 }
}

function doThing()
{
 if(view[4].color!=c1) return {cell:4,color:c1}
 var o=findOrient(c1,c2,c3)
 if(view[4].ant.food>0&&fAlly(wg)>=0&&o==0)
 {
  var op=fOpen()
  if(op>=0) return {cell:op,type:wg}
 }
 if(view[v[o][1]].color!=c1&&pootis(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1],color:c1}
 if(view[v[o][0]].color!=c2&&pootis(v[o][0])) return {cell:v[o][0],color:c2}
 if(view[v[o][2]].color!=c3&&pootis(v[o][2])) return {cell:v[o][2],color:c3}
 if(mOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
 if(view[v[o][3]].color!=c2&&pootis(v[o][3])) return {cell:v[o][3],color:c2}
 if(view[v[o][5]].color!=c3&&pootis(v[o][5])) return {cell:v[o][5],color:c3}
 if(view[v[o][6]].color!=c2&&pootis(v[o][6])) return {cell:v[o][6],color:c2}
 if(view[v[o][8]].color!=c3&&pootis(v[o][8])) return {cell:v[o][8],color:c3}
 if(view[v[o][7]].color!=c1&&pootis(v[o][7])) return {cell:v[o][7],color:c1}
 return {cell:4}
}

function support()
{
 var o = findOrient(c1,c2,c3)
 var p = fAlly(wq)

 switch(p)
 {
  case v[o][0]:
   //if(mOpen(v[o][3])) return {cell:v[o][3]}
   //if(mOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
   break
  case v[o][1]:
   //if(view[v[o][0]].food&&mOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
   //if(view[v[o][2]].food&&mOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
   break
  case v[o][2]:
   //if(mOpen(v[o][5])) return {cell:v[o][5]}
   //if(mOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
   break
  case v[o][3]:
   //if(mOpen(v[o][6])) return {cell:v[o][6]}
   break
  case v[o][5]:
   //if(mOpen(v[o][8])) return {cell:v[o][8]}
   break
  case v[o][6]: break
  case v[o][7]: break
  case v[o][8]: break
  default:
   if(sOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
   break
 }
 return {cell:4}
}

function bodyguard()
{
 var o=0
 switch(view[4].color)
 {
  case c1: o=findOrient(c1,c2,c3);break
  case c2: o=findOrient(c2,c6,c1);break
  case c3: o=findOrient(c3,c1,c6);break
  default: return {cell:4}
 }
 var p = fAlly(wq)
 if(view[4].ant.food>0)
 {
  switch(p)
  {
   case v[o][0]:
    if(sOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(sOpen(v[o][3])) return {cell:v[o][3]}
    break
   case v[o][1]:
    if(sOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    break
   case v[o][2]:
    if(sOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(sOpen(v[o][5])) return {cell:v[o][5]}
    break
   case v[o][3]:
    if(sOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    break
   case v[o][5]:
    if(sOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    break
   case v[o][6]:
    if(sOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][3]])) return {cell:v[o][3]}
    break
   case v[o][7]:
    if(sOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    break
   case v[o][8]:
    if(sOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(sOpen([v[o][5]])) return {cell:v[o][5]}
    break
   default:
  }
 }
 else
 {
  switch(p)
  {
   case v[o][0]:
    if(mOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen(v[o][3])) return {cell:v[o][3]}
    break
   case v[o][1]:
    if(view[v[o][2]].food&&mOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    break
   case v[o][2]:
    if(mOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen(v[o][5])) return {cell:v[o][5]}
    break
   case v[o][3]:
    if(view[v[o][1]].food&&mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    break
   case v[o][5]:
    if(view[v[o][1]].food&&mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    break
   case v[o][6]:
    if(view[v[o][1]].food&&mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][3]])) return {cell:v[o][3]}
    break
   case v[o][7]:
    if(view[v[o][0]].food&&mOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(view[v[o][2]].food&&mOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][0]])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    break
   case v[o][8]:
    if(view[v[o][1]].food&&mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][2]])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][1]])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
    if(mOpen([v[o][5]])) return {cell:v[o][5]}
    break
   default:
  }
 }
 if(view[4].color==c1)
 {
  if(view[v[o][1]].color!=c1&&pootis(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1],color:c1}
  if(view[v[o][0]].color!=c2&&pootis(v[o][0])) return {cell:v[o][0],color:c2}
  if(view[v[o][2]].color!=c3&&pootis(v[o][2])) return {cell:v[o][2],color:c3}
  if(view[v[o][3]].color!=c2) return {cell:v[o][3],color:c2}
  if(view[v[o][5]].color!=c3) return {cell:v[o][5],color:c3}
  if(view[v[o][6]].color!=c2) return {cell:v[o][6],color:c2}
  if(view[v[o][8]].color!=c3) return {cell:v[o][8],color:c3}
  if(view[v[o][7]].color!=c1) return {cell:v[o][7],color:c1}
 }
 return {cell:4}
}

function gather()
{
 if(view[4].ant.food>0)
 {
  if(view[4].color==c1&&(testSQ(c1,c2)||testSQ(c1,c3))) return gDoThing(c1,c3,c2)
  if(view[4].color==c2&&testSQ(c2,c1)) return gDoThing(c2,c1,c6)
  if(view[4].color==c3&&testSQ(c3,c1)) return gDoThing(c3,c6,c1)
  return wander(c5)
 }
 var n=fAlly(wq)
 if(n<0) return wander(c4)
 switch(n)
 {
  case 0:
   if(mOpen(8)) return {cell:8}
   if(mOpen(7)) return {cell:7}
   if(mOpen(5)) return {cell:5}
   break
  case 1:
   if(mOpen(6)) return {cell:6}
   if(mOpen(8)) return {cell:8}
   if(mOpen(7)) return {cell:7}
   break
  case 2:
   if(mOpen(6)) return {cell:6}
   if(mOpen(3)) return {cell:3}
   if(mOpen(7)) return {cell:7}
   break
  case 3:
   if(mOpen(8)) return {cell:8}
   if(mOpen(2)) return {cell:2}
   if(mOpen(5)) return {cell:5}
   break
  case 5:
   if(mOpen(0)) return {cell:0}
   if(mOpen(6)) return {cell:6}
   if(mOpen(3)) return {cell:3}
   break
  case 6:
   if(mOpen(2)) return {cell:2}
   if(mOpen(5)) return {cell:5}
   if(mOpen(1)) return {cell:1}
   break
  case 7:
   if(mOpen(2)) return {cell:2}
   if(mOpen(0)) return {cell:0}
   if(mOpen(1)) return {cell:1}
   break
  case 8:
   if(mOpen(0)) return {cell:0}
   if(mOpen(1)) return {cell:1}
   if(mOpen(3)) return {cell:3}
   break
  default:
   break
 }
 return {cell:4}
}

function testSQ(ac1,ac2)
{
 for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  if(view[r1[i]].color==ac1)
  {
   if(view[v[i][0]].color==ac2&&view[v[i][3]].color==ac2) return 1
   if(view[v[i][2]].color==ac2&&view[v[i][5]].color==ac2) return 1
  }
 }
 return 0
}

function gDoThing(ac1,ac2,ac3)
{
 var o=findOrient(ac1,ac2,ac3)
 if(view[v[o][1]].color!=ac1&&pootis(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1],color:ac1}
 if(view[v[o][0]].color!=ac2&&pootis(v[o][0])) return {cell:v[o][0],color:ac2}
 if(view[v[o][2]].color!=ac3&&pootis(v[o][2])) return {cell:v[o][2],color:ac3}
 if(sOpen(v[o][1])) return {cell:v[o][1]}
 if(ac1==c2)
 {
  if(sOpen(v[o][0])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
  if(sOpen(v[o][3])) return {cell:v[o][3]}
  if(sOpen(v[o][6])) return {cell:v[o][6]}
 }
 else if(ac1==c3)
 {
  if(sOpen(v[o][2])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
  if(sOpen(v[o][5])) return {cell:v[o][5]}
  if(sOpen(v[o][8])) return {cell:v[o][8]}
 }
 else
 {
  if(sOpen(v[o][0])) return {cell:v[o][0]}
  if(sOpen(v[o][2])) return {cell:v[o][2]}
  if(sOpen(v[o][3])) return {cell:v[o][3]}
  if(sOpen(v[o][5])) return {cell:v[o][5]}
 }
 return {cell:4}
}

function pootis(p)
{
 var a=view[p].ant
 if(a!=null&&a.friend&&a.type==wg&&(view[p].color==c4||view[p].color==c5)) return 0
 return 1
}

function fAlly(t)
{
 var a=view[4].ant
 for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
 {
  if(i==4) i++
  a=view[i].ant
  if(a!=null&&a.friend&&a.type==t) return i
 }
 return -1
}

function fOpen()
{
 for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
 {
  if(i==4) i++
  if(sOpen(i)) return i
 }
 return -1
}

function sOpen(p)
{
 return (view[p].ant==null&&!view[p].food)
}

function mOpen(p)
{
 return (view[p].ant==null)
}

function wander(ac)
{
 if(view[4].ant.type==5||view[4].ant.food==0)
 {
  var vf = vFood()
  if(vf>=0) return {cell:vf}
  if(view[4].color!=ac) return {cell:4,color:ac}
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
   if(view[x1[i]].color==ac&&view[x2[i]].color!=ac&&view[x2[i]].color!=c1&&mOpen(x2[i])) return {cell:x2[i]}
  }
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
   if(mOpen(x1[i])&&view[x1[i]].color!=c1) return {cell:x1[i]}
  }
 }
 else
 {
  if(view[4].color!=ac) return {cell:4,color:ac}
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
   if(view[x1[i]].color==ac&&view[x2[i]].color!=ac&&sOpen(x2[i])) return {cell:x2[i]}
  }
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
   if(sOpen(x1[i])) return {cell:x1[i]}
  }
 }
 return {cell:4}
}

function findOrient(ac1,ac2,ac3)
{
 var w=[0,0,0,0]
 w[0]=DI(view[0].color,view[1].color,view[2].color,0,ac1,ac2,ac3)
 w[1]=DI(view[8].color,view[7].color,view[6].color,1,ac1,ac2,ac3)
 w[2]=DI(view[6].color,view[3].color,view[0].color,2,ac1,ac2,ac3)
 w[3]=DI(view[2].color,view[5].color,view[8].color,3,ac1,ac2,ac3)
 var t=[0,0,0,0]
 for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  switch(w[i])
  {
   case 4: t[0]++;break
   case 5: t[1]++;break
   case 6: t[2]++;break
   case 7: t[3]++;break
   case 8: t[0]+=2;break
   case 9: t[1]+=2;break
   case 10: t[2]+=2;break
   case 11: t[3]+=2;break
   case 12: t[0]+=3;break
   case 13: t[1]+=3;break
   case 14: t[2]+=3;break
   case 15: t[3]+=3;break
   default: break
  }
 }
 var m=Math.max(...t)
 for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  if(t[i]==m) return i
 }
 return 0
}

function DI(v1,v2,v3,d,ac1,ac2,ac3)
{
 var t=[0,0,0,0]
 switch(v1)
 {
  case ac2: t[0]++;t[3]++;break
  case ac3: t[1]++;t[2]++;break
  default: break
 }
 switch(v2)
 {
  case ac1: t[0]++;t[1]++;break
  case ac2: t[3]++;break
  case ac3: t[2]++;break
  default: break
 }
 switch(v3)
 {
  case ac2: t[1]++;t[3]++;break
  case ac3: t[0]++;t[2]++;break
  default: break
 }
 var m=Math.max(...t)
 if(m==0) return 0
 var n=0
 for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  if(t[i]==m){n=i;break}
 }
 if((d==2&&n==2)||(d==3&&n==3)) n=1
 else if((d==2&&n==3)||(d==3&&n==2)) n=0
 else n^=d
 return m*4+n
}

function vFood()
{
 for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
 {
  if(view[i].food) return i
 }
 return -1
}

function nColor(c)
{
 var t=0
 for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
 {
  if(view[i].color==c) t++
 }
 return t
}
```

To summarize, the queen moves in a straight line, creating the pattern behind her. A support worker is created to move right behind her and keep her in line. There are also gatherers, that hunt for food a la lone wolf or single queen, who will keep going until they acquire something to bring back to the rail, which will then lead them back to the queen.

All right, here's version 2. Now the gatherers actually do something.

Version 2.1 now. Yellow/Cyan markings have been switched around to prevent Black Hole from eating the entire trail any time they appear together in the same game.

Version 3. Bodyguard has been added to provide extra protection from the front (and grab food on the rail), while gatherers now draw black edges to ward away trail eraser and possibly help protect from Black Hole. Also the queen avoids cyan tiles in gatherer mode to prevent premature deployment.

All right, time for version 3.1. Colors have been changed again to keep trail eraser at bay *without* inciting the wrath of Wildfire. Gatherers have also been edited to keep on and identify the rail better (less bailing out/making new rails). There's some other minor things in there as well that I can't really bother with mentioning.

Version 3.2: Fixed some issues with bodyguard. It no longer attempts to grab food if it already has some, is less prone to getting stuck, and will draw rails if it can't find the queen.

Comment: As long as there are new entries/edits I'll be running new tournaments to see how the leaderboard looks. There's no closing date. The current tournament has maybe a few days left before it converges on unique 1st, 2nd and 3rd place, then I'll start a new tournament including this new player. I'm afraid it'll take over a week before it shows what position you reach, but I'll let you know when it does.

Comment: @QuoteBeta I understand your paranoia... I have just seen this challenge so i am in the process of creating an entry before the momentum of the challenge stops.

Comment: All right then. I wasn't sure if this was going to end soon or not, what with the updates slowing down a bit.

Comment: Most folks are probably done, but we're waiting on leaderboards. And those are taking a while.

Comment: Looks like your ants may want some of my trail-clearing code (see Black Hole, how the ants lost in the interior clear out old trails). https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTmA6.png

Comment: Yeah, the code is still a bit slapdash here, heh. It's not gonna work with diagonals, so I'll probably come up with my own solution here. Before I do that, I'll update support so that it grabs food that's just sitting there in the rail when the queen passes it.

Comment: Having hit a "diagonal move solo ant" point with Glider I've also run up against the clear-ahead code with diagonals problem. I may have to appropriate the code from Claustrophobic queen as the best-case alternative.

Comment: This errors on the input `[{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":4,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":3,"food":1,"ant":null},{"color":6,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":4,"food":0,"ant":{"type":3,"food":1,"friend":true}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":6,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":4,"food":0,"ant":{"type":5,"food":5,"friend":true}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":null}]` by moving onto the food at cell 2

Comment: Huh, I thought food was supposed to automatically transfer to the queen if she is adjacent?

Comment: If a laden worker is next to their queen, the food will be transferred. In this case though, the worker is never created because disqualification results if "The cell to produce a worker on is not empty (contains food or an ant)."

Comment: (sorry for the delayed response - I didn't get a notification so only noticing your comment now when checking through before starting a new tournament)

Answer (score 6):

## Claustrophobic Queen

A queen-only approach that does a random walk while attempting to avoid colored-in areas. Not a top contender, but moderately successful and tamper-proof. Parameter tweaking in progress.

```
var i, j
var orthogonals = [1, 3, 7, 5]  // These are the non-diagonal cells
var move;
var scores = [];   // An array of how desirable each potential move is
var score, neighbor, claustrophobia, newColor;
var crowdedNeighbors = null;   // How many diagonal neighbors are colored CROWDED?
var runningFrom = null;    // When in running phase, which direction did we come from?
var runningTo = null;      // When in running phase, which direction should we head?

// Assign color magic numbers to variables
var EMPTY = 1;
var VISITED = 4;
var CROWDED = 7;
var RUNNING = 8;

function neighbors(cell) {
    switch (cell) {
        case 0: return [1, 3];
        case 1: return [0, 2];
        case 2: return [1, 5];
        case 3: return [0, 6];
        case 4: return orthogonals;
        case 5: return [2, 8];
        case 6: return [3, 7];
        case 7: return [6, 8];
        case 8: return [7, 5];
        default: return null;
    }
}

function isHungry(ant) {
    if (ant.type === 5 || ant.food === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Color own cell based on the number of neighbors that are colored
claustrophobia = 0;
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (view[i].color !== EMPTY || i === 4) {
        claustrophobia++;
    }
    if (i % 2 === 0 && i !== 4) {
        if (view[i].color === CROWDED) {
            crowdedNeighbors++;
        } else if (view[i].color === RUNNING) {
            crowdedNeighbors++;
            runningFrom = i;
        }
    }
}

if (claustrophobia > 4) {
    if (crowdedNeighbors > 1 || runningFrom !== null) {
        // We're entering or currently in a straight-line running state
        // in which we keep going until we find sufficient whitespace
        newColor = RUNNING;
    } else {
        newColor = CROWDED;
    }
} else {
    newColor = VISITED;
}
if (view[4].color !== newColor) {
    return {cell:4, color:newColor}
}

// If we've already colored the current cell properly, and we're in running mode,
// then move diametrically away from the runningFrom cell
switch (runningFrom) {
    case 0:
        runningTo = 8;
        break;
    case 2:
        runningTo = 6;
        break;
    case 6:
        runningTo = 2;
        break;
    case 8:
        runningTo = 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

// Calculate a score for each potential move
// Lower numbers are better; null means illegal move
// Unexplored areas are better; food is the best (as long as ant can eat); don't move onto other ants
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    // Base score of tile is 2 times color of tile
    score = 2 * (view[i].color);
    // Add colors of neighboring tiles
    for (neighbor of neighbors(i)) {
        score += view[neighbor].color;
    }
    // Give very good score to runningTo tile, unless it's also RUNNING color
    if (i === runningTo && view[i].color !== RUNNING) {
        score -= 4;   // Magic number, possibly to be tweaked
    }
    if (i!==4 && view[i].ant) {
        // Tile contains another ant; give very bad score
        score = null;
    } else if (view[i].food) {
        // If a tile contains food, it's either highly desirable if the ant can eat, or illegal if it can't
        if (isHungry(view[4].ant)) {
            // Ant can eat; give food tile very good score
            score = -1;
        } else {
            // Ant cannot eat; give food tile very bad score
            score = null;
        }
    }
    scores.push(score);
}

// Select best move based on the scores array
move = 4;   // By default, stay put (this probably won't be the best move)
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (scores[i] !== null && scores[i] < scores[move]) {
        move = i;
    }
}

return {cell:move};
```

The queen lays down a trail of cyan as she moves. She prioritizes moving to blank cells and cells with blank neighbors. The way the math comes out at the moment, this results in mostly diagonal movement and a checkerboard pattern. If the current cell has four or more colored neighbors, it is colored blue instead of cyan; blue cells are avoided with higher priority. Finally, if the queen is adjacent to two blue cells, she starts on a diagonal line of black until she reaches an open area again.

[image]

Comment: Not tamper-proof; trail-eraser can erase its trail, which will lead the ant into going around in circles

Comment: Er, in squares?

Comment: @ppperry I said "*moderately*... tamper-proof." ;) The only thing Trail-Eraser can do is make it more likely to cover ground that's already been covered; but it could just as easily keep moving into unexplored territory.

Answer (score 6):

## Hoppemaur

*First of all I want to thank Trichoplax for creating this awesome challenge, which made me sign up to this site and start programming in javascript. I want to also thank you the other people still lurking around in the chatroom of this question, even exactly 3 months after it has been asked.*

My bot is not a serious contender for first place, but a single queen/self avoiding random walk approach, a little bit like a jumping [Claustrophobic Queen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135818/75302).

[image: Hoppemaur bot detail with painted pattern]

### Code

```js
//Hoppemaur
//å hoppe: to jump
//maur: ant

var WHITE = 1;
var OWN = 2;
var FOOD = 6;
var ESCAPE = 3;
var paint = 0;
var score = {0:2,1:-3,2:2,3:-3,4:-1,5:-3,6:2,7:-3,8:2}; 
// The ant should only walk diagonal (except when feeding)
var highest = 0;
var scoreindex;
var diagonals = [0, 2, 6, 8];
var diagonalsandself = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
var inversdiagonals = [8, 6, 2, 0];
var orthogonals = [1, 3, 5, 7];
var inverseorthogonals = [7, 5, 3, 1];
var rotate1orthogonals = [3, 1, 7, 5];
var rotate2orthogonals = [5, 7, 1, 3];

//checks if one of the diagonals or the own tile are painted
function checkforemptypattern() {
  for (var i=0; i<diagonalsandself.length; i++) {
    if (view[diagonalsandself[i]].color == OWN){
     return false;}
  }
  return true;
}

//counts the diagonals painted in the requestest colour
function checktrapped(pattern) {
  var diags=0;
  for (var i=0; i<diagonals.length; i++) {
    if (view[diagonals[i]].color == pattern){
     diags=diags+1;
    }
  }
return diags;
}

//Biggest threat to this ant is food on orthogonals,
//it messes up the pattern if not dealt with it
if (view[4].color !== FOOD){
    for (var i=0; i<orthogonals.length; i++) {
        if (view[orthogonals[i]].food) {
            return {cell:4, color:FOOD};
            }
        }
    }

if (view[4].color == FOOD){
    for (var i=0; i<orthogonals.length; i++) {
        if (view[orthogonals[i]].food) {
        if (!view[orthogonals[i]].ant){
            return {cell:orthogonals[i]};
            }
        }
        }
    }

//If food shows up on diagonals while out of pattern,
//before grabbing food, the pattern must be painted
for (var i=0; i<diagonals.length; i++){
    if (view[diagonals[i]].food){
        if (checkforemptypattern()){
            return {cell:4, color: OWN}
            }
        }
    }


//Otherwise, food can easily be grabbed if not ant in way
for (var i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (view[i].food) {
        if(!view[i].ant){
        return {cell:i}
        }
    }
}


//After food has been grabbed orthogonal, back to food pile
if (view[4].color == WHITE){
    for (i=0; i<orthogonals.length; i++) {
        if (view[orthogonals[i]].color == FOOD && checktrapped(FOOD) == 0 && view[inverseorthogonals[i]].color !== FOOD && view[rotate1orthogonals[i]].color !== FOOD && view[rotate2orthogonals[i]].color !== FOOD){
                 if (!view[orthogonals[i]].ant){
                     return {cell:orthogonals[i]};
                     }
                 }
        }
    }

//First part of scoring
// Scoring to determine next move
// Scoring everything higher than own pattern and escape
for (var i=0; i<9; i++) {
  if (view[i].color !== OWN) {
      score[i] = score[i]+3;
  }
  if (view[i].color !== ESCAPE){
      score[i] = score[i]+5;
  }
}

// Scoring while in painted area (f.e. wildfire)

var l = 0;
for (var i=2; i<9; i++) {
                          var k = 0;
    for (var j=0; j<9; j++) {
                             if (view[j].color == i) {
            k=k+1;
            if (k > 6){
            paint=i;
            }
        if (view[j].color !==WHITE) {
          l=l+1;

        }
    }
}
}

if (paint !== OWN && l >7) {
    for (var i=0; i<diagonals.length; i++){
        if (view[diagonals[i]].color == OWN) {
            score[inversdiagonals[i]]=score[inversdiagonals[i]]+7;
            }
        if (view[diagonals[i]].color == WHITE) {
          score[diagonals[i]]=score[diagonals[i]]+7
        }
        }
    }


if (paint == OWN && l >7) {
    for (var i=0; i<diagonals.length; i++){
        if (view[diagonals[i]].color == ESCAPE) {
            score[inversdiagonals[i]]=score[inversdiagonals[i]]+7;
            }
        if (view[diagonals[i]].color == WHITE) {
          score[diagonals[i]]=score[diagonals[i]]+7
        }
        }
    }

// the following might lead to some traps?
// score diagonals adjactant to white higher
  if (view[1].color === WHITE) {
    score[0] = score[0]+1;
    score[2] = score[2]+1;
   }
  if (view[3].color === WHITE) {
    score[0] = score[0]+1;
    score[6] = score[6]+1;
   }
  if (view[5].color === WHITE) {
    score[2] = score[2]+1;
    score[8] = score[8]+1;
   }
  if (view[7].color === WHITE) {
    score[6] = score[6]+1;
    score[8] = score[8]+1;
   }


//Don't move next to others, they steal your food!
  if (view[0].ant || view[1].ant || view[2].ant){
      score[6] = score [6]+10;
      score[8] = score [8]+10;
  }

  if (view[0].ant || view[3].ant || view[6].ant){
      score[2] = score [2]+10;
      score[8] = score [8]+10;
  }

  if (view[6].ant || view[7].ant || view[8].ant){
      score[0] = score [0]+10;
      score[2] = score [2]+10;

  }
   if (view[2].ant || view[5].ant || view[8].ant){
      score[0] = score [0]+10;
      score[6] = score [6]+10;

  }
//don't step on others!
for (var i=0; i<9; i++) {
  if (i!==4 && view[i].ant) {
        score[i] = -5;
 }
}

//end of scoring, calculate best
for (var i=0; i<9; i++) {
  if (score[i] > highest) {
    highest = score[i];
    scoreindex = i;
    }
  }

//Basic enemy avoidance
for (var i=0; i<9; i++) {
  if (i!==4 && view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:scoreindex}
        }
  }

//basic movement

//when surrounded by other paint
if (paint == ESCAPE && l>7){
    if(view[4].color == OWN){
      return{cell:scoreindex}
    }
}

if (paint !== OWN && paint !== 0 && l>7){
  if(view[4].color !== OWN){
    return{cell:4, color:OWN}
  }
}


if (paint == OWN && l>7){
  if(view[4].color !== ESCAPE){
    return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
  }
}

//a) when off pattern
if (view[4].color !== OWN) {
    if (view[4].color == ESCAPE){
         if (checktrapped(ESCAPE)==4){
            return{cell:scoreindex}
            }
        }
        if (view[4].color == ESCAPE){
         if (checktrapped(ESCAPE)==3){
            return{cell:scoreindex}
            }
        }
    if (checkforemptypattern()) {
    return{cell:4, color:OWN};
    }

    //Am I trapped? Different possible traps follow here
    if (view[4].color !== ESCAPE){
         if (checktrapped(OWN)==4){
            return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
            }
    }
    if (view[4].color !== ESCAPE){
         if (checktrapped(OWN)==3 && checktrapped(ESCAPE)==1){
            return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
            }
    }
    if (view[4].color !== ESCAPE){
         if (checktrapped(OWN)==2 && checktrapped(ESCAPE)==1){
            return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
            }
    }
    if (view[4].color !== ESCAPE){
         if (checktrapped(OWN)==2 && checktrapped(ESCAPE)==2){
            return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
            }
    }
    if (view[4].color !== ESCAPE){
         if (checktrapped(OWN)==1 && checktrapped(ESCAPE)==2){
            return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
            }
    }
    if (view[4].color !== ESCAPE){
         if (checktrapped(OWN)==1 && checktrapped(ESCAPE)==1){
            return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
            }
    }
    if (view[4].color !== ESCAPE){ //when the orthogonals are painted, some other guy was here before and movement traps are likely
         if (view[1].color == OWN || view[7].color == OWN || view[3].color == OWN || view[5].color == OWN){
            return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
            }
    }
    if (view[4].color !== ESCAPE){ //when the orthogonals are painted, some other guy was here before and movement traps are likely
         if (view[1].color == ESCAPE || view[7].color == ESCAPE || view[3].color == ESCAPE || view[5].color == ESCAPE){
            return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
            }
    }
}

//b) when on pattern check surroundings for escape route
if (checktrapped(ESCAPE)==3){
    return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
}
if (checktrapped(ESCAPE)==4){
    return{cell:4, color:ESCAPE}
}

//otherwise just move on
return{cell:scoreindex}
```

### Explanation

The main idea of this bot was to shorten the painting time while still being able to identify the already visited area. To achieve this, the queen will normally only paint after every second movement. However the movement direction information is lost by doing so, resulting in a non directed jumping pattern. To avoid a true random walk, the queen values non-painted tiles higher than already painted ones and in case of backtracking, uses a pink escape colour to signal herself that she was there before. A scoring mechanism that incorporates the aforementioned provides the backbone of the general movement.

One big risk are foodpiles outside her diagonal movement pattern. If she stumbles on such, she will use green colour to mark her point of origin that she will get back to after grabbing the food to not get out of pattern. The last part of the bot deals with different situations the pink escape colour will be used in.

As an addition, basic enemy avoidance and a diagonal movement in already painted areas are also included (but not really tested yet).

Last but not least, the bot draws some beautiful abstract patterns, when left alone:

[image: Hoppemaur bot overview pattern at the end of the game]

Comment: Welcome to the site! KoTH challenges are often the easiest to break into, here, though much less common. I think there are three or four older ones with controllers still available that could be interesting to attempt, even if they are officially over. CodeBots 4 (bots that inject their code into each other) and Prisoners Dillema 3 (petri dish). Also Battle of the Fellowship and Worldwide Pandemic. I know PD was in Python and I think CB was in Java, don't remember the others.

Comment: Thanks, @Draco18s! I might check those older challenges out, but not before I managed to build a colony ant bot :-)

Answer (score 6):

## The Formation

This submission is hosted in [a github repository](https://github.com/eaglgenes101/formic-formation).

```
var marcher_count;var gatherer_count;var excess_gatherers;var tcell;var lh_cell;var rh_cell;var ant_off;var alt_cell;var cell_off;function debug(message)
{}
const MARCHER_A=1;const MARCHER_B=2;const GATHERER=3;const QUEEN=5;const S_END=[6,5,7,4,0,2,1,3];const S_FRONT=[7,5,6,0,4,1,3,2];const S_SIDE=[7,3,5,1,6,2,0,4];const S_GATHERER=[7,6,5,4,0,3,2,1];const SCAN_MOVES=[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8];const CORNERS=[0,2,6,8];const EDGES=[1,3,5,7];const CCW=[[0,3,6,7,8,5,2,1],[1,0,3,6,7,8,5,2],[2,1,0,3,6,7,8,5],[3,6,7,8,5,2,1,0],[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],[5,2,1,0,3,6,7,8],[6,7,8,5,2,1,0,3],[7,8,5,2,1,0,3,6],[8,5,2,1,0,3,6,7]];const NEARS=[[6,5,3,5,4,2,3,2,1],[5,6,5,4,5,4,2,3,2],[3,5,6,2,4,5,1,2,3],[5,4,2,6,5,3,5,4,2],[4,5,4,5,6,5,4,5,4],[2,4,5,3,5,6,2,4,5],[3,2,1,5,4,2,6,5,3],[2,3,2,4,5,4,5,6,5],[1,2,3,2,4,5,3,5,6]];const SAN_ORD=[[1,3,6,2,5,7,8],[0,2,5,3,6,8,7],[5,1,0,8,7,3,6],[6,0,1,7,8,2,5],[],[2,8,7,1,0,6,3],[3,7,8,0,1,5,2],[8,6,3,5,2,0,1],[7,5,2,6,3,1,0]];const D_MARCH=1;const D_FOOD=2;const D_STALLED=3;const D_GATHERER=4;const U_REALIGN=5;const U_SENTINEL=6;const U_READY=7;const U_PANIC=8;const PUPS=[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1],[2,0,2,0,4,2,2,0,2],[3,0,0,3,4,3,3,0,3],[4,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,4],[5,1,2,3,4,5,5,0,5],[6,1,2,3,0,5,5,0,6],[7,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7],[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]];const PDOWNS=[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,1,0,3,4,5,5,0,1],[2,0,2,3,4,5,5,0,2],[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,3,4,0,0,0,4],[5,5,5,3,0,5,5,0,5],[6,5,5,3,0,5,5,0,6],[7,0,0,3,0,0,0,7,7],[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]];const PSIDES=[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,1,0,3,4,1,1,0,1],[2,0,2,0,4,5,5,0,2],[3,3,0,3,3,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,3,4,0,0,0,4],[5,1,5,3,0,5,5,0,5],[6,1,5,3,0,5,5,0,6],[7,0,0,3,0,0,0,7,7],[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]];const INIT_SEED=3734978372;const FINAL_SEED=2338395782;const SRECOLOR_PROB=0.7;const SONSTRIDE_PROB=0.5;const QFSPAWNP_MAX=0.05;const QFSPAWNP_MIN=0.00;const QFSPAWNP_DECAY=0.005;const QBSPAWNP_MAX=0.65;const QBSPAWNP_MIN=0.55;const QBSPAWNP_DECAY=0.01;const QFORMP_MAX=0.5;const QFORMP_MIN=0.3;const QFORMP_DECAY=0.01;const DISCOLORT=35;const ERASET=20;const SOBSTRUCT_FUZZ=6;const SSTRIDE_FUZZ=6;const OBSTRUCT_QWT=3;const SPREFWT=2;var state=null;function rand_init()
{state=INIT_SEED;for(var cell=0;cell<9;cell++)
{var v=view[cell];state^=v.color;state^=v.food<<3;if(v.ant!==null)
{state^=v.ant.friend<<4;state^=v.ant.type<<5;state^=v.ant.food<<8;}
ant_rand();}
state^=FINAL_SEED;if(state===0)state=1;}
function ant_rand()
{if(state===null)rand_init();state^=state<<13;state^=state>>>17;state^=state<<5;return state>>>0;}
function rand_choice(prob)
{return ant_rand()/4294967296<prob;}
function rand_sub(array,num)
{var return_array=array.slice();for(var i=0;i<num;i++)
{var rand_index=i+ant_rand()%(array.length-i);var x_val=return_array[rand_index];return_array[rand_index]=return_array[i];return_array[i]=x_val;}
return return_array.slice(0,num);}
function rand_perm(array)
{var return_array=array.slice();for(var i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)
{var rand_index=i+ant_rand()%(array.length-i)
var x_val=return_array[rand_index];return_array[rand_index]=return_array[i];return_array[i]=x_val;}
return return_array;}
function index_sort(arr)
{var index_array=[];for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)index_array.push(i);index_array.sort((a,b)=>(arr[a]===arr[b])?(a-b):(arr[a]-arr[b]));return index_array;}
function this_ant()
{return view[4].ant;}
function c_at(cell)
{return view[cell].color;}
function is_ally(cell)
{return view[cell].ant!==null&&view[cell].ant.friend===true;}
function is_enemy(cell)
{return view[cell].ant!==null&&view[cell].ant.friend===false;}
function is_harvestable(cell)
{return is_enemy(cell)&&view[cell].ant.type===QUEEN&&view[cell].ant.food>0;}
function lchk(c)
{if(is_ally(CCW[c][6])&&view[CCW[c][6]].ant.type===GATHERER)
if(is_ally(CCW[c][5])&&view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type!==GATHERER)return D_GATHERER;if(is_ally(CCW[c][7])&&view[CCW[c][7]].ant.type===GATHERER&&is_ally(CCW[c][1]))return D_GATHERER;if(is_ally(CCW[c][5])&&view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type===GATHERER)
if(is_ally(CCW[c][3])&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return D_STALLED;if(view[CCW[c][6]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][5])&&view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type!==GATHERER)return D_FOOD;if(view[CCW[c][7]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][1])&&c_at(CCW[c][1])===D_FOOD)return D_FOOD;if(view[CCW[c][5]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][3])&&view[CCW[c][3]].ant.type!==QUEEN&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return U_REALIGN;return null;}
function lchk2(c)
{if(is_ally(CCW[c][6])&&view[CCW[c][6]].ant.type===GATHERER)
if(is_ally(CCW[c][5])&&view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type!==GATHERER)return D_GATHERER;if(is_ally(CCW[c][7])&&view[CCW[c][7]].ant.type===GATHERER&&is_ally(CCW[c][1]))return D_GATHERER;if(is_ally(CCW[c][5])&&view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type===GATHERER)
if(is_ally(CCW[c][3])&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return D_STALLED;if(is_ally(CCW[c][2])&&view[CCW[c][2]].ant.type===GATHERER)
if(is_ally(CCW[c][1])&&view[CCW[c][1]].ant.type!==GATHERER)return D_GATHERER;if(is_ally(CCW[c][3])&&view[CCW[c][3]].ant.type===GATHERER)
if(is_ally(CCW[c][5])&&c_at(CCW[c][5])===D_GATHERER)return D_GATHERER;if(is_ally(CCW[c][1])&&view[CCW[c][1]].ant.type===GATHERER)
if(is_ally(CCW[c][7])&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return D_STALLED;if(view[CCW[c][6]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][5])&&view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type!==GATHERER)return D_FOOD;if(view[CCW[c][7]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][1])&&c_at(CCW[c][1])===D_FOOD)return D_FOOD;if(view[CCW[c][5]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][3])&&view[CCW[c][3]].ant.type!==QUEEN&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return U_REALIGN;if(view[CCW[c][2]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][1])&&view[CCW[c][1]].ant.type!==GATHERER)return D_FOOD;if(view[CCW[c][3]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][5])&&c_at(CCW[c][5])===D_FOOD)return{cell:4,color:D_FOOD};if(view[CCW[c][1]].food===1&&is_ally(CCW[c][7])&&view[CCW[c][7]].ant.type!==QUEEN&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return U_REALIGN;return null;}
function sigc(output,order,c)
{if(c_at(4)===output)
for(cell_off of order)
{var tcell=CCW[c][cell_off];if(!is_ally(tcell)&&c_at(tcell)!==D_MARCH)
{if(view[tcell].food!==0&&view[tcell].color===D_FOOD)
{for(alt_cell of SCAN_MOVES)
{var n_wt=NEARS[tcell][alt_cell];if(n_wt>3&&n_wt<6&&is_ally(alt_cell))
if(view[alt_cell].ant.type===QUEEN||view[alt_cell].ant.type===GATHERER)
continue;}}
return{cell:tcell,color:D_MARCH};}}
return{cell:4,color:output};}
function is_gatherer_marcher(cell)
{if(!is_ally(cell)||view[cell].ant.food>0||view[cell].ant.type!==GATHERER)return false;if(this_ant().type===QUEEN)return true;lh_cell=CCW[cell][1];rh_cell=CCW[cell][7];if(is_ally(lh_cell)&&view[lh_cell].ant.type===QUEEN)return!is_ally(rh_cell)
else if(is_ally(rh_cell)&&view[rh_cell].ant.type===QUEEN)return!is_ally(lh_cell)
else return false;}
function is_like(cell)
{if(c_at(cell)===U_PANIC)return false;if(is_ally(CCW[cell][1])&&c_at(CCW[cell][1])===U_PANIC)return false;if(is_ally(CCW[cell][7])&&c_at(CCW[cell][7])===U_PANIC)return false;if(CORNERS.includes(cell)&&is_ally(cell))
{switch(view[cell].ant.type)
{case MARCHER_A:return view[cell].ant.food===0&&this_ant().type!==MARCHER_B;case MARCHER_B:return view[cell].ant.food===0&&this_ant().type!==MARCHER_A;case GATHERER:return is_gatherer_marcher(cell)&&this_ant().type!==GATHERER;case QUEEN:return true;default:return false;}}
return false;}
function is_other(cell)
{if(c_at(cell)===U_PANIC)return false;if(EDGES.includes(cell)&&is_ally(cell))
{switch(view[cell].ant.type)
{case MARCHER_A:return view[cell].ant.food===0&&this_ant().type!==MARCHER_A;case MARCHER_B:return view[cell].ant.food===0&&this_ant().type!==MARCHER_B;case GATHERER:return this_ant().type===QUEEN
case QUEEN:return true;default:return false;}}
return false;}
function view_corner()
{var scores=[0,0,0,0];for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
for(var j=0;j<8;j++)
{scores[i]*=2;var tcell=CCW[CORNERS[i]][j];if(is_ally(tcell)&&(is_like(tcell)||is_other(tcell)))scores[i]++;}
if(scores[0]>scores[1]&&scores[0]>scores[2]&&scores[0]>scores[3])return CORNERS[0];else if(scores[1]>scores[2]&&scores[1]>scores[3])return CORNERS[1];else if(scores[2]>scores[3])return CORNERS[2];else return CORNERS[3];}
const ONE_EDGE=10;const ONE_CORNER=11;const EE_BENT=20;const EE_STRAIGHT=21;const EC_LEFT=22;const EC_RIGHT=23;const EC_SKEWED=24;const EC_SPAWN=25;const CC_EDGED=26;const CC_LINE=27;const THREE_MARCH=30;const THREE_STAND=31;const THREE_RECOVER=32;const THREE_UNSTAND=33;const THREE_BLOCK=34;const THREE_HANG=35;const THREE_UNHANG=36;const THREE_SIDE=37;const FOUR_Z=40;const FOUR_STAIRS=41;const FOUR_BENT=42;function neighbor_type(top_left)
{var corners=[];for(tcell of CORNERS)
if(is_ally(tcell)&&is_like(tcell))corners.push(tcell);var edges=[];for(tcell of EDGES)
if(is_ally(tcell)&&is_other(tcell))edges.push(tcell);if(corners.length===1&&edges.length===0)return ONE_CORNER;if(corners.length===0&&edges.length===1)return ONE_EDGE;if(corners.length===0&&edges.length===2)return(edges[1]===CCW[edges[0]][4])?EE_STRAIGHT:EE_BENT;if(corners.length===2&&edges.length===0)return(corners[1]===CCW[corners[0]][4])?CC_LINE:CC_EDGED;else if(corners.length===1&&edges.length===1)
{if(edges[0]===CCW[top_left][1])return EC_LEFT;if(edges[0]===CCW[top_left][3])return EC_SPAWN;if(edges[0]===CCW[top_left][5])return EC_SKEWED;if(edges[0]===CCW[top_left][7])return EC_RIGHT;return null;}
else if(corners.length===1&&edges.length===2)
{if(edges.includes(CCW[top_left][1])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][3]))return THREE_MARCH;if(edges.includes(CCW[top_left][3])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][7]))return THREE_STAND;if(edges.includes(CCW[top_left][1])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][5]))return THREE_RECOVER;if(edges.includes(CCW[top_left][5])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][7]))return THREE_UNSTAND;if(edges.includes(CCW[top_left][1])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][7]))return THREE_BLOCK;return null;}
else if(corners.length===2&&edges.length===1)
{if(corners.includes(CCW[top_left][4])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][3]))return THREE_HANG;if(corners.includes(CCW[top_left][4])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][1]))return THREE_UNHANG;if(corners.includes(CCW[top_left][2])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][1]))return THREE_SIDE;}
else if(corners.length===2&&edges.length===2)
{if(edges.includes(CCW[top_left][3])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][7])&&corners.includes(CCW[top_left][4]))
return FOUR_Z;if(edges.includes(CCW[top_left][1])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][3])&&corners.includes(CCW[top_left][4]))
return FOUR_STAIRS;if(edges.includes(CCW[top_left][1])&&edges.includes(CCW[top_left][3])&&corners.includes(CCW[top_left][2]))
return FOUR_BENT;return null;}
return null;}
function sok(cand)
{if(cand===4)return true;if(view[cand].food!==0&&this_ant().food!==0)return false;if(view[cand].ant!==null)return false;return true;}
function spref(cand)
{var okscore=0;if(cand===4)okscore-=9;if(this_ant().type===GATHERER)
{for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(NEARS[cand][tcell]>1)
if(is_ally(tcell)&&view[tcell].ant.type===QUEEN)okscore-=1;}
else
{if(this_ant().food===0&&view[cand].food!==0)
{for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(is_ally(tcell)&&view[tcell].ant.food===0)
{if([MARCHER_A,MARCHER_B].includes(view[tcell].ant.type))
{var has_common_enemy=false;for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
if(is_enemy(i)&&NEARS[tcell][i]>=4)has_common_enemy=true;if(!has_common_enemy)
{var wt=(view[tcell].ant.type===this_ant().type)?1:-1;if(NEARS[4][tcell]===5)okscore+=wt;if(NEARS[4][tcell]===4)okscore-=wt;if(NEARS[cand][tcell]===5)okscore-=wt;if(NEARS[cand][tcell]===4)okscore+=wt;}}}
if(okscore>0)okscore=0;}}
return okscore*SPREFWT;}
function ssep()
{var has_ally=false;var cands=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];for(var i=0;i<9;i++)cands[i]+=spref(i);for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
{if(is_ally(tcell))
{has_ally=true;var wt=(is_like(tcell)||is_other(tcell))?3:1;for(var i=0;i<9;i++)cands[i]-=NEARS[tcell][i]*wt;}}
if(!has_ally)return null;var prox_order=index_sort(cands);for(var i=8;i>=0;i--)
{var i_cell=prox_order[i];if(sok(i_cell))return{cell:i_cell};}
return null;}
function sstep(col)
{if(c_at(4)===1)return{cell:4,color:col};var cands=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(c_at(tcell)===col)
for(var i=0;i<9;i++)cands[i]-=NEARS[tcell][i];for(var i=0;i<9;i++)cands[i]+=spref(i);var prox_order=index_sort(cands);for(var i=8;i>=0;i--)
{var i_cell=prox_order[i];if(sok(i_cell))return{cell:i_cell};}
return{cell:4,color:col};}
function smove()
{for(tcell of rand_perm(SCAN_MOVES))
if(sok(tcell))return{cell:tcell};return{cell:4};}
function sdec_alone()
{var try_sep=ssep();if(try_sep!==null)return try_sep;var c=U_PANIC;for(tcell of rand_sub(SCAN_MOVES,7))
if(c_at(tcell)>1&&c_at(tcell)!==c)
{c=c_at(tcell);break;}
return sstep(c);}
function sdec_erase()
{var try_sep=ssep();if(try_sep!==null)return try_sep;for(tcell of rand_perm(SCAN_MOVES))
if(c_at(tcell)!==1)return{cell:tcell,color:1};if(c_at(4)!==1)return{cell:4,color:1};return sdec_alone();}
function sdec_discolor()
{if(c_at(1)!==c_at(6)&&c_at(6)!==1)return{cell:1,color:c_at(6)};if(c_at(2)!==c_at(3))return{cell:3,color:c_at(2)};var proximities=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=ant_rand()%SOBSTRUCT_FUZZ+spref(i);for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(is_ally(tcell))
for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=NEARS[tcell][i];var prox_order=index_sort(proximities);for(var i=8;i>=0;i--)
if(sok(prox_order[i]))return{cell:prox_order[i]};return smove();}
function sdec_stride()
{if(rand_choice(SONSTRIDE_PROB))
{var stride_scores=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
{for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
if(c_at(tcell)!==c_at(i)&&c_at(i)!==1)stride_scores[i]+=NEARS[tcell][i];}
for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
stride_scores[i]+=ant_rand()%SSTRIDE_FUZZ+spref(i);var prox_order=index_sort(stride_scores);for(var i=8;i>=0;i--)
if(sok(prox_order[i]))return{cell:prox_order[i]};}
return smove();}
function sdec_obstruct_textured()
{var proximities=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
{if(is_enemy(tcell))
{var wt=(view[tcell].ant.type===QUEEN)?OBSTRUCT_QWT:1;for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=NEARS[tcell][i]*wt;}}
for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=ant_rand()%SOBSTRUCT_FUZZ;var prox_order;if(rand_choice(SRECOLOR_PROB))
{prox_order=index_sort(proximities);for(var i=8;i>0;i--)
{var i_cell=prox_order[i];for(var j=0;j<i;j++)
{var j_cell=prox_order[j];if(c_at(i_cell)!==c_at(j_cell))return{cell:i_cell,color:c_at(j_cell)};}}}
for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(is_ally(tcell))
for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=NEARS[tcell][i];for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=spref(i);prox_order=index_sort(proximities);for(var i=8;i>=0;i--)
if(sok(prox_order[i]))return{cell:prox_order[i]};return{cell:4,color:1};}
function sdec_obstruct_flat()
{var proximities=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
{if(is_enemy(tcell))
{var wt=(view[tcell].ant.type===QUEEN)?OBSTRUCT_QWT:1;for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=NEARS[tcell][i]*wt;}}
for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=ant_rand()%SOBSTRUCT_FUZZ;var prox_order;if(rand_choice(SRECOLOR_PROB))
{prox_order=index_sort(proximities);for(var i=8;i>0;i--)
{var i_cell=prox_order[i];if(c_at(i_cell)!==D_MARCH)return{cell:i_cell,color:D_MARCH};}}
for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(is_ally(tcell))
for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=NEARS[tcell][i];for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proximities[i]+=spref(i);prox_order=index_sort(proximities);for(var i=8;i>=0;i--)
if(sok(prox_order[i]))return{cell:prox_order[i]};return{cell:4,color:1};}
function saboteur()
{var colored_neighbors=0;for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(c_at(tcell)>1)colored_neighbors++;if(colored_neighbors<=2)return sdec_alone();else
{var num_enemies=0;for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(is_enemy(tcell))num_enemies++;var diversity=0;var counts=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
{diversity+=5-counts[c_at(i)];counts[c_at(i)]++;}
if(num_enemies>0)
{if(diversity>=ERASET)return sdec_obstruct_textured();else return sdec_obstruct_flat();}
else
{if(diversity>=DISCOLORT)return sdec_discolor();else if(diversity>=ERASET)return sdec_stride();else return sdec_erase();}}}
function gwatch(cand)
{if(cand.cell===4)return cand;if(cand.hasOwnProperty("color"))return cand;if(view[cand.cell].food!==0&&this_ant().food!==0)return sigc(U_PANIC,S_SIDE,0);if(view[cand.cell].ant!==null)return sigc(U_PANIC,S_SIDE,0);return cand;}
function egwatch(cand)
{if(cand.cell===4)return cand;if(cand.hasOwnProperty("color"))return cand;if(view[cand.cell].food!==0&&this_ant().food!==0)return gwatch(sdec_erase());if(view[cand.cell].ant!==null)return gwatch(sdec_erase());return cand;}
function gdec_ee_bent(c)
{return{cell:CCW[c][4]};}
function gdec_ec_left(c)
{if(c_at(c)===D_FOOD&&c_at(CCW[c][1])===D_FOOD)return{cell:CCW[c][7]};if(c_at(c)===D_STALLED&&c_at(CCW[c][1])===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_READY,S_GATHERER,c);if(c_at(c)===D_MARCH&&c_at(CCW[c][1])===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_GATHERER,c);return sigc(c_at(4),S_GATHERER,c);}
function gdec_ec_right(c)
{if([D_MARCH,D_FOOD].includes(c_at(c))&&[D_MARCH,D_FOOD].includes(c_at(CCW[c][7])))
return{cell:CCW[c][6]};if(is_ally(c)&&view[c].ant.type===QUEEN)
return{cell:CCW[c][1]};if(c_at(c)===D_STALLED&&c_at(CCW[c][7])===D_STALLED)
return sigc(U_READY,S_GATHERER,c);return sigc(c_at(4),S_GATHERER,c);}
function gdec_cc_edged(c)
{if(view[CCW[c][2]].ant.type!==QUEEN)return saboteur();return{cell:CCW[c][1]};}
function gdec_three_block(c)
{if(c_at(CCW[c][7])==D_FOOD)return{cell:CCW[c][6]};return{cell:CCW[c][2]};}
function gdec_three_unstand(c)
{if(view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type!==QUEEN)return saboteur();return{cell:CCW[c][4]};}
function gdec_four_bent(c)
{return{cell:CCW[c][4]};}
function early_gatherer()
{var qcell=null;var food_count=0;for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
{if(is_ally(tcell)&&view[tcell].ant.type===QUEEN)qcell=tcell;else if(is_enemy(tcell))return saboteur();}
if(qcell===null)return saboteur();if(c_at(qcell)===D_FOOD)return{cell:CCW[qcell][7]};if(this_ant().food===0)
{for(tcell of rand_perm(CORNERS))
if(view[tcell].food>0&&NEARS[tcell][qcell]===5)
{if(c_at(tcell)===D_FOOD)return{cell:tcell};else return{cell:tcell,color:D_FOOD};}
for(tcell of rand_perm(EDGES))
if(view[tcell].food>0)
{if(c_at(tcell)!==D_FOOD&&NEARS[tcell][qcell]===4)
return{cell:tcell,color:D_FOOD};}}
return{cell:CCW[qcell][1]};}
function gatherer_retrieve()
{if(c_at(4)===U_PANIC)return saboteur();var c=view_corner();switch(neighbor_type(c))
{case EC_LEFT:return gwatch({cell:CCW[c][2]});case THREE_BLOCK:{if(c_at(CCW[c][7])===D_FOOD)return gwatch({cell:CCW[c][6]});return gwatch({cell:CCW[c][2]});}
case FOUR_BENT:return gwatch(sigc(c_at(4),S_FRONT,c));default:return early_gatherer();}}
function gatherer_return()
{if(c_at(4)===U_PANIC)return saboteur();var c=view_corner();switch(neighbor_type(c))
{case EC_LEFT:return gwatch({cell:CCW[c][2]});case THREE_BLOCK:return gwatch({cell:CCW[c][2]});case FOUR_BENT:return gwatch({cell:CCW[c][4]});default:return early_gatherer();}}
function gatherer_formation()
{if(c_at(4)===U_PANIC)return saboteur();var c=view_corner();switch(neighbor_type(c))
{case EC_LEFT:return gwatch(gdec_ec_left(c));case EC_RIGHT:return gwatch(gdec_ec_right(c));case CC_EDGED:return gwatch(gdec_cc_edged(c));case EE_BENT:return gwatch(gdec_ee_bent(c));case THREE_BLOCK:return gwatch(gdec_three_block(c));case THREE_UNSTAND:return gwatch(gdec_three_unstand(c));case FOUR_BENT:return gwatch(gdec_four_bent(c));default:return egwatch(early_gatherer());}}
function gatherer_decision()
{var marcher_count=0;var gatherer_count=0;var queen_pos=null;for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(is_ally(tcell))
{if(view[tcell].ant.type===MARCHER_A||view[tcell].ant.type===MARCHER_B)marcher_count++;if(view[tcell].ant.type===GATHERER)gatherer_count++;if(view[tcell].ant.type===QUEEN)queen_pos=tcell;}
if(gatherer_count>0)return saboteur();if(this_ant().food>0&&marcher_count>0)return gwatch(gatherer_return());else if(queen_pos!==null&&marcher_count>0)return gwatch(gatherer_formation());else if(marcher_count>0)return gwatch(gatherer_retrieve());else if(queen_pos!==null)return egwatch(early_gatherer());else return saboteur();}
function mdec_one_corner(c)
{if(view[c].ant.type===QUEEN)
return sigc(c_at(4),S_SIDE,c);else return saboteur();}
function mdec_one_edge(c)
{if([U_REALIGN,D_MARCH].includes(c_at(CCW[c][1])))
{if(view[CCW[c][2]].food===1)return{cell:c};if(is_ally(CCW[c][2])&&view[CCW[c][2]].ant.type===GATHERER)return{cell:c};}
return saboteur();}
function mdec_ee_bent(c)
{if(view[CCW[c][1]].ant.type===GATHERER&&view[CCW[c][3]].ant.type===QUEEN)return saboteur();if(view[CCW[c][1]].ant.type===QUEEN&&view[CCW[c][3]].ant.type===GATHERER)return saboteur();var u_sig=c_at(CCW[c][1]);var d_sig=c_at(CCW[c][3]);if(is_ally(c)&&view[c].ant.type===GATHERER)return sigc(c_at(4),S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);var provisional=lchk(c);if(provisional!==null)
{if(provisional===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_END,c);return sigc(provisional,S_END,c);}
if(u_sig===D_STALLED)
{if([D_STALLED,U_READY,D_GATHERER].includes(d_sig)&&[D_STALLED,U_READY].includes(c_at(4)))
return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(d_sig===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)
return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(view[CCW[c][1]].ant.type===QUEEN)
{var provisional=lchk(CCW[c][4]);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if(u_sig===D_GATHERER&&d_sig===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)
return sigc(D_GATHERER,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===U_SENTINEL)
{if(d_sig===U_REALIGN&&[D_MARCH,U_SENTINEL].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_SIDE,c);if(d_sig===D_STALLED&&[U_SENTINEL,D_STALLED].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_SIDE,c);if(d_sig===D_MARCH&&[U_SENTINEL,D_MARCH].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);}
if(u_sig===D_GATHERER&&d_sig===D_STALLED&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);return{cell:CCW[c][2]};}
function mdec_ee_straight(c)
{return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,c);}
function mdec_ec_left(c)
{if(view[CCW[c][1]].ant.type===GATHERER&&view[c].ant.type===QUEEN)return saboteur();if(view[CCW[c][1]].ant.type===QUEEN&&view[c].ant.type===GATHERER)return saboteur();if(is_other(CCW[c][1])&&view[c].ant.type===QUEEN)return{cell:CCW[c][3]};var d_sig=PDOWNS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][1])];if(is_ally(CCW[c][4])&&view[CCW[c][4]].ant.type===GATHERER&&d_sig===D_STALLED&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)
return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,c);var provisional=lchk(CCW[c][4]);if(provisional!==null)
{if(provisional===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_END,CCW[c][4]);return sigc(provisional,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===U_REALIGN)
{if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===U_SENTINEL)
{if(c_at(c)===D_MARCH)return{cell:CCW[c][2]};return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}}
if(d_sig===D_STALLED)
{if([D_MARCH,D_STALLED].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===U_SENTINEL)return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_GATHERER)
{if(c_at(4)===D_FOOD)return sigc(D_GATHERER,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===U_READY)
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)
{if(c_at(CCW[c][2])!==D_MARCH)return{cell:CCW[c][2],color:D_MARCH};return sigc(D_MARCH,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(c_at(4)===U_SENTINEL)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
return{cell:CCW[c][2]};}
function mdec_ec_right(c)
{if(view[c].ant.type===GATHERER&&view[CCW[c][7]].ant.type===QUEEN)
if(is_ally(CCW[c][4])&&view[CCW[c][4]].ant.type!==this_ant().type)return{cell:CCW[c][5]};var d_sig=PDOWNS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][7])];var provisional=lchk(CCW[c][4]);if(provisional!==null)
{if(provisional===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_END,CCW[c][4]);return sigc(provisional,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_MARCH)
{if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER,U_READY].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_MARCH,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_FOOD)
{if([U_SENTINEL,D_STALLED].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER,U_READY].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_GATHERER)
{if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER,U_READY].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_MARCH,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if([U_SENTINEL,D_STALLED].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER,U_READY].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===U_READY)
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_END,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER,U_READY].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_MARCH,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===U_REALIGN)
{if(c_at(4)===U_SENTINEL)return{cell:CCW[c][6]};if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER,U_READY].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
return sigc(d_sig,S_END,CCW[c][4]);}
function mdec_ec_spawn(c)
{if(view[c].ant.type===QUEEN&&c_at(c)===D_MARCH&&c_at(CCW[c][3])===D_STALLED)
if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);return saboteur();}
function mdec_three_march(c)
{var d_sig=PDOWNS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][1])];var u_sig=c_at(CCW[c][3]);var provisional=lchk2(c);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_FRONT,c);if(u_sig===U_SENTINEL)
{if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&[D_GATHERER,D_STALLED].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_STALLED&&[D_MARCH,D_STALLED].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);}
if(u_sig===U_REALIGN)
{if(d_sig===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)
if(c_at(c)===U_SENTINEL)
{if(c_at(CCW[c][7])===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,c);return{cell:CCW[c][2]};}
if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&[D_MARCH,D_FOOD].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_FOOD,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===U_READY&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_STALLED&&[D_MARCH,D_STALLED].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&[D_GATHERER,D_STALLED].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_MARCH&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);}
if(u_sig===D_MARCH)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===D_FOOD)return sigc(D_FOOD,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)
if(c_at(c)===U_SENTINEL)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===U_READY&&c_at(4)===U_READY)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,c);}
if(u_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(d_sig===U_READY&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_READY,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_STALLED&&[D_STALLED,D_MARCH].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_MARCH&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===U_REALIGN&&[D_STALLED,D_MARCH].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);}
if(u_sig===D_GATHERER)
{if(d_sig===D_STALLED&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)
if(view[CCW[c][3]].ant.type===QUEEN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_GATHERER,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_FOOD,S_FRONT,c);}
if(u_sig===D_FOOD)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===D_FOOD)return sigc(D_FOOD,S_FRONT,c);if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_GATHERER,S_FRONT,c);}
return{cell:CCW[c][2]};}
function mdec_three_stand(c)
{var provisional=lchk2(c);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_SIDE,c);var u_sig=c_at(CCW[c][3]);var d_sig=PSIDES[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][7])];if(u_sig===U_REALIGN)
{if([D_MARCH,D_STALLED].includes(d_sig)&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===D_MARCH&&d_sig===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);if(u_sig===D_STALLED&&[D_STALLED,U_REALIGN].includes(d_sig)&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)
return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);}
function mdec_three_unstand(c)
{if(view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type===QUEEN)
{var provisional=lchk(c);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_FRONT,c);var d_sig=PUPS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][7])];return sigc(d_sig,S_FRONT,c);}
else
{var provisional=lchk(CCW[c][4]);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);var u_sig=c_at(CCW[c][5]);var d_sig=PDOWNS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][7])];if(u_sig===D_MARCH)
{if(d_sig===U_READY&&c_at(4)===U_READY)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===D_FOOD)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===D_GATHERER)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(d_sig===U_READY)
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_READY,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_FOOD)
{if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if([D_MARCH,U_REALIGN].includes(d_sig)&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)
return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===D_FOOD)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===U_REALIGN)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===U_SENTINEL)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD)
{if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===D_MARCH&&c_at(4)===U_SENTINEL)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===D_STALLED&&c_at(4)===U_SENTINEL)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===U_READY&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_READY,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===U_READY)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}
return sigc(c_at(4),S_FRONT,CCW[c][4]);}}
function mdec_three_recover(c)
{return sigc(U_SENTINEL,S_FRONT,c);}
function mdec_three_hang(c)
{return sigc(c_at(4),S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);}
function mdec_three_unhang(c)
{return sigc(c_at(4),S_SIDE,c);}
function mdec_four_z(c)
{var provisional=lchk2(CCW[c][4]);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);var u_sig=PSIDES[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][7])];var d_sig=PSIDES[c_at(CCW[c][4])][c_at(CCW[c][3])];if(u_sig===D_FOOD)
{if([D_FOOD,D_STALLED,U_REALIGN].includes(d_sig)&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)
return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&[U_REALIGN,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))
return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(d_sig===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===D_GATHERER)
{if(d_sig===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&[U_REALIGN,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))
return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===U_REALIGN)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_REALIGN,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);if(d_sig===U_READY&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);}
if(u_sig===U_READY&&d_sig===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)
return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,CCW[c][4]);}
function mdec_four_stairs(c)
{var provisional=lchk2(c);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_SIDE,c);var u_sig=PSIDES[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][1])];var d_sig=PSIDES[c_at(CCW[c][4])][c_at(CCW[c][3])];if(u_sig===D_MARCH)
{if(d_sig===D_FOOD)
{if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_FOOD,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===U_READY)
{if(c_at(4)===U_READY)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if([D_MARCH,U_REALIGN].includes(d_sig)&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);}
if(u_sig===D_FOOD)
{if(d_sig===D_MARCH)
{if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_FOOD,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===U_READY)
{if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&[U_REALIGN,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_FOOD,S_SIDE,c);if([U_REALIGN,D_STALLED].includes(d_sig)&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(u_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(d_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_MARCH)
{if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_GATHERER)
{if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);if([D_STALLED,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===U_READY)
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_READY,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===U_REALIGN&&[U_REALIGN,D_MARCH].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(u_sig===D_GATHERER)
{if(d_sig===D_STALLED)
{if([D_STALLED,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===U_READY)
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_FOOD&&[D_GATHERER,U_REALIGN].includes(c_at(4)))return sigc(D_FOOD,S_SIDE,c);if([D_MARCH,U_REALIGN].includes(d_sig)&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(d_sig===D_GATHERER&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(u_sig===U_REALIGN)
{if(d_sig===U_REALIGN)
{if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(c_at(4)===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_MARCH&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER,U_READY].includes(d_sig)&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);}
if(u_sig===U_READY)
{if(d_sig===D_MARCH)
{if(c_at(4)===U_READY)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_READY,S_SIDE,c);}
if([D_FOOD,D_GATHERER].includes(d_sig))
{if(c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_READY,S_SIDE,c);}
if(d_sig===D_STALLED&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_READY,S_SIDE,c);if(d_sig===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_SIDE,c);if(d_sig===U_READY&&c_at(4)===U_REALIGN)return sigc(U_READY,S_SIDE,c);}
return sigc(c_at(4),S_SIDE,c);}
function mwatch(cand)
{if(cand.cell===4)return cand;if(cand.hasOwnProperty("color"))return cand;if(view[cand.cell].food!==0)return sigc(D_FOOD,S_SIDE,0);if(is_harvestable(cand.cell))return sigc(D_FOOD,S_SIDE,0);if(view[cand.cell].ant!==null)return sigc(U_PANIC,S_SIDE,0);return cand;}
function marcher_decision()
{if(c_at(4)===U_PANIC||this_ant().food>0)return saboteur();var gatherer_count=0;var enemy_count=0;for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
{if(is_ally(tcell)&&view[tcell].ant.type===GATHERER)gatherer_count++;else if(is_enemy(tcell)&&!is_harvestable(tcell))enemy_count++;}
if(gatherer_count>1||enemy_count>0)return saboteur();var colored_neighbors=0;for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(c_at(tcell)>1)colored_neighbors++;if(colored_neighbors>5)return saboteur();var c=view_corner();switch(neighbor_type(c))
{case ONE_CORNER:return mwatch(mdec_one_corner(c));case ONE_EDGE:return mwatch(mdec_one_edge(c));case EE_BENT:return mwatch(mdec_ee_bent(c));case EE_STRAIGHT:return mwatch(mdec_ee_straight(c));case EC_LEFT:return mwatch(mdec_ec_left(c));case EC_RIGHT:return mwatch(mdec_ec_right(c));case EC_SPAWN:return mwatch(mdec_ec_spawn(c));case THREE_MARCH:return mwatch(mdec_three_march(c));case THREE_STAND:return mwatch(mdec_three_stand(c));case THREE_RECOVER:return mwatch(mdec_three_recover(c));case THREE_UNSTAND:return mwatch(mdec_three_unstand(c));case THREE_HANG:return mwatch(mdec_three_hang(c));case THREE_UNHANG:return mwatch(mdec_three_unhang(c));case FOUR_Z:return mwatch(mdec_four_z(c));case FOUR_STAIRS:return mwatch(mdec_four_stairs(c));default:return saboteur();}}
function opening_queen()
{for(tcell of rand_perm(SCAN_MOVES))
if(view[tcell].food===1)return{cell:tcell};var has_ally=false;var proxs=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
{if(view[tcell].ant!==null)
{has_ally=true;for(var i=0;i<9;i++)proxs[i]-=NEARS[tcell][i];}}
if(has_ally)
{var prox_order=index_sort(proxs);for(var i=8;i>=0;i--)
{var i_cell=prox_order[i];if(view[i_cell].ant===null&&view[i_cell].food===0)return{cell:i_cell};}}
if(this_ant().food>0)
{var num_ants=0;for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(view[tcell].ant!==null)num_ants++;if(num_ants===0)
{var is_clear=true;var num_black_corners=0;var black_corner=null;for(var tcell=0;tcell<9;tcell++)
{if(CORNERS.includes(tcell))
{if(c_at(tcell)===8)
{num_black_corners++;black_corner=tcell;}
else if(c_at(tcell)!==1)is_clear=false;}
else if(c_at(tcell)!==1)is_clear=false;}
if(num_black_corners===1&&is_clear)return{cell:CCW[black_corner][7],type:GATHERER};}}
if(c_at(4)!==8)return{cell:4,color:8};var cands=[0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0];for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
if(c_at(tcell)===8)
for(var i=0;i<9;i++)cands[i]-=NEARS[tcell][i];var cand_order=index_sort(cands);for(var i=8;i>=0;i--)
{var i_cell=cand_order[i];if(view[i_cell].ant===null&&view[i_cell].food===0)return{cell:i_cell};}
return{cell:4,color:8};}
function early_queen()
{var gcell=null;var ally_count=0;for(tcell of rand_perm(SCAN_MOVES))
{if(is_ally(tcell))
{ally_count++;if(view[tcell].ant.type===GATHERER&&EDGES.includes(tcell))gcell=tcell;}}
if(gcell===null)return opening_queen();for(tcell of rand_perm(CORNERS))
if(view[tcell].food>0&&NEARS[tcell][gcell]===5)
{if(c_at(tcell)===D_FOOD)return{cell:tcell};else return{cell:tcell,color:D_FOOD};}
for(tcell of rand_perm(EDGES))
if(view[tcell].food>0)
{if(c_at(tcell)!==D_FOOD&&NEARS[tcell][gcell]===4)
return{cell:tcell,color:D_FOOD};}
if(c_at(4)===D_FOOD)
{if(c_at(CCW[gcell][2])===D_FOOD&&view[CCW[gcell][2]].food===0)
return{cell:CCW[gcell][2],color:D_MARCH};return{cell:4,color:D_MARCH};}
if(c_at(CCW[gcell][6])===D_FOOD&&view[CCW[gcell][6]].food===0)
return{cell:CCW[gcell][6],color:D_MARCH};if(EDGES.includes(gcell)&&this_ant().food>2&&ally_count===1)
{var num_clear_cells=0;var num_down_food=0;var is_valid=true;for(var tcell=0;tcell<9;tcell++)
{if(c_at(tcell)===D_FOOD)
{num_down_food++;if(tcell!==4&&tcell!==gcell)is_valid=false;}
if(c_at(tcell)===D_MARCH)num_clear_cells++;}
if(is_valid&&num_down_food===1&&num_clear_cells===8)
{var food_factor=QFORMP_MAX-QFORMP_MIN
var food_coefficient=QFORMP_DECAY/food_factor
var actual_prob=food_factor/(food_coefficient*(this_ant().food-3)+1)+QFORMP_MIN;if(rand_choice(actual_prob))return{cell:CCW[gcell][1],type:rand_choice(.5)?MARCHER_A:MARCHER_B};else return{cell:gcell,color:D_MARCH};}}
return{cell:CCW[gcell][7]};}
function qwatch(cand)
{if(cand.hasOwnProperty("type")&&this_ant().food===0)return sigc(U_PANIC,S_SIDE,0);if(cand.hasOwnProperty("type")&&view[cand.cell].food!==0)return sigc(U_PANIC,S_SIDE,0);if(cand.cell===4)return cand;if(cand.hasOwnProperty("color"))return cand;if(is_enemy(cand.cell))return sigc(U_PANIC,S_SIDE,0);if(is_ally(cand.cell))return sigc(c_at(4),S_SIDE,0);return cand;}
function eqwatch(cand)
{if(cand.hasOwnProperty("type")&&this_ant().food===0)return qwatch(opening_queen());if(cand.hasOwnProperty("type")&&view[cand.cell].food!==0)return qwatch(opening_queen());if(cand.cell===4)return cand;if(cand.hasOwnProperty("color"))return cand;if(is_enemy(cand.cell))return qwatch(opening_queen());if(is_ally(cand.cell))return qwatch(opening_queen());return cand;}
function qdec_ee_straight(c)
{return sigc(c_at(4),S_SIDE,c);}
function qdec_ee_bent(c)
{return{cell:CCW[c][2]};}
function qdec_ec_skewed(c)
{if(view[CCW[c][5]].ant.type!==GATHERER)return opening_queen();if(this_ant().food>0&&view[c].ant.type===MARCHER_A)return{cell:CCW[c][7],type:MARCHER_B};if(this_ant().food>0&&view[c].ant.type===MARCHER_B)return{cell:CCW[c][7],type:MARCHER_A};return opening_queen();}
function qdec_ec_spawn(c)
{if(view[CCW[c][3]].ant.type!==GATHERER)return opening_queen();if(this_ant().food>0&&view[c].ant.type===MARCHER_A)return{cell:CCW[c][1],type:MARCHER_B};if(this_ant().food>0&&view[c].ant.type===MARCHER_B)return{cell:CCW[c][1],type:MARCHER_A};return opening_queen();}
function qdec_cc_edged(c)
{if(view[c].ant.type!==GATHERER)return opening_queen();if(this_ant().food>0&&view[CCW[c][2]].ant.type===MARCHER_A)return{cell:CCW[c][1],type:MARCHER_B};if(this_ant().food>0&&view[CCW[c][2]].ant.type===MARCHER_B)return{cell:CCW[c][1],type:MARCHER_A};return opening_queen();}
function qdec_three_march(c)
{var u_sig=PUPS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][1])];if(u_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(c_at(CCW[c][3])===D_MARCH&&[D_MARCH,D_GATHERER].includes(c_at(4)))
return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(c_at(CCW[c][3])===U_READY&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_READY,S_FRONT,c);}
if(u_sig===D_MARCH&&c_at(CCW[c][3])===U_READY&&c_at(4)===U_READY)
return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,c);if(u_sig===U_READY&&c_at(CCW[c][3])===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===U_READY)
if(c_at(CCW[c][1])===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,c);return sigc(c_at(4),S_FRONT,c);}
function qdec_three_stand(c)
{var u_sig=PUPS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][7])];if(u_sig===D_STALLED)
{if(c_at(CCW[c][3])===D_MARCH&&c_at(4)===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_STALLED,S_FRONT,c);if(c_at(CCW[c][3])===U_READY&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)return sigc(U_READY,S_FRONT,c);}
if(u_sig===D_MARCH&&c_at(CCW[c][3])===U_READY&&c_at(4)===U_READY)
return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,c);if(u_sig===U_READY&&c_at(CCW[c][3])===U_REALIGN&&c_at(4)===U_READY)
if(c_at(CCW[c][1])===D_MARCH)return sigc(D_MARCH,S_FRONT,c);return sigc(c_at(4),S_FRONT,c);}
function qdec_three_recover(c)
{var u_sig=PUPS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][1])];if(u_sig===D_FOOD)return sigc(D_FOOD,S_FRONT,c);if(this_ant().food>0&&[D_STALLED,U_READY].includes(u_sig))
{var food_factor=QFSPAWNP_MAX-QFSPAWNP_MIN
var food_coefficient=QFSPAWNP_DECAY/food_factor
var actual_prob=food_factor/(food_coefficient*(this_ant().food-1)+1)+QFSPAWNP_MIN;if(rand_choice(actual_prob))return{cell:CCW[c][3]};}
var provisional=lchk(c)
if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_FRONT,c);return sigc(c_at(4),S_FRONT,c);}
function qdec_three_unstand(c)
{var u_sig=PUPS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][7])];if(this_ant().food>0&&u_sig===D_STALLED&&c_at(CCW[c][5])===D_MARCH&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)
{var food_factor=QBSPAWNP_MAX-QBSPAWNP_MIN
var food_coefficient=QBSPAWNP_DECAY/food_factor
var actual_prob=food_factor/(food_coefficient*(this_ant().food-1)+1)+QBSPAWNP_MIN;if(rand_choice(actual_prob))return{cell:CCW[c][3]};}
if(u_sig===D_STALLED&&c_at(CCW[c][5])===U_READY&&c_at(4)===D_STALLED)
return sigc(U_READY,S_FRONT,c);return sigc(u_sig,S_FRONT,c);}
function qdec_three_block(c)
{var u_sig=PUPS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][1])];return sigc(u_sig,S_FRONT,c);}
function qdec_three_side(c)
{var u_sig=PUPS[c_at(CCW[c][1])][c_at(CCW[c][2])];return sigc(u_sig,S_FRONT,CCW[c][2]);}
function queen_wait()
{var c=view_corner();switch(neighbor_type(c))
{case ONE_EDGE:{if(this_ant().food>1)return{cell:CCW[c][3],type:GATHERER};}
break;case EC_LEFT:{var u_sig=PUPS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][1])];if(u_sig===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_GATHERER,S_FRONT,c);if(u_sig===U_REALIGN&&[U_REALIGN,U_SENTINEL].includes(c_at(c)))
if([U_REALIGN,U_SENTINEL].includes(c_at(CCW[c][1])))
return eqwatch(early_queen());var provisional=lchk(c);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_FRONT,c);if(this_ant().food>1)
{if(c_at(CCW[c][3])!==D_MARCH)return{cell:CCW[c][3],color:D_MARCH};return{cell:CCW[c][3],type:GATHERER};}}
break;case EC_RIGHT:{var u_sig=PUPS[c_at(c)][c_at(CCW[c][7])];if(u_sig===D_GATHERER)return sigc(D_GATHERER,S_FRONT,c);if(u_sig===U_REALIGN&&[U_REALIGN,U_SENTINEL].includes(c_at(c)))
if([U_REALIGN,U_SENTINEL].includes(c_at(CCW[c][7])))
return eqwatch(early_queen());var provisional=lchk(c);if(provisional!==null)return sigc(provisional,S_FRONT,c);if(this_ant().food>1)
{if(c_at(CCW[c][5])!==D_MARCH)return{cell:CCW[c][5],color:D_MARCH};return{cell:CCW[c][5],type:GATHERER};}}
break;}
if(c_at(4)!==U_PANIC)return sigc(U_PANIC,S_SIDE,c);else return opening_queen();}
function queen_march()
{var c=view_corner();switch(neighbor_type(c))
{case EE_STRAIGHT:return qwatch(qdec_ee_straight(c));case EE_BENT:return qwatch(qdec_ee_bent(c));case EC_SKEWED:return qwatch(qdec_ec_skewed(c));case EC_SPAWN:return qwatch(qdec_ec_spawn(c));case CC_EDGED:return qwatch(qdec_cc_edged(c));case THREE_MARCH:return qwatch(qdec_three_march(c));case THREE_STAND:return qwatch(qdec_three_stand(c));case THREE_RECOVER:return qwatch(qdec_three_recover(c));case THREE_UNSTAND:return qwatch(qdec_three_unstand(c));case THREE_BLOCK:return qwatch(qdec_three_block(c));case THREE_SIDE:return qwatch(qdec_three_side(c));default:return eqwatch(early_queen());}}
function queen_decision()
{marcher_count=0;gatherer_count=0;excess_gatherers=0;for(tcell of SCAN_MOVES)
{if(is_ally(tcell))
{if(view[tcell].ant.type===MARCHER_A||view[tcell].ant.type===MARCHER_B)marcher_count++;if(view[tcell].ant.type===GATHERER)
{if(EDGES.includes(tcell)||is_gatherer_marcher(tcell))gatherer_count++;else excess_gatherers++;}}
else if(is_enemy(tcell))return opening_queen();}
if(marcher_count>0&&gatherer_count===1&&excess_gatherers===0)return qwatch(queen_march());else if(marcher_count>0&&gatherer_count===0&&excess_gatherers===0)return qwatch(queen_wait());else if(gatherer_count===1&&excess_gatherers===0)return eqwatch(early_queen());else return opening_queen();}
function main_decide()
{switch(this_ant().type)
{case QUEEN:return queen_decision();case GATHERER:return gatherer_decision();case MARCHER_A:case MARCHER_B:return marcher_decision();default:return sanitize(saboteur());}}
return main_decide();
```

### Overview

This submission aims to create a line of ants that can sweep the area. Colors are used as signals to help the queen coordinate the line, not as trailmarkers.

This submission uses three types of workers in addition to the queen:

- Type 1: Formation marcher, A phase
- Type 2: Formation marcher, B phase
- Type 3: Gatherer
- Type 4: Reserved for future use

Ants are created in a full-width diagonal line as follows:

```
    A
    BA
     BA
      BA
       BA
        BA
         BA
          QG
```

The first four ants ants created are a gatherer and a marcher, A or B with equal probability, then one of each. After that, ants are created with probability after finding food, alternating between A and B. In the formation, the queen gatherer alternates between the two phases of marching, depending on the formation marcher last created.

### Early phase

When the queen spawns, she performs a bog-standard half-lightspeed straight-line walk, trying to avoid retracing her path. Once this gets her a single piece of food, she spawns a gatherer. After gathering 3 pieces of food, for every additional piece of food, the queen has a moderate probability of spawning 3 workers in a hard-coded formation creation routine, and the line takes off.

### General behavior

Ants march in lockstep, with phase A and phase B ants alternating between stopping and moving. The phase is recognised via matching the pattern of their neighboring allies, as the ants are unable to store state. Ants always move such that they remain adjacent to at least two other ants.

When an ant is diagonally behind an obstacle, it spends its turn shooting down the appropriate signal. The signal travels instantaneously down towards the queen (thanks to all the workers being in creation order), while upwards it can only manage lightspeed. The adjacent upstream marcher recognises the signal and propogates a signal to shoot a different signal up the line.

Workers disassociated from the line (either by mistake or by a panic signal) become saboteurs, scrambling nests and attempting to obstruct enemy workers they come across. They will actively avoid the formation if they run across it, as re-incorporation is impractical.

### Food collection

When food is encountered, the line halts. However, because signals can only manage lightspeed upstream, it takes time for the signal to propogate upwards, which causes upstream to get bent into a straight line. The ants on the end prevent it from completely straightening out by bending into a hook, but they too are halted.

The worker encountering the food shoots down a food signal instead of the usual clear signal, which all downstream ants relay and heed. The next turn, the same signal is recognised upstream and translated to a realignment signal, which travels upstream and causes workers upstream to also halt as they receive the signal. The last workers at the end maintain a bend at the end to maintain proximity to other workers.

The downstream signal makes it to the queen in a single turn, which the gatherer recognises as a signal to walk the line. Following the edge of the food signal, the gatherer walks forward until it finds food, and then goes the opposite direction to return it to the queen. If there is more pending food, the food signal persists; otherwise a stalled signal now shoots down the line, signalling the queen to shoot a ready signal, which in turn signals the point of the bend to shoot down the march signal.

Once the line goes back to marching, the stalled workers resume their march as the line catches up to them. The process occurs to the ants as the signals come to them, so it is entirely practical (and does happen) that the line resumes before the realign signal reaches the end of the line, or for an upstream part of the line to halt downstream before it receives a realign signal downstream.

### Off of the line

The line is designed to survive shearing, and any contiguous line of workers longer 3, along with a queen and gatherer, in creation order, is a full-functioning marching formation. Though the line is quite reliable, it is vulnerable to obstruction by enemy workers. When this happens, the ant that is most directly in front of the enemy worker emits a panic signal. The next turn, it shears off the line and goes off on its own, followed by all upstream workers which subsequently discover the inconsistency in not having anyone at their right, and do likewise. The downstream marchers are not bothered by this event, and continue marching.

Once off of the line, workers become saboteurs. They attempt to recolor colored areas with surrounding colors to create a mess that somewhat resembles the original area but does not contain the patterns critical to nest functioning. They will actively stick around enemy workers and try to obstruct or mislead them, and will actively avoid allies to prevent them from interfering with the line. If they are not surrounded by color, they perform a straight-line half-lightspeed walk to seek new colored areas to mix up.

Sabotaging workers may end up in a formation serendipitously, but the lack of a queen anchoring the right end should mean that they break apart soon after. If it doesn't, file a bug.

### Extras

Queen looting is a work in progress. The workers will recognise enemy queens as food rather than as enemy workers, but precisely how this interacts afterwards is untested and untuned.

To prevent existing color signals from interfering with the line, workers will recolor surrounding areas white if they would send a color signal, but are already standing on the color signal they want to send. This surroundings-clearing is so powerful that a marching formation can bore through a colored nest at full speed without problems.

Queen spawning is controlled by probability. As the game goes on and the queen has more food on hand, she becomes less eager to spawn new lines and add workers to existing lines, down to a tuneable asymptotic limit probability.

### To-do

- Clean out logical cruft
- Test and refine queen looting
- See if enemy workers can be walked around
- Investigate signal state reduction
- See if intentially shearing off the end worker helps

### Release notes

1.0: First version put up for submission, initial release

1.0.1: Performed logical reductions, made compatible with more controllers

1.1: Compacted a bunch of stuff, improved logic relating to error cases

1.1.1: Hotfix to solve disqualification problem

1.2: Removed further deadlocks, saboteur now overhauled

1.3: Reduced queen spawning rate, gave saboteurs a tuneup

1.3.1: Further reduced queen spawnrate, and fixed a disqualifying bug

1.4: Parameter tuning

Answer (score 6):

## Mandelbrant

*All of my answers contain similar low-level logic in the form of the Formic Functions Framework.*

*"HIGH-LEVEL LOGIC STARTS HERE" marks the end of the Framework's code.*

***WARNING:*** *This entry is mostly a demo of what's possible within the Formic Functions rule set. It wasn't thoroughly tested on non-empty map. Although it survived two whole games, I don't expect it to stay qualified for long.*

```js
// FORMIC FRAMEWORK \\
//  Version 7.0.4   \\
const QUEEN = 5;
const HERE = view[4];
const ME = HERE.ant;
const ORTHOGONALS = [1, 3, 5, 7];
const DIAGONALS = [0, 2, 6, 8];
const DIAGONALS_ORTHOGONALS = [0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7];
const DIRECTIONS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS = [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3];
const ROTATIONS = [
    [0, 1, 2,
     3, 4, 5,
     6, 7, 8],

    [6, 3, 0,
     7, 4, 1,
     8, 5, 2],

    [8, 7, 6,
     5, 4, 3,
     2, 1, 0],

    [2, 5, 8,
     1, 4, 7,
     0, 3, 6]
];
const NEIGHBORS = [
    [1, 4, 3],
    [2, 5, 4, 3, 0],
    [5, 4, 1],
    [0, 1, 4, 7, 6],
    [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3],
    [8, 7, 4, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 7],
    [6, 3, 4, 5, 8],
    [7, 4, 5]
];
const HORIZONTAL_FLIP = [2, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6];
const VERTICAL_FLIP = [6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2];

const DEBUG_MODE = false;
const log = DEBUG_MODE ? console.log : () => { };

function cells(...indices) {
    return indices.map(i => view[i]);
}
function colors(...indices) {
    return cells(...indices).map(c => c.color);
}
function ants(...indices) {
    return cells(...indices).map(c => c.ant);
}

function isColor(color, index) {
    return view[index].color === color;
}
function isAnyColor(colors, index) {
    return colors.includes(view[index].color);
}
function hasFood(index) {
    return view[index].food === 1;
}
function hasAnt(qualifies, index) {
    const a = view[index].ant;
    return a && (!(qualifies instanceof Function) || qualifies(a));
}
function hasFriend(type, index) {
    return hasAnt(a => a.friend && (!type || a.type === type), index);
}
const hasAnyFriend = bind(hasFriend, null);
function bind(f, ...args) {
    return f.bind(null, ...args);
}

function noTransform() {
    return { revert() { }, detransformAction() { } };
}
function indexTransform(indices) {
    const revertedIndices = new Array(9);
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        revertedIndices[indices[i]] = i;
    }

    view = indices.map(index => view[index]);

    return { revert() { view = revertedIndices.map(index => view[index]); }, detransformAction(action) { action.cell = indices[action.cell]; } };
}

const rotationTransformers = [noTransform, ...ROTATIONS.slice(1).map(r => bind(indexTransform, r))];

function bestTransformers(transformers, scorer) {
    let bestScore = 0;
    const bestIndices = [];
    const bestTransformers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < transformers.length; ++i) {
        const t = transformers[i];
        const {revert} = t();
        const score = scorer();
        revert();
        if (score > bestScore) {
            bestScore = score;
            bestIndices.length = 0;
            bestTransformers.length = 0;
        }
        if (score >= bestScore) {
            bestIndices.push(i);
            bestTransformers.push(t);
        }
    }

    return {score: bestScore, indices: bestIndices, transformers: bestTransformers};
}
function* withBestTransformation(transformers, scorer, continuation) {
    const best = bestTransformers(transformers, scorer);
    if (best.score > 0) {
        const {revert, detransformAction} = best.transformers[0]();
        for (const output of continuation(best)) {
            if (isAction(output)) {
                detransformAction(output);
            }
            yield output;
        }
        revert();
    }
}
const withBestRotation = bind(withBestTransformation, rotationTransformers);

const wait = {cell: 4};
function move(index) {
    return index >= 0 && index < 9 && view[index].ant === null && (view[index].food === 0 || ME.food === 0 || ME.type === QUEEN) ? { cell: index } : null;
}
function moveMany(...indices) {
    return indices.map(move);
}
function paint(color, index) {
    return index >= 0 && index < 9 && color >= 1 && color <= 8 && view[index].color !== color ? { cell: index, color } : null;
}
function paintMany(colors, ...indices) {
    return pairMap(indices, colors, paint);
}
function spawn(type, index) {
    return index >= 0 && index < 9 && view[index].ant === null && view[index].food === 0 && ME.food > 0 && ME.type === QUEEN && type >= 1 && type <= 4 ? { cell: index, type } : null;
}
function spawnMany(types, ...indices) {
    return pairMap(indices, types, spawn);
}
function pairMap(mainArr, sideArr, func) {
    return mainArr.map((v, i) => func(sideArr[i % sideArr.length], v));
}

function isAction(value) {
    return value instanceof Object && value.cell !== undefined; // TODO: Make this more strict.
}

log('=== start logic ===');
for (const output of main()) {
    if (isAction(output)) {
        log('=== end logic ===');
        return output;
    }
}

throw 'Decision was omitted.';

function* main() {
    // HIGH-LEVEL LOGIC STARTS HERE \\

    // TARGET SIZE:  2^21 pixels -- SUPPORTED
    // STRETCH GOAL: 2497 x 996
    // MAX POSSIBLE: 2500 x 1000

    // How long the painting triplet will go on for until they begin returning to the shifting station.
    // This value should not exceed 997 for the painter to work in all cases, or 2497 if you don't care about being positioned vertically.
    // It also shouldn't be too low. The exact lowest value is unclear, but it's likely to be in the teens.
    const LENGTH = 6 * 11;

    // Which function will be used for painting in the pixels.
    const getPictureColorAt = mandelbrot;

    function notReallyRainbow(index) {
        return index % 6 + 2;
    }
    function fromColorString(index) {
        // Input your own color string ({ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h } => { 8, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1 }).
        const colorString = '';

        return [8, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1][colorString.charCodeAt(index % colorString.length) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)];
    }
    function mandelbrot(index) {
        const ESCAPE = 2 ** 2, MAX_I = 8 * 10 - 1;
        const x0 = (index % LENGTH) / (LENGTH - 1) * 3 - 2, y0 = Math.floor(index / LENGTH) / (Math.floor(LENGTH * 2 / 3) - 1) * 2 - 1;
        let x = 0, y = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < MAX_I; ++i) {
            [x, y] = [x * x - y * y + x0, 2 * x * y + y0];
            if (x * x + y * y > ESCAPE) {
                return (i + 1) % 8 + 1;
            }
        }
        return 8;
    }

    // WARNING! Beyond likely lies awful code.
    // There are no more tunable parameters.
    // Continue reading at your own risk.

    const L1_OVERFLOW = 4096;
    const FILL_ORDER_INDEX = [1, 2, 3, 6];
    const FILL_ORDER_DIGIT = [0, 1, 2, 4];

    function parseNumber(...indices) {
        return indices.reduceRight((a, index) => (a << 3) + (index !== -1 ? view[index].color - 1 : 0), 0);
    }

    function colorAtDigit(n, d) {
        return ((n >>> (d * 3)) & 7) + 1;
    }

    function paintPictureFragment(number) {
        log(`initialized painter with ${number}`);
        return paint(getPictureColorAt(number), 0);
    }

    const COPIER = 1;
    const COUNTER = 2;
    const MAJOR = 3;
    const MINOR = 4;

    function* moveWait(index) {
        yield move(index);
        yield wait;
    }

    log(`type: ${ME.type}`);
    switch (ME.type) {
        case COPIER: {
            yield* withBestRotation(() => Math.max(hasFriend(QUEEN, 7) + hasFriend(MINOR, 3), hasFriend(QUEEN, 6) + hasFriend(MINOR, 0)) - 1, bind(moveWait, 5));
            yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, COUNTER, 7), function*() {
                if ([6, 3].findIndex(hasAnyFriend) === -1) {
                    yield paint(8, 3);
                    yield move(3);
                }
                yield wait;
            });
            yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, COUNTER, 8), function*() {
                const targetIndex = FILL_ORDER_INDEX[view[4].color - 3];
                yield paint(view[5].color, targetIndex);
                yield wait;
            });
            yield wait;
        }

        case COUNTER: {
            yield* withBestRotation(() => hasFriend(COPIER, 2) + hasFriend(MAJOR, 0) - 1, bind(moveWait, 5));
            yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, COPIER, 1), function*() {
                if (hasFriend(MAJOR, 0)) {
                    yield paint(view[6].color, 8);
                }
                yield wait;
            });
            yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, COPIER, 0), function*() {
                if (!hasAnyFriend(6)) {
                    const progress = view[0].color;
                    if (progress === 8) {
                        const number = parseNumber(8, 7, 4, 1) + 1;
                        yield* paintMany([1, 2, 3].map(bind(colorAtDigit, number)), 3, 5, 2);
                        yield paint(7, 0);
                    } else if (progress === 7) {
                        const number = parseNumber(8) + 1;
                        yield paint(colorAtDigit(number, 0), 4);
                        yield paint(6, 0);
                    } else {
                        const number = parseNumber(...progress === 6 ? [4, 3] : [7, 8], 5, 2) * LENGTH;
                        if (progress > 2) {
                            if (progress === 6) {
                                yield* paintMany(colors(4, 3), 7, 8);
                            } else if (progress === 5) {
                                yield* paintMany([5, 6].map(bind(colorAtDigit, number)), 3, 4);
                            }
                            yield paint(colorAtDigit(number, FILL_ORDER_DIGIT[progress - 3]), 1);
                            if (progress !== 3) {
                                yield paint(progress - 1, 0);
                            } else {
                                yield paint(number + 1 === L1_OVERFLOW ? 2 : 1, 0);
                            }
                        } else {
                            yield paint(colorAtDigit(number, 3), 1);
                            yield wait;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            yield wait;
        }

        case MAJOR: {
            yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, COPIER, 5), bind(moveWait, 6));
            yield* withBestRotation(() => hasFriend(QUEEN, 7) + hasFriend(MINOR, 1) - 1, bind(moveWait, 5));
            yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, QUEEN, 2), bind(moveWait, 1));
            yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, MINOR, 2), function*() {
                const number = parseNumber(-1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 4, 5) + (isColor(2, 1) ? L1_OVERFLOW : 0);
                yield* paintMany([4, 5, 6].map(bind(colorAtDigit, number)), 6, 7, 8);
                yield move(7);
            });
            yield wait;
        }

        case MINOR: {
            yield* withBestRotation(() => hasFriend(COPIER, 8) + hasFriend(QUEEN, 6) - hasFriend(MAJOR, 3) - 1, bind(moveWait, 7));
            yield* withBestRotation(() => hasFriend(MAJOR, 6) + hasFriend(QUEEN, 7) - 1, bind(moveWait, 3));
            yield* withBestRotation(() => hasFriend(MAJOR, 8) - hasFriend(QUEEN, 7), bind(moveWait, 5));
            yield* withBestRotation(() => hasFriend(MAJOR, 7) + hasFriend(QUEEN, 5) - 1, bind(moveWait, 1));
            yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, QUEEN, 6), function*() {
                if (hasFriend(MAJOR, 3)) {
                    yield wait;
                }
                const number = parseNumber(0, 1) + 1;
                yield* paintMany([0, 1].map(bind(colorAtDigit, number)), 3, 4);
                yield move(7);
            });
            yield wait;
        }

        case QUEEN: {
            if (DIRECTIONS.some(hasAnyFriend)) {
                yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, COPIER, 5), function*() {
                    if (!hasFriend(COUNTER, 7)) {
                        yield spawn(COUNTER, 8);
                    }
                    if (!hasFriend(MAJOR, 3) && !hasFriend(MAJOR, 0)) {
                        yield spawn(MAJOR, 6);
                    }
                    yield spawn(MINOR, 0);
                    if (!hasFriend(MAJOR, 0) && hasFriend(MAJOR, 3)) {
                        yield move(7);
                    }
                    yield wait;
                });

                yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, MAJOR, 2), function*() {
                    if (!hasFriend(MINOR, 8)) {
                        yield move(1);
                    }
                    yield wait;
                });

                yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, MINOR, 0), function*() {
                    if (hasFriend(MAJOR, 3)) {
                        yield move(1);
                        yield wait;
                    } else if (hasFriend(MAJOR, 6)) {
                        yield wait;
                    }
                });

                yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, MAJOR, 7), function*() {
                    if (!hasFriend(COPIER, 6)) {
                        yield paintPictureFragment(parseNumber(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8));
                    }
                    yield wait;
                });

                yield* withBestRotation(bind(hasFriend, MINOR, 5), function*() {
                    if (isColor(3, 4)) {
                        const number = parseNumber(1, 2, 3, 5) + 1;
                        yield* paintMany([colorAtDigit(number, 2), number + 1 === L1_OVERFLOW ? 2 : 1, colorAtDigit(number, 3)], 6, 7, 8);
                        yield move(7);
                        yield wait;
                    } else {
                        const number = parseNumber(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8);
                        yield paintPictureFragment(number);
                        if ((number + 1) % LENGTH === 0) {
                            yield move(8);
                            yield wait;
                        }
                        yield paint(3, 4);
                    }

                    throw 'illogical failure 1';
                });

                throw 'illogical failure 2';
            }

            yield* moveMany(...DIAGONALS_ORTHOGONALS.filter(hasFood));

            if (ME.food >= 4) {
                yield* spawnMany([COPIER], ...ORTHOGONALS);
            }

            yield* moveMany(...DIAGONALS_ORTHOGONALS.filter(bind(isColor, 1)), ...DIAGONALS_ORTHOGONALS); // TODO: Watch out for accidental entrapment.
            yield wait;
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Gallery

[image: Mandelbrot full]
[image: Mandelbrot tiny]

---

## Explanation

I will keep the explanation quite short, but keep in mind that there are a lot of nasty details that I had to figure out while making this that I won't go into.

#### Phase 1

First, the queen collects 4 food to make 4 workers, each serving a different purpose. She doesn't leave any colors behind in order to minimize the chance of ruining the painting. You will see why that is shortly.

#### Phase 2

After spawning the 4 workers, the core loop of the entry promptly begins. From now on I will assume a consistent view orientation, since the entry does that as well.

First a coordinated 5-ant dance is performed to achieve the correct orientation for painting. This is likely the most volatile phase, and it's probable that the entry will be disqualified because of enemy intervention here. Afterwards the ants split up.

3 ants (the queen and 2 workers) go into a painting loop. They carry a 21-bit (7 cells * 3 bits per cell) integer in the form of colors with them, which can be used to index into any image desired. By default, this image is the Mandelbrot set. Additionally, the top-left cell is reserved for the pixel being painted, and the central cell is reserved for things that are outside the scope of this explanation. The triplet doesn't need any colors to guide them, since they figure out the orientation by finding each other. Each cycle they shift the integer by 1 cell downwards, making sure to increment it by 1 every time they do that. The loop ends when the end of the painted line is reached, which is configured by the `LENGTH` constant. At that point, a 3-ant coordinated dance begins and results in the trio ending up in an awkward returning configuration. The queen also shifts to the right one cell during the dance. They travel upwards until they meet up with the pair of ants waiting for them.

While waiting for the queen and her helpers to return, said pair of ants sets up the local color environment so that the painters can continue working after their arrival. This was the most difficult part to figure out. One ant maintains a 4-color (12-bit) integer, which it uses to provide instructions to the other ant. Those instructions describe which cell should be painted by it and to what color. This is necessary because a single ant does not have enough space in its view to store all the required information to do the coloring by itself. Before and during this process, it is also necessary for the integer maintainer to move the number 1 to the right, and also increment it 1. After the instruction relay is done, the integer maintainer fills in the cells it has access to and completes the environment setup. Hibernation begins - the pair idles, awaiting the return of the painters.

The cycle completes when the three ants return to the pair and start performing the 5-ant dance again.

---

This entry features parameters. It is currently tuned to draw a tiny Mandelbrot set. You can adjust the `LENGTH` of the picture, swap out the picture painting function or even roll your own. Have fun!

Recommended controller: [dzaima's](https://dzaima.github.io/koth-webplayer/formic.htm#).

---

## Changelog

#### Version 1.0

- initial release

Comment: Wow. I specifically designed this challenge to be limiting and low information, and I'm still being amazed by how much this can be worked around with cooperation between ants.

Comment: I appreciate this is a proof of concept rather than a competitive entry, but it also makes me wonder if it could have a practical application as a queen trap, with a suitable pattern to lead other queens in to have their food stolen.

Comment: I ran this with all other players unticked, to see the image being printed at maximum speed, and while watching it I hear old fashioned dot matrix printer sounds in my head :)

Comment: Having run a few games to see how this performs against all the other players, it's worth pointing out that even as a proof of concept this doesn't score lowest - doing better than several of the other players. Once a full tournament has been run this one isn't going to be last.

Comment: Why? WHY? ***Why would you do this?*** Crikey, this challenge has had answers posted while I've been at *three different jobs.*

Comment: @trichoplax I'm not exactly sure how volatile maintaining a counter throughout the whole game in order to catch queens would be. Regardless, this *is* quite slow, so I haven't bothered to evaluate it for the purpose. And I'm also pretty sure that there are more efficient ways of baiting queens - for starters, the counter *really* doesn't need to be able to count to 2 freaking million.

Comment: @Draco18s I just love this challenge too much :P

Comment: Will posting a new KotH save you from this one...?

Comment: @trichoplax I've been waiting for another groundbreaking KotH (or even a spiritual successor to Formic) for over a year now, but none are coming...

Comment: I have things developing in my mind but my ideas have a very long gestation period...

Answer (score 5):

## Brownian Jig

This player produces no workers, and the queen moves randomly. The random motion is because the queen returns the same direction each time, but the input visible cells are presented at a random orientation each move, preventing the movement being in a straight line.

The first code block in an answer is the one automatically included in the game:

```
// Full version that won't be disqualified for moving onto another ant

// Move to food if visible
for (var i=0; i<9; i+=1) {
    if (view[i].food) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move to one of the diagonal cells if not occupied
for (var i=0; i<9; i+=2) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise one of the vertical or horizontal cells if not occupied
for (var i=1; i<9; i+=2) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise don't move at all
return {cell:4}
```

Here is a simpler version that doesn't check for other ants, but has identical behaviour up until the point it gets disqualified for trying to step onto another ant:

```
// Basic version for an intuitive understanding

// Move to food if visible
for (var i=0; i<9; i+=1) {
    if (view[i].food) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move "up and left", which will be a random direction
return {cell:0}
```

This second code block won't be picked up by the game - this means you can include additional code blocks as part of your answer's explanation. Just make sure the code block that you wish to compete in the game is the first one in the answer.

For an example of producing straight line movement despite the random orientation of the input, see [Romanesco Road](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135104/20283).

Comment: Why does it need to mark colors?

Comment: Good question. This is just an initial example answer to give people something to help pick up the rules. It could score twice as high by simply not marking any colour, but as an example I wanted its path to be clearly visible to aid understanding.

Comment: I see, makes sense.

Comment: I've now edited to remove the colour marking, as this was an unnecessary (and redundant) distraction. The queen will now move to food if visible, and favour diagonal moves to cover more ground. No colour is used at all.

Answer (score 5):

## Steamroller Ants

```
/*Ants will try to move diagonally in the following fashion:
 * 2
 * 51
 *
 *Type 1 and queen are the two core ants
 */


switch (view[4].ant.type) {

  case 1: //Guiding ant
    //Look for queen, try to move diagonally
    if (view[7].ant && view[7].ant.friend && view[7].ant.type === 5 && !view[8].ant) return {cell: 8};
    else if (view[5].ant && view[5].ant.friend && view[5].ant.type === 5 && !view[2].ant) return {cell: 2};
    else if (view[3].ant && view[3].ant.friend && view[3].ant.type === 5 && !view[6].ant) return {cell: 6};
    else if (view[1].ant && view[1].ant.friend && view[1].ant.type === 5 && !view[0].ant) return {cell: 0};
    else return {cell: 4};
  case 2: //Other wing
    //Look for queen, try to move diagonally. If there is food, rotate the other way to start rotating procedure
    if (view[7].ant && view[7].ant.friend && view[7].ant.type === 5 && !view[6].ant) {
      if (view[6].food) {
        if (!view[8].ant) return {cell: 8};
        else return {cell: 4};
      } else return {cell: 6};
    } else if (view[5].ant && view[5].ant.friend && view[5].ant.type === 5 && !view[8].ant) {
      if (view[8].food) {
        if (!view[2].ant) return {cell: 2};
        else return {cell: 4};
      } else return {cell: 8};
    } else if (view[3].ant && view[3].ant.friend && view[3].ant.type === 5 && !view[0].ant) {
      if (view[0].food) {
        if (!view[6].ant) return {cell: 6};
        else return {cell: 4};
      } else return {cell: 0};
    } else if (view[1].ant && view[1].ant.friend && view[1].ant.type === 5 && !view[2].ant) {
      if (view[2].food) {
        if (!view[0].ant) return {cell: 0};
        else return {cell: 4};
      } else return {cell: 2};
    } else return {cell: 4};
  case 5: //Queen ant
    
    //If forever alone
    if (!view[1].ant && !view[3].ant && !view[5].ant && !view[7].ant) {
      if (view[4].color === 2) { //If on colored square, try to move
        if (view[0].color === 2 && !view[8].ant) return {cell: 8};
        else if (view[2].color === 2 && !view[6].ant) return {cell: 6};
        else if (view[6].color === 2 && !view[2].ant) return {cell: 2};
        else if (view[8].color === 2 && !view[0].ant) return {cell: 0};
        //Can't find color, or path is blocked? try diagonals regardless of color
        else if (!view[0].ant) return {cell: 0};
        else if (!view[2].ant) return {cell: 2};
        else if (!view[6].ant) return {cell: 6};
        else if (!view[8].ant) return {cell: 8};
        //Everything else failed? Stay put.
        else return {cell: 4};
      } else { //If not on colored square, look for food, or set current color to 2.
        if (view[4].ant.food >= 1) { //Try to make Guiding ant
          if (!view[1].ant && !view[1].food) return {cell: 1, type: 1};
          else if (!view[3].ant && !view[3].food) return {cell: 3, type: 1};
          else if (!view[5].ant && !view[5].food) return {cell: 5, type: 1};
          else if (!view[7].ant && !view[7].food) return {cell: 7, type: 1};
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) { //Look for food
          if (view[i].food) return {cell: i};
        }
        return {cell: 4, color:2};
      }
    } else { //Queen has partner
      //Make other wing
      if (view[4].ant.food >= 1) {
        if (view[1].ant && view[1].ant.friend && view[1].ant.type === 1 && !view[3].ant && !view[3].food && !view[5].ant) return {cell: 3, type: 2};
        else if (view[3].ant && view[3].ant.friend && view[3].ant.type === 1 && !view[7].ant && !view[7].food && !view[1].ant) return {cell: 7, type: 2};
        else if (view[5].ant && view[5].ant.friend && view[5].ant.type === 1 && !view[1].ant && !view[1].food && !view[7].ant) return {cell: 1, type: 2};
        else if (view[7].ant && view[7].ant.friend && view[7].ant.type === 1 && !view[5].ant && !view[5].food && !view[3].ant) return {cell: 5, type: 2};
      }

      //If food is orthogonal to Queen, stay put
      if (view[1].food || view[3].food || view[5].food || view[7].food) return {cell: 4};

      //Look for guiding type 1 ant, try to move diagonally
      else if (view[7].ant && view[7].ant.friend && view[7].ant.type === 1 && !view[6].ant) return {cell: 6};
      else if (view[5].ant && view[5].ant.friend && view[5].ant.type === 1 && !view[8].ant) return {cell: 8};
      else if (view[3].ant && view[3].ant.friend && view[3].ant.type === 1 && !view[0].ant) return {cell: 0};
      else if (view[1].ant && view[1].ant.friend && view[1].ant.type === 1 && !view[2].ant) return {cell: 2};
    }
  default: return {cell: 4};
}
```

These ants work off of a similar concept as Dave's [Forensic Ants](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135108/52152). However, they move diagonally, and moves in groups of 3.

### Phase 1: Food scramble

The Queen ant just moves diagonally until it can see a single piece of food. It does this using a similar concept to the [Romanesco Road](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135104/52152), where the color trail laid behind the Queen can help it figure out which way is forward.

### Phase 2: 2 ants

The Queen makes a new type 1 "guiding" ant, which partners with the Queen to move diagonally together. They each figure out which way is forward relative to their respective partners.

### Phase 3: Steamrolling

Once the Queen and her partner find a piece of food, the queen uses it to make a type 2 ant. This ant has specific instructions to follow the Queen, and also tags along. This makes a 3 wide diagonally moving row of ants, making it quite fast at getting food.

### Rotating

If the type 2 ant sees that it will move into some food, it instead will move in the other direction, where the type 1 ant used to be. This means that all the ants will have rotated the direction they move in, and so the ants should have a very low probability of wrapping back to their starting point.

Note: if for some reason (maybe a collision with another ant?) the type 2 ant was born before the type 1 ant, then this rotation would result in the type 2 ant trying to move onto the type 1 ant. To resolve this, the type 2 ant would instead leave itself behind, and let the Queen make another type 2 ant.

Comment: During one of my experiments I found that randomly changing direction when finding food can be quite effective for avoiding infinite wrapping. It reduces the chance of every step covering new ground, but maybe it could be useful here?

Comment: @Dave the part about changing direction is what concerns me. If I can find a way to change direction without losing either of my workers, then this idea will definitely work. If not, I might try to have a color as a marker for when to leave behind a worker, and have the queen change direction.

Comment: @trichoplax Do you know the seed that was used during that disqualification, and maybe the move number too? It would be very beneficial to know the circumstances that led to that issue.

Comment: @trichoplax Nevermind, I just went and added some extra sanity checks. It (hopefully) wont get disqualified anymore.

Comment: You can use a seed for testing, which allows rerunning it to see exactly what happened if something went wrong, but that would give the same result every game, which is no good for the leaderboard. The leaderboard tournaments are run with no tick in the seeded random checkbox, which means it uses cryptorandom to make it as fair as possible.

Comment: @trichoplax Again? My god, I must have done something terribly wrong to get disqualified twice... I'll take a look into it.

Comment: @KZhang there have been a few players disqualified and then reincluded after an edit. It seems there's a surprising number of edge cases that are easy to overlook...

Comment: I'll include it in the next leaderboard tournament now it's fixed. Might take over 24 hours though, as the tournaments are getting more and more long running with all the worker-heavy strategies...

Comment: The latest edit of this player was disqualified: "A laden worker cannot move onto food." **Input:** [{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":{"food":0,"type":2,"friend":true}},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":{"food":28,"type":5,"friend":true}},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":1,"friend":true}},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":1,"food":1,"ant":null},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":{"food":0,"type":1,"friend":false}},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":{"food":25,"type":5,"friend":false}}] **Response:** {"cell":6}

Answer (score 5):

## Medusa

```
function clean(move) {
    if (move["color"] == undefined) {
        if (view[move["cell"]].ant != null) {
            move = {
                cell: 4
            }
        }
        if (move["type"] == undefined) {
            if (view[4].ant.type == 5 && move["cell"] != 4 && view[move["cell"]].color > 2) {
                move["color"] = 1
            }
            if (view[move["cell"]].food == 1 && view[4].ant.type < 5 && view[4].ant.food > 0) {
                move = {
                    cell: 4
                }
            }
        } else if (view[4].ant.type != 5 || view[4].ant.food == 0 || view[move["cell"]].food != 0) {
            move = {
                cell: 4
            }
        }
    }
    return move
}

function coord(cell) {
    var x = (cell % 3) - 1
    var y = 1 - (cell - (cell % 3)) / 3
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    }
}

function getcell(x, y) {
    return (x + 1) + (1 - y) * 3
}

var diags = [0, 2, 8, 6]

var colorcounts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    colorcounts[view[i].color]++
}

var queen = -1
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend == true && view[i].ant.type == 5) {
        queen = i
    }
}

var guard = -1
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend == true && view[i].ant.type == 1) {
        guard = i
    }
}

var forager = -1
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (view[i].ant != null && view[i].ant.friend == true && view[i].ant.type == 2) {
        forager = i
    }
}

var black = -1
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (view[i].color == 8) {
        black = i
    }
}

var yellow = -1
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (view[i].color == 2) {
        yellow = i
    }
}


if (view[4].ant.type == 5) {
    if (forager >= 0 && view[forager].color == 8) {
        return clean({
            cell: forager,
            color: 2
        })
    }

    if (guard == -1) {
        if (view[4].color == 3) {
            if (view[4].ant.food > 1) {
                return clean({
                    cell: 0,
                    type: 2
                })
            }
            return clean({
                cell: 0,
                type: 1
            })
        }
        if (view[4].ant.food >= 3) {
            return clean({
                cell: 4,
                color: 3
            })
        }
        if (view[4].color == 1) {
            return clean({
                cell: 4,
                color: 2
            })
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (view[i].food == 1) {
                return clean({
                    cell: i
                })
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (view[diags[i]].color != 2 && view[diags[(i + 2) % 4]].color == 2) {
                return clean({
                    cell: diags[i]
                })
            }
        }
        return clean({
            cell: 0
        })
    }

    var state = 3
    var max = 0
    for (var i = 3; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (colorcounts[i] > max) {
            max = colorcounts[i]
            state = i
        }
    }

    if (state == 3) {
        if (black >= 0 && forager == -1) {
            return clean({
                cell: black,
                type: 2
            })
        }
        if (forager >= 0 && view[forager].color != 2) {
            return clean({
                cell: 0,
                color: 8
            })
        }
        if (colorcounts[3] == 9) {
            return clean({
                cell: 4,
                color: 4
            })
        }
    }
    if (state == 4) {
        if (colorcounts[4] == 9) {
            return clean({
                cell: 4,
                color: 3
            })
        }
    }
    return clean({
        cell: 4
    })
}
if (view[4].ant.type == 1) {
    var dest = 0
    var destmap = [1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 7, 8, 7]
    dest = destmap[queen]
    if (view[queen].color != view[dest].color && (view[queen].color == view[4].color || view[4].color == view[dest].color)) {
        if (queen < 4 && view[dest].color > 2 && view[dest].color < 5) {
            return clean({
                cell: queen,
                color: view[dest].color
            })
        }
        return clean({
            cell: dest,
            color: view[queen].color
        })
    }
    return clean({
        cell: dest
    })
}
if (view[4].ant.type == 2) {
    if (queen >= 0 && view[4].color == 8) {
        return clean({
            cell: 4
        })
    }
    var state = 3
    var max = 0
    for (var i = 5; i <= 7; i++) {
        if (colorcounts[i] > max) {
            max = colorcounts[i]
            state = i
        }
    }
    var flowx = 0
    var flowy = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < 9; j++) {
            var loci = coord(i)
            var locj = coord(j)
            var dx = locj.x - loci.x
            var dy = locj.y - loci.y
            var cyc = 0
            if (view[i].color >= 5 && view[i].color <= 7 && view[j].color >= 5 && view[j].color <= 7) {
                var cyc = ((view[j].color - view[i].color) % 3 + 3) % 3
                if (cyc == 2) {
                    cyc = -1
                }
            } else if (view[i].color >= 5 && view[i].color <= 7) {
                cyc = 0.1
            } else {
                cyc = -0.1
            }
            flowx += cyc * dx / (dx * dx + dy * dy)
            flowy += cyc * dy / (dx * dx + dy * dy)

        }
    }
    if (flowx * flowx > flowy * flowy) {
        flowy = 0
    } else {
        flowx = 0
    }
    if (flowx < 0) {
        flowx = -1
    }
    if (flowy < 0) {
        flowy = -1
    }
    if (flowx > 0) {
        flowx = 1
    }
    if (flowy > 0) {
        flowy = 1
    }
    if (queen >= 0) {
        var locq = coord(queen)
        flowx = -locq.x
        flowy = -locq.y
        state = 5
    }
    if (view[4].ant.food > 0) {
        if (guard >= 0) {
            var destmap = [1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 7, 8, 7]
            return clean({
                cell: destmap[guard]
            })
        }
        dest = getcell(-flowx, -flowy)
        if (dest != 7) {
            dest = 1
        }
        if (view[dest].color >= 5 && view[dest].color <= 7) {
            return clean({
                cell: dest
            })
        }
        if (view[dest - 1].color >= 5 && view[dest - 1].color <= 7) {
            return clean({
                cell: dest - 1
            })
        }
        return clean({
            cell: 4
        })
    }
    if (view[4].color >= 5 && view[4].color <= 7) {
        state = view[4].color
    }
    var nextc = ((state - 4) % 3 + 5)
    var prevc = ((state - 3) % 3 + 5)
    var centerdest
    centerdest = getcell(flowx, flowy)
    if (view[centerdest].color != state && view[centerdest].color != nextc) {
        return clean({
            cell: centerdest,
            color: nextc
        })
    }
    for (var dest = 1; dest < 9; dest++) {
        var locd = coord(dest)
        var net = locd.x * flowx + locd.y * flowy
        if (net > 0 && view[dest].color != view[centerdest].color) {
            return clean({
                cell: dest,
                color: view[centerdest].color
            })
        }
    }
    for (var dest = 0; dest < 9; dest++) {
        if (view[dest].food == 1) {
            if (view[dest].color >= 5 && view[dest].color <= 7) {
                return clean({
                    cell: dest
                })
            }
            return clean({
                cell: dest,
                color: state
            })
        }
    }
    if (centerdest == 4 && view[0].color >= 5 && view[0].color <= 7) {
        return clean({
            cell: 0
        })
    }
    if (centerdest > 0 && view[centerdest - 1].color >= 5 && view[centerdest - 1].color <= 7) {
        return clean({
            cell: centerdest - 1
        })
    }
    return clean({
        cell: centerdest
    })
}
```

This bot... isn't good, but it uses several cool strategies that I think will be included in my future ant bots.  Its name comes from the shape the colony makes on the game board.

[image: Medusa in action]

## Phase 1: Initial Investment

The queen moves straight diagonally until it picks up 3 pieces of food, enough to start a colony.  Once it accumulates those pieces, it settles down (becomes a stationary queen) and then makes 2 foragers and 1 guard. As an interesting part of strategy, the presence of the guard ant itself is what triggers the next phase, and is what prevents the queen from ever become mobile again.

## Phase 2: Colonize

Here, the three types of ants play different roles:

**Queen**

The queen slowly oscillates between two states, with the assistance of the guard.  The current state is what determines whether or not a newly acquired piece of food is turned into a worker, so roughly 50% of food is re-invested in the colony.  The entire 3x3 area containing the queen is used to store state, so that any erasure can be undone and the state recovered.

**Guard**

The guard lives his whole life adjacent to the queen, circling it randomly.

The guard plays a key role in maintaining the queen's state.  It attempts to correct any errors in the queen's 3x3 area.  When there are two valid alternative colors in the area, which of the two colors becomes the "corrected" state is relatively random.  Once a consensus is reached, however, the queen flips her square to the opposite color, re-initiating the process.  This is what causes the oscillation of the queen's state, and it is done in a very error-resistant way.

The guard also serves as a gatekeeper the the queen's "palace".  When a forager sees the guard, it is able to move next to the queen even though the queen is out of visual range.

**Foragers**

The foragers lays out a cyclic red-green-blue pattern as they leave the colony, and follow it backwards when they are carrying food.  They end up painting quite a considerable area, because really *wide* paths are necessary to ensure that the paths do not become too tangled and that they can find their way back even if some cells are damaged.

Typical path of a forager:

[image: Forager path]

Notice how it usually travels in a straight line but occasionally turns 90 degrees.  This is a result of the way it randomly walks within its own path as it is laying it down.

Comment: I wonder whether my trail-eraser will be able to strand the foragers. It's good at erasing wide paths, as you can see when it goes against black hole.

Comment: @ppperry Sometimes it does.

Comment: Would it be possible to make the workers return more efficiently by only moving in the cycle r->b->g->r?

Comment: @trichoplax I didn't realize that was something it wasn't allowed to do.  Anyways fixed now.

Comment: It was under "Disqualification": "The cell to produce a worker on is not empty." but I've edited the spec to make it a bit more explicit now: "The cell to produce a worker on is not empty (contains food or an ant)."

Answer (score 4):

## FireFlyMkII

*Note that until my entry is complete, this code will be ugly as it is trans-compiled from my master development source which is being performed in java.*

```js
    // maps current view's cells' indecies to the rotated cell's location's indecies for each direction
    var rotate = 
            [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
             [2,5,8,1,4,7,0,3,6],
             [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0],
             [6,3,0,7,4,1,8,5,2]];

    // the colours that form the pattern of the trail back to the queen
    var TRAIL_COLOR_A = 8;
    var TRAIL_COLOR_B = 2;
    var TRAIL_COLOR_C = 5;
    var trailColours = [TRAIL_COLOR_A,TRAIL_COLOR_B,TRAIL_COLOR_C];
    var trailColoursLookUp = [-1,-1,1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,0];

    var ORIENTATION_MARKER = 8;

    // Queens Modes
    var QUEEN_MODE_HUNTING_MOVING = 6;
    var QUEEN_MODE_HUNTING_PAINTING = 1;
    var QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING = 5;
    var QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING_SPAWNING = 3;
    var QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_EVEN = 7;
    var QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_ODD = 4;
    var QUEEN_MODE_NESTING = 2;

    // the number of non-blank (i.e. not colour 1 ) colours to used to encode the queen's worker spawn counter. Min of 1. Max of 7
    var SPAWN_COUNTER_NON_BLANK_COLOURS_COUNT = 7;


    // the maximum number that can be encoded using the queen's worker spawn counter
    var SPAWN_COUNTER_MAX = SPAWN_COUNTER_NON_BLANK_COLOURS_COUNT*SPAWN_COUNTER_NON_BLANK_COLOURS_COUNT*SPAWN_COUNTER_NON_BLANK_COLOURS_COUNT -1;//SPAWN_COUNTER_NON_BLANK_COLOURS_COUNT * SPAWN_COUNTER_USED_CELLS_COUNT_MAX;

    // the minimum game ticks between spawning a worker. Min of 0, Max of SPAWN_COUNTER_MAX
    var TICKS_BETWEEN_FOOD_RETURN_MAX = 50;

    // No Operation... i.e. stay put do nothing
    var NO_OP = {cell:4};

    var ANT_TYPE_WORKER = 1; 
    var ANT_TYPE_QUEEN = 5;

    var orientationMarkerRotation = -1;

    var i=0;
    var j=0;

    // returns true of the provided colour is a trail colour
function isTrailColour(colour)
    {
        return colour === trailColours[0] || colour === trailColours[1] || colour === trailColours[2];
    }

    // returns the colour of the colour in the trail away from queen
function nextTrailColor(currentTrailColour)
    {
        return trailColours[(trailColoursLookUp[currentTrailColour]+1)%3];
    }

    // returns the colour of the colour in the trail toward from queen
function prevTrailColor(currentTrailColour)
    {
        return trailColours[(3+trailColoursLookUp[currentTrailColour]-1)%3];
    }

    // RNG
function randomNumberGenerator(seed)
    {
        return (1103515245 * seed + 12345) % 2147483647;
    }

    // returns a positive random integer based on the provided ant's view and seed
function randomInt(view,seed)
    {
        for (var i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            if (view[i].ant !=null)
            {
                seed=randomNumberGenerator(seed+view[i].ant.food);
                seed=randomNumberGenerator(seed+view[i].ant.type);
                seed=randomNumberGenerator(seed+(view[i].ant.friend?1:0));
            }
            seed=randomNumberGenerator(seed+view[i].color);
            seed=randomNumberGenerator(seed+view[i].food);
        }
        return seed<0?-seed:seed;
    }

    // SHUFFLE *NOT* IMPLEMENTED 
function shuffleIndecies(view,seed,range)
    {
        var indecies = new Array(range);

        for (var i=0;i<range;i++)
        {
            indecies[i]=i;
        }

        return indecies;
    }

function processOrientation(view)
    {
        // count orientation markers
        var orientationMarkerCount = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<rotate.length;i++)
        {
            if (view[rotate[i][1]].color === ORIENTATION_MARKER)
            {
                orientationMarkerCount++;
                orientationMarkerRotation = i;
            }
        }

        // corruption detected
        if (orientationMarkerCount >1)
        {
            return {cell:4, color: QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING};
        }

        // place the orientation marker
        if (orientationMarkerCount === 0)
        {
            return {cell:1, color: ORIENTATION_MARKER};
        }
        return null;
    }

function incrementSpawnCounter(view)
    {
        var action = processOrientation(view);
        if (action != null)
        {
            return action;
        }

        var newCount = decodeThreeCellsToInt(view) + 1;

        var MSD = view[rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][3]].color-1;
        var NSD = view[rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][7]].color-1;
        var LSD = view[rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][5]].color-1;

        var MSDisEven =(MSD & 1) ===0;
        var NSDisEven =(NSD & 1) ===0; 

        var MSDdelta =  Math.floor(newCount / 49) - MSD;
        var NSDdelta =  (MSDisEven ? Math.floor(Math.floor(newCount%49)/7) :( 6 - Math.floor(Math.floor(newCount%49)/7))) - NSD;
        var LSDdelta =  (((MSDisEven && NSDisEven) || (!MSDisEven && !NSDisEven)) ? Math.floor(newCount%7) :( 6 - Math.floor(newCount%7))) - LSD;

        // check for roll over 
        if (MSDdelta > 6)
        {
            return {cell:rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][3], color:1};
        }

        // Most Significant Digit (cell) update
        if (MSDdelta != 0)
        {
            return {cell:rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][3], color:(MSD+MSDdelta)+1};
        }

        // Next Significant Digit (cell) update
        if (NSDdelta != 0)
        {
            return {cell:rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][7], color:(NSD+NSDdelta)+1};
        }

        // Least Significant Digit (cell) update
        if (LSDdelta != 0)
        {
            return {cell:rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][5], color:(LSD+LSDdelta)+1};
        }

        return null;
    }

function decodeThreeCellsToInt(view)
    {
        var MSD = view[rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][3]].color-1;
        var NSD = view[rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][7]].color-1;
        var LSD = view[rotate[orientationMarkerRotation][5]].color-1;

        var MSDisEven =(MSD & 1) ===0;
        var NSDisEven =(NSD & 1) ===0; 
        return MSD * 49 + 
               (MSDisEven?NSD:6-NSD) * 7 + 
               ((MSDisEven && NSDisEven) || (!MSDisEven && !NSDisEven)?LSD:6-LSD);
    }
    // Performs a paint command to reset the queen's worker spawn counter to 0.
    // NOTE that is may take multiple calls on sequential game ticks to complete the reset.
    // returns null if the counter is reset
function resetSpawnCounter(view)
    {
        var orientationMarkerCount = 0;
        for (i=1; i<9; i+=2) 
        {
            if (view[i].color === ORIENTATION_MARKER && orientationMarkerCount ===0)
            {
                orientationMarkerCount++;
            }
            else if (view[i].color!=1)
            {
                return {cell:i, color:1};
            }
        }

        // place the orientation marker
        if (orientationMarkerCount === 0)
        {
            return {cell:1, color: ORIENTATION_MARKER};
        }

        return null;
    }


function spawnNewWorker(view,type,defaultAction)
    {
        // ensure that we do not try and create a worker when having no food
        if (view[4].ant.food > 0)
        {
            // now try to spawn an ant
            if (view[1].ant===null && view[1].food===0)
            {
                return {cell:1, type:type};
            }

            // previous spawn cell was blocked, try another 
            if (view[3].ant===null && view[3].food===0)
            {
                return {cell:3, type:type};
            }

            // previous spawn cell was blocked, try another
            if (view[5].ant===null && view[5].food===0)
            {
                return {cell:5, type:type};
            }

            // previous spawn cell was blocked, try another
            if (view[7].ant===null && view[7].food===0)
            {
                return {cell:7, type:type};
            }
        }
        return defaultAction;
    }

function isCellTrailToQueen(cell,currentAntCellColour)
    {
        // is cell containing our queen, or is the cell the next cell colour on the trail back
        return (cell.ant!=null && cell.ant.friend && cell.ant.type === ANT_TYPE_QUEEN) ||
                cell.color === prevTrailColor(currentAntCellColour);
    }

    // entry point into ant logic
function getAction(view)
    {
        var random = 1;
        var food = view[4].ant.food;
        var currentCellColour = view[4].color;

/////////////////////////////////////// QUEEN ///////////////////////////////////////
        if (view[4].ant.type === ANT_TYPE_QUEEN)
        {
            // move to visible food. this queen is greedy!
            for (i=0; i<9; i++) 
            {
                if (view[i].food>0) {
                    return {cell:i};
                }
            }

            // see if we have spawned a worker in the last few turns
            var workerSpawned = false;
            // look in orthogonal cells
            for (i=1; i<9; i+=2) 
            {
                // ant detected and is friendly and of worker type
                if (view[i].ant !=null && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type===ANT_TYPE_WORKER)
                {
                    workerSpawned=true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            var queenMode = currentCellColour;
            var foodModRemainder=1;

            var minFoodLatch = 0;
            if (food>=500) minFoodLatch = 500;
            else if (food>=400) minFoodLatch = 400;
            else if (food>=300) minFoodLatch = 300;
            else if (food>=200) minFoodLatch = 200;
            else if (food>=100) minFoodLatch = 100;
            else if (food>=50) minFoodLatch = 50;
            else if (food>=20) minFoodLatch = 30;
            else if (food>=20) minFoodLatch = 20;
            else if (food>=10) minFoodLatch = 10;
            else if (food>=5) minFoodLatch = 5;

            switch (queenMode)
            {
                case QUEEN_MODE_HUNTING_MOVING:
                {


                    // move to the cell mirror of the trail cell
                    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
                        if (view[i].ant===null && view[i].color===QUEEN_MODE_HUNTING_MOVING) {
                            if (view[8-i].ant==null)
                            {
                                return {cell:8-i};
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Otherwise move to one of the diagonal cells if not occupied
                    for (i=0; i<9; i+=2) 
                    {
                        if (view[i].ant===null) 
                        {
                            return {cell:i};
                        }
                    }

                    // Otherwise move to one of the vertical or horizontal cells if not occupied
                    for (i=1; i<9; i+=2)
                    {
                        if (view[i].ant===null)
                        {
                            return {cell:i};
                        }
                    }
                    return {cell:4};
                }
                case QUEEN_MODE_HUNTING_PAINTING:
                {
                    // no food found, change to move mode
                    if (food ===0)
                    {
                        // Queenie places a trail
                        return {cell:4, color:QUEEN_MODE_HUNTING_MOVING};
                    }
                    // found food, now change to nesting mode
                    else
                    {
                        return {cell:4, color:QUEEN_MODE_NESTING};
                    }
                }

                // initialise colony
                case QUEEN_MODE_NESTING:
                {
                    // we have spawned a worker so change to counting mode
                    if (workerSpawned===true)
                    {
                        return {cell:4, color:QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_ODD};
                    }

                    var action = processOrientation(view);
                    if (action != null)
                    {
                        return action;
                    }

                    // ensure that we have the initial band constructed around the queen
                    for (i=0; i<9; i+=2) 
                    {
                        if (i!=4 && view[i].color!=TRAIL_COLOR_A)
                        {
                            return {cell:i, color:TRAIL_COLOR_A};
                        }
                    }

                    // ensure that the counter cells are reset.
                    action = resetSpawnCounter(view);
                    if (action != null)
                    {
                        return action;
                    }

                    // spawn initial worker
                    return spawnNewWorker(view, ANT_TYPE_WORKER, NO_OP);
                }


                case QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING_SPAWNING:

                    // spawn the worker if we have not spawned a worker in the last few turns 
                    if (!workerSpawned===true)
                    {
                        return spawnNewWorker(view, ANT_TYPE_WORKER, NO_OP);
                    }
                    // must have spawned a worker previously, so reset the counter 
                    var action = resetSpawnCounter(view);

                    // still in process of resetting counter...
                    if (action != null)
                    {
                        return action;
                    }


                    // spawn counter as been reset. We will set the queen back to counting mode;
                    return {cell:4, color:food%2===0?QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_EVEN:QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_ODD};

                case QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING:

                    action = resetSpawnCounter(view);

                    // still in process of resetting counter...
                    if (action != null)
                    {
                        return action;
                    }


                    // spawn counter as been reset. We will set the queen back to counting mode;
                    return {cell:4, color:food%2===0?QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_ODD:QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_EVEN};

                case QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_ODD:
                    foodModRemainder = 2;
                case QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_EVEN:
                {
                    foodModRemainder--;

                    action = processOrientation(view);
                    if (action != null)
                    {
                        return action;
                    }

                    var spawnCounter = decodeThreeCellsToInt(view);

                    // repair any damage to the initial band constructed around the queen
                    for (i=0; i<9; i+=2) 
                    {
                        if (i!=4 && view[i].color!=TRAIL_COLOR_A)
                        {
                            return {cell:i, color:TRAIL_COLOR_A};
                        }
                    }

//                    // spawn interval time threshold as been reached and we have food to convert into workers...
//                    if (spawnCounter>=TICKS_BETWEEN_FOOD_RETURN_MAX && food>minFoodLatch)
//                    {
//                        // change to reset spawn counter mode to spawn a new worker
//                        return new Paint(4,QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING_SPAWNING);
//                    }
//
//                    // Check to see if a worker has just returned some food.
//                    if (food>0 && food%2 == foodModRemainder)
//                    {
//                        // change to reset spawn counter mode
//                        return new Paint(4,QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING);
//                    }

                    // Check to see if a worker has just returned some food.
                    if (food>0 && food%2 === foodModRemainder)
                    {

                        // spawn interval time threshold as been reached and we have food to convert into workers...
                        if (spawnCounter>=TICKS_BETWEEN_FOOD_RETURN_MAX && food>0)
                        {
                            // change to reset spawn counter mode to spawn a new worker
                            return {cell:4, color:QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING_SPAWNING};
                        }

                        // change to reset spawn counter mode
                        return {cell:4, color:QUEEN_MODE_RESETTING};
                    }


                    if (spawnCounter < SPAWN_COUNTER_MAX)
                    {
                        // simply increment the counter
                        return incrementSpawnCounter(view);
                    }

                    return NO_OP;
                }
                default:
                {
                }

            }


        }

/////////////////////////////////////// WORKER ///////////////////////////////////////



        var expectedNextPathColourToEdge = nextTrailColor(currentCellColour);

        // worker is looking for food
        if (food===0)
        {
/////////////////////////////////// WORKER HUNTNING //////////////////////////////////    

            // determine whether we are a recently spawned worker
            for (var i=1;i<9;i+=2)
            {
                // are we orthogonal to the queen?
                if (view[i].ant!=null && view[i].ant.friend && view[i].ant.type === ANT_TYPE_QUEEN)
                {
                    // test to see whether queen's counter has reset so worker is free to move
                    if (view[i].color === QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_ODD || view[i].color === QUEEN_MODE_COUNTING_EVEN )
                    {
                        for (var j=1;j<9;j+=2)
                        {
                            if (view[j].ant===null && view[j].color===TRAIL_COLOR_A)
                            {
                                return {cell:j};
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // wait until queen's counter has reset
                    return NO_OP;
                }
            }

//            // this is to try and unstick stuck ants... not overly well i might add
//            if (randomInt(view,1)%20==1)
//            {
//                // attempt to pick an empty random trail-cell
//                for (i = randomInt(view,666)%9;i>0;i--)
//                {
//                    if (view[i].ant==null && view[i].food==0 && isTrailColour(view[i].color))
//                    {
//                        return new Move(i);
//                    }
//                }
//            }

            // see if there is any food off band that is enclosed or almost enclosed by trail cells
            // if so, then move to claim the food
            if (view[1].food>0 &&
                isTrailColour(view[0].color) &&
                isTrailColour(view[2].color))
            {
                return {cell:1};
            }

            if (view[3].food>0 &&
                isTrailColour(view[0].color) &&
                isTrailColour(view[6].color))
            {
                return {cell:3};
            }

            if (view[5].food>0 &&
                isTrailColour(view[2].color) &&
                isTrailColour(view[8].color))
            {
                return {cell:5};
            }

            if (view[7].food>0 &&
                isTrailColour(view[6].color) &&
                isTrailColour(view[8].color))
            {
                return {cell:7};
            }


            // if not on trail, attempt see if cells surrounding are trail colours... and set our own cell accordingly
            if (!isTrailColour(currentCellColour))
            {
                for (var priority = 0; priority <4;priority++)
                {
                    // repeat for each rotation
                    var indecies = shuffleIndecies(view,random,4);
                    for (var j=0;j<4;j++)
                    {
                        var r = indecies[j];
                        switch(priority)
                        {
                        // C??  ...
                        // ???  .P.
                        // P?N  ...
                        case 0:
                            if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][0]].color) && 
                                nextTrailColor(view[rotate[r][0]].color) === view[rotate[r][8]].color &&
                                prevTrailColor(view[rotate[r][0]].color) === view[rotate[r][6]].color)
                            {
                                return {cell:4, color: view[rotate[r][6]].color};
                            }
                            break;

                        // ??C  ...
                        // ???  .C.
                        // N?C  ...
                        case 1:
                            if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][2]].color) && 
                                view[rotate[r][2]].color === view[rotate[r][8]].color &&
                                nextTrailColor(view[rotate[r][2]].color) === view[rotate[r][6]].color)
                            {
                                return {cell:4, color: view[rotate[r][2]].color};
                            }
                            break;

                        // C??  ...
                        // ???  .C.
                        // P??  ...
                        case 2:
                            if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][0]].color) && 
                                prevTrailColor(view[rotate[r][0]].color) === view[rotate[r][6]].color)
                            {
                                return {cell:4, color: view[rotate[r][0]].color};
                            }
                            break;

                        // C??  ...
                        // ???  .C.
                        // ???  ...
                        case 3:
                            if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][0]].color))
                            {
                                return {cell:4, color: view[rotate[r][0]].color};
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // we are completely lost! lets perform a random walk and hopefully find the surface again
                return {cell:view[2].ant === null?2:4};
            }

            // decide worker action...
            for (var priority = 0; priority <13;priority++)
            {
                // repeat for each rotation
                var indecies = shuffleIndecies(view,random,4);
                for (var j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    var r = indecies[j];
                    var cellToMoveTo =-1;

                    switch(priority)
                    {
                    /////// AVOID MOVING/PAINTING LOCK-STEP ///////

                    // X?X  ...
                    // ?C?  .M.
                    // C?W  ...

                    case 0:
                        if (view[rotate[r][6]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            !isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][0]].color) &&
                            !isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][2]].color) &&
                            view[rotate[r][8]].ant!=null &&
                            view[rotate[r][8]].ant.type!=ANT_TYPE_QUEEN) 
                        {
                            // step back on path back to queen
                            return NO_OP;
                        }
                        break;

                    /////// REPAIR PATH ///////

                    // P?X  ..C
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // C??  ...

                    case 1:
                        if (view[rotate[r][2]].color != currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][6]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][0]],currentCellColour))
                        {
                            return {cell:rotate[r][2], color:currentCellColour};
                        }
                        break;

                    // ??C  N..
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // X?P  ...

                    case 2:
                        if (view[rotate[r][2]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][8]],currentCellColour) &&
                            !isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][6]].color) &&
                            view[rotate[r][0]].color != expectedNextPathColourToEdge)
                        {
                            return {cell:rotate[r][0], color:expectedNextPathColourToEdge};
                        }
                        break;

                    // C?N  ...
                    // ?C?  .N.
                    // ??P  ...

                    case 3:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][2]].color === expectedNextPathColourToEdge &&
                            isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][8]],currentCellColour))
                        {
                            return {cell:4, color:expectedNextPathColourToEdge};
                        }
                        break;

                    // C??  N..
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // ??P  ...

                    case 4:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][8]],currentCellColour))
                        {
                            return {cell:rotate[r][0], color:expectedNextPathColourToEdge};
                        }
                        break;

                    /////// MOVING ///////

                    // C?P  ...
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // ??C  N..
                    case 5:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][8]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][2]],currentCellColour) &&
                            view[rotate[r][6]].color != expectedNextPathColourToEdge)
                        {

                            if (view[rotate[r][6]].ant === null)
                            {
                                return {cell:rotate[r][6], color:expectedNextPathColourToEdge};
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return NO_OP;
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    // C?P  ...
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // N?C  M..
                    case 6:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][8]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][2]],currentCellColour) &&
                            view[rotate[r][6]].color === expectedNextPathColourToEdge)
                        {
                            cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][6];
                        }
                        break;

                    // Special case. we need to first paint the cell prior to moving other wise will cause corruption
                    // C??  ...
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // C??  ..N
                    case 7:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][6]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][8]].color != expectedNextPathColourToEdge)
                        {
                            if (view[rotate[r][8]].ant === null)
                            {
                                return {cell:rotate[r][8], color:expectedNextPathColourToEdge};
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return NO_OP;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    // C??  ...
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // C?N  ..M
                    case 8:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][6]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][8]].color === expectedNextPathColourToEdge)
                        {
                            cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][8];
                        }
                        break;
                    // C??  ..M
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // P?C  ...
                    case 9:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            view[rotate[r][8]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][6]],currentCellColour))
                        {
                            cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][2];
                        }
                        break;
                    // C??  ...
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // P??  ..M
                    case 10:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                            isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][6]],currentCellColour))
                        {
                            cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][8];
                        }
                        break;
                    // C??  ...
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // ???  M..
                    case 11:
                        if (view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour)

                        {
                            cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][6];
                        }
                        break;
                    // ???  ...
                    // ?C?  ...
                    // P??  ?.M
                    case 12:
                        if (isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][6]],currentCellColour))

                        {
                            cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][8];
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (cellToMoveTo>-1)
                    {
                        return {cell:view[cellToMoveTo].ant === null?cellToMoveTo:4};
                    }
                }
            }
            return NO_OP;
        }

        // worker is transporting food
        else
        {
            // worker deadlock avoidance
            for (i=0; i<9; i+=2)
            {
                // does the cell have another ant in it?
                if (i!=4 && view[i].ant!=null && !(view[i].ant.type===ANT_TYPE_QUEEN && view[i].ant.friend))
                {
                    // attempt to pick an empty random trail-cell
                    for (i = randomInt(view,54321)%9;i>0;i--)
                    {
                        if (view[i].ant===null && view[i].food===0 && isTrailColour(view[i].color))
                        {
                            return {cell:i};
                        }
                    }

                    // no luck... just pick a random empty cell
                    for (i = randomInt(view,12345)%9;i>0;i--)
                    {
                        if (view[i].ant===null && view[i].food===0)
                        {
                            return {cell:i};
                        }
                    }

                    // deadlock unavoidable!
                    return NO_OP;
                }
            }

//            // this is to try and unstick stuck ants
//            if (randomInt(view,1)%20==1)
//            {
//                // attempt to pick an empty random trail-cell
//                for (i = randomInt(view,666)%9;i>0;i--)
//                {
//                    if (view[i].ant==null && view[i].food==0 && isTrailColour(view[i].color))
//                    {
//                        return new Move(i);
//                    }
//                }
//            }


            // decide move action
            for (var priority = 0; priority <14;priority++)
            {
                // repeat for each rotation
                var indecies = shuffleIndecies(view,random,4);
                for (var j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    var r = indecies[j];
                    var cellToMoveTo =-1;

                    switch(priority)
                    {
                        // PRE-EMPTIVE PATH PRUNING

                    // C?X  X..
                    // ?X?  ...
                    // P?X  ...
                    case 0:
                        if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][0]].color) &&
                            !isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][2]].color) &&
                            !isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][4]].color) && 
                            prevTrailColor(view[rotate[r][0]].color) === view[rotate[r][5]].color)
                        {
                            return {cell:rotate[r][0], color: 1};
                        }
                        break;


                        // ?C?  ...
                        // CXN  X..
                        // ?X?  ...
                        case 1:
                            if (!isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][4]].color) &&
                                !isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][7]].color) &&
                                isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][1]].color) && 
                                view[rotate[r][3]].color === view[rotate[r][1]].color &&
                                nextTrailColor(view[rotate[r][1]].color) === view[rotate[r][5]].color)
                            {
                                return {cell:rotate[r][3], color: 1};
                            }
                            break;

                        // ?C?  ...
                        // PXC  ..X
                        // ?X?  ...
                        case 2:
                            if (!isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][4]].color) &&
                                !isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][7]].color) &&
                                isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][1]].color) && 
                                view[rotate[r][5]].color === view[rotate[r][1]].color &&
                                prevTrailColor(view[rotate[r][1]].color) === view[rotate[r][3]].color)
                            {
                                return {cell:rotate[r][5], color: 1};
                            }
                            break;

                        // N??  ..N
                        // ?C?  ...
                        // C?C  ...

                        case 3:
                            if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][4]].color) &&
                                view[rotate[r][2]].color != expectedNextPathColourToEdge &&
                                view[rotate[r][8]].color === currentCellColour &&
                                view[rotate[r][0]].color === expectedNextPathColourToEdge &&
                                view[rotate[r][6]].color === currentCellColour)
                            {
                                return {cell:rotate[r][2], color:expectedNextPathColourToEdge};
                            }
                            break;

                        // N??  ...
                        // ?X?  .C.
                        // C?C  ...


                        case 4:
                            if (!isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][4]].color) && 
                                isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][8]].color) &&
                                view[rotate[r][0]].color === nextTrailColor(view[rotate[r][8]].color) &&
                                view[rotate[r][8]].color === view[rotate[r][6]].color)
                            {
                                return {cell:rotate[r][4], color:view[rotate[r][8]].color};
                            }
                            break;

                        // N??  ..C
                        // ?C?  ...
                        // C?P  ...

                        case 5:
                            if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][4]].color) && 
                                view[rotate[r][0]].color === expectedNextPathColourToEdge &&
                                view[rotate[r][6]].color === currentCellColour &&
                                isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][8]],currentCellColour) &&
                                view[rotate[r][2]].color != currentCellColour)
                            {
                                return {cell:rotate[r][2], color:currentCellColour};
                            }
                            break;

                        // C?N  ...
                        // ?X?  .N.
                        // ??P  ...

                        case 6:
                            if (!isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][4]].color) && 
                                isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][0]].color) && 
                                view[rotate[r][2]].color === nextTrailColor(view[rotate[r][0]].color) &&
                                view[rotate[r][8]].color === prevTrailColor(view[rotate[r][0]].color))
                            {
                                return {cell:rotate[r][4], color:nextTrailColor(view[rotate[r][0]].color)};
                            }
                            break;

                        // ??P  ...
                        // ?X?  .N.
                        // ??N  ...

                        case 7:
                            if (!isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][4]].color) && 
                                isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][2]].color) &&
                                nextTrailColor(view[rotate[r][2]].color) === view[rotate[r][8]].color)
                            {
                                return {cell:4, color:view[rotate[r][8]].color};
                            }
                            break;



                        // if we are on the corner of a trail band... move opposite to the apex
                        case 8:
                            if (isTrailColour(currentCellColour) &&
                                view[rotate[r][0]].color === currentCellColour &&
                                view[rotate[r][2]].color === currentCellColour)
                            {
                                if (randomInt(view,currentCellColour)%2 === 0)
                                {
                                    cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][0];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][2];
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        // if we on the opposite corner of a trail band... move back toward the apex
                        case 9:
                            if (isTrailColour(currentCellColour) &&
                                isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][0]],currentCellColour) &&
                                isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][2]],currentCellColour))
                            {
                                if (randomInt(view,currentCellColour)%2 === 0)
                                {
                                    cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][0];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][2];
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        // if an adjacent cell is a trail to the queen, move that way
                        case 10:
                            if (isTrailColour(currentCellColour) &&
                                isCellTrailToQueen(view[rotate[r][0]],currentCellColour))
                            {
                                cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][0];
                            }
                            break;
                        // if we are not on a trail and an adjacent cell is a trail, then move that way
                        case 11:
                            if (!isTrailColour(currentCellColour) && isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][8]].color))
                            {
                                cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][8];
                            }
                            break;
                        // are we on a cell between trail cells? if so then move onto a cell on the trail.
                        case 12:
                            if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][1]].color))
                            {
                                cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][1];
                            }
                            break;
                        // are we on a terminal trail cell? if so then move onto a cell on the trail.
                        case 13:
                            if (isTrailColour(view[rotate[r][0]].color))
                            {
                                cellToMoveTo = rotate[r][0];
                            }
                            break;

                    }
                    if (cellToMoveTo>-1)
                    {
                        if (view[cellToMoveTo].ant != null || view[cellToMoveTo].food > 0) continue;
                        return {cell:cellToMoveTo};
                    }
                }
            }
            return NO_OP;
        }

    }

    return getAction(view);
```

*VERSION 1*

[image: version1]

The basic premise of this entry will to search in an ever expanding square spiral. Search square perimeter expansion will create a three band repeating pattern allowing for quick food delivery and return to perimeter.

There name of the entry is from the "firefly" enemy in the classic puzzle game BolderDash, the repeating three colour pattern is reminisent of the enemy.

This initial version, whilst has latent bugs, fulfills the basic requirements to be a basic entry: the ants do collect and return food to the queen. However, food is immediately converted to workers, so will never place well in a tournament.

However for the next version I think i will fundamentally change the way and order the ants move/paint: from paint then move, to move then paint. While i cannot be certain, I think some of the cell colour pattern corruption is occuring from cells that contain ants being re-painted by adjacent ants. Changing the order should help to reduce that risk... but will potentially more complicated/risky to move before painting.

*VERSION 2*

[image: version 2]

This version is superior, it now is rotated 45 degrees allowing for more exploration per worker ant step.

It also now collects food (if it does not get distracted)

It is, however not robust and easily gets interrupted by other ant's trails. So it is not a good contender as it currently stands.

However when left alone, it averages 700 food collected with 300 workers.

*VERSION 2.1*

Added sanity check to ensure that queen does not try to make a worker when not having any food.

*VERSION 2.1.1*

fixed the fix in 2.1 (I did not actually use the "food" field of the ant's view and was therefore referencing a null object.

*VERSION 2.1.1.1*

/me hides head in hands

I found a simple indexing bug in spawning function which meant that the queen may try to spawn on top of herself... needless to say that is grounds for disqualification. now fixed.

*VERSION 2.2*

Fixed copy paste error that re-introduced illegal spawn bug

*VERSION 2.2.1*

Fixed possible illegal move in the beginning scramble when queen is attempting to find the first piece of food.

Comment: Your strategy also suffers from the same weakness as Zigurrat: theft. I could tweak the Zigurrat identification code in Vampire to target Firefly in about 90 seconds. It'd literally be "copy 60 lines of code, paste 60 lines of code, change 3 numbers." Although, I'd much prefer making the Zigurrat-ID code modular instead ("do this, with these colors").

Comment: Your ants also stack up a lot: if one's painting, one will come up behind it and *wait* until the right combination of triggers makes the wait-er pop out and start a new line. Detecting that there's a friendly ant in front and popping out to start a new line should be easy. Shouldn't even need to wait for a corner to do it. The second problem is when two ants on separate lines are at the same draw step. The one on the outside draws a corner, the inner one redraws it. Should be able to detect neighbor ants in this situation as well (best action might be to wait for the other ant to move).

Comment: @Draco18s Yeah, there are a few flaws with this initial version :-) but it is a place to start from. Regarding the theft threat: i do plan to make a guard ant which will seek the enemy thieving queen and "steal" back. It should minimize the loss.

Comment: Oh, I realize it's a place to start, just making some observations. :)

Comment: I am in the process of moving house so i have had no time to work on it (all though I have made significant changes since this version). So please ignore this version in you next tournament

Comment: @Moogie Cool, I look forward to seeing it when you can get yourself set up again. By that time the revised Vampire code will be available (which will include a disabled portion that targets Firefly) which will let you consider anti-vampire logic.

Comment: oh drat. ok will see why that is occuring.

Comment: @trichoplax Ok, i did not have a final sanity check on worker production to ensure food is available. As for why it occured, i do not know why, my guess is that another player's ant changed the colour of the queen's cell and caused an illegal transition from one mode to the worker producing mode.

Comment: Is it done? Can I go in and smash the place up with a vampiric bat? :D

Comment: yes it is done for the mean time.... i may when i have spare time try to make it less susceptible to other ants.

Comment: @trichoplax there is indeed some cases in the initial queen scramble that have not been guarded against. Will fix up and re-post.

Comment: @trichoplax i am quite embarrassed... the check i put in to avoid queen scramble ant-on-ant move dq bug has the opposite logic... it actually will actively try to go onto another ant instead of avoid! should be fixed now

Comment: Reincluded now :)

Answer (score 4):

## La Reine Bleue

```
var Queen = 5;
var QueenTrail = [];
var EnemyAnts = [];
var EnemyColors = [];
var QueenTrailColor = 7;
var QueenTrailColor2 = 8;
var QueensPosition = -1; //Future use...

var rotations =   
[ 0,1,2,
  3,4,5,
  6,7,8,

  6,3,0,
  7,4,1,
  8,5,2,

  8,7,6,
  5,4,3,
  2,1,0,

  2,5,8,
  1,4,7,
  0,3,6];

var moves = [];
getMoves();
return findBestMove();

function getMoves()
{
    var matchIdx = -1;
    //Initialization of current state
    for(ii = 0; ii < 9; ii++)
    {
        if(ii != 4)
        {
            if(view[ii].color == QueenTrailColor)
            {
                QueenTrail.push(ii);
            }
            else if(view[ii].color == QueenTrailColor2)
            {
                QueenTrail.push(ii);
            }
            else if(view[ii].color != 1)
            {
                EnemyColors.push(ii);
            }
        }

        if(ii != 4 && view[ii].ant != null)
        {
            if(view[ii].ant.friend)
            {
                if(view[ii].ant.type == Queen)
                {
                    QueensPosition = ii * ii;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EnemyAnts.push(ii);
            }
        }
    }

    switch (view[4].ant.type) 
    {
        case Queen:
        {        
            //first get the food
            for (var ii = 0; ii < 9; ii++) 
            {
                if (view[ii].food > 0 && view[ii].ant == null) 
                {
                    moves.push(getCell(ii)) ;
                }
            }
            if(EnemyAnts.length == 0)
            {
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor),AA(4), {cell:4, color:QueenTrailColor});
            }

            if(QueenTrail.length >= 5 || EnemyAnts.length > 0)
            {
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,1,2),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,1,3),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,1,5),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,1,6),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,1,7),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,1,8),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,2,3),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,2,6),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,2,7),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,3,7),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,3,8),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,5,7),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(1,2,7),{cell:1});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(1,3,5),{cell:1});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,1),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,2),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,3),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,5),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,7),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(0,8),{cell:0});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(1,3),{cell:1});
                lm(AA(-QueenTrailColor), AA(1,7),{cell:1});
            }
            if(QueenTrail.length == 4)
            {
                lmQT(AA(0,1,2,3),{cell:7});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,2,5),{cell:7});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,2,6),{cell:7});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,2,7),{cell:5});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,2,8),{cell:7});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,3,5),{cell:7});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,3,7),{cell:8});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,3,8),{cell:2});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,5,6),{cell:8});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,5,7),{cell:6});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,5,8),{cell:3});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,6,7),{cell:8});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,6,8),{cell:2});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,7,8),{cell:2});
                lmQT(AA(0,2,3,7),{cell:8});
                lmQT(AA(0,2,3,8),{cell:6});
                lmQT(AA(0,2,6,8),{cell:1});
                lmQT(AA(0,3,5,7),{cell:2});
                lmQT(AA(0,3,5,8),{cell:2});
                lmQT(AA(1,3,5,7),{cell:0});
            }
            if(QueenTrail.length == 1)
            {                
                lmQT(AA(0), {cell:8});
                lmQT(AA(1), {cell:7});
            }
            else if(QueenTrail.length == 0)
            {
                moves.push(getCell(1));
            }

            if(QueenTrail.length == 0) // starting out or someone is messing with us
            {
                moves.push( getCellColor(1, QueenTrailColor));
            }    
            else if (QueenTrail.length >= 5) //queen is stuck? move her randomly until we get a straight trail
            {    
                moves.push( getCellColor(1, QueenTrailColor2));
            }
            else if (QueenTrail.length >= 3)
            {
                lmQT(AA(0,1,2),{cell:3});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,3),{cell:7});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,5),{cell:3});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,6),{cell:7});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,7),{cell:3});
                lmQT(AA(0,1,8),{cell:3});
                lmQT(AA(0,2,3),{cell:6});
                lmQT(AA(0,2,6),{cell:3});
                lmQT(AA(0,2,7),{cell:1});
                lmQT(AA(0,3,7),{cell:8});
                lmQT(AA(0,3,8),{cell:5});
                lmQT(AA(0,5,7),{cell:6});
                lmQT(AA(1,2,7),{cell:0});
                lmQT(AA(1,3,5),{cell:6});
            }
            else if(QueenTrail.length == 2)
            {
                lmQT(AA(0,1),{cell:7});
                lmQT(AA(0,2),getCellColor(1, QueenTrailColor));
                lmQT(AA(0,3),{cell:6});
                lmQT(AA(0,5),{cell:1});
                lmQT(AA(0,7),{cell:3});
                lmQT(AA(0,8),{cell:3});
                lmQT(AA(1,3),{cell:6});
                lmQT(AA(1,7),{cell:0});
            }
            else if(QueenTrail.length == 1) //we are either going in a straight line or trapped?
            {    
                if(view[4].ant.food > 0)
                {
                    lmQT(AA(0), getCell(0));
                    //clear out the area for the ants
                    if(EnemyColors.length > 0)
                    {
                        moves.push( getCellColor(EnemyColors[0],1));
                    }
                }
                lmQT(AA(0), getCell(8));
                lmQT(AA(1), getCell(7));
                lmQT(AA(2), getCell(6));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    moves.push( getCell(4));
}

function leftOfPos(x)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (x == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (x == 3)
    {
        return 6;
    }
    else if (x == 5)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (x == 6)
    {
        return 7;
    }
    else if (x == 7)
    {
        return 8;
    }
    else if (x == 8)
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

function findBestMove() 
{
    var keeper = 0;
    for(var ii = 0; ii < moves.length ; ii++)
    {
        if(moves[ii].cell < 0 || moves[ii].cell > 8 || (moves[ii].cell != 4 && (moves[ii].color == null || moves[ii].color == 0) && view[moves[ii].cell].ant != null) || (view[moves[ii].cell].food > 0 && (view[4].ant.food > 0 && view[4].ant.type < 5))) 
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(moves[ii].type != null && (view[moves[ii].cell].ant != null || view[moves[ii].cell].food > 0 || view[0].color == 1)) //semi random here. 
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            keeper = ii;
            break;
        }
    }
    return moves[keeper];
}

function lm(matchingColors, coords, matchCell)
{
    var matchTarget = coords.length ;
    var matchCount = [0,0,0,0];
    var returnVal = -1;
    for(var ii = 0; ii < coords.length; ii++)
    {        
        for(var jj = 0; jj < 4; jj++)
        {
            var actualIndex = rotations[coords[ii] + (jj * 9)];
            var foundMatch = false;
            for(var kk = 0; kk < matchingColors.length; kk++)
            {
                var matchingColor = matchingColors[kk];

                if(matchingColor >= 1 && matchingColor <= 8 && view[actualIndex].color == matchingColor)
                {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    break;
                }    
                else if(matchingColor < 0 && view[actualIndex].color != -matchingColor)
                {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(foundMatch)
            {
                matchCount[jj] = matchCount[jj] + 1;
                if(matchCount[jj] == matchTarget)
                {
                    matchCell.cell = rotations[matchCell.cell + (jj * 9)];
                    moves.push(matchCell);
                    returnVal = jj;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}

function lmQT(coords, matchCell)
{
    return lm(AA(QueenTrailColor, QueenTrailColor2), coords,matchCell);
}

function AA()
{
    return arguments;
}

function getCell(x)
{
    return {cell:x};
}

function getCellColor(x, y)
{
    return {cell:x, color:y};
}
```

The blue queen will leave a blue trail, she avoids black and leaves black crumbs if 'stuck'.

She looks for specific blue/black "shapes" using all 4 rotations and creates a list of potential moves. Disqualifying moves are removed and a single result is chosen. The Queen is somewhat predictable but certain shapes will cause a randomness. She will mostly change directions after finding food due to the fact that the orientation will change which moves are discovered first.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: It's good to be here!

Answer (score 3):

## Romanesco Road

This player produces no workers, and the queen moves in a straight line, marking each cell she visits. The straight line motion is possible despite the random orientation of the input visible cells, because the queen can see the marked cell she just left, and moves in the opposite direction to this to ensure a straight line.

The first code block in an answer is the one automatically included in the game:

```
// Full version that won't be disqualified for moving onto another ant

var i

// Color own cell if white
if (view[4].color === 1) {
    return {cell:4, color:3}
}

// Otherwise move to food if visible
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (view[i].food) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move to a white cell opposite a colored cell
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (view[i].color === 1 && view[8-i].color > 1 && !view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move to an unoccupied cell
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise don't move at all
return {cell:4}
```

Here is a simpler version that doesn't check for other ants, but has identical behaviour up until the point it gets disqualified for trying to step onto another ant:

```
// Basic version for an intuitive understanding

var i

// Color own cell if white
if (view[4].color === 1) {
    return {cell:4, color:3}
}

// Otherwise move to food if visible
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (view[i].food) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move to a white cell opposite a colored cell
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (view[i].color === 1 && view[8-i].color > 1) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move "left and up", which will be a random direction
return {cell:0}
```

This second code block won't be picked up by the game - this means you can include additional code blocks as part of your answer's explanation. Just make sure the code block that you wish to compete in the game is the first one in the answer.

For an example of producing random movement rather than a straight line, see [Brownian Jig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135103/20283).

Answer (score 3):

## Lone Wolf

*All my answers are sharing the same set of low-level helper functions.
 Search for "High-level logic begins here" to see the code specific to this answer.*

```js
// == Shared low-level helpers for all solutions ==

var QUEEN = 5;

var WHITE = 1;
var COL_MIN = WHITE;
var COL_LIM = 9;

var CENTRE = 4;

var NOP = {cell: CENTRE};

var DIR_FORWARDS = false;
var DIR_REVERSE = true;
var SIDE_RIGHT = true;
var SIDE_LEFT = false;

function sanity_check(movement) {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  if(!movement || movement.cell < 0 || movement.cell > 8) {
    return false;
  }
  if(movement.type) {
    if(movement.color) {
      return false;
    }
    if(movement.type < 1 || movement.type > 4) {
      return false;
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].ant || view[movement.cell].food) {
      return false;
    }
    if(me.type !== QUEEN || me.food < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if(movement.color) {
    if(movement.color < COL_MIN || movement.color >= COL_LIM) {
      return false;
    }
    if(view[movement.cell].color === movement.color) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if(view[movement.cell].ant) {
    return false;
  }
  if(view[movement.cell].food + me.food > 1 && me.type !== QUEEN) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function as_array(o) {
  if(Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o;
  }
  return [o];
}

function best_of(movements) {
  var m;
  for(var i = 0; i < movements.length; ++ i) {
    if(typeof(movements[i]) === 'function') {
      m = movements[i]();
    } else {
      m = movements[i];
    }
    if(sanity_check(m)) {
      return m;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function play_safe(movement) {
  // Avoid disqualification: no-op if moves are invalid
  return best_of(as_array(movement)) || NOP;
}

var RAND_SEED = (() => {
  var s = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    s += view[i].color * (i + 1);
    s += view[i].ant ? i * i : 0;
    s += view[i].food ? i * i * i : 0;
  }
  return s % 29;
})();

var ROTATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [6, 3, 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2],
  [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 6],
];

function try_all(fns, limit, wrapperFn, checkFn) {
  var m;
  fns = as_array(fns);
  for(var i = 0; i < fns.length; ++ i) {
    if(typeof(fns[i]) !== 'function') {
      if(checkFn(m = fns[i])) {
        return m;
      }
      continue;
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < limit; ++ j) {
      if(checkFn(m = wrapperFn(fns[i], j))) {
        return m;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function identify_rotation(testFns) {
  // testFns MUST be functions, not constants
  return try_all(
    testFns,
    4,
    (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]) ? ROTATIONS[r] : null,
    (r) => r
  );
}

function near(a, b) {
  return (
    Math.abs(a % 3 - b % 3) < 2 &&
    Math.abs(Math.floor(a / 3) - Math.floor(b / 3)) < 2
  );
}

function try_all_angles(solverFns) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    4,
    (fn, r) => fn(ROTATIONS[r]),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function try_all_cells(solverFns, skipCentre) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    9,
    (fn, i) => ((i === CENTRE && skipCentre) ? null : fn(i)),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function try_all_cells_near(p, solverFns) {
  return try_all(
    solverFns,
    9,
    (fn, i) => ((i !== p && near(p, i)) ? fn(i) : null),
    sanity_check
  );
}

function ant_type_at(i, friend) {
  return (view[i].ant && view[i].ant.friend === friend) ? view[i].ant.type : 0;
}

function friend_at(i) {
  return ant_type_at(i, true);
}

function foe_at(i) {
  return ant_type_at(i, false);
}

function foe_near(p) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    if(foe_at(i) && near(i, p)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function move_agent(agents) {
  var me = view[CENTRE].ant;
  var buddies = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i) {
    ++ buddies[friend_at(i)];
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < agents.length; i += 2) {
    if(agents[i] === me.type) {
      return agents[i+1](me, buddies);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function grab_nearby_food() {
  return try_all_cells((i) => (view[i].food ? {cell: i} : null), true);
}

function go_anywhere() {
  return try_all_cells((i) => ({cell: i}), true);
}

function colours_excluding(cols) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = COL_MIN; i < COL_LIM; ++ i) {
    if(cols.indexOf(i) === -1) {
      r.push(i);
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function generate_band(start, width) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < width; ++ i) {
    r.push(start + i);
  }
  return r;
}

function colour_band(colours) {
  return {
    contains: function(c) {
      return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1;
    },
    next: function(c) {
      return colours[(colours.indexOf(c) + 1) % colours.length];
    }
  };
}

function random_colour_band(colours) {
  return {
    contains: function(c) {
      return colours.indexOf(c) !== -1;
    },
    next: function() {
      return colours[RAND_SEED % colours.length];
    }
  };
}

function fast_diagonal(colourBand) {
  var m = try_all_angles([
    // Avoid nearby checked areas
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[5]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[0]};
      }
    },

    // Go in a straight diagonal line if possible
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[8]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[0]};
      }
    },

    // When in doubt, pick randomly but avoid doubling-back
    (rot) => (colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) ? null : {cell: rot[0]}),

    // Double-back when absolutely necessary
    (rot) => ({cell: rot[0]})
  ]);

  // Lay a colour track so that we can avoid doubling-back
  // (and mess up our foes as much as possible)
  if(!colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)) {
    var prevCol = m ? view[8-m.cell].color : WHITE;
    return {cell: CENTRE, color: colourBand.next(prevCol)};
  }

  return m;
}

function follow_edge(obstacleFn, side) {
  // Since we don't know which direction we came from, this can cause us to get
  // stuck on islands, but the random orientation helps to ensure we don't get
  // stuck forever.

  var order = ((side === SIDE_LEFT)
    ? [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0]
    : [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 0]
  );
  return try_all(
    [obstacleFn],
    order.length - 1,
    (fn, i) => (fn(order[i+1]) && !fn(order[i])) ? {cell: order[i]} : null,
    sanity_check
  );
}

function start_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => ((
      !protectedCols.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color) &&
      !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color)
    )
      ? {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3], color: colourBand.next(WHITE)}
      : null)
  ]);
}

function lay_dotted_path(colourBand, side, protectedCols) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => {
      var ahead = rot[right ? 2 : 0];
      var behind = rot[right ? 8 : 6];
      if(
        colourBand.contains(view[behind].color) &&
        !protectedCols.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[ahead].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: ahead, color: colourBand.next(view[behind].color)};
      }
    }
  ]);
}

function follow_dotted_path(colourBand, side, direction) {
  var forwards = (direction === DIR_REVERSE) ? 7 : 1;
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);

  return try_all_angles([
    // Cell on our side? advance
    (rot) => {
      if(
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color) &&
        // Prevent sticking / trickery
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[0]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[2]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[forwards]};
      }
    },

    // Cell ahead and behind? advance
    (rot) => {
      var passedCol = view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color;
      var nextCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        colourBand.contains(passedCol) &&
        nextCol === colourBand.next(passedCol) &&

        // Prevent sticking / trickery
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 3 : 5]].color) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 0 : 2]].color)
      ) {
        return {cell: rot[forwards]};
      }
    }
  ]);
}

function escape_dotted_path(colourBand, side, newColourBand) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);
  if(!newColourBand) {
    newColourBand = colourBand;
  }

  return try_all_angles([
    // Escape from beside the line
    (rot) => {
      var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color) ||
        !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 6 : 8]].color)
      ) {
        // not oriented, or in a corner
        return null;
      }
      return best_of([
        {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2], color: newColourBand.next(approachingCol)},
        {cell: rot[right ? 3 : 5]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 0 : 2]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 6 : 8]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 2 : 0]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 8 : 6]},
        {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]}
      ]);
    },

    // Escape from inside the line
    (rot) => {
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[7]].color) ||
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[1]].color) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      return best_of([
        {cell: rot[3]},
        {cell: rot[5]},
        {cell: rot[0]},
        {cell: rot[2]},
        {cell: rot[6]},
        {cell: rot[8]}
      ]);
    }
  ]);
}

function latch_to_dotted_path(colourBand, side) {
  var right = (side === SIDE_RIGHT);

  return try_all_angles([
    (rot) => {
      var approachingCol = view[rot[right ? 2 : 0]].color;
      if(
        colourBand.contains(approachingCol) &&
        view[rot[right ? 8 : 6]].color === colourBand.next(approachingCol) &&
        !colourBand.contains(view[rot[right ? 5 : 3]].color)
      ) {
        // We're on the wrong side; go inside the line
        return {cell: rot[right ? 5 : 3]};
      }
    },

    // Inside the line? pick a side
    (rot) => {
      var passedCol = view[rot[7]].color;
      var approachingCol = view[rot[1]].color;
      if(
        !colourBand.contains(passedCol) ||
        !colourBand.contains(approachingCol) ||
        colourBand.contains(view[CENTRE].color)
      ) {
        return null;
      }
      if((approachingCol === colourBand.next(passedCol)) === right) {
        return best_of([{cell: rot[3]}, {cell: rot[6]}, {cell: rot[0]}]);
      } else {
        return best_of([{cell: rot[5]}, {cell: rot[2]}, {cell: rot[8]}]);
      }
    }
  ]);
}


// == High-level logic begins here ==


var COLOURS = random_colour_band(colours_excluding([1]));
return play_safe([
  grab_nearby_food,
  fast_diagonal.bind(null, COLOURS),
  go_anywhere,
  {cell: 1, color: COLOURS.next()}
]);
```

So it occurred to me that in a couple of my answers I used the same initial step for gathering starting food quickly. What happens if an ant uses that strategy for the entire game? Well it turns out they do rather well.

This just races around the field at half the speed of light, grabbing any nearby food. There's a chance the direction will change randomly when grabbing food, and it will try to avoid any area already covered by itself or others. No worker ants are ever generated.

In theory, this covers 2.5 cells per frame, which isn't terrible, and it's pretty much impossible to trap it or mess it up in any way. It seems to do better than everything except Black Hole (though that may change now that Black Hole has a saboteur).

I promise to stop spamming this challenge with answers now…

---

The latest update makes it slightly less likely to re-search covered ground by making it push away from more types of filled areas.

Comment: It's not spam when they are all distinct and interesting strategies!

Comment: Which entry is Black Hole's saboteur?

Comment: @Draco18s not sure which one it is, but it quickly draws diagonal blue lines which often seem to make Black Hole stop spawning workers earlier than it wants to, and causes it to become super elongated, making all the workers take forever to get anywhere. There's also the white-paint-missile one which is causing woe to all, which can really run amok if it gets its hands on the black hole.

Comment: @Dave The bot that does that is Antdom Walking Artist

Answer (score 3):

## Pierce

This bot consistently obtains close to 90 food, beating out most of the other bots.

```
var ORTHOGONALS = [1,3,5,7];
var CORNERS = [0,2,6,8];
var CENTER = 4;

var QUEEN = 5;

var no_op = {cell:CENTER};
var me = view[4].ant;

var ants;
var food;
var friendlies;
var unfriendlies;
var colors;

var j = 0;
var i = 0;
var cell = 0;
var rotation;

var out;

init_arrays();
var seed = rSeed();

var response;

var adjacents_all = {0:[1,3,4],1:[0,2,3,4,5],2:[1,4,5],3:[0,1,4,6,7],4:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],5:[1,2,4,7,8],6:[3,4,7],7:[3,4,5,6,8],8:[4,5,7]};
var adjacents_ortho = {0:[1,3],1:[0,2,4],2:[1,5],3:[0,4,6],4:[1,3,5,7],5:[2,4,8],6:[3,7],7:[4,6,8],8:[5,7]};
var adjacents_diag = {0:[4],1:[3,5],2:[4],3:[1,7],4:[0,2,6,8],5:[1,7],6:[4],7:[3,5],8:[4]};

function valid_move(move) {
  if(!move || move.cell == undefined || move.cell < 0 || move.cell > 8) {return false;}
  if(move.type) {
    if(move.color) {return false;}
    if(move.type < 1 || move.type > 4) {return false;}
    if(view[move.cell].ant || view[move.cell].food) {return false;}
    if(me.type != QUEEN || me.food < 1) {return false;}
    return true;
  }
  if(move.color) {
    if(move.color < 1 || move.color > 8) {return false;}
    return true;
  }
  if(view[move.cell].ant){return false;}
  if(view[move.cell].food && me.food&& me.type != 5) {return false;}
  return true;
}

function steal_then_road(){
  if(count(unfriendlies, 5)>=1 && me.food==0){
    //steal from a queen with more than 30 food
    if(ants[unfriendlies.indexOf(5)].food>30){
      for(i=0;i<adjacents_ortho[unfriendlies.indexOf(5)].length;i++){
        if(ants[adjacents_ortho[unfriendlies.indexOf(5)][i]]==null){
          return {cell:adjacents_ortho[unfriendlies.indexOf(5)][i]};
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return road();
}

function try_corners(){
  for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(view[CORNERS[i]].ant==null){
      return {cell:CORNERS[i]};
    }
  }
}

function try_ortho(){
  for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(view[ORTHOGONALS[i]].ant==null){
      return {cell:ORTHOGONALS[i]};
    }
  }
}

function corner_then_ortho(){
  if(try_corners()){return try_corners();}
  if(try_ortho()){return try_ortho();}
  return {cell:4}; //PANIC!
}

function ortho_then_corner(){
  if(try_ortho()){return try_ortho();}
  if(try_corners()){return try_corners();}
  return {cell:4}; //PANIC!
}

function road(color){
  if (colors[color] != color) {
      return {cell:CENTER,color:color};
    }
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (colors[i] == color && ants[8 - i] == null && i != color) {
      return {cell:8-i};
    }
  }
}

function color_self(color){
  return {cell:4,color:color};
}

function make_valid_move(move){
  if(valid_move(move)){return move;}
  return no_op;
  //return{cell:seed%9,color:seed%7+1};
}

function count(array, element) {
  out = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[j] == element) {
      out++;
    }
  }
  return out;
}

function target_ant(ant_type, location) {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (ants[location] != null) {
      if (ants[location].type == ant_type) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    ants = rot_left(ants);
    friendlies = rot_left(friendlies);
    unfriendlies = rot_left(unfriendlies);
    food = rot_left(food);
    colors = rot_left(colors);
  }
}


function target_color(color, location) {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (colors[location] != null) {
      if (colors[location].type == color) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    ants = rot_left(ants);
    friendlies = rot_left(friendlies);
    unfriendlies = rot_left(unfriendlies);
    food = rot_left(food);
    colors = rot_left(colors);
  }
}

function init_arrays() {
    ants = new Array(9);
  for (cell = 0; cell < 9; cell++) {ants[cell] = view[cell].ant;}


  food = new Array(9);
  for (cell = 0; cell < 9; cell++) {food[cell] = view[cell].food;}

  colors = new Array(9);
  for (cell = 0; cell < 9; cell++) {colors[cell] = view[cell].color;}

  friendlies = new Array(9);
  for (cell = 0; cell < 9; cell++) {
    if (ants[cell] != null) {
      if (ants[cell].friend) {friendlies[cell] = ants[cell].type;}
    }
  }

  unfriendlies = new Array(9);
  for (cell = 0; cell < 9; cell++) {
    if (ants[cell] != null) {
      if (!ants[cell].friend) {unfriendlies[cell] = ants[cell].type;}
    }
  }
}

function rot_n_pos(pos, n) {
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pos = [2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 6][pos];
  }
  return pos;
}

function rot_left(a) {
  return [a[2], a[5], a[8], a[1], a[4], a[7], a[0], a[3], a[6]];
} 

function rot_right(a) {
  return [a[6], a[3], a[0], a[7], a[4], a[1], a[8], a[5], a[2]];
}

function rSeed(){
  out=23;
  for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    if(food[i]){
      out+=17;
    }
    out += 3 * colors[i];
    if(ants[i]){
      out *= 19;
    }
  }
  return out;
}

function get_response(){
  if (me.type == 5) { //Queen Case:
    return type5();
  }
  else if (me.type == 1) {
    return type1();
  }
  else if (me.type == 2) {
    return type2();
  }
  else if (me.type == 3) {
    return type3();
  }
  else if(me.type == 4){
    return type4();
}

function type5(){
  if (me.food == 0 && count(friendlies, 1) == 0 && count(friendlies, 2) == 0) {
    if (count(food, 1) > 0) {
      for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (food[j]) {
          return {cell: j};
        }
      }
    }
    // travel up
    // color own cell if not 4

    if(road()){return road();}

    //move
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      if (ants[i] == null && i != 4) {
        return {cell:i};
      }
    }
    return corner_then_ortho();
  }
  if (me.food >= 1 && count(friendlies, 1) == 0 && count(friendlies, 2) == 0) {
    if (ants[5] == null) {
      return {cell:5,type:1};
    }
    if (ants[1] == null) {
      return {cell:5, type:1};
    }
    if (ants[3] == null) {
      return {cell:5,type:1};
    }
    if (ants[7] == null) {
      return {cell:5, type:1};
    }
    return color_self(5);
  }
  if (me.food == 0 && count(friendlies, 1) == 1 && count(friendlies, 2) == 0) {
    if (friendlies.indexOf(1) % 2 == 0) {
      return ortho_then_corner();//PANIC!!! TODO: FIX
    }
    rotation = target_ant(1, 1);
    if (ants[0] == null) {
      return {cell: rot_n_pos(0, rotation)};
    } else {
      return corner_then_ortho;
    }
  }
  if (me.food >= 1 && count(friendlies, 1) == 1 && count(friendlies, 2) == 0) {
    if (friendlies.indexOf(1) % 2 == 0) {
      return corner_then_ortho(); //PANIC!!! TODO: FIX
    }
    rotation = target_ant(1, 1);
    if (ants[3] == null) {
      return {cell: rot_n_pos(3, rotation),type: 2};
    }
    if (ants[0] == null) {
      return { cell: rot_n_pos(0, rotation)};
    }
    return {cell: 4};
  }
  if (count(friendlies, 1) == 1 && count(friendlies, 2) == 1) {
    if (friendlies.indexOf(1) % 2 == 0) {
      return ortho_then_corner();
    }
    rotation = target_ant(1, 1);
    if(food[0] || food[8]){
      return no_op;
    }
    if(ants[5]!=null){
      if(ants[5].type == 2 && ants[2]==null){
        return {cell: rot_n_pos(2, rotation)};
      }
    }
    return corner_then_ortho();
  }
  return corner_then_ortho();
}

function type1(){
//right flank
  if (count(friendlies, 5) == 0 && count(friendlies, 2) == 0 && count(friendlies,1) == 1) {
    //no friends = destruction
    return steal_then_road();
  }
  if (count(friendlies, 5) == 1 && count(friendlies, 2) == 0 && count(friendlies,1) == 1) {
    if (friendlies.indexOf(5) % 2 == 0) {
      return ortho_then_corner();
    }
    rotation = target_ant(5, 3);
    if (ants[0] == null) {
      return {cell: rot_n_pos(0, rotation)};
    }
    return corner_then_ortho(); // PANIC!! TODO: FIX
  }
  if (count(friendlies, 5) == 1 && count(friendlies, 2) == 1 && count(friendlies,1) == 1) {
    if (friendlies.indexOf(5) % 2 == 0) {
      return ortho_then_corner(); 
    }
    rotation = target_ant(5, 3);
    if(friendlies[8] !=null){
      if(friendlies[8].type==2){
        if (ants[0] == null){
          return {cell: rot_n_pos(0, rotation)};
        }
      }
    }
    if (ants[0] != null) {
      if (ants[0].type == 2 && ants[6] == null) {
        return {cell: rot_n_pos(6, rotation)};
      }
    }
    if (ants[6] != null) {
      if (ants[6].type == 2 && ants[0] == null) {
        return {cell: rot_n_pos(0, rotation)};
      }
    }
    return corner_then_ortho();
  }
  return corner_then_ortho();
}

function type2(){
  //left flank
  if (count(friendlies, 5) == 0 && count(friendlies, 1) == 0  && count(friendlies,2) == 1) {
    return steal_then_road();
  }
  if (count(friendlies, 5) == 1 && count(friendlies, 1) == 0  && count(friendlies,2) == 1) {
    if (friendlies.indexOf(5) % 2 == 0) {
      return ortho_then_corner();
    }
    rotation = target_ant(5, 1);
    if (ants[0] == null) {
      return {cell: rot_n_pos(2, rotation)};
    }
    return corner_then_ortho();
    }
    if (count(friendlies, 5) == 1 && count(friendlies, 2) == 1) {
      return {cell: 4,color:2};
    }
    }
  return corner_then_ortho();
}

function type3(){}
function type4(){}

response = get_response();

return make_valid_move(response);
```

## Strategy.

#### Phase 1: Queen scramble.

The queen scrambles for food using a technique similar to Romanesco road (uses the `road()` function). Whenever she sees a food she takes it and spawns a type 1 worker, activating phase 2.

#### Phase 2: Queen-partner scramble.

The queen and partner use each other to orient, so they travel at the speed of light. They ignore any food around them and just get what hits them. When the queen gets a food, she spawns a type 2 worker, activating phase 3.

#### Phase 3: Pierce.

The three ants use each other to find their way, travelling at the speed of light. Whenever the queen sees a food that none of the workers can get, she stops, causing the workers to rotate around her and turning the formation 90 degrees.

## Strengths:

The three-ant formation creates no trails, doesn't wrap, and travels at the speed of light, getting an average of 0.1%*3=0.003 food per move. This equates to 0.003*30000 = 90 food per game on average, which is usually obtained.

## Weaknesses:

The bot has two weaknesses. The main one is an ant walking in front of the formation. The handling for that is not the best and sometimes causes the queen to create excessive amounts of workers. Luckily, the workers are programmed to steal from other queens (`steal_then_road()`). But since the formation creates no trails, it is practically impossible to find.

Another weakness is the `road()` algorithm which appears to have problems which I am working on fixing. A road being Brownian motion is not good. This means a very slow start and a bad escape from unhealthy situations.

Comment: These ants are practically the same as my [steamroller ants](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135154/52152), but seem to do worse in my testing. The only difference I notice is that your ants turn when the queen sees food that the other workers can't reach, while mine turns when the type 2 worker will hit some food. I think your ants should also perform well, but I don't understand why it sometimes under performs.

Comment: @KZhang Interesting. On my testing, Pierce does better generally, except when it hits a major interference of ants (Wildfire? Black Hole?) when it creates tens of new ants unnecessarily. Only time and testing will tell.

Comment: Reincluded in the current tournament ready for the next leaderboard following the edit.

Comment: I've noticed that in rare situations this pattern can get stuck in an endless loop. Specifically, if there are two pieces of food which are separated by 1 space, and then the queen enters a position adjacent to both of them; when this happens the pattern constantly turns, presumably because it only reacts to "food which would be missed if we don't turn" and not "food which will be missed if we do turn"

Answer (score 3):

## Explorer

*Spread out Gang!*

[image]

Explorer is a 5 man team that aims to spread as far apart as possible, whilst still bringing food back to the queen.

### The Queen

The queen itself uses a 3 stage setup.

#### Stage 1.

At the start of a match, it's a wild dash for food, like any good queen. It just paths in a straight line diagonally until it finds food, then randomly changes direction. When it has 4 food, it moves to stage 2.

#### Stage 2.

This will probably take no more than 8 moves. It sets the four tiles around it to four unique colours, and spawns ants on them, with their respective types. After they're all spawned, stage 3 is moved to.

#### Stage 3.

All stage 3 does is sit still for the rest of the match, ensuring the four tiles around it are set correctly.

### The Workers

The workers themselves are very simple two stage creatures. First, they wait for the queen to signal she's finished Stage 2. The second stage is a lot more complex (But still fairly simple). It walks clockwise around its own path until it finds its end, then it continues to expand it. When it finds food, it reaches out to it, then orbits clockwise around the path again, which leads it back to the queen.

```javascript
var me = view[4].ant
var turf = view[4].color

var queenHolder = 2 // "Queen Holder", the turf colour for the queen in stage 3.
var queenBuild = 7 // "Queen Build", the turf colour for the queen in stage 2.
var antTrail = [3, 4, 5, 6] // Various colours of the ant's trails.
var orth = [1, 3, 5, 7] // Orthogonal Directions.
var rotates = [[1,3,5,7],[3,7,1,5],[5,1,7,3],[7,5,3,1]] // These are the orthogonal directions rotated so 0 is the first position, used in the queen build stage.
var outside = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8] // Every tile but the center one.
var diag = [0,2,6,8] // Diagonal Directions.

// Define a move function to avoid throwing an error.
function move(dir){
    if(view[dir].ant)   // If we're going to move onto an ant.
        dir = 4 // Don't move anywhere.
    if(view[dir].food && me.type < 5 && me.food > 0)    // If we're going to over-eat.
        dir = 4 // Don't move anywhere.
    return {cell: dir}  // Build the move output.
}

if(me.type == 5){ // If we're the queen.
    var invDiag = [8,6,2,0] // Inverse of diagonals, using the indexing of diag. So 0 becomes 8, and such.
    if(turf == 1 || turf == 8){
        // Stage 1.
        // Find enough food to start a hive.
        for(var i=0; i < view.length; i++){ // Check every tile in view
            if(view[i].food){   // Is it food?
                return move(i)  // Move to it.
            }
        }
        if(me.food > 3) // Do we have 4 food?
            return {cell:4, color:queenBuild}   // Move to stage 2.
        if(turf == 1)   // Are we on a white tile?
            return {cell:4, color:8}    // Set the tile to black.
        for(var i=0; i < diag.length; i++)  // Check all diagonals.
            if(view[diag[i]].color == 8)    // Is it black?
                return move(invDiag[i]) // Move in the opposite direction. This creates a straight diagonal line.
        return move(2)  // When in doubt, move randomly diagonally.
    }else if(turf == queenBuild){
        // Stage 2.
        // Spawn ants around, and set up their movement paths.
        if(me.food < 1) // Have we used all our food?
            return {cell:4, color:queenHolder}  // Move to stage 3.

        var firstHolder = -1; // Stores which way we're facing.
        for(var i=0; i < orth.length; i++){ // Check orthogonals.
            if(view[orth[i]].color == antTrail[0]){ // Is it the first trail colour?
                firstHolder = i // THIS WAY UP
                break;
            }
        }
        if(firstHolder==-1) // No way is up?
            return {cell:1, color:antTrail[0]} // Set a random direction to up.

        var orthRot = rotates[firstHolder]  // Get the rotated orthogonal set for the current up direction.
        for(var i=0; i < orthRot.length; i++){  // For each of them.
            if(!view[orthRot[i]].ant)   // Is there an ant on this tile yet?
                return {cell:orthRot[i], type:(i+1)}    // If not, place one down with the correct type.
            if(view[orthRot[i]].color!=antTrail[i]) // Otherwise, is the turf set correctly yet?
                return {cell:orthRot[i], color:antTrail[i]} // If not, set the turf.
        }
        return {cell:4, color:queenHolder}; // After all's said and done, move to stage 3. Probably won't happen this way.
    }else if(turf == queenHolder){
        // Stage 3.
        // Sit still, ensure rails exist around.

        var firstHolder = -1;   // Same behavoir of which way is up from stage 2.
        for(var i=0; i < orth.length; i++){
            if(view[orth[i]].color == antTrail[0]){
                firstHolder = i
                break;
            }
        }
        if(firstHolder==-1)
            return {cell:1, color:antTrail[0]}

        var orthRot = rotates[firstHolder]
        for(var i=0; i < orthRot.length; i++)   // Basically stage 2 without the spawning of ants.
            if(view[orthRot[i]].color!=antTrail[i])
                return {cell:orthRot[i], color:antTrail[i]}

        return {cell:4, color:queenHolder}  // And if there's nothing better to do, waste your time.
    }else{
        return {cell:4, color:1}    // We're lost, go back to stage 1, and try again.
        // I could probably add logic to check if we're stage 3 or something, but meh.
    }
    
}else{  // If we're a worker!

    for(var i=0; i < orth.length; i++)  // Check around.
        if(view[orth[i]].ant && view[orth[i]].ant.type == 5 && view[orth[i]].ant.friend && view[orth[i]].color == queenBuild)   // Is there a queen, in build mode, around us?
            return move(4)  // Wait politely for her to finish.

    var col = antTrail[me.type-1] // Which colour I use.

    if(me.food < 1){    // If we have no food.
        for(i=0; i < orth.length; i++){ // Check Orthogonals
            if(view[orth[i]].food){ // Is there food there?
                if(turf != col) // If we're not standing on our trail.
                    return {cell: 4, color: col}    // Place our trail here, so we can still find our way back.
                return move(orth[i])    // Otherwise, move to the food!
            }
        }
    }

    if(turf == col) // If we're sitting on our trail.
        return move(2) // Move off it randomly

    var corq = (t)=>t.color == col || (t.ant && t.ant.type == 5 && t.ant.friend)    // Helper function, does this tile contain our trail or the queen?
    var corqorf = (t)=>corq(t) || t.food    // Helper function, odes this tile contain our trail, the queen, or a piece of food?
    var queenInView = false;
    for(var i=0; i < view.length; i++)  // Check the entire view.
        if(view[i].ant && view[i].ant.type == 5 && view[i].ant.friend) // Can we see the queen?
            queenInView = true; // Remember this.

    // Using food > 0 behavoir if we see a queen, makes it so that we don't accidentally build our path over the queen or something silly.

    if(me.food > 0 || queenInView){ // If we have food, or we can see the queen.
        // DON'T build paths, just orbit our path clockwise.
        var orthmov = [3,7,1,5] // Directions to move if we see a path on an orthogonal.
        var diagC = [3,1,7,5]   // Directions to move if we see a path on a diagonal.
        for(var i=0; i < orth.length; i++)  // For each Orthogonal, which takes preference.
            if(corqorf(view[orth[i]]))  // Is there the queen, a trail, or food here?
                return move(orthmov[i]) // move CW to it.
        for(var i=0; i < diag.length; i++)  // Ditto for Diagonals.
            if(corqorf(view[diag[i]]))
                return move(diagC[i])

    }else{
        // EXTEND paths, or continue orbiting clockwise.
        var orthM = [0,6,2,8]   // Directions a path should be when we check an orthogonal.
        var orthMo = [3,7,1,5]  // Directions to move if we see an orthogonal, and the diagonal is there.
        var diagC = [3,1,7,5]   // Directions to place a path if we only see an orthogonal.
        for(var i=0; i < orth.length; i++){ // In each Orthogonal.
            var v = view[orth[i]]
            if(corq(v)){    // Is there a trial?
                if(corq(view[orthM[i]]))    // Is there a trail in the after it position?
                    return move(orthMo[i])  // Move in the correct direction.
                return {cell:orthM[i], color:col}   // Place the trail in the after it position.
            }
        }
        for(var i=0; i < diag.length; i++)  // Check diagonals as a last resort.
            if(corq(view[diag[i]])) // Is there a path /HERE/?
                return {cell:diagC[i], color:col}   // Place the respective diagonal's orthogonal.
        
    }
    return move(2)  // When we're lost, scamper around. Just like Trail-eraser wants us to.
}
```

Comment: This player was disqualified in a tournament game and will be excluded from leaderboards until edited to fix. Further details in the next comment.

Comment: **Reason:** Cannot create new worker on top of food. **Input:** [{"color":7,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":8,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":3,"food":1,"ant":null},{"color":7,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":5,"friend":true}},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":1,"food":0,"ant":null},{"color":7,"food":0,"ant":null}] **Response:** {"cell":3,"type":1}

Answer (score 3):

## Single Queen

```
var C = 5;

for(var i = 0; i<9; i++)
{
  if(view[i].food === 1)
    return {cell:i};
}


if(view[4].color != 5 && !view[0].ant && !view[1].ant && !view[2].ant && !view[3].ant && !view[5].ant && !view[6].ant && !view[7].ant && !view[8].ant)
  return {cell:4, color:C};

if(!view[0].ant && 
   view[0].color != C && view[8].color === C && view[1].color != C && view[3].color != C && view[2].color != C && view[6].color != C)

      return {cell:0};

if(!view[2].ant && 
   view[2].color != C && view[6].color === C && view[1].color != C && view[5].color != C  && view[0].color != C && view[8].color != C)

     return {cell:2};

if(!view[6].ant && 
   view[6].color != C && view[2].color ===  C && view[3].color != C && view[7].color != C  && view[0].color != C && view[8].color != C)

     return {cell:6};

if(!view[8].ant && 
   view[8].color != C && view[0].color === C && view[5].color != C && view[7].color != C  && view[2].color != C && view[6].color != C)

     return {cell:8};


if(!view[0].ant)
  return {cell:0};

if(!view[2].ant)
  return {cell:2};

if(!view[6].ant)
  return {cell:6};

if(!view[8].ant)
  return {cell:8};


return {cell:4};
```

Simple code searching diagonally for food.  Tries to avoid searching it's old area, but will search other areas to try and pass through their areas hoping to find open space.

Appears to be similar strategy to Lone Wolf (unintentional).

Answer (score 3):

## VinceAnt

Do you feel that after nine months, the arena still looks a little bland?

Do you think that the [Antdom Walking Artist](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/135156#135156) and orphaned [The Formation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/161838#161838) workers could do with a little help in decorating it attractively?

Then you'll like this one!

[image: A Highway, refashioned]

From time to time, as our means allow, the queen will sponsor and spawn a painter or two. These will go on to mess with the colors around them, in various personal styles, often taking existing colors into account but rearranging and twisting them as they see fit. They usually work alone, or sometimes in pairs. (That two ants can follow a straight horizontal or vertical line had been clear since day one and Dave's [Forensic Ants](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/135108#135108), but watch out now for a tandem who shift the patterns they encounter by one cell's worth.)

[image: Claude and Jean]

To make this affordable, there's a backbone lifted from my [Windmill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/143980#143980) - imagine a Windmill queen and secretary/navigator who never grow up and settle. (The idea had previously been perfected by [Lightspeed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/153688#153688), having been pioneered by the [Vampire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135102/formic-functions-ant-queen-of-the-hill-contest/135984#135984)'s bouncer facility. The implementation is different from Lightspeed's, though.) A number of modifications were needed to prevent things from falling apart when we run into our own offspring.

By its nature, this entry can't beat Lightspeed, but is expected to do reasonably well for all its extravaganza - about fifth among the current (as of April 2018) contenders.

Commented un-golfed source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/GNiklasch/VinceAnt), and I'm planning to add more details about each painter type and style there once I've got round to collecting some nice screenshots.

```
var ANV=1;var AMK=2;var AGS=3;var AWM=4;var AQ=5;var THC=1;var THP=[0,0,0,0,0,0];THP[AMK]=19;THP[AGS]=17;THP[AWM]=15;var RM=15;var SPDAT =[0,AMK,AGS,0,AWM,0,AGS,AWM,0,AMK,0,AWM,AMK,0,AGS];var PW=1;var PY=2;var PP=3;var PC=4;var PR=5;var PG=6;var PB=7;var PK=8;var LCLR=PW;var LT=PY;var LLSF=PG;var TN=8;var POSC=4;var NOP={cell:POSC};var CCW=[6,7,8,5,2,1,0,3,6,7,8,5,2,1,0,3,6,7,8,5,2,1];
var xn=-1;var here=view[POSC];var mC=here.color;var myself=here.ant;var mT=myself.type;var mF=myself.food;var mS=(mT!=AQ&&mF>0);var dOK=[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true];
var uo=true;var sL=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];var sD=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];var sN=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];var sT=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];var fdL=0;var fdD=0;var fdT=0;sT[mC]++;for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){var cell=view[CCW[i]];sD[cell.color]++;sN[cell.color]++;sT[cell.color]++;if (cell.food>0){fdD++;fdT++;if (mS){dOK[CCW[i]]=false;uo=false;}}}for (var i=1; i<TN; i+=2){var cell=view[CCW[i]];sL[cell.color]++;sN[cell.color]++;sT[cell.color]++;if (cell.food>0){fdL++;fdT++;if (mS){dOK[CCW[i]]=false;uo=false;}}}var aF=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var aLF=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var aUF=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var fT=0;var mQ=0;var aE=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var aLE=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var aUE=[0,0,0,0,0,0];var eT=0;for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){var cell=view[CCW[i]];if (cell.ant){if (cell.ant.friend){aF[cell.ant.type]++;fT++;if (cell.ant.type==AQ){xn=i&6;mQ=i&1;}if (cell.ant.food>0){aLF[cell.ant.type]++;} else {aUF[cell.ant.type]++;}} else {aE[cell.ant.type]++;eT++;if (cell.ant.food>0){aLE[cell.ant.type]++;} else {aUE[cell.ant.type]++;}}dOK[CCW[i]]=false;uo=false;}}switch (mT){case AQ:return (rQSs());case ANV:return (rNSs());case AMK:return (rMSs());case AGS:return (rGSs());case AWM:return (rWSs());default:return NOP;}function rQSs(){switch (aF[ANV]){case 0:return (rQScrSy());case 1:for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){var cell=view[CCW[i]];if (cell.ant&&cell.ant.friend&&cell.ant.type==ANV){xn=i&6;if (i&1){return (rQLsSy());} else {return (rQCSy());}}}break;default:return (rQCNSy());}return NOP;}function rNSs(){if (aF[AQ]>0){if (mQ==1){return (rSLSy());} else {return (rNRSy());}} else if ((mF==0)&&(fdT>0)){return (rPEgSy());} else {return (rPPgSy());}}function rMSs(){if ((aF[AQ]>0)&&(mF==0)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else {return NOP;}} else if ((mF>0)&&(aF[AQ]+aF[ANV]>0)){return NOP;} else if ((mF==0)&&(fdT>0)){return (rPEgSy());} else if (aF[AGS]+aF[AWM]>1){return (rPMgSy());} else if (aF[AGS]==1){return (rCPgSy());} else {return (rMPgSy());}}function rGSs(){if ((aF[AQ]>0)&&(mF==0)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else {return NOP;}} else if ((mF>0)&&(aF[AQ]+aF[ANV]>0)){return NOP;} else if ((mF==0)&&(fdT>0)){return (rPEgSy());} else if (aF[AMK]+aF[AWM]>1){return (rPMgSy());} else if (aF[AMK]==1){return (rJPgSy());} else {return (rGPgSy());}}function rWSs(){if ((aF[AQ]>0)&&(mF==0)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else {return NOP;}} else if ((mF>0)&&(aF[AQ]+aF[ANV]>0)){return NOP;} else if ((mF==0)&&(fdT>0)){return (rPEgSy());} else if (aF[AMK]+aF[AGS]>1){return (rPMgSy());} else {return (rWPgSy());}}function rQScrSy(){if (uo){if (fdT>0){return (rQSETc());} else if (mF>=THC){for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LT)||(view[CCW[i+1]].color==LT)){return {cell:CCW[i+1],type:ANV};}}return {cell:1,type:ANV};} else if (mC!=LT){if ((mC==LCLR)||(sN[LCLR]>=TN-1)){return {cell:POSC,color:LT};} else {return (rQSTCTc());}} else if ((sN[LCLR]>=4)&&(sN[LT]==1)){for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LT)||(view[CCW[i+1]].color==LT)){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};}}} else if (sN[LCLR]==TN){return {cell:0};} else {return (rQSATc());}} else {if ((fdT>0)&&(eT>0)&&(eT==aE[AQ])){return (rQSSTc());} else {return (rQSEvTc());}}return NOP;}function rQLsSy(){if ((sT[LCLR]<=2)&&(mF>1)&&(eT==0)){var artist=SPDAT[mF % RM];if ((artist!=0)&&(mF>=THP[artist])&&(aF[artist]<=1)){var tc=[6,2,4,5,3];for (var i=0; i<tc.length; i++){var c=CCW[xn+tc[i]];if (dOK[c]&&(view[c].food==0)){return {cell:c,type:artist};}}}}if ((eT==0)&&(fT==1)){if (view[CCW[xn+2]].food>0){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if ((view[CCW[xn+3]].food +view[CCW[xn+4]].food>0)&&(view[CCW[xn+1]].color!=LLSF)){return NOP;} else {return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};}} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else {return NOP;}}function rQCNSy(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){var cell=view[CCW[i]];if (cell.ant&&cell.ant.friend&&cell.ant.type==ANV){if (i&1){if (dOK[CCW[i-1]]){return {cell:CCW[i-1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+1]]){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};} else {return NOP;}} else {if (dOK[CCW[i+7]]){return {cell:CCW[i+7]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+1]]){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};} else {return NOP;}}}}return (rQCSy());}function rQCSy(){return NOP;}function rSLSy(){if ((eT==0)&&(fT==1)){if (view[CCW[xn]].food>0){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (view[CCW[xn+7]].food +view[CCW[xn+6]].food>0){return {cell:POSC,color:LLSF};} else {return {cell:CCW[xn]};}} else if ((eT>0)&&view[CCW[xn+2]].ant&&!view[CCW[xn+2]].ant.friend){return {cell:POSC,color:LLSF};} else if ((fT>1)&&((view[CCW[xn+6]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+6]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[xn+6]].ant.food>0))||(view[CCW[xn+5]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[xn+5]].ant.food>0)))){return {cell:POSC,color:LLSF};} else {if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};}}return NOP;}function rNRSy(){if (view[CCW[xn+1]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+1]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[xn+1]].ant.type==mT)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else {return NOP;}} else if (view[CCW[xn+7]].ant&&view[CCW[xn+7]].ant.friend&&(view[CCW[xn+7]].ant.type==mT)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else {return NOP;}} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+2]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else {return NOP;}}function rPPgSy(){if (aLF[AMK]+aLF[AGS] +aLF[AWM]>0){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.food>0)){if (dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+3]]){return {cell:CCW[i+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+5]]){return {cell:CCW[i+5]};}}}} else if (aF[mT]>0){return (rSPTc());}return (rPPgTc());}function rMPgSy(){if (aF[mT]>0){return (rSPTc());}return (rMPgTc());}function rGPgSy(){if (aF[mT]>0){return (rSPTc());}return (rGPgTc());}function rWPgSy(){if (aF[mT]>0){return (rSPTc());}return (rWPgTc());}function rCPgSy(){var phase=0;for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==AGS)){xn=i&6;phase=i&1;break;}}if ((phase==1)&&(mC==view[CCW[xn+7]].color)&&(view[CCW[xn]].color==view[CCW[xn+1]].color)){if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else {return NOP;}} else {return {cell:CCW[xn+7],color:mC};}return NOP;}function rJPgSy(){var phase=0;for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==AMK)){xn=i&6;phase=i&1;break;}}if (phase==0){if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+4]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+6]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else {return NOP;}} else {return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:mC};}return NOP;}function rPEgSy(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].food>0)&&dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}function rPMgSy(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type!=mT)){if (dOK[CCW[i+1]]&&!view[CCW[i+7]].ant&&!view[CCW[i+2]].ant&&!view[CCW[i+3]].ant){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+7]]&&!view[CCW[i+1]].ant&&
!view[CCW[i+6]].ant&&!view[CCW[i+5]].ant){return {cell:CCW[i+7]};}}}for (var i=1; i<TN; i+=2){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type!=mT)){if (dOK[CCW[i-1]]&&!view[CCW[i+6]].ant){return {cell:CCW[i-1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+1]]&&!view[CCW[i+2]].ant){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};}}}for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return {cell:POSC,color:view[CCW[0]].color};}function rQSETc(){if (mC!=LT){return {cell:POSC,color:LT};}for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].food>0){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}function rQSSTc(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].food>0)&&(dOK[CCW[i]])){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}function rQSTCTc(){if ((mC!=LCLR)&&(sN[mC]>=4)){if (sN[LT]==0){return {cell:POSC,color:LT};} else if (sN[LT]>=3){return {cell:POSC,color:LT};} else {for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LT)&&(view[CCW[i+2]].color!=LT)){return {cell:CCW[i+2],color:LT};}}return NOP;}} else if (sN[LT]==1){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LT)&&(view[CCW[i+4]].color!=LCLR)){if (view[CCW[i+1]].color==LCLR){return { cell:CCW[i+1]};} else if (view[CCW[i+7]].color==LCLR){return { cell:CCW[i+7]};} else {return {cell:POSC,color:LT};}}}return {cell:POSC,color:LT};} else {return {cell:POSC,color:LT};}return NOP;}function rQSATc(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if ((view[CCW[i]].color==LCLR)&&(view[CCW[i+1]].color==LCLR)&&(view[CCW[i+2]].color==LCLR)){if ((view[CCW[i+3]].color==LCLR)&&(view[CCW[i+4]].color==LCLR)){return {cell:CCW[i+2]};}return {cell:CCW[i+1]};}}for (var i=TN-1; i>=0; i--){if (view[CCW[i]].color!=LT){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].color!=LT){return {cell:CCW[i],color:LCLR};}}return {cell:0,color:LCLR};}function rQSEvTc(){if (sN[LT]>0){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].color==LT){xn=i&6;}}if ( dOK[CCW[xn+7]]&&dOK[CCW[xn]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+1]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+2]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]] ){return {cell:CCW[xn+1]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+6]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]&&dOK[CCW[xn]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+7]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+3]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+4]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+6]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+7]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+1]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+2]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+3]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+7]]&&dOK[CCW[xn]]&&dOK[CCW[xn+1]]){return {cell:CCW[xn]};} else {for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}} else {for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]&&dOK[CCW[i+1]]&&dOK[CCW[i+2]]&&dOK[CCW[i+3]]&&dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+2]};}}for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]&&dOK[CCW[i+1]]&&dOK[CCW[i+2]]){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};}}for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}return NOP;}function rPPgTc(){if (sL[mC]==0){return {cell:1,color:mC};}for (var i=1; i<TN; i+=2){if (view[CCW[i]].color==mC){xn=i&6;break;}}var col1=(mC+1) % 8+1;if ((view[CCW[xn+5]].color==mC)&&(view[CCW[xn+3]].color==col1)&&(view[CCW[xn+7]].color!=col1)){xn=(xn+4) % 8;}if (view[CCW[xn+7]].color!=col1){return {cell:CCW[xn+7],color:col1};} else if (view[CCW[xn]].color!=col1){return {cell:CCW[xn],color:col1};}var col2=(mC+5) % 8+1;if (view[CCW[xn+3]].color!=col2){return {cell:CCW[xn+3],color:col2};} else if (view[CCW[xn+2]].color!=col2){return {cell:CCW[xn+2],color:col2};} else if (view[CCW[xn+5]].color!=mC){return {cell:CCW[xn+5],color:mC};} else if (view[CCW[xn+4]].color!=col2){return {cell:CCW[xn+4],color:col2};} else if (dOK[CCW[xn+5]]){return {cell:CCW[xn+5]};} else {return (rWgPTc());}}function rMPgTc(){switch (sT[mC]){case 9:var col=((mC+2) % 8)+1;return {cell:CCW[0],color:col};case 8:for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){var col=view[CCW[i]].color;if (col!=mC){if (i==0){return {cell:POSC,color:col};} else if ((i==1)&&dOK[CCW[i+3]]){return {cell:CCW[i+3]};} else if ((i==2)&&dOK[CCW[i+5]]){return {cell:CCW[i+5]};} else {return {cell:CCW[i-1],color:col};}}}break;case 7:return rWgPTc();case 6:for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].color!=mC){if ((i==0)&&dOK[CCW[i+5]]){return {cell:CCW[i+5]};} else if ((i==1)&&dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};} else {return {cell:CCW[i],color:mC};}}}break;case 5:case 4:case 3:for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].color!=mC){return {cell:CCW[i],color:mC};}}break;case 2:case 1:default:for (var i=TN-1; i>=0; i--){var col=view[CCW[i]].color;if ((col==mC)&&(sT[view[CCW[i+4]].color]==7)&&dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};}if (sT[col]>=3){return {cell:POSC,color:col};}}var col=view[CCW[1]].color;if (view[CCW[0]].color!=col){return {cell:CCW[0],color:col};} else if (view[CCW[2]].color!=col){return {cell:CCW[2],color:col};}break;}return (rWgPTc());}function rGPgTc(){var col=0;for (var c0=view[CCW[0]].color; c0<view[CCW[0]].color+8; c0++){var c=(c0 % 8)+1;if (sN[c]==0){col=c;}}if (col==0){return (rWgPTc());}for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (sN[view[CCW[i]].color]>1){return {cell:CCW[i],color:col};}}return (rWgPTc());}function rWPgTc(){var col=((mC+6) % 8)+1;if (sT[mC]==9){return {cell:CCW[0],color:col};}var myRand=(view[CCW[0]].color+sT[view[CCW[2]].color]) % 3;
switch (myRand){case 0:for (var i=0; i<TN; i+=2){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}break;case 1:if (view[CCW[1]].color!=view[CCW[7]].color){return {cell:CCW[1],color:view[CCW[7]].color};} else if (view[CCW[5]].color!=view[CCW[3]].color){return {cell:CCW[5],color:view[CCW[3]].color};}break;case 2:if (view[CCW[5]].color!=view[CCW[3]].color){return {cell:CCW[5],color:view[CCW[3]].color};} else if (view[CCW[1]].color!=view[CCW[7]].color){return {cell:CCW[1],color:view[CCW[7]].color};}break;default:break;}for (var i=1; i<TN; i+=2){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return (rWgPTc());}function rSPTc(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (view[CCW[i]].ant&&view[CCW[i]].ant.friend&&
(view[CCW[i]].ant.type==mT)){if (dOK[CCW[i+4]]){return {cell:CCW[i+4]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+3]]){return {cell:CCW[i+3]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+5]]){return {cell:CCW[i+5]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+2]]){return {cell:CCW[i+2]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+6]]){return {cell:CCW[i+6]};} else if (dOK[CCW[i+1]]){return {cell:CCW[i+1]};}}}return NOP;}function rWgPTc(){for (var i=0; i<TN; i++){if (dOK[CCW[i]]){return {cell:CCW[i]};}}return NOP;}
```

Enjoy!

** v1.0.1 Now compatible with strict-mode controllers.

** v1.0.2 Fixes a disqualifying typo.

Comment: Note that if the ants are "creative" enough and manage to confuse more advanced ants, then this entry might actually have a chance of surpassing Lightspeed - less strong competitors = higher score. That probably won't be the case here, though, since even Highway usually manages to survive the artists' treatment...

Comment: @Alion the VinceAnt painters do occasionally manage to confuse Windmill ants among others, and sometimes block enemy workers, or cause Sliding Miners or Windmill miners to start new rails in the wrong places - but if Lightspeed is playing in the same games as well, then Lightspeed will also benefit...

Comment: The indev version of the formation attempts to clump up around enemy workers and outcolor them with garbage, but even this doesnt always lead to railbending. And even when it does, it is uncommon that this puts a dent in other workers' ability to navigate to and from the queen. Take it from me, it's quite hard to mislead rail nests.

Comment: @trichoplax Fixed - sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Antdom Walking Artist

This is a fancy <strike>queen-only</strike> random walk entry with a slight twist-- the queen ant wanders around coloring cells if she feels that there aren't enough non-colored cells nearby.  If she sees food, she'll instantly grab it. Hopefully she could gather some food, unless other ants steal them away.

A lot of worker ants would stop by and be appalled at the "*marvelous*" art.  This means that other worker ants may eventually forget to return to their own queen ants.

Workers can be spawn occasionally.  They walk along horizontal or vertical lines if they haven't found any food yet, and will walk on diagonal lines once they found some food.  Unfortunately, there is little coordination between the queen and the workers, and the workers will forever roam free.

### How it works

1. If this is a **Queen ant** (type 5):

   a. If there is food in either of the 8 neighboring cells, fetch food.

   b. Otherwise, if there are strictly less than 4 colored cells in the 8 neighboring cells, color the lowest-indexed white cell with the color code `next_color = (8 - #colored)`.

   c. Otherwise, when time is just right, (*i.e.* if `seed = 666 mod 2333` and `me['food'] = 2 mod 3`), spawn a worker of random type.

   d. Otherwise, walk to the lowest-indexed neighboring cell that contains no ant.
2. If this is a **Worker ant** (type 1-4):

   a. If the worker is unladen (does not carry food) and if there is food in either of the 8 neighboring cells, fetch food.

   b. Otherwise, if the worker is walking on a white cell, it gets colored by `Math.abs(next_color - 2) + 2`.

   c. Otherwise, attempt to walk along a straight line in the vertical or horizontal direction.  If this is not possible, walk to the lowest-indexed neighboring cell that contains no ant (and no food if the worker is laden).

### Code

```
var action = { cell: 4, color: 0, type: 0 },
    colors = view.map((v) => v.color),
    foods = view.map((v) => v.food === 1),
    ants = view.map((v) => v.ant),
    me = ants[4];

var seed = colors.reduce((s, v) => s * 8 + (v - 1));

// Search the neighboring cells for food and walk on to them.
var next_food = foods.indexOf(true);

// As the last measure, find a move that avoids other ants and food.
var get_direction = (view) => {
    var direction = 4, complete = false;
    for (var i = 0; !complete && i < 4; ++i) {
        if (view[i]['ant'] === null && view[i]['food'] === 0) {
            complete = true;
            direction = i;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 5; !complete && i < 9; ++i) {
        if (view[i]['ant'] === null && view[i]['food'] === 0) {
            complete = true;
            direction = i;
        }
    }
    return direction;
};

// Attempt to walk along a diagonal.
var get_diagonal_opposite = (view, food) => {
    var direction = null;
    if (view[0]['color'] === 1 && view[8]['color'] > 1 && view[0]['ant'] === null && view[0]['food'] <= food) {
        direction = 0;
    } else if (view[8]['color'] === 1 && view[0]['color'] > 1 && view[8]['ant'] === null && view[8]['food'] <= food) {
        direction = 8;
    } else if (view[2]['color'] === 1 && view[6]['color'] > 1 && view[2]['ant'] === null && view[2]['food'] <= food) {
        direction = 2;
    } else if (view[6]['color'] === 1 && view[2]['color'] > 1 && view[6]['ant'] === null && view[6]['food'] <= food) {
        direction = 6;
    }
    return direction;
};

// Attempt to walk along a horizontal or vertical line.
var get_lateral_opposite = (view, food) => {
    var direction = null;
    if (view[1]['color'] === 1 && view[7]['color'] > 1 && view[1]['ant'] === null && view[1]['food'] <= food) {
        direction = 1;
    } else if (view[7]['color'] === 1 && view[1]['color'] > 1 && view[7]['ant'] === null && view[7]['food'] <= food) {
        direction = 7;
    } else if (view[3]['color'] === 1 && view[5]['color'] > 1 && view[3]['ant'] === null && view[3]['food'] <= food) {
        direction = 3;
    } else if (view[5]['color'] === 1 && view[3]['color'] > 1 && view[5]['ant'] === null && view[5]['food'] <= food) {
        direction = 5;
    }
    return direction;
};

// A random color. Starts from 8. Reduce 1 if any neighboring cells are colored.
var next_color = 8 - colors.reduce((s, v, i) => s + ((i !== 4 && v > 1) ? 1 : 0), 0);
if (me['type'] === 5) {
    // Queen Ant
    if (next_food !== -1) {
        // Moves onto food.
        action['cell'] = next_food;
    } else if (next_color > 4) {
        // If not enough colored cells, go around and color.
        var target = colors.indexOf(1);
        action['cell'] = target;
        action['color'] = next_color;
    } else if (seed % 2333 === 666 && me['food'] % 3 === 2) {
        // If queen has (3k + 2) food pellets, randomly spawn worker ants.
        var type = seed % 4 + 1;
        if (ants[1] === null) {
            action['type'] = type;
            action['cell'] = 1;
        } else if (ants[0] === null) {
            action['type'] = type;
            action['cell'] = 0;
        }
    } else {
        action['cell'] = get_direction(view);
    }
} else if (me['type'] <= 4) {
    // Gatherers
    if (me['food'] === 0) {
        // 1. Collect food if one is nearby.
        // 2. Color current cell.
        // 3. Move in a vertical/horizontal line.
        if (next_food !== -1) {
            action['cell'] = next_food;
        } else if (colors[4] < 2) {
            action['cell'] = 4;
            action['color'] = Math.abs(next_color - 2) + 2;
        } else {
            // Do not color everything.  That will expose oneself.
            action['cell'] = get_lateral_opposite(view, 1) || get_direction(view);
        }
    } else {
        // 1. Color current cell.
        // 2. Move diagonally.
        if (colors[4] < 2) {
            // Color current cell.
            action['cell'] = 4;
            action['color'] = Math.abs(next_color - 2) + 2;
        } else {
            action['cell'] = get_diagonal_opposite(view, 0) || get_direction(view);
        }
    }
}

if (action['color'] === 0) {
    delete action['color'];
}
if (action['type'] === 0) {
    delete action['type'];
}

return action;
```

Comment: Edit 1: Spawning free-roaming workers with a small probability.

Comment: This ones does not appear to behave in a deterministic manner. That is, all alone by itself on the same seed will produce different results.  I believe this is against the rules, per no use of `Math.random()`. I don't know what it is that is doing it, but it's making it very difficult for me to test a certain behavior when this ant does not behave deterministically.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is. And just that the minor changes I've been making have resulted in a different number of *ants* which messes with things. Nevermind!

Answer (score 2):

## HalfThere

```
if(view[4].ant.type==5&&view[4].food>1)
{
    for(var i = 0; i<9; i++)
    {
        if(!view[i].ant)
        {
            return{cell:i,type: 1};
        }
    }
}
if(view[4].color != 3){
    return {cell: 4, color: 3};
}
for(var i = 0; i<9; i++)
{
    if(view[i].food==1)
    {
        return({cell:i})
    }
    
}


var i, j
var orthogonals = [1, 3, 7, 5]  // These are the non-diagonal cells



// Otherwise move to a white cell opposite a colored cell
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    j = (i+2) % 4
    if (view[orthogonals[i]].color === 1 &&
        view[orthogonals[j]].color > 1 && !view[orthogonals[i]].ant) {
        return {cell:orthogonals[i]}
    }
}

// Otherwise move to one of the vertical or horizontal cells if not occupied
for (i=1; i<9; i+=2) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move to one of the diagonal cells if not occupied
for (i=0; i<9; i+=2) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}


for(var i = 0; i<9; i++)
{
    if(view[i].color==1)
    {
        return {cell:i};
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i<9; i++)
{
    if(view[i].ant==null)
    {
        return {cell:i};
    }
}
```

This bot is half there...
Basically it just makes a line and goes in a straight line and kinda derps around if it sees another line.

## THIS IS A WORK IN PROGRESS BOT.

Comment: This can get disqualified for creating workers on food in exotic circumstances

Comment: @ppperry actually it can't. Never makes workers :/

Comment: Actually, it can't, because the "create worker' logic is just dead code. Still worth pointing out

Comment: I was confused by the dead `view[4].food > 1` check, which is a mistake I made once myself

Comment: @ppperry solution?

Comment: solution to what?

Comment: @ppperry my workers not spawning

Comment: Change `view[4].food > 1` to `view[4].ant.food > 1` on the first line

Comment: This player was disqualified during a tournament game so will be excluded until edited with a fix. The exact details follow in the next comment.

Comment: **Input:** [{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":4,"friend":false}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":4,"friend":false}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":4,"friend":false}},{"color":7,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":3,"friend":false}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":{"food":24,"type":5,"friend":true}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":4,"friend":false}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":4,"friend":false}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":4,"friend":false}},{"color":3,"food":0,"ant":{"food":1,"type":2,"friend":false}}] **Response:** undefined

Comment: In plain English, the queen became surrounded on all sides by 8 ants (a very rare occurrence, hence not being disqualified until 6 months later...). Currently the code runs through lots of possibilities but none of them match this case, so there is no return value. Some extra code at the end to say what to do if nothing else matched would fix this (even if that's just to say stay still and do nothing).

Comment: Prior to disqualification, this player was joint 9th out of 27, and would likely resume that position with the trivial fix described.

Answer (score 2):

## Straighter

```
var i, j
var orthogonals = [1, 3, 7, 5]  // These are the non-diagonal cells
// Color own cell if white
if (view[4].color != 6) {
    return {cell:4, color:6}
}
var specified = null;
// Otherwise move to a white cell opposite a colored cell
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    j = (i+2) % 4
    if (view[orthogonals[i]].color !== 6 &&
        view[orthogonals[j]].color == 6 && !view[orthogonals[i]].ant) {
        specified = {cell:orthogonals[i]};
    } else if (view[orthogonals[i]].food) {
        return {cell:orthogonals[i]}
    }
}
if(specified) { return specified; }
// Otherwise move to one of the vertical or horizontal cells if not occupied
for (i=1; i<9; i+=2) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i}
    }
}

// Otherwise move to one of the diagonal cells if not occupied
for (i=0; i<9; i+=2) {
    if (!view[i].ant) {
        return {cell:i};
    }
}

// Otherwise don't move at all
return {cell:4};
```

Since, while testing trail eraser, I noticed that it sometimes nears the top of the leaderboard when it doesn't find any trails, I'm  posting an ant using the same movement but no workers. Basicaly a repost of smart straight line from meta, except ignores other colors and doesn;t make workers (thereby avoiding disqualification)

Comment: Note that this does have some synergy with trail-eraser in that they use the same color, and trail eraser ignores green incursions, but they aren't written to collaborate together