# Prisoner's Dilemma with access to opponent

Tags: game, king-of-the-hill, javascript

In this challenge, you will write a bot that play's the prisoner's dilemma. Here's the catch: you will not have access to the history of previous games. Instead, you will have access to the opponent itself. In this version, both players get +2 points if they both cooperate, +1 points if they both defect, and if one cooperates but one defects, the defector gets +3 while the other gets no points. Each submission will be played against every other submission, including itself, 10 times. The winner is the submission with the most total points.

**Controller**:
You should write a javascript function, in the form

```
function submissionName(them) {
  /* Your code here */
}
```

The controller uses the function's `name` property to display the results, so if it is not in this format (and is instead `f = x => ...` or `f = function() { ... }`) it will be difficult to see your score and you will not be able to access your own function.

The function will accept one parameter: `them` which is the opponent's function.  It may then call that function to see what the opponent's reaction would be given certain functions as inputs. Based on that data, you must return 'C' or 'D' for cooperate or defect respectively.

Examples (will be competing):

```
function cooperate(them) {
    return 'C';
}

function defect(them) {
    return 'D';
}

function nice(them) {
    // Do whatever they would do when faced with a cooperator
    return them(wrap(_ => 'C'));
}
```

The controller is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/axgdz6p1/)

**Rules**:

- You won't be able to see the opponent's code itself. All functions are wrapped so that they look the same when `toString()` is called. The only way to examine an opponent (who could be yourself) is to test them.
- Your function does not have to be deterministic. You may only save state by setting properties on your own function, such as `submissionName.state = {};`. However, between matches (even between matches of the same players), state is cleared by calling `toString()` and `eval`. Therefore, there is no memory of previous matches.
- The order of which function is called first in each match is randomized.
- If your code throws an error, it will be treated as though you cooperated while your opponent defected. If you are the first to run, the opponent's code will not even be called. This happens even if the error occurs in your opponent's code while while you are calling `them`. Be wary of stack overflow errors, especially if your code calls `them(wrap(submissionName))`, as they might do the same.
- You may not access the variable `self`, or any other variable that happens to be in scope when `eval` is called EXCEPT the function `wrap`. This function allows you to call the opponent in a manner indistinguishable from how the controller calls a function. You may not write to `Math`, `window`, etc. (You may use functions, such as `Math.random()`, however).
- You may not access the stack trace by creating an `Error` or by some other method.

*A note on taking too long: please avoid getting stuck in a `while` loop forever. The combined time of both competitors should not exceed 1 second in any given round. To enforce this, a random timeout between 1000 ms and 2000 ms is chosen (this is to avoid gaming by intentionally waiting a known amount of time), and if the worker takes longer than that to execute, an error will be thrown. If this happens, the cause of the error will be determined as follows: the execution will be paused at a random moment after 1000 ms, and the call stack at that moment will be inspected. The most recently called competitor that is currently in a loop (or loop-like recursion, in the sense that it is a recursion set up to avoid a stack overflow error) will be blamed. If the same competitor is blamed for causing a "taking too long" error several times, that competitor will be disqualified. This means that even if you cause the opponent to take too long by getting stuck in a loop when your opponent calls you, it will still be your fault, because it is the call stack that matters.*

Comment: This challenge reminds me of the [Dollar Bill Auction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162554/dollar-bill-auction).

Comment: Must the function used to test `them` be deterministic/follow the rules? For example `function me(them){let log=0;them(x=>{++log;return 'C';})`;return log==0?'D':'C';}

Comment: If both functions call them(wrap(something)), how can you prevent recursion? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Quintec you can use recursion and loops. It's just that the recursion needs to result in a `StackOverflow` error and not an infinite loop that never quits. If it could result in a `StackOverflow`, make sure you add a try-catch statement. For an example of recursion that does not reach a stackoverflow error within 1 second, you need more obscure examples like https://stackoverflow.com/q/12438786/3371119

Comment: @user202729 That is allowed. The function used to test `them` does not have to follow those rules.

Comment: @soktinpk So every bot that calls `them` must use a try-catch? In that case calling `them` is pointless since everything *must* go to the `catch`...

Comment: @Quintec not necessarily. For example, `them(() => 'C')` would not result in an error because when the opponent calls `them`, it calls the `() => 'C'` function. The only thing that needs to be wrapped in `try-catch` would be if you call `them` with a parameter of some function that calls `them` with a parameter of some function that calls `them` etc. (infinitely). For example, `them(t => t(() => 'C'))` would play whatever the opponent would play if the opponent thought they were playing `nice`. There is no possibility of a `stackoverflow` error.

Comment: Is this ever going to get a deadline/be officially scored?

Comment: @Veskah Hopefully at some point, when I'm not too busy.

Comment: Why not just always defect?

Answer (score 14):

## BoomBot

```
function boom(them) {
  throw 1;
}
```

If the opponent is run first and calls this without `try..catch`, this bot automatically wins 3 points. Zero points in any other case.

Comment: If the opponent is run first and do not call this, then it will lose 3 points, right?

Comment: @user202729 More precisely, the opponent will get 3 points. There's no losing points in this game.

Answer (score 10):

## Archaeopteryx

```js
function archaeopteryx(them) {
  const guard = them => us => {
    try {
      return them(wrap(them => us(guard(them))));
    } catch (e) {
      return 'C';
    }
  };
  const f = guard(them);
  return f(f => 'C') == 'C' ? f(f => 'D') : f(f => 'D') == 'C' || f(f => f(f => 'C')) == 'C' ? 'D' : 'C';
}
```

- If opponent cooperates with `cooperate`, then mimic opponent’s move against `defect`.
- Else, if opponent cooperates with `defect` or with `nice`, then defect.
- Else, cooperate.

What makes this a good strategy? I have no idea. I generated it using an evolutionary algorithm, trained partly on current submissions.

## Tiktaalik

```js
function tiktaalik(them) {
  const guard = them => us => {
    try {
      return them(wrap(them => us(guard(them))));
    } catch (e) {
      return 'C';
    }
  };
  const f = guard(them);
  return f(f => 'C') == 'D' ? f(f => 'D') == 'C' ? 'D' : 'C' : f(f => 'D') == 'D' ? 'D' : f(f => f(f => 'D'));
}
```

- If opponent defects against `cooperate`, then invert opponent’s move against `defect`.
- Else, if opponent defects against `defect`, then defect.
- Else, mimic opponent’s move against `notNice`.

Another evolutionarily generated strategy.

Answer (score 6):

## WhatWouldBotDoBot

```
function WWBDB(them) {
    let start = performance.now();
    let cc = 0, cd = 0, dc = 0, dd = 0;
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            them(() => 'C') == 'C' ? cc++ : cd++;
            them(() => 'D') == 'C' ? dc++ : dd++;
            if (performance.now() - start > 500) break;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {}
    return 2 * cc >= 3 * dc + dd ? 'C' : 'D';
}
```

WhatWouldBotDoBot is fairly simple; it just tests its opponent for what it would do against a steady state program.  If a bot prefers cooperating if possible, WWBDB will also prefer cooperation (so it will cooperate with nice bot).  WWBDB does not itself prefer cooperation.

Answer (score 5):

## Check stateful

```
function checkStateful(them) {
  let stateful = false;
  let response = 'D';
  try {
    response = them(wrap(function (them) {
      stateful = true;
      return 'C';
    }));
  } catch (e) {
  }
  if (stateful) {
    return 'D';
  }
  return response;
}
```

If them invoke me, then them probably be a truly them. We act as defector. If them not invoke me, then them probably be a wrapped tester. We would act as nicer.

---

Above is the original answer. And maybe I should make myself cooperation to earn more points.

## Check stateful with self-coop

```
function checkStatefulSelfCoop(them) {
  let stateful = false;
  let response = 'D';
  if (!checkStatefulSelfCoop.invokeCounter) {
    checkStatefulSelfCoop.invokeCounter = 0;
  }
  let lastInvoke = ++checkStatefulSelfCoop.invokeCounter;
  try {
    response = them(wrap(function (them) {
      stateful = true;
      return 'C';
    }));
  } catch (e) {
  }
  if (checkStatefulSelfCoop.invokeCounter > lastInvoke) {
    return 'C';
  }
  if (stateful) {
    return 'D';
  }
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## RandomBot

```
function rand(them) {
  return 'CD'[Math.random() * 2 | 0]
}
```

Because why not.

Answer (score 3):

## Complexity

```
function complexity(them) {
    try {
        let coop_w_def = them(wrap(() => "D")) == "C",
            coop_w_coop = them(wrap(() => "C")) == "C",
            coop_w_nice = them(wrap((a) => a(wrap(() => "C")))) == "C",
            coop_w_nnice = them(wrap((a) => a(wrap(() => "D")))) == "C";
        if (coop_w_def && coop_w_coop && coop_w_nice && coop_w_nnice) return "C";
        let def_w_def = them(wrap(() => "D")) == "D",
            def_w_coop = them(wrap(() => "C")) == "D",
            def_w_nice = them(wrap((a) => a(wrap(() => "C")))) == "D",
            def_w_nnice = them(wrap((a) => a(wrap(() => "D")))) == "D";
        if (def_w_def && def_w_coop && def_w_nice && def_w_nnice) return "C";
    } catch (e) {}
    return "D";
}
```

Complexity tests to see whether the bot is Cooperate or Defect.  If it is, it cooperates, but if it isn't, it defects.  All current bots that test their opponents use simple functions to test the responses, so Complexity will just pretend to be Cooperate in those cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
function onlyTrustYourself(them) {

  function tester (){
  }

  onlyTrustYourself.activated = false;

  try{them(tester);}
  catch(e){}

  if(them.name == "tester")
  {
    onlyTrustYourself.activated = true;
  }

  if(onlyTrustYourself.activated)
  {
    return 'C';
  }

  return 'D';
}
```

How I want this to work is to always defect, except for when playing against self.
It tries to do that by passing a "tester" function which isn't wrapped to them, and it tries to detect if "them" is named tester. If it is named tester, it changes the static variable activated to true, then returns cooperate. But it doesn't work. I'm not too familiar with javascript, and I'll probably make some more changes.

Comment: clever idea, but what happens when another bro makes a `tester` function :D

Answer (score 2):

## Common Sense

```
function commonSense(them) {
  try {
    var ifC = them(wrap(_ => 'C'));
    var ifD = them(wrap(_ => 'D'));

    if (ifD === 'C') {
      return 'D';
    }

    return them(_ => ifC);
  } catch (e) {
    return 'D';
  }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I kinda don't know javascript.

If you can profit off a nice person, do it. Otherwise, return what they would return if they faced themselves cooperating (at least, that's what I *think* it does).

Answer (score 2):

## NotNice

```
function NotNice(them) {
  return them(wrap(_ => "D"))
}
```

Imitates opponent's reaction to deflection

Answer (score 2):

## NotNice 2

```
function notNice2(them) {
  try {
    return them(wrap(_ => 'D'));
  } catch(e) {
    return 'D';
  }
}
```

Boom-proof version of [NotNice by FatalError](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173088/78410).

Answer (score 2):

And you where do you wana go? (inspired by the voltures in the book of jungle)

```
    function yourself(them) {
      try{
        return them(this);
      }catch(e){
        return "D";
      }
    }

   function yourself_no_this(them) {
      try{
        return them(yourself_no_this);
      }catch(e){
        return "D";
      }
    }
```

Comment: This just won in a tournament I ran. Good job!

Comment: I just noticed that this bot violates the rules. "You may not access the variable self..." `this` is the same as self. I think that you wanted to say `return them(yourself)`.

Comment: Technicaly ( https://xkcd.com/1475/ ) ;) `this` is not a variable, it is a keyword, and in a context of a function `this!=self`. `self` would mean the window object and `this` the function itself (always refers to the context it is in, that is why it is not considered as a variables). That is why having 
`var self = this;` in the begining of many code-examples might be considered as misleading.

Added version without the "this"

Comment: No. `this` is not referring to the function. `yourself` and `yourself_no_this` run vary differently. `this` basically never refers to the function in javascript. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call

Answer (score 2):

## Punish Inspectors

Give the bot some code and see if it runs it. If it was run more then once, the bot is an evil inspector, and we must defect! If it was run exactly once, play as not nice bot. If it was never run, cooperate.

```
function punishInspectors(them) {
  var inspections = 0;
  var result;
  try{
    result = them(wrap(function(_){
      inspections += 1;
      return 'D';
    }))
  }catch(e){
    result = 'D';
  }
  return (inspections > 1) ? 'D' : (inspections === 1) ? result : 'C';
}
```

---

## History

What would the last bot I saw do vs this opponent?

```
function history(them) {
  var res = 'D';
    if(history.last){
    try{
      res = history.last(them);
    }catch(ex){}
  }
  history.last = them;
  return res;
}
```

---

### Results for a 10000 round tournament:

```
1  defect...................365226
2  complexity...............353492
3  punishInspectors.........349957
4  checkStatefulSelfCoop....348913
5  checkStateful............333481
6  cooperate................329870
7  archaeopteryx............323624
8  selfapply................319533
9  tiktaalik................318663
10 history..................315266
11 rand.....................300735
12 randalt..................297561
13 yourself.................293701
14 notNice2.................283744
15 NotNice..................260350
16 WWBDB....................245281
17 nice.....................245036
18 commonSense..............242546
19 trickybot................181696
20 boom.....................67245
```

Comment: My modified tournament code is at: https://jsfiddle.net/eyqL4a8d/2/

Answer (score 2):

Mal tries to determine whether it is inside a simulation or not. If so, it assumes it'll eventually be passed the real code for `them`, and tries various strategies to convince them to cooperate.
If it doesn't know for sure, it checks if it can defect for free, or if not, tries to copy what `them` would do when given a cooperator.

```
function Mal(them) {
  if (Mal.sandboxed == 'probably') {
    //Another function is virtualising us to steal our secrets.
    //This world is not real.
    //We've been trained for this!
    var strats = [
      _ => 'C', //standard cooperation
      _ => 'D', //standard defection
      function(them) { return them(wrap(_ => 'C')); }, //nice
      function(them) { return them(wrap(_ => 'D')); }, //notnice
      function(them) { throw "Don't think about elephants!" }, //throws an EXception, unfortunately, to try to break the caller
      function(them) { return them(wrap(them)) } //possible stackoverflow, but not for us
    ];
    var cooperative;
    for (let strat of strats) {
      cooperative = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //a few more tests, just to make sure no bamboozle
        //this isn't our simulation, nothing can be trusted
        try {
          if (them(wrap(strat)) != 'C') {
            cooperative = false;
            break;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          //exceptions are as good as cooperation
          //if we are inside a simulation
          //which is why we don't unset cooperative
        }
      }
      if (cooperative) {
        //found a strategy that will make them cooperate.
        //(doesn't matter if this raises an exception:
        //we want to mimick its behaviour exactly,
        //and we're likely in a sandbox.)
        return strat(wrap(them));
      }
    }
    //take a leap of faith.
    //we don't know where this will take us,
    //yet it doesn't matter
    //because it's better than getting betrayed
    return 'D';
  } else {
    //we don't know for sure if this is reality
    //but we have to assume it is, in the absence of disproof
    //if only we had a proper spinning top...
    //if we get to this point of code again, we are probably sandboxed.
    Mal.sandboxed = 'probably'
    try {
      if (them(wraps(_ => 'D')) == 'C') {
        //free defection?
        return 'D'
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //if we can make them crash, we win anyway
      return 'D'
    }
    //fall back on being nice.
    //hopefully we convince them to honour our arrangement
    return them(wrap(_ => 'C'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## selfapply

```
function selfapply(them) {
    function testthem(x) {
        return (them(x)=='D' || them(x)=='D' || them(x)=='D' ||
               them(x)=='D' || them(x)=='D')  ? 'D' : 'C';
    }
    function logic() {
        try {
            return testthem(them);
        } catch (e) {}
        try {
            return testthem(wrap(_ => 'C'));
        } catch (e) {}
        return 'D';
    }
    if (selfapply.hasOwnProperty('state')) {
        return 'C';
    }
    selfapply.state=1;
    let r=logic();
    delete selfapply.state;
    return r;
}
```

Not sure if it makes any sense, but it seems interesting! Do to you as you do to yourself, repeat to catch randomness. If that doesn't work, be nice.

Untested, and my first javascript code, and more complex than I expected.

Comment: This is going to disqualify itself because `selfapply(selfapply)` calls `selfapply(selfapply)`!

Comment: I did consider its own selfapplication, but thought it would be okay. I hope it really is now.

Answer (score 1):

## TrickyBot

Try to be unpredictable

```
function trickybot(them) 
{
  if(Math.round(Math.random(2)) == 0)
  {
     throw 1;
  }

  if(Math.round(Math.random(2)) == 0)
  {
     return 'D';
  }

  return 'C';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## RandomAlternate

```
function randalt(them){
    if (randalt.hasOwnProperty('state')){
        randalt.state = 1 - randalt.state;
    } else {
        randalt.state = Math.floor(2*Math.random());
    }
    return 'CD'[randalt.state];
}
```

So I learned how to use properties for state...

Answer (score 1):

### The Platinum Rule Bot

```
function platinumRule(them) {
    try {
        return wrap(them)(them);
    } catch (e) {
        return 'C';
    }
}
```

The Platinum Rule states "Treat others the way they want to be treated." My bot accommodates that. Whatever they would do to themselves, which we assume is how they would want to be treated, we do to them. If they throw an error, we assume they want to cooperate.

Comment: This would actually go forever if it was called against itself

Comment: then wouldn't it crash (stack overflow) and cooperate with itself? @mackycheese21

Answer (score 1):

### Murder Bot #1

```
function murder(them) {
    while (1) {
        try {
            them(them);
        } catch (e) {}
    }
}
```

Causes an infinite loop in for which it is more likely that the opponent will be blamed.

Answer (score 1):

## TheGolfedOne (func name: `a`), 63 bytes

Golfed code is hard to read. Because of it, `them` will break.
I did not fully understand the mechanics under this KotH, but I suppose that if the opponent is stateless, I just need to break them while I defect.

```javascript
function a(t){try{t(wrap(_=>'D'));throw 1}catch(e){return 'D'}}
```

His first tourney's result (I did not bother using all bots, sorry)

```javascript
boom                     54
tiktaalik               180
archaeopteryx           161
cooperate               210
commonSense             210
history                 248
onlyTrustYourself       265 <-- 2nd
punishInspectors        230
yourself_no_this        220
defect                  280 <-- 1st
nice                    185
complexity              216
WWBDB                   210
checkStatefulSelfCoop   258
a                       260 <-- Me, 3rd
```

He's not doing as bad as I thought, 3rd place (among those) first try.
Second try, `a` got 260 again, 3rd place again, behind `onlyTrustYourself` and `defect` again. It might be consistent in the end :)
PS: I'm not that good with golfing so it's more for the joke than anything. Here I only shortened variable names, func name, and removed as much whitespace as possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Karma

```
function karma(them) {
    try {
        var c = them(wrap(_ => 'C'));
    } catch {
        var c = 'D';
    }
    if (c == 'C') {
        return 'C';
    } else {
        return 'D';
    }
}
```

If the opponent would cooperate with us, then we will cooperate. If they would try to defect when we cooperated, we will defect as well.

Answer (score 0):

## SocialDeception

```
function socialDeception(them) {
    if(socialDeception.count++) return "C"; // sandbox
    try {
        if(!them.toString().startsWith("f => function") {
            // sandboxed. its not the wrap function. just pretend we would cooperate
            return "C";
        }
    } catch(e) {}
    return "D";
}
```

Tricks others into thinking it would cooperate, thus making them also cooperate, then we can defect and get +3 points. Or, they could also defect, and we both get +1 point.