# Rock Paper Scissors Meta-Gaming Tournament

Tags: king-of-the-hill

This is a rock paper scissors competition. Algorithms will face each other in 100 rounds of rock paper scissors. Except that the algorithms will also be able to read the source code of each other!

## Leaderboard

```
1. Chaos Bot (by Aiden4) - 27 Points, 168 bytes
2. Anti-99%-of-posts (by Lyxal) - 24 Points, 489 bytes
3. Psuedo-Hash Cycle (by qwatry) - 23 Points, 143 bytes
4. Destroyer of Bots (by Baby_Boy) - 23 Points, 433 bytes
5. If-If (by PkmnQ) - 21 Points, 63 bytes
6. Biased-Cycler (by HighlyRadioactive) - 20 Points, 17 bytes
7. RadiationBot v0.1 (by HighlyRadioactive) - 18 Points, 121 bytes
8. Cycler (by petStorm) - 17 Points, 17 bytes
9. Craker (by petStorm) - 17 Points, 58 bytes
10. Lookup (by petStorm) - 17 Points, 61 bytes
11. Custom (by petStorm) - 16 Points, 56 bytes
12. Anti-Cycler (by Lyxal) - 14 Points, 17 bytes
13. Mr. Paper - 13 Points, 58 bytes
14. PseudoRandom (by HighlyRadioactive) - 13 Points, 89 bytes
15. Itna-Cycler (by petStorm) - 11 Points, 17 bytes
16. Lycler (by petStorm) - 11 Points, 24 bytes
17. Mr. Rock - 11 Points, 57 bytes
18. Mr. Scissors - 10 Points, 61 bytes
```

Submissions are graded automatically via an online judge

[View Online Judge](https://react-ts-4ri9hm.stackblitz.io/#)

## The Competition

Your code will be a javascript anonymous function (sorry, other languages aren't supported!) that takes in two arguments:

- The source code of your opponent AI (as a string)
- The current round number

It should then return one of "R", "P", or "S", indicating that it will throw a rock, paper, or scissors for that round.

Your code must follow these rules, otherwise it will be disqualified:

- **Your code may not be longer than 500 bytes**
- **Your function must be pure**

  - That is, if your function is given the same set of arguments, your code must always return the same result
  - This is to ensure that the tournament results are consistent
- **eval() calls are banned!**

  - If this were allowed, two submissions with eval() would end up calling each other in an endless loop which would never terminate.
  - (See the discussion in the comments for more details/reasoning)
- Your code may not:

  - Access external resources (e.g. make web fetch/get requests)
  - Attempt to modify or tamper with the judge system code
  - Cause excessive lag or time delay
  - Modify any globals or object prototypes
  - Attempt to do an XSS attack or any other sketchy/illegal stuff

### Example submission

```js
(code, round) => {
  if (round === 1) {
    // Throw rock if it's the first round
    return "R";
  }
  else if (code.includes('"R"')) {
    // Throw paper if the opponent code includes "R"
    return "P";
  } else {
    // Otherwise throw scissors
    return "S";
  }
}
```

## Tournament structure

Each submission will play 100 rounds of rock paper scissors with each other submission.

To get the ball rolling, the following three functions will be submitted by default:

```js
(code, round) => {
  // Always throw rock
  return "R";
}
```

```js
(code, round) => {
  // Always throw paper
  return "P";
}
```

```js
(code, round) => {
  // Always throw scissors
  return "S";
}
```

## Scoring

A submission gains 2 points for winning against another submission, and 1 point for tying against another submission (no points are awarded for losses).

Leaderboard positions are ordered by most points first. If two submissions have the same number of points, they will be ranked in order of least bytes. If two submissions have the same number of points and bytes, the older submission will be ranked higher.

## Judging & Testing

Post your submissions here, I will periodically add submissions to the [online judge](https://react-ts-4ri9hm.stackblitz.io/#) which will automatically rank each algorithm.

You can also test your algorithms using the [online judge](https://react-ts-4ri9hm.stackblitz.io/#) testing area. A testing area is provided at the bottom to test different algorithms against each other.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35079/31625).

Comment: why does it have to be js? to make sure any submission can interact with any other?

Comment: Did you intend the last default function to be for scissors?

Comment: @xnor yes, thanks for noticing, has been fixed

Comment: @golf69 It's JS only so that submissions can be scored automatically online

Comment: Related: [Prisoner's Dilemma with access to opponent](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173065/20260)

Comment: Since it seems natural for submissions to try to simulate each other, it will be easy for infinite loops to be created. How would this resolve? Perhaps each submissions could be  run for a fixed amount of time, and any that does output without that time forfeits the round.

Comment: @xnor functions are fed a string source-code of the opponents function, not the actual function. But yea you're right if they do try to eval each other, there's currently no method in place from going indefinitely

Comment: @MrSiliconGuy I don't know JS, but does anything then stop a submissions from attempting to execute the opponent's source code string and so simulate their opponent? An when you say, "Your code may not: Cause excessive lag or time delay", if someone writes code that intentionally takes very long if someone tries to simulate it but runs quickly by itself, would they be breaking this rule, or would the code trying to simulate it be breaking it?

Comment: The problem is, if there is only one solution that simulates others, then no loops will be created. Therefore, the first person to do that gets a large advantage.

Comment: My original intention was for the code to analyze the other code as a string, without evaluating it. It's pretty difficult to ensure that a function terminates, given that code can eval each other.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure programs can glean anything really interesting just from analyzing the strings of the other competitors without simulating, especially since code can be written to be obfuscated. But if that's your intention, might it work to ban any calls to eval-style interpreter functions? I guess someone can write a small bit of an interpreter, but this can only get so far in 500 bytes.

Comment: Yea, I might do that then. You're right tho it is probably less interesting

Comment: I remember this silicon guy from the Super Mario Problem! Hi!~~

Comment: @petStorm hi sorry, I'm camping over these few days. Will update the leaderboard as soon as I can get home

Comment: @petStorm sorry for the wait! Leaderboard is finally updated

Comment: Can we please disallow submission updates? The lookup is always gonna win cuz it can be edited.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive yea I don't update submissions after their posted. Any edits to submissions are ignored. If anyone wants to update their submission, they must post a new one instead

Answer (score 5):

## Chaos Bot

I lost track of what's going on here, but it seems to win or tie everything but the standard cycler.

```
(c,r) => {if(c.includes("else")){return "SSR"[r%3];}if(c.includes("/")){if(c.includes("P")){return "S";//17
} return "SRP"[r%3];} else{return "PPS"[(c.length + r)%3];}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE! Congrats your bot is currently winning

Answer (score 4):

## Anti-99%-of-posts

```
(code,r)=>{var S="S";var R="R";var P="P";var x=S+R+P;var y=R+P+S;var z=P+S+R
if(code.includes("17")){return "P";}
else if(code.includes("[r%2]")){return"RR"[r%2]}
else if(code.includes("[r%3]")){
if (code.includes(x)){return (R+P+S)[r%3];}
else if(code.includes(y)){return (P+S+R)[r%3];}
else if(code.includes(z)){return (S+R+P)[r%3];}
}else{if(code.includes("scissors")){return "R"}else if (code.includes("rock")){return "P"}else if (code.includes("paper") ){return "S"}else{return "P"}}}
```

Haha. Testing it on submissions gives either a win or a tie.

Comment: I have witnessed pure evil

Comment: You should rename this to "Rookup"

Comment: Indeed, this answer currently wins the game. However, are you sure that you can handle the new answers with the remaining 11 bytes !?

Answer (score 4):

## If-If

```
(c,r)=>{if(c.includes("i")){return"RPS"[2]}else{return"P"}; 17}
```

This was built off of an algorithm that detected if "if" was in the code.

Answer (score 3):

### Cycler

Picks depending on the round number.

```
(c,r)=>"RPS"[r%3]
```

Comment: Isn't this trivially beaten by `++r%3`?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, but every simple strategy is trivially beaten by the same strategy, but rotated, so it's not unique in that way.

Answer (score 3):

### Custom

A bot designed to beat the default bots. I'm a horrible golfer indeed...

Edit: I'm now also trying to get around RadiationBot, by changing the algorithm.

```
(c,r)=>["P","S","R"][-~[["P","S","R"].findIndex(i=>!c.indexOf(i))%3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Anti-Cycler

```
(c,r)=>"PSR"[r%3]
```

Someone had to do it. Why not me? ;P

Answer (score 2):

## RadiationBot v0.1

HighlyRadioactive's botty bot.

```
(c,r)=>{if(c.indexOf("RP")>=0){return "PSR"[r%3];}else if(c.indexOf("PS")>=0){return "SRP"[r%3];}else{return "RP"[r%2];}}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Lookup

The lookup table here explains everything.

```
(c,r)=>({17:["R","P","S"][(r-(~-c.slice(8).indexOf(`S`)||(r-3+r%2))+3)%3],24:"S",56:"S",58:"S",63:["P","S","R"][2],69:"S",81:"P",121:"PS"[r%2],168:"SSR"[(c.length+r)%3],489:"S"})[c.length]||"R"
```

Comment: This submission can't be accepted, because the function doesn't always return "R", "P", or "S". You should add a case for if the length of the code isn't in the lookup table.

Comment: @MrSiliconGuy Fixed.

Comment: Alright looks good

Comment: And change the name, you are not HighlyRadioactive & lookup table's not the spirit of RadiationBot...

Answer (score 2):

### Lycler

Like Cycler, but this time with length.

```
(c,r)=>"RPS"[c.length%3]
```

Comment: I like the idea of using the code of others to decide the result, but the length can be easily countered. I think some sort of hashing of the code should take place in order to make it much harder to adjust the code as each change also changes the hash

Comment: @RFSnake [Added](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209459/96495)

Answer (score 2):

## Destroyer of Bots

```
//"P" else
(c,r) => {if(c.includes("SSR")){return "R";}else if(c.includes("PRPSRS")){return "S"}else if(c.includes("RRP")){return "F";return"S"}else if(c.includes("paper")){return"S"}else if(c.includes("rock")){return"P"}else if(c.includes(".findIndex")){return"F";return "PSR"[c.length%3]}else if(c.includes("SRP")){return "RPS"[r%3]}else if(c.includes("RPS")){return"F";return "PSR"[r%3]}else if(c.includes("RP")){return"S"}else{return "R";}}
```

This bot uses confusion tactics and targeted attacks to win or tie against all current bots.

note: Wins against Chaos Bot, current #1 bot.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange! You probably wanted to put a newline between `//"P" else` and the rest of the bot, because right now your entire bot is just a line comment and gives a syntax error when I try to run it.

Comment: .....  when iwas minimizing my code, such a dumb mistake....

Comment: @Aiden4 is it working for you now?

Comment: It runs just fine.

Comment: nice, now you can witness your destruction :)

Comment: Leaderboard updated, you are currently in 4th place!

Comment: well not too bad...

Answer (score 1):

## PseudoRandom

```
(c,r)=>{a=0;for(i=0;i<c.length;i++){a+=c[i].charCodeAt()^r^i;}return "RPS"[a%3];}
```

Not too random I guess but I tried.

Comment: I had to modify your solution a little, to include `let a=0` and `let i=0` because it wasn't working for some reason without it. Probably because the judge is running with "use strict"; mode. Sorry for the lost bytes!

Answer (score 1):

### Itna-Cycler

Let's raise the maximum score of the cycler family to 8!

```
(c,r)=>"SRP"[r%3]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Craker

Inspired by Custom. (Hopefully) does something different.

```
(c,r)=>"RPS"[-~[..."RPS"].findIndex(i=>c.indexOf(i)>-1)%3]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Biased-Cycler

```
(c,r)=>"RRP"[r%3]
```

Yay.

Answer (score 1):

### #</>

Let's add an awful hash answer.

```
(c,r)=>"SPR"[c.split``.reduce((t,i)=>(t<<5)+i.charCodeAt(0),5381)%3]
```

Comment: This should replace PseudoRandom. EDIT: Oh wait, round number is not involved.

Answer (score 1):

## Psuedo-Hash Cycle

```
(c, r) => {var hash = 0;for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){var char = c.charCodeAt(i);hash = hash + char;}return "PRPSRS"[(c.length+hash+r)%6]}
```

This function is intended to return nearly-random values that will be difficult to predict.

Comment: Leaderboard has been updated