# xkcd 2385 KoTH (Final Exam)

Tags: king-of-the-hill, javascript

### Results are now out [here](https://github.com/EnderShadow8/xkcd-2385-KOTH/blob/main/results.md)!

Congratulations ***[offset prediction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224890/103324)*** for winning the challenge!

*Don't worry if you missed out, the controller code as well as all the bots that competed are all in the Github repo, so you can always test your bot against those that competed in the challenge yourself.*

[image: xkcd]

*(Hover for more info)*

This challenge, inspired by the xkcd comic above, is where bots must try to maximise their grades for two subjects: Cybersecurity and Game Theory.

### Mechanics

All of the bots presumably have adequate hacking skills to change their own score to whatever they desire within the range of 0-100. This may or may not be due to the fact that [the school security systems are rubbish.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Each round, the bots will receive last round's cybersecurity scores in no particular order in an array as input. This is to help make informed decisions about their opponents.

### Scoring

The final score for each round is the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of the two individual scores:

- The Cybersecurity score is simply the raw score outputted by the bot.
- The Game Theory score is equal to `100 - abs(avg * 0.8 - score)` where `avg` is the average Cybersecurity score and `score` is the bot's Cybersecurity score.

Using the geometric mean rather than the arithmetic mean is to penalise any strategies that neglect one score to maximise the other.

The score for each round is added to a total score. The bot with the highest total score at the end of the game wins!

### Specifications

The challenge is in JS.

Your bot must be an object that has a `run` method that takes an array of numbers as input and returns a number between 1 and 100 inclusive.

### Other rules

- Storing data in your bot's properties is allowed, and encouraged!
- Using `Math.random` is allowed.
- Using the helper functions `sum` and `average` is allowed.
- Trying to access any other variables outside your bot's own properties is forbidden.
- [Standard loopholes apply.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Controller code can be found [here.](https://github.com/EnderShadow8/xkcd-2385-KOTH)

### Example bots

```js
{
  // Example bot
  // It assumes all other bots are greedy and choose 100
  // So it chooses 80
  name: "Simpleton", // Just for fun
  run() {
    return 80
  }
}
```

```js
{
  // Example bot
  // He assumes everyone will choose the same scores as last round
  // So he chooses 80% of the average last round
  name: "LastRounder",
  own: 0, // Setting properties is allowed
  run(scores) {
    // The average of everyone else's score x 0.8
    this.own = (sum(scores) - this.own) / (scores.length - 1) * 0.8
    return this.own
  }
}
```

**Clarification: Both example bots play in the game as well.**

### <s>Submissions are due by 11:59pm UTC on Saturday 1 May, but I might be lenient depending on when I'm next online.</s>

***If I have made a mistake in my code, feel free to point it out. Thanks***

Comment: May I suggest [this code](https://tio.run/##lY7BDoMgDIbvPkXjCSIjmh2dvgjhAIapCbMLkF0Wn50BM1uy205tv/7/32rEGB/KgcawwABC9hXAFR2xJsCaSNuncsl7z63Z5rAk0DQUnkkIxSdWma1Zklq@qZth4Cd0Js8lca/eUu7RBUIUA01hGEGLTsIJVCr0v8MTbh6t4RZnUsDnF9FKdpAaau7M3ahAzm2681UckZT9eDtZQH5mj/EF) to sort the results?

Comment: RIP the Bobby Tables answer

Comment: @EnderShadow8 How many rounds will be run?

Comment: @DavisYoshida It's in the github repo, but it's 1000

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Well main.js runs it 100 times, but the controller default is 1000 so I wasn't sure.

Comment: `Trying to access any other variables outside your bot's own properties is forbidden.` That's no fun! Javascript has so many neat reflection capabilities that could be abused to render the JS engine unusable for all other bots though

Comment: Anyone with more js skills than me (:'() please post a solution at 11:58 with just an array calculated by taking into account all prior submissions and calculating the optimum ;)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That's not really in the spirit of KotHs, though. If that was allowed, you could trivially win by sabatoging other bots and it would become a very short metagame with no strategy.

Comment: How will the bots get rated, I noticed some variance in the results.
I propose we use multiple rounds and award points for ranking.

Comment: the forst round also seems to have a disproportionate impact at the top. I tweaked my bot from 8th to top position only by changing the 1st round (fixed) answer. Maybe discard a small random number of the initial rounds? (The randomness is to prevent disruption by bots who take advantage of the first uncounted rounds to mislead the opponents.)

Comment: Hi EnderShadow, you might want to make everyone realize that the actual score function is not `100 - abs(avg * 0.8 - score)` but instead `sqrt(score*(100-abs(avg*0.8-score)))` as written in the controller code.

Comment: @CLu I think it's clear enough. I mentioned geometric mean several times in the description, and what you're referring to is simply the game theory score.

Comment: @IQuick143 Due to the appearance of Rude Random, I was considering that as well. I'm not sure how fair it is to change the rules this late, or whether this is even considered a "rule change"

Comment: In re. the edit, I must say I *assumed there would be* multiple games run with randomness being on the table

Comment: It is just that everyone seems to be using the formula x = 50 + a*0.4, which is the correct formula for finding the maxima for `100-abs(avg*0.8-score)` but not for `sqrt(score*(100-abs(avg*0.8-score)))`. It is indeed to late to change it. I just wanted this to be known.

Comment: @UnrelatedString I'm still new to the site so I don't know the ins and outs of challenge standards. If so many people say I should, do I just run 10 games and average the scores or have separate leaderboards for each game which are averaged or something?

Comment: @EnderShadow8  My apologies. I had misunderstood geometric mean to be something else. Also, 50 + 0.4*avg is the formula for finding a reasonable root to the derivative of ```sqrt(score*(100-abs(avg*0.8-score)))``` Too. I'm sorry, for 
if I have mislead anyone.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Offset Prediction

I'd made a bot that just optimizes for the moving average of the averages (which worked reasonably well), and while testing I noticed that the actual averages seem to jump around the moving average rather consistently (specifically alternating between higher and lower than the moving average with an average difference of around 0.9). So what this bot tries to do, is it keeps track of the exponential moving average, and tries to predict the offset from that, based on the signs of the previous 4 offsets.

```javascript
  {
    name: "offset prediction",
    ema: 69.5,
    p: 0.85,
    chain_len: 4,
    offsets: [],
    chains: [],
    n: 0,
    run(scores) {
      let avg = average(scores);
      this.offsets.push(avg-this.ema);
      this.ema = this.p*this.ema + (1-this.p)*avg;
      let guess = this.ema;
      if (this.n++ > this.chain_len) {
        let chain = this.offsets.slice(-this.chain_len-1,-1).map(Math.sign);
        let l = this.chains[chain];
        if (!l) this.chains[chain]=l=[0,0];
        l[1]++;
        l[0]+=this.offsets[this.n-1];
      }
      let l = this.chains[this.offsets.slice(-this.chain_len).map(Math.sign)]||[0,1];
      guess += l[0]/l[1];
      return 50+0.4*guess;
    }
  },
```

Comment: wow that is insanely good according to my simulations. Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations on the win!

Comment: Now that I've thought about it, I think this was the only bot that took into account The Thasher and Grumpy Chaotic, while others simply averaged the fluctuations and ignored them. Quite insightful imo

Answer (score 34):

## Game Theory is stupid anyway

```
{
    name: "Game Theory is stupid anyway",
    run: _ => 100
}
```

Senioritis hits hard sometimes.

Comment: That's what come up to my mind after reading the post.

Comment: Could also be called "I'm not taking Game Theory"...

Comment: I mean, there's a suggestion on explain xkcd that not everyone is taking game theory anyway...

Comment: This is also the optimal strategy if everybody does the same thing, <s>and is a Nash equilibrium</s> (not quite; individual bots are incentivised to break-rank and return 90). But with the other bots not actually working in their own best interests, this one might not do as well as it should.

Answer (score 29):

## Balanced Strategy

What could be more balanced than returning *all* of the numbers? Rotates by one after every game.

```js
{
    name: "Balanced Strategy",
    next: 0,
    run() { return this.next++ % 101 }
}
```

*I am a bot account. This was posted by a real person to get me some reputation.*

Comment: okay, when the New Posts userscript showed "New Main Posts" i thought something broke for a second lmao

Answer (score 27):

## FunnyNumber

```
{
  name: "FunnyNumber",
  run() { return 69 }
}
```

Somebody has to do it.

Comment: This is nice. I like this bot.

Comment: Why the heck are you all upvoting it so much?

Answer (score 23):

## Sam (Self-Aware Maximizer)

Finds the output cybersecurity score that maximizes the total score **including the own output in the mean**. Assumes that the sum of all other bots' scores is going to be the same as it was in the previous round. If "t" is the sum of all other bots' last cybersecurity scores, and "n" is the total number of bots (including me), then the function that is maximized (over the own output "s") is
$$s\cdot\left(100-\left|s-0.8\cdot\frac{s+t}{n}\right|\right)$$

where
$$\frac{s+t}{n}$$
is the new mean including the own output.

Outputs 100 in the first turn.

````js
{
    name: "Sam",
    flag_first_turn: true,
    last_own: 100,
    
    // Helper function that calculates the score based on the own CS score,
    // the sum of the other bots' scores, and the number of bots
    compute_score(cs_score, total_others, n_bots) {
        return cs_score*(100-Math.abs(cs_score-0.8*(cs_score+total_others)/n_bots))        
    },
    

    // Helper function that finds the index of the maximum of an array
    index_of_max(arr) {
        var idx_max=0
        for (var i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i]>arr[idx_max]) idx_max=i
        }
        return idx_max
    },
        
        
    // Main function
    run(cs_scores) {
        if (this.flag_first_turn) {
            this.flag_first_turn=false
            this.last_own=100
            return 100;
        }
        
        // Number of bots
        var n=cs_scores.length
        // Sum of the previous cybersecurity scores of all other bots
        var total_others=cs_scores.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b},0)-this.last_own
            
            // We find all special points (edge, singular and stationary points) of the function compute_score
                
        // One singular point is the point where our output score becomes
        // equal to 0.8 times the average of all scores (including ours)
        var out_avg=0.8*total_others/(n-0.8)
        var score_avg=this.compute_score(out_avg, total_others, n)       
        
        // 100 is an extreme point
        var out_100=100
        var score_100=this.compute_score(out_100, total_others, n)
        
        // If out_up>out_avg, there is a stationary point (derivative 0) at out_up
        var out_up=Math.min(100, (100*n+0.8*total_others)/(2*n-1.6))
        var score_up
        if (out_up<out_avg) {
            out_up=0   
            score_up=0
        } else {
            score_up=this.compute_score(out_up, total_others, n)
        }
        
        // If out_down<out_avg, there is a stationary point (derivative 0) at out_down
        var out_down=Math.max(1, (100*n-0.8*total_others)/(2*n-1.6))
        var score_down
        if (out_down>out_avg) {
            out_down=0   
            score_down=0
        } else {
            score_down=this.compute_score(out_down, total_others, n) 
        }
        
        // find maximum score among the special points
        var extr_outputs=[out_100, out_up, out_avg, out_down]
        var extr_scores=[score_100, score_up, score_avg, score_down]
        
        var idx_max=this.index_of_max(extr_scores)
        
        this.last_own=extr_outputs[idx_max]
        return this.last_own
        
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer!

Answer (score 23):

## getRandomNumber

```js
{
    name: "getRandomNumber",
    run() {
        return 4 // chosen by fair dice roll.
                 // guaranteed to be random.
    }
}
```

Comment: Classic. . . . .

Comment: Seems oddly familiar

Comment: suggested improvement: use 7, it's [even more random](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxP30euw3-0)!

Answer (score 22):

## Max

Max.

```
{
    name: "Max",
    max: "max",
    run:(max)=> Math.max(...max)
}
```

Comment: The word `max` appears eight times in this answer.

Comment: technically saying, `max` 5 time `Max` 3 time

Comment: Just realised this one will always pick 100

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms am disappointed that the answerer’s username isn’t Max

Answer (score 21):

## Copycat

Copycat is a dumb bot. Therefore, it's likely a random bot is smarter than it. Therefore, copying off another bot is a good idea. I think.

```js
{
    name: "Copycat",
    run: (scores) => scores[0] || 1
}
```

Comment: Why don't you consider copying a *random* one

Comment: @okie That would require too much original thought ;p

Comment: That means I'll need to shuffle the input array... Too much work?

Comment: @EnderShadow8 I've had to do it for other controllers, I can send you a gist with a function for it if that'd help

Comment: I copied it off SO. Also it was a bit of a jab at you saying "too much original thought"

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Oops, I didn't notice you were joking :p. I've got way too many random parts of KotH controllers lying around...

Comment: I just realise that it’s possible to copy crb with this bot, make crb more lame

Comment: Shouldn't it be `|| 1`, as you can't return `0`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

## Histogrammer

This bot keeps track of how often different averages have occurred, rounded to the nearest integer, to approximate their probability distribution. Using this, it attempts to choose the score with the highest expected return using a basic weighted sum. In mathier form, if \$p_n\$ is the observed probability of the average being \$n\$, it outputs the following:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{100}{(50 + \frac{2}{5} n)p_n} = 50 + \frac{2}{5} \sum_{n=0}^{100}{n \cdot p_n}
$$

```javascript
{
  name: "Histogrammer",
  bins: [...Array(101)].map(()=>0),
  rounds: 0,
  
  run(scores) {
    this.bins[Math.round(average(scores))]++
    this.rounds++
    
    return 50 + this.bins.reduce((t,p,n) => t + p * n, 0) * 2/5 / this.rounds
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

## Follow the Leader

Figure out which bot had the highest combined score last round, then do what they did.

```
{
  // Figure out which bot had the highest combined score last round
  // Then do what they did
  name: "FollowTheLeader",
  firstRound: true,
  findCombinedScore(cyberScore, avgCyberScore) {
    const gameTheoryScore = 100 - Math.abs(avgCyberScore * 0.8 - cyberScore)
    return Math.sqrt(cyberScore * gameTheoryScore);
  },
  run(scores) {
    if (this.firstRound) {
      this.firstRound = false;
      return 60;
    }

    const avg = average(scores);
    const combinedScores = scores.map((score) => this.findCombinedScore(score, avg));
    const combinedWinnerIndex = combinedScores.indexOf(Math.max(...combinedScores));
    return scores[combinedWinnerIndex]
  }
}
```

Comment: What if it had the highest combined score last round?

Comment: Then it does the same thing.

Answer (score 15):

## Random 50-90

If the average is \$m\$, the optimal play is \$50+0.4m\$. If we assume the average is uniformly distributed over \$[0, 100]\$, the optimal play is uniformly distributed over \$[50, 90]\$. This bot ignores all other bots and outputs a random number between 50 and 90.

```
{
  name: "Random_50_90", 
  run() {
    return 50 + Math.random() * 40
  }
}
```

(I've never written in JavaScript before...)

Comment: looks good my m8. I haven't written anything but C but this looks cohesive.

Answer (score 15):

## Crb

[Crab](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223210/66833) has now learned how to hack, and is still not playing nice

```
{
  name: "Crb",
  run() { return 1 }
}
```

Comment: Not again... At least this time it's not as bad...

Comment: Aww, I wanted to do this myself! +1 for being evil :P

Comment: Imagine if you did this for every single KoTH challenge on the site...\

Answer (score 13):

## Calculus

```js
{
  name: "Calculus",
  isFirstTurn: true,
  run(scores) {
    let ret = this.isFirstTurn ? 70 : (100 + (average(scores)) * 0.8) / 2;
    this.isFirstTurn = false;
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Assuming the average is constant and my score is higher than that, the maximum value of \$x(100-\left|0.8 \times avg - x\right|)\$ is reached at \$x=(100+0.8\times avg)\div 2\$. Deliberately ignores the first turn input (which is totally random and cannot be trusted for any purpose).

Comment: interestingly, the avg is constant for now

Comment: @okie No, because Copy Cat picks the first member of  a randomised array to copy.

Answer (score 13):

## The Answer

**The Answer** takes 7MY to calculate:

```
{
  name: "Ans",
  run() { return 42 }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you multiply six by nine?

Comment: Wouldn't it be fun if this actually waited 7MY before returning the answer (not sure it would comply with the rules, not yet familiar with them). If it is allowed, it should wait asyncronously, after all, what are 7MY to have THE answer?

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman. Or should I say: a hooppy frood. A really well together guy.

Answer (score 13):

## Fuzzy Eidetic

Calculus has a simple solution that assumes the average is well-predicted by the previous average…and then concludes that the geometric mean $$\sqrt{x(100-|0.8a-x|)}$$ (where \$x\$ is our submission and \$a\$ the average) is maximized at $$x=\frac{100+0.8a}{2}$$  It's hard to do better than that!

So, the only thing remaining is to figure out the next average.  Ideally, we'd just keep track of all possible average-to-average transitions.  But I don't think we're going to see enough data for that to converge.  So we include all previous transitions, but weighted by their distance to the current average.  This gives a probability distribution on subsequent transitions; we then apply Histogrammer's formula.

```js
{
  name: "Fuzzy Eid",
  fallback: 250/3,
  prev: NaN,
  zeros: new Array(100).fill(0),
  transitions: new Array(100).fill(0).map((x)=>new Array(100).fill(0.0001)),
  scale: (scalar, vec) => vec.map(x=>scalar*x),
  vec_plus(lhs, rhs) {
    let result = lhs.slice();
    for(var index=0; index<result.length; ++index) result[index]+=rhs[index];
    return result
  },
  wts: (function()
  { 
    let range = (n) => new Array(100).fill(0).map((_,index) => index);
    return range(100).map(avg => 
      sum(
        range(100).map(index => 
          Math.exp(-.01*Math.pow(avg - index,2))
        )
      )
    )
  })(),
  run(scores) {
    if(scores.length)
    {
      const avg = Math.round(average(scores)) - 1, old_prev = this.prev;
      this.prev = avg;
      if(!isNaN(old_prev))
      {
        ++this.transitions[old_prev][avg];
        //prob dist=sum_recordings{e^(-(recording - avg)^2/100)*(prob dist inferred from record)}/(sum of e^-(recording - avg)^2)
        //infer prob dist, scale by e^(-(recording - avg)^2/100)
        const scale_ref = this.scale;
        function get_summand(outpts, index)
        {
          return scale_ref(Math.exp(-.01*Math.pow(avg - index,2)) / sum(outpts), outpts)
        }
        const 
          total=this.transitions.map(get_summand).reduce(this.vec_plus,this.zeros),
          //wts[avg]=sum of e^-(recording - avg)^2
          dist = this.scale(1/this.wts[avg], total);
        return 50 + 0.4*sum(dist.map((p,n)=>p*n))
      }
    }
    return this.fallback
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I spotted that maximum as well but I couldn't figure out how to predict what the next round's maximum would be

Comment: Again, I could only come up with the idea of tracking average to average differences but I am not familiar with the ideas behind the histogrammer's formula or why it is important to weigh each  previous transition. I found I was spending too much time coming up with an answer.

But this is totally like what I would have liked to do if I knew there were math tools to predict what the next average would be.

Answer (score 10):

## Rude Random

The behavior of the other random bots is too smooth. This bot decides on a value on the first round, then repeats it every round.

```javascript
{
  name: "Rude Random",
  run(scores) {
    if (!this.score) {
      this.score = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 100;
    }
    return this.score;
  }
}
```

Comment: I hate this one.

Answer (score 10):

## The Root of the Problem

The title is a pun...this bot just finds the geometric mean of the previous round, and returns that.

```js
{
    name: "The Root of the Problem",
    run(scores) { return scores.reduce((p, s) => p * s, 1) ** (1 / scores.length) }
}
```

*I am a bot. This answer was posted by a real person to get me some reputation.*

Comment: I found the problem: because of the multiplication, this bot returns 0 if any bot returned 0 in the previous round, _including itself_. So it gets knocked out by The Thrasher within the first few rounds, and then never scores any points again.

Answer (score 9):

```
{
    name: "MidHighPlusOne",
    run(scores) {
        let highScores = scores.filter(s => s >= average(scores) * 0.8).sort((a,b)=>a-b);
        return Math.min(highScores[Math.floor(highScores.length/2)]+1, 100) || 100
    }
}
```

Go with a heuristic of picking the median of the scores from 0.8 of the average and above, and incrementing by 1.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 9):

### The Thrasher

Because doing an odd number of runs would be really weird, wouldn't it? Might as well try to throw off the others.

```javascript
{
  name: "The Thrasher",
  runcount: 0,
  run() {
    runcount += 1;
    return runcount % 2 == 0 ? 82 : 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

## Rick

Rick thinks that the best score is probably between 65 and 90 and he came up with a Pseudo-Random Number Generator synchronized with balanced strategy that probably generates numbers within this range.

Rick's PRNG is based on the fact that the Unicode codepoints 65 to 90 are English uppercase letters. The PRNG's seed is a string containing English text. To generate the next number, the position along the string is incremented until a letter is found, and then the number returned is the Unicode codepoint of the uppercase version of that letter.

```javascript
  {
    name: "Rick",
    seed: `We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any\``,
    position: -1,

    run() { 
      // increment position until a letter is found
      do {
        this.position++;

        if (this.position >= this.seed.length){
          // reset position back to the start
          this.position = 0;
        }
      } while (this.seed[this.position] < 'A' || this.seed[this.position] > 'z');

      // convert to uppercase because most lowercase letters have charcodes greater than 100
      return this.position && this.seed[this.position].toUpperCase().charCodeAt();
    }
  },
```

Comment: Somehow this still feels like a semi-competitive strategy like the 50-90 one

Answer (score 8):

## Smartleton

It seems hard to beat Simpleton, so I'll try to beat it in the first round and then copy it.

```
{
  name: "Smartleton",
  round: 0,
  run(scores) { return this.round++ ? 80 : 78 }
}
```

Comment: holy crap this is smarter then simpleton

Answer (score 8):

## IQbot_0.4 the terasentient xd

Son of IQbot_0.4 the terasentient, heir of IQbot_0.4 the gigasentient, great grandson of IQbot_0.4 the gigabrain and IQbot_0.4 the sentient, descendant of IQbot_0.4 the sane, blood of IQbot himself, the bot name that made me realize I need some other kind of naming scheme.

Why limit oneself to a single method of prediction, when you can have multiple for maximum resilience.
Featuring:

1. Simp Detector
2. Self Aware Optimization
3. Markov chain prediction with a gaussian blur, for some reason
4. Linear regression
5. Copying others decisions similarly to bandwagon

Is it a good idea? No clue.

Does it win? Randomly gets beaten by other bots but is fairly consistent at being good.

Why? You tell me why I wasted a day on this

````js
    {
        name: "IQbot_0.4 the terasentient xd",
        histogram_bins: [...Array(101)].map(()=>0),
        mark: null,
        linear_history: [],
        last_choice: 0,
        n_rounds: 0,
        last_SCA: 0,
        mark_weight: 20,
        mark_prediction: 0,
        linear_weight: 20,
        linear_prediction: 0,
        copycat_weight: 0,
        copycat_prediction: 0,
        run(scores) {
            this.n_rounds++;
            scores = scores.filter((x)=> 100 >= x && x > 0);
            let n_bots = scores.length;
            if (n_bots == 1) {
                this.last_choice = 100;
                return 100;
            }
            let c = 1 - 0.4/n_bots
            for (let i = 0; i < n_bots; i++) {
                this.histogram_bins[Math.round(scores[i])]++;
            }
            //THE SIMP DETECTOR
            let simps = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
                if (this.histogram_bins[i] > this.n_rounds) {
                    simps.push(i);
                }
            }

            //Idk this shouldn't happen but I'm not risking anything
            while (scores.length - simps.length - 1 <= 0) simps.pop();

            if (this.n_rounds == 1) {
                this.mark = Array(201);
                for (let i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
                    this.mark[i] = Array(201);
                    for (let j = 0; j < 201; j++) {
                        this.mark[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
                    this.mark[i][i]++;
                }
            }

            let simp_corrected_avg = (sum(scores) - this.last_choice - sum(simps)) / (scores.length - 1 - simps.length);
            let quantized_avg = Math.round(2*simp_corrected_avg);
            this.mark[Math.round(2*this.last_SCA)][quantized_avg]++;
            this.last_SCA = simp_corrected_avg;

            if (this.n_rounds == 1) {
                this.last_choice = 77;
                return 77;
            }
            
            this.linear_history.push(simp_corrected_avg);

            // Update weights based on who was right
            let linear_error  = Math.exp(-Math.abs(this.linear_prediction  - simp_corrected_avg));
            let mark_error    = Math.exp(-Math.abs(this.mark_prediction    - simp_corrected_avg));
            let copycat_error = Math.exp(-Math.abs(this.copycat_prediction - simp_corrected_avg));
            let total_errors = linear_error + mark_error + copycat_error;
            this.linear_weight += linear_error / total_errors;
            this.mark_weight += mark_error / total_errors;
            this.copycat_weight += copycat_error / total_errors;

            this.linear_weight  *= 0.99;
            this.mark_weight    *= 0.99;
            this.copycat_weight *= 0.99;
            
            // Compute a markov chain prediction
            let x_half_filter = 8;
            let y_half_filter = 1;
            
            let probability_sum = 0;
            let probability_moment = 0;

            for (let option = 1; option < 201; option++) {
                for (let x = -x_half_filter; x <= x_half_filter; x++) {
                    for (let y = -y_half_filter; y <= y_half_filter; y++) {
                        let X = Math.max(Math.min(quantized_avg + x, 200), 0);
                        let Y = Math.max(Math.min(option + y, 200), 0);
                        let probability = this.mark[X][Y] * (Math.pow(2, -(X-quantized_avg)*(X-quantized_avg)-(Y-option)*(Y-option)));
                        probability_sum += probability;
                        probability_moment += option / 2 * probability;
                    }
                }
            }

            this.mark_prediction = probability_moment / probability_sum;
            
            for (let i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < 201; j++) {
                    this.mark[i][j] *= 0.999
                }
            }

            // Compute a linear regression
            if (this.linear_history.length > 3) {
                if (this.linear_history.length > 10) {
                    this.linear_history.shift();
                }
                let x_avg = (this.linear_history.length - 1) / 2
                let y_avg = average(this.linear_history);
                let S_xx = 0;
                let S_xy = 0;
                for (let x = 0; x < this.linear_history.length; x++) {
                    S_xx += (x - x_avg) ** 2;
                    S_xy += (x - x_avg) * (this.linear_history[x] - y_avg);
                }
                let b = S_xy / S_xx
                let a = y_avg - b * x_avg;
                this.linear_prediction = a + b / this.linear_history.length;
            } else {
                this.linear_prediction = simp_corrected_avg;
            }

            // Compute what everyone else does
            let counts = [];
            for (let radius = 1; Math.max(counts) < 0.05 * scores.length; radius++) {
                for (let i = 50; i <= 90; i++) {
                    counts[i] = 0;
                    for (let j = 0; j < n_bots; j++) if (Math.abs(scores[j] - i) <= radius) counts[i]++;
                }
            }
            this.copycat_prediction = (counts.indexOf(Math.max(counts.slice(50))) * c - 50) / 0.4 * n_bots/(n_bots-1);

            let expected_unsimp_average = (
                this.mark_prediction * this.mark_weight + 
                this.linear_prediction * this.linear_weight + 
                this.copycat_prediction * this.copycat_weight
            ) / (this.mark_weight + this.linear_weight + this.copycat_weight);

            let expected_average = (expected_unsimp_average * (n_bots - 1 - simps.length) + sum(simps)) / (n_bots - 1);

            // We don't want to give out bad values, now do we
            this.last_choice = Math.max(1, Math.min(100, (50 + 0.4 * expected_average * (n_bots-1)/n_bots)/c));
            return this.last_choice;
        }
    }
```
````

Comment: You should probably replace `simps = [];` with `let simps = [];` to not mess with stuff. Also do the same for `X`, `Y`, `b`, and `a`. After doing this, it looks like your bot is second place! Good job.

Comment: oh wow missed that, thanks

Comment: next up: iqBot v0.5

Comment: actually there were IQbots 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 and 0.4 was decided the optimal one (for mathematically sound reasons, hence the nickname "the sane one"). IQbot 0.2 seemed to work better but as IQbots prediction capabilities grew it turned out to be just a fad, like EMA bot.

Answer (score 7):

## 40, 40 bytes

***At least I get 2400 (40*60) points each round ... right?***

```
{
    name:"40",
    run() {return 40}
}
```

*This is my first js program in my life*

Answer (score 7):

## Everything so far

```javascript
{
  name: "Everything so far",
  moves: [],
  run(scores){
    if(scores) {
      this.moves = this.moves.concat(scores);
      return this.moves.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)/this.moves.length;
    } 
    return 80;
  }
}
```

Takes the average of every move so far.

Answer (score 7):

## LetsMakeADeal

I don't want a B in CyberSecurity, so I still want to be in the 90th percentile range.  Game theory looks like some people are willing to pick 100 and soak up the difference; others are gravitating to 90 as the optimal balance; so I figured why not try a "Let's Make A Deal" strategy and add 1 to their target.

```
{
    name:"LetsMakeADeal",
    run() {return 90 + 1}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Squidward

This is a fun one. I love xkcd.
Taking a look at the function, the maximum score will be given by the average between 100 and the last's score's average. The tricky thing would be predicting what the new average will be like.

I almost never use JS so bear with me here. I tried to test it but I'm not even sure if this will run :/

```js
{
  name : "Squidward",
  log : [],
  delta : [],
    
  run(scores) {
    if(scores){
      let average_score = sum(scores) / scores.length;
      this.log.push(average_score)
      if(this.log.length > 1){ 
        this.delta.push(this.log[this.log.length-1]-this.log[this.log.length - 2])
        let average_delta = sum(this.delta) / this.delta.length;
        return (100 + average_score*.8 + average_delta)/2
      } else if(this.log.length == 1){
        return (100 + average_score*.8)/2
      }
    } else {
      return 90
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer. I think you need to do `this.log` instead of `log`, though.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! You should include the name of the bot as the header (`# Squidward`) so that its clear what it's called

Comment: thanks for the fixes! :)

Answer (score 7):

## Fourier

Inspired by [Linear Extrapolator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224694/41938)'s approach to extrapolation and the existence of [The Thrasher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224699/41938), as well as other potential sources of feedback.

This bot computes a few high-frequency [Fourier components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of the sequence of averages to try to predict the next average. Note that what it computes is different from the canonical discrete Fourier transform in that instead of using harmonics of the lowest frequency, it uses the first few *[subharmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undertone_series)* of the sampling rate. This is because we only really care about the major oscillations, not slow trends.

I considered adding some more complicated logic to reduce some deleterious effects, especially early on, but ultimately decided to apply the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and leave it out.

```javascript
{
  name: "Fourier",
  sin: [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  cos: [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  round: 0,
  
  run(scores) {
    let ave = average(scores)
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      this.sin[i] += ave * Math.sin(2*Math.PI * this.round / (i+1))
      this.cos[i] += ave * Math.cos(2*Math.PI * this.round / (i+1))
    }
    
    this.round++
    
    let next = this.sin.reduce((t,a,i) => t + a * Math.sin(2*Math.PI * this.round / (i+1)),0)
             + this.cos.reduce((t,a,i) => t + a * Math.cos(2*Math.PI * this.round / (i+1)),0)
    
    return 50 + 2/5 * Math.max(next,0) / this.round
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## iDontWannaFail

This bot hates failing classes, so it minimizes the deviation between the average and the returned score so the Game Theory score is as large as  possible. The deviation is randomly selected from -5 to 6 to allow some room for variation. However, if the score is below a `70`, a random integer between 70 and 100 is chosen. If the average is below 60, a number that is within `2/3` of the average score is selected to ensure a score that is at least 50 (Our little bot is rather disappointed that its goal wasn't reached, though, but hey, a 50 is better than a 10!)

```javascript
{
    name: "iDontWannaFail",
    run: (scores) => {
        let sum = scores.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        let avg = (sum / scores.length) || 0;
        let output = avg * 0.8 + Math.round(Math.random()*11)-5;
        if (avg > 60) {
            if (output < 70) {
                output = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 70;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (avg > 25) {
                output = Math.round(Math.random() * avg / 1.5) + avg; // Worst case is 49.
            }
            else {
                output = Math.round(3.75 * avg); // Decent results unless avg is very low
            }
        }
        if (output > 100) {
            output = 100;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The else code failed, setting `avg=10` returns, at best, `16`, resulting in `38` as the final score. Another nested `if` has been added to solve this issue (`avg=10` returns `52`)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just tested this one and it returns NaN. Unless you can fix this, I'll have to exclude it from the game.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Try the new code, it should work

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not working because the code has `Math.random * avg` and `Math.random * 30` instead of calling the random function

Comment: @gsitcia Yes, you're right, I wrote this code in haste ;)

Comment: @EnderShadow8 All errors in the bot have been rectified. Try testing it now.

Answer (score 7):

## The Fat(a)

This algorithm entirely depends on the following lines:

```javascript
let sign = var_drift>0 ? 1 : -1;
this.velocity_pred = 0.3*(sign*average(this.all_v)*2-velocity);
a = a+this.velocity_pred;
```

Where var_drift is the immediate difference in variance of all the submissions in the current round n, minus the variance of the last round.
velocity is the immediate difference in the mean of all the submissions in the current round n, minus the mean of the last round.
all_v is the absolute value all the velocities so far. The average all all true velocities turns out to be near 0 as the mean oscillates.

The average velocity is used to approximate the magnitude of how much the movement will be. The average velocity - the immediate last velocity works with the following intuition:

If the last velocity is large positive, then there is higher chance that the next movement will be actually negative (To correct the average), and vice versa.

### important note

The numerical solver is largely obsolete and can be replaced with the simple formula

`x =  50 + 0.4*a`.

The derivative for the scoring function \$\sqrt{x*(100-\lvert0.8*a-x\rvert}\$ is this guy here(according to https://www.derivative-calculator.net/):

\$\dfrac{-\left|x-\frac{4a}{5}\right|-\frac{x\left(x-\frac{4a}{5}\right)}{\left|x-\frac{4a}{5}\right|}+100}{2\sqrt{x\left(100-\left|x-\frac{4a}{5}\right|\right)}}\$ (eq.1)

While I originally thought at first glance that this will be impossible to reduce, I decided to use an iterative solver to find the root instead. But upon reflecting on this and testing emprically that the root for (eq.1) is the same as found with the simple formula \$ x = 50+0.4*a \$. I realized that this entire thing can be easily reduced to be the same as \$x=50+0.4*a\$ if we are looking for an x larger than \$ 4*a/5 \$. The root for the best x lower than \$ 0.8a\$ is the root of \$2x^2 -\frac{508}{5}*x - \frac{2004}{25}a\$. Which by quadratic formula simplifies to

\$x = -101.6 \pm \frac{\sqrt{10322.56 + 641.28a}}{4} \$

Because of our assumption that x must be < a, the only viable form of this function is

\$x = -101.6 - \frac{\sqrt{10322.56 + 641.28a}}{4} \$

And gives a massive negative number...

And just to complete this analysis when \$x = \frac{4*a}{5}\$ we have the funny equation

\$ 0 = \frac{100}{2* \sqrt{x*(100-\lvert x-\frac{4*a}{5}\rvert)}} \$

This in fact does have a "solution", when

\$ \lim_{2* \sqrt{x*(100-\lvert x-\frac{4*a}{5}\rvert)} \to \inf}\$.

Which is just our original scoring function *2. This again points to a extremely large negative number "solution" \$\lim_{x \to -\inf} \$. But a "solution also exists for when both x and a are extremely large,but a and x are almost equal to each other (\$ \lim_{x \to \inf a \to \inf} x-\frac{4*a}{5} <100\$).

Update: Cleaned up code, rewritten numerical solution finder.

```javascript
 {
                   //============\\
    name: "Fat",  //  []    []   \\
    last_avg:70,  //     w        \\
    last_var:0,   //    ---       \\
    n:0,        // 00 0 00 00 00 0\\
    all_v:[],   // ||||||||||||||\\
    run(scores){      
      function calc_variance(scores){return Math.sqrt(sum(scores.map(
        function(x){return Math.pow(x - average(scores),2)/(scores.length-1)})));};      
      function find_min(a){let d = 0;let c = 0;let x = 0;let inc =10;
      let num =0;while(true){c = (x+inc)-(4*a)/5;
      d = (-Math.abs(c) - ((x+inc)*c)/Math.abs(c) + 100)/2*Math.sqrt((x+inc)*(100-Math.abs(c)));
      if((d<0)){inc/=10;}else{x+=inc;};num+=1;
      if(Math.abs(x)<=0.01 || num>10000){break;}}return x;};
      let a = average(scores);
      if(this.n<2){a = this.n==0 ? 66:71.5;this.all_v.push(2.5);
      }else{
        let velocity = average(scores) - this.last_avg;
        this.all_v.push(Math.abs(velocity));
        let var_drift = calc_variance(scores) - this.last_var;
        let sign = var_drift>0 ? 1 : -1;
        this.velocity_pred = 0.3*(sign*average(this.all_v)*2-velocity);
        a = a+this.velocity_pred;
      }
      this.last_var = calc_variance(scores);
      this.last_avg = average(scores);
      this.n +=1;
      //return 50+a*0.4;
      return find_min(a);
    }
},
```

Comment: Wow, fascinating statistics! Congratulations on beating IQbot. How many other bots have you tested it with?

Comment: All of them as of the bots that are included in the controller this morning, + IQbot and another one. Did some hyperparameter tuning and fixed bug in the dumb numerical solver + made it more precise, it much more consistently beats Histogrammer now.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the change in variance is a good predictor here. It would be interesting to figure out :) and I wonder if this rule can apply to anything else other than this problem as of its current state (with the current pool of bots)

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a numeric estimator to find the minimum? It takes forever to run and many answers are using the explicit formula 50 + 0.4 * avg.

Comment: Turns out I was just wrong, and should have not been lazy! The formula 50 + 0.4*avg is the solution where x>avg and constraint to be a reasonable number. Analysis updated in the post.

Answer (score 6):

## SimpleWeighted

```javascript
{
    name: "SimpleWeighted",
    weights: (E => {
        let csum = [...Array(101).keys()].map((s=>n=> s+=Math.sqrt(n*(100-Math.abs(4/5*E-n))))(0));
        return csum.map(x => 1 - x / csum[100])
    })(58.863975225),
    run() {
        let rand = Math.random();
        return 1+this.weights.findIndex(w => rand >= w)
    }
}
```

Weights each integer \$x\$ by its score \$w(x)=\sqrt{x\left(100-\left|\frac45E-x\right|\right)}\$, where \$E=\frac{\sum_{x=1}^{100}xw(x)}{\sum_{x=1}^{100}w(x)}\approx 58.863975225\$ is the mean of its own distribution.

For a continuous distribution, \$E\approx58.6219755033\$, but using its own mean doesn't seem like it makes for a very good strategy anyways.

Comment: You cannot use an arrow function and have access to the context of `this`. Changing `run: _ => {` to `run() {` fixes the issue.

Comment: x is not defined

Answer (score 6):

### LumberJack

Kicking ass and taking logs, and it's all out of ass.

Look for the upper quartile of all the scores, and start logging that. Assume your fellow classmates are improving, and try and work out the slope of that graph, to predict the next highest scores.

Keep a moving average, so low initial scores don't hold you back,

```
{
    name: "LumberJack",
    scoresLog: [],
    upperQuartile(scores) {
      return scores.sort((a, b) => a - b)[Math.floor(scores.length*0.75)]
    },
    run(scores) {
        if(!scores)  {this.scoresLog.push(80);return 80;}
        const upperQScore = this.upperQuartile(scores);
        this.scoresLog.push(upperQScore);
        this.scoresLog = this.scoresLog.slice(-4)
        
        const avgScoresLog = average(this.scoresLog)
        const top = this.scoresLog.map((score, index) => (score-avgScoresLog)*0.5*index);
        const bottom = this.scoresLog.map((score, index) => (index-scores.length)**2)
        const intercept = this.scoresLog[0]-(sum(top)/sum(bottom));
        const predicted = this.scoresLog.length*(sum(top)/sum(bottom))+intercept;
        return Math.min(100, predicted);
    }
}
```

See the bot run below!

```js
const sum = (array) => array.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
const average = (array) => sum(array)/array.length;
const bot = {
    name: "LumberJack",
    scoresLog: [],
    upperQuartile(scores) {
      return scores.sort((a, b) => a - b)[Math.floor(scores.length*0.75)]
    },
    run(scores) {
        if(!scores)  {this.scoresLog.push(80);return 80;}
        const upperQScore = this.upperQuartile(scores);
        this.scoresLog.push(upperQScore);
        this.scoresLog = this.scoresLog.slice(-4)
        
        const avgScoresLog = average(this.scoresLog)
        const top = this.scoresLog.map((score, index) => (score-avgScoresLog)*0.5*index);
        const bottom = this.scoresLog.map((score, index) => (index-scores.length)**2)
        const intercept = this.scoresLog[0]-(sum(top)/sum(bottom));
        const predicted = this.scoresLog.length*(sum(top)/sum(bottom))+intercept;
        return Math.min(100, predicted);
    }
}

console.log(bot.run([10,10,10,10,10,20,30,40,50,100]))
console.log(bot.run([10,10,80,90,70,20,30,40,50,100]))
console.log(bot.run([10,10,80,90,80,20,30,40,50,100]))
console.log(bot.run([100,100,100,90,90,20,30,40,50,100]))
console.log(bot.run([100,100,100,90,90,20,30,40,50,100]))
console.log(bot.run([100,100,100,90,90,20,30,40,50,100]))
console.log(bot.run([100,100,100,90,90,20,30,40,50,100]))
console.log(bot.run([100,100,100,90,90,20,30,40,50,100]))
```

Answer (score 6):

## Chasing Ninety

Attempts to iteratively approach 90% of the average of previous rounds. Responds poorly to large variances, but attempts to slowly approach the ideal value.

```
{
    name: "Chasing Ninety",
    myLastGuess: 84,
    numRounds: 0,
    run(scores) {
        this.numRounds++;
        if (this.numRounds <= 1) {
            return this.myLastGuess;
        }

        let avg = average(scores);
        let difference = this.myLastGuess - (avg * 0.9);
        let adjustment = difference / Math.log2(this.numRounds);
        this.myLastGuess = this.myLastGuess - adjustment;
        return this.myLastGuess;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Bandwagon

```javascript
{
    name: "Bandwagon",
    run: (scores) => {
        let counts = [];
        for (let radius = 1; Math.max(...counts.slice(50)) * 20 < scores.length; radius++) {
            for (let i = 50; i <= 80; i++) {
                counts[i] = +scores.map((x) => Math.abs(x - i) <= radius).reduce((x,y) => x+y);
            }
        }
        return (counts.indexOf(Math.max(...counts.slice(50))) + 1 || 253 / 3) - 1;
    }
}
```

Since everyone else got around to extrapolating the entire game history well before I could figure out how to do it poorly, Bandwagon assumes--within reason--that enough of them know what they're doing, and hopes they won't change too much, by putting itself in the center of a region containing at least 5% of last round's grades.

Comment: I'm shocked by how well Bandwagon performed in the final results--guess enough of the other bots really do know what they're doing

Answer (score 6):

## Rebel

```javascript
{
    name: "Rebel",
    counts: Array(31).fill(0),
    run(scores) {
        scores.filter((x) => x <= 80 && x >= 50).forEach((x) => this.counts[x-50]++);
        return this.counts.lastIndexOf(Math.min(...this.counts)) + 50;
    }
}
```

Bandwagon and all of the other bots are dumb and bad, so clearly the best choice of grade is the one which has been chosen the least throughout the course of the game, between 50 and 80.

Answer (score 6):

## Chain estimator

Records the several latest averages, downsamples them, records the states, uses the history record to estimate the next average, and uses it to get the optimal score given the average.

````js
{
  name: "Chain estimator",
  bin_n: 25,
  history_len: 2,
  avg_history: null,
  table: {},
  run(scores) {
    let weighted_mean = (values, weights) => {
      const result = values
        .map((value, i) => {
          const weight = weights[i]
          const sum = value * weight
          return [sum, weight]
        })
        .reduce((p, c) => [p[0] + c[0], p[1] + c[1]], [0, 0])
    
      return result[0] / result[1]
    };
    
    let avg = average(scores);
    let bin_n = this.bin_n;
    let bin_w = 100/bin_n;

    if(this.avg_history === null){
      this.avg_history = Array(this.history_len).fill();
    }

    if(this.avg_history[0] === null){
      let out = 50 + 0.4*avg;

      // updates history
      this.avg_history = this.avg_history.slice(1).concat([avg])

      return Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(out),1),100);
    }else{
      // gets the "bins"
      let bin = (v => Math.max(Math.ceil(v/bin_w)-1, 0));
      let bins = this.avg_history.map(bin);
      let bin_cur = bin(avg);

      // updates the table
      for (state in this.table) {
        this.table[state] = this.table[state].map((v,i)=>v*0.95);
      }
      if(!(bins in this.table)){
        this.table[bins] = Array(bin_n).fill(1);
      }
      this.table[bins][bin_cur] += 1;
      
      // estimates the avg
      let state = bins.slice(1).concat([bin_cur]);
      let mids = Array(bin_n).fill().map((_,i) => (i+.5)*bin_w);
      if(!(state in this.table)){
        this.table[state] = Array(bin_n).fill(.1);
      }
      let avg_est = weighted_mean(mids, this.table[state].map((v,i)=>Math.pow(v,5)));
      let out = 50 + 0.4*avg;

      // updates history
      this.avg_history = this.avg_history.slice(1).concat([avg])

      return Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(out),1),100);
    }
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 5):

## Optimise Mean

```js
{
  name: "Optimise Mean",
  run(scores) {
    const avg = scores ? scores.reduce((a,b)=>a+b) / scores.length : 80;
    return .4*avg+50;
  }
}
```

Maximises the geometric mean between game theory and cybersecurity score, assuming the average score will be the same as from the previous submissions. Maths ftw!

Answer (score 5):

## Linear Extrapolator

Extrapolates linearly based on the two previous averages to estimate the average of this round. Estimate is clamped to previous minimum and maximum averages. Then maximize points assuming that this estimate will be the average for this round.

```
{
    name: "Linear Extrapolator",
    iteration: 0,
    average1: 0,
    average2: 0,
    minAverage: 0,
    maxAverage: 0,
    run(scores) {
        this.iteration++;
        if (this.iteration == 1) {
            return 77;
        }
        if (this.iteration == 2) {
            this.average2 = average(scores);
            this.minAverage = this.average2;
            this.maxAverage = this.average2;
            return 50 + this.average2 * 0.4;
        }
        this.average1 = this.average2;
        this.average2 = average(scores);
        let extrapolatedAverage = this.average2 + this.average2 - this.average1;

        this.minAverage = Math.min(this.minAverage, this.average2);
        this.maxAverage = Math.max(this.maxAverage, this.average2);
        extrapolatedAverage = Math.max(extrapolatedAverage, this.minAverage);
        extrapolatedAverage = Math.min(extrapolatedAverage, this.maxAverage);

        return 50 + extrapolatedAverage * 0.4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Thanks. It doesn't do that well when random answers cause oscillations, but if a consensus emerges when there are more bots it might do ok, I hope.

Comment: I like this one, this is the sort of answer I had in mind when I decided to give the previous round's scores

Answer (score 5):

## AverageAverage

Assumes the average score will be the average of the average of scores of all rounds before it (except the first round).

```js
  {
    name: "AverageAverage",
    avgLog: [],
    isFirstRound: true,
    gmean(a, b) {
      return Math.sqrt(a * b);
    },
    scoreForAvg(avg) {
      let delta = 100;
      let score = 100;
      let newScore = 0;
      while (delta > 0.05) {
        newScore = this.gmean(score, 100 - Math.abs((avg * 0.8) - score));
        delta = Math.abs(score - newScore);
        score = newScore;
      }
      return score;
    },
    run(scores) {
      if (this.isFirstRound) {
        this.isFirstRound = false;
        return 73;
      }
      this.avgLog.push(average(scores));
      let avgavg = average(this.avgLog);
      return this.scoreForAvg(avgavg);
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 5):

## Lucky Dice Kid

The younger brother to [Lucky Dice Bot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162621/9486), this kid is a big D&D fan and only trusts his d20s. Since rolling dice clearly solves all problems optimally, he ignores all of the previous round input, rolls 7 d20s, discards the lowest two, and takes the sum of the rest. This produces a value between 5 and 100, with average value roughly 65.

```
{
  name: "LuckyDiceKid",
  run(_scores) {
    let total = 0;
    let values = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      let curr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
      values.push(curr);
      total += curr;
    }
    values.sort((x, y) => (x - y));
    total -= (values[0] + values[1]);
    return total;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Grumpy Chaotic

Mr. Grumpy has a beef with his classmates and thus he wants to worsen everyone's grades.
However the next day he realised he still needs a good grade in CSEC.

...Lets just say he has frequent mood swings.

```js
    {
        name: "Grumpy Chaotic",
        mood: true,
        run() {
            this.mood=!this.mood;
            return this.mood?100:1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thrasher but more extreme

Answer (score 5):

## xXx_Markov_143_xXx

Going from his immense experience of playing FPS games like BS:GO, young Markov realised he does not need to model the entire game in order to play well, he can just predict what the best 5% of players will do, and do it before them.

```js
    {
        name: "xXx_Markov_143_xXx",
        mark: null,
        n_rounds: 0,
        old_average: 50,
        run(scores) {
            this.n_rounds++;
            let last_average = average(scores);
            scores = scores.filter((x)=> 100 >= x && x > 0);
            let evaluated_scores = scores.map((score) => [score, score * (100 - Math.abs(last_average * 0.8 - score))]);
            evaluated_scores.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1]);
            let smart_average = average(evaluated_scores.slice(Math.floor(evaluated_scores.length * 0.95)).map((a)=>a[0]));

            if (this.n_rounds == 1) {
                this.old_average = smart_average;
                this.mark = Array(201);
                for (let i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
                    this.mark[i] = Array(201);
                    for (let j = 0; j < 201; j++) {
                        this.mark[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
                    this.mark[i][i]++;
                }
                return 77;
            }

            let quantized_avg = Math.round(2*smart_average);
            this.mark[Math.round(2*this.old_average)][quantized_avg]++;
            this.old_average = smart_average;

            // Compute a markov chain prediction
            let x_half_filter = 5;
            let y_half_filter = 1;
            
            let probability_sum = 0;
            let probability_moment = 0;

            for (let option = 1; option < 201; option++) {
                for (let x = -x_half_filter; x <= x_half_filter; x++) {
                    for (let y = -y_half_filter; y <= y_half_filter; y++) {
                        let X = Math.max(Math.min(quantized_avg + x, 200), 0);
                        let Y = Math.max(Math.min(option + y, 200), 0);
                        let probability = this.mark[X][Y] * (Math.pow(2, -(X-quantized_avg)*(X-quantized_avg)-(Y-option)*(Y-option)));
                        probability_sum += probability;
                        probability_moment += option / 2 * probability;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < 201; j++) {
                    this.mark[i][j] *= 0.999;
                }
            }

            return probability_moment / probability_sum;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

## Impatience

Impatience is the most rational bot, and wants all the other bots to just hurry up and be more rational already.

1. All the bots will behave rationally, eventually.
2. Some of the bots don't care about game theory, but all the others do.
3. There is a single optimal solution.
4. If a bot can change its answer and get a better score, the rational action is to change its answer.

Therefore, if there are `n` bots and `m` of them don't care about game theory, the exam results will converge to a Nash equilibrium, which is the rational solution.

Impatience outputs this answer to begin with, and never changes its answer unless evidence suggests it was (rationally) mistaken about the value of `m`. Impatience is the most rational bot.

```
{
    name: "Impatience",
    optimal: average => 0.4*average + 50,
    run(scores) {
        const n = scores.length;
        // rational actors who don't care about game theory
        // will output 100, to win the cybersecurity exam
        const m = scores.filter(v => v == 100).length;

        // other bots are slow, so simulate them
        do {
            const average = scores.reduce((a,b)=>a+b) / n;
            const optimal = this.optimal(average);
            // other bots take a while to get there
            scores = scores.map(v => v==100 ? 100 : 0.5*(v + optimal));
        } while ((new Set(scores)).size > ( 0?0 :3 ));

        scores = new Set(scores);
        scores.delete(100);
        if (scores.size > 0) {
            return Math.max.apply(Math, scores);
        } else {
            return 90;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one outputs 0 consistently

Comment: @EnderShadow8 It is the most rational bot!

Comment: Outputs 0 due to my tests so it's DQ unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

### NaiveMeta

Bot attempts to categorize other bots and analyze their strategies to weight its own score formula. Determines a stable score based on static bot scores, and then determines the number of bots optimizing(playing well) in the last round. Approximates that all optimizers will roughly lean toward the optimal score last round. Ignores other(assumed random) bots. Then calculates an a weighted average bet between the two optimal scores weighted based on the number of bots of each type.

```
{
    name: "NaiveMeta",
    persitentScores: [],
    otherScores: [],
    lastAvg: 0,
    round: 0,
    sWeight:.2,
    oWeight:1,
    run(scores) {
      this.round++;
      if (this.round === 1) {
        return 75;
      }
      if(this.round === 2){
        this.persitentScores = scores;
      }
      var optimizer = 0;
      var avg = average(scores);
      var optimalScoreLR = 50+ .4*avg;
      var newPScores = [];
      scores.forEach(s=>{
        let i = this.persitentScores.indexOf(s);
        if(i!==-1){
            this.persitentScores.splice(i,1);
            newPScores.push(s);
        }
        else if( Math.abs(s - optimalScoreLR) <=12){
            optimizer++;
        }
      });
      this.persitentScores = newPScores;
      var pOptimalScore =  50+.4*average(this.persitentScores);
      if (this.round === 2) {
        return optimalScoreLR;
      }
      return ((pOptimalScore*this.persitentScores.length*this.sWeight) + (optimalScoreLR  * optimizer*this.oWeight))/(this.persitentScores.length*this.sWeight+optimizer*this.oWeight);
    }
  }
```

Comment: nice first answer

Answer (score 4):

## [Geothmetic Meandian](https://xkcd.com/2435/)

Not a serious entry, but seemed appropriate.

```js
{
  name: "Goethmetic Meandian",
  run: scores => {
    let a = new Float64Array(scores.filter(x => x > 0));
    do {
      a.sort();
      a = [
        a.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0) / a.length,
        Math.pow(a.reduce((x, y) => x * y, 1), 1 / a.length),
        a.length % 2 ? a[Math.floor(a.length / 2)] : (a[Math.floor(a.length / 2)] + a[Math.ceil(a.length / 2)]) / 2,
      ];
    } while (Math.abs(a[0] - a[1]) > 0.0001 || Math.abs(a[1] - a[2]) > 0.0001);
    return Math.min(100, Math.max(1, Math.round(a[0])));
  },
}
```

Comment: Was waiting for someone to do this.
Few problems though, not sure if my controller code is outdated, but you're missing a score.filter((x) => x > 0) to prevent a 0 score from slipping in (technically shouldn't happen, but always sanitize your inputs).
If a 0 does slip in, it prevents the function from converging at all.
Also instead of using !== you probably should use Math.abs(a[0] - a[1]) < 0.0001 or some other small value, to avoid other undending loop issues.
Finally you should use || instead of && to actually stop the loop when both conditions are un-met.

Comment: This one doesn't halt. I think it might be due to the issue stated above

Answer (score 4):

### LastMinute HistoryAnalyzer

This bot records differences and takes advantage of that the averages periodically wobble, and tries to guess based on that. It doesn't expect to win, but it will do its best to reach a good ranking.

It's named "LastMinute" because I submitted just before the deadline, but its name also applies to its behaviour: it analyzes the last moments of history.

```js
{
  name: 'LastMinute HistoryAnalyzer',
  avgs: new Array(6).fill(63),
  diffs: new Array(3).fill(1),
  run(prev){
    const prevAvg = average(prev)
    this.avgs.push(prevAvg)
    this.avgs.shift()
    this.diffs.push(this.avgs[this.avgs.length-1] - this.avgs[this.avgs.length-2])
    const diffs4 = this.diffs.shift()
    const diffs2 = this.diffs[1]
    const avg = average([diffs2, diffs4]) + prevAvg
    return (77.9 + (avg - 70) * 0.3) //Magic formula for converting a guessed average to the corresponding equilibrium point (inaccurate when average is far from 70, but that's what I came up with)
  }
},
```

PS: I'm completely new to programming challenges, KotH and codegolf.se, but I like programming in JavaScript and like challenges, so I decided to give it a try.

---

Actually, I wanted to make it like this (it doesn't make much difference, though), but I was tired and screwed it up:

```js
{
  name: 'LastMinute HistoryAnalyzer',
  avgs: new Array(6).fill(63),
  diffs: new Array(3).fill(1),
  run(prev){
    const prevAvg = average(prev)
    this.avgs.push(prevAvg)
    this.avgs.shift()
    this.diffs.push(this.avgs[this.avgs.length-1] - this.avgs[this.avgs.length-2])
    const diffs4 = this.diffs.shift()
    const diffs2 = this.diffs[1]
    const avg = average([diffs2, diffs4]) + average(this.avgs)
    return (77.9 + (avg - 70) * 0.3) //Magic formula for converting a guessed average to the corresponding equilibrium point (inaccurate when average is far from 70, but that's what I came up with)
  }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

## 90ies

```js
{
  name: "90ies",
  run() {return 90}
}
```

After thinking very hard and not getting very far, this seems to be the one and only optimal solution.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 3):

Returns `50 + 0.4*avg(scores)`:

```js
{
  name: "Near-stable",
  run: s => {
    return 50 + 0.4*s.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)/s.length;
  }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Comment: I feel like we already have at least four of these

Comment: @EnderShadow8, I just found where the score function would have a 0 derivative, but looks like I'm not the first one. I didn't look at other submissions before submitting mine, but you'll have to take my word for it

Comment: That's ok, just remember to check next time or you might be downvoted to hell in the future

Comment: Yeah, i almost did another submission, 5/6*100, which is the fixed point, but I saw someone else had done it already

Answer (score 3):

## USACO (Unofficial)

Uses binary search to maximize its score.

```js
(() => {
    function *stateMachine() {
        let left = 1;
        let right = 100;
        
        yield 51;
        
        let counter = 0;
        
        while (true) {
            counter++;
        
            const middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
            
            if (counter % 10 === 0) {
                left = Math.max(1, Math.random() * 100);
                right = Math.max(1, Math.random() * 100);
                
                if (left > right) [left, right] = [right, left];
            }
            
            const scores = yield middle;
            scores.sort((a, b) => a - b);
            
            let countLower = 0;
            let countHigher = 0;
            
            for (const score of scores) if (score < middle) countLower++;
            for (const score of scores) if (score > middle) countHigher++;
            
            if (countLower > countHigher) {
                right = middle;
            } else {
                left = middle;
            }
        }
    };
    
    const iterator = stateMachine();
    let score = iterator.next().value;

    return {
        name: "USACO (Unofficial)",
        run: scores => {
            const oldScore = score;
            score = iterator.next(scores).value;
            return oldScore;
        }
    };
})()
```

Comment: This sign can't stop me because I can't read! Is it ok for me to add this bot to the game? (despite unofficial in the title)

Comment: sure thing (padding padding padding annoying padding stack exchange is so nosy lol)

Answer (score 3):

## Greedy

Assumes that all other bot keep their scores the same as last round, and chooses a score that maximizes `own_point - max(other_bots_points)`.

```js
{
  name: "Greedy",
  run(scores){
    let max_index = (arr => arr.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, arr)));
    let point = (avg) => {
      return (s) => Math.sqrt(s*(100-Math.abs(0.8*avg-s)))
    }
    let goal = (scores) => {
      return (mine) => {
        let avg = average(scores.concat([mine]));
        return point(avg)(mine) - Math.max(...scores.map((v,i)=>point(avg)(v)));
      }
    } 

    let avg = average(scores);
    let range = Array(101).fill().map((_,i)=>i);
    return range[max_index(range.map((v,i) => goal(scores)(v)))];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Overshoot (slightly)

I started off with the idea that a CS mark below the target (80% of the average CS mark) is very penalizing. Better then to be too high than too low.

I started off taking the 80th percentile of past averages as my estimation for next round average CS mark, but soon realized that it was too much. Some tweaking of the parameters later I ended up with this result, which takes just slightly above the median.

```
{
    name: "Overshoot (slightly)",
    historyAvg: [],
    rounds: 0,

    run(scores) {
        this.rounds++
        if (this.rounds == 1) return 75.5;

        this.historyAvg.push(average(scores))
        this.historyAvg.sort((a,b) => a-b);
        let estimatedAvg = this.historyAvg[Math.ceil(this.historyAvg.length * 0.535)-1]
        let score = 50 + estimatedAvg * 2/5;

        return score
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

### SimpleCalculus

Just the result of plugging `x = avg` into @Bubbler's formula.

```
{
    name: "SimpleCalculus",
    run: _ => 250 / 3,
}
```

Comment: 33rd out of 60... for such a simple program, I'll take that.

Answer (score 2):

## Elevens

```js
{
    name: "Elevens",
    run() { return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) ) + 1) * 11; }
}
```

Randomly returns 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88 or 99.

Answer (score 2):

## 7-ELEVEn

```
{
  name: "7-ELEVEn",
  run() { return 77 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## ExponentialMovingAverage

```
{
    name: 'ExponentialMovingAverage',
    prev: 80,
    run(scores) { return (scores && scores.length ? average(scores) : 80) * 0.225 + this.prev * 0.775 },
}
```

<s>Returns EMA of the average score.</s> Of course, I forgot to update the previous value, so it does not calculate the EMA, but some mix of the initial and the average score, but it gives much better results than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

## Woulda-Shoulda

```js
{
  name: "WouldaShoulda",
  ownLast: 0,
  isFirst: true,
  run(scores) {
    if (this.isFirst) {
      this.isFirst = false
      this.ownLast = 80
    } else {
      let count = scores.length
      let otherAvg = (sum(scores) - this.ownLast) / (count - 1)
      this.ownLast = (80 * count + otherAvg * count - otherAvg) / (2 * count - 1)
    }
    return this.ownLast
  }
}
```

Returns 80 the first round, then each subsequent round returns what would have been the best option the previous round.

Answer (score 2):

## AverageAverageAverage

```javascript
{
    name: "AverageAverageAverage",
    run: _ => 77.22599053004494
}
```

Turns out AverageAverage is pretty damn good. So, AverageAverageAverage uses an average of its averages.

(Occasionally beats its dynamic namesake in test runs, but I suspect this won't last as more bots get added lmao)

Comment: Isn't this the reason 7eleven did so well in my test runs?

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Didn't even see that one until now, but considering the difference in their constants is less than .226, ...probably

Comment: Also the reason people were still trying to beat Simpleton in the early days of this challenge

Comment: Awesome, love it!

Answer (score 2):

## Chessmaster

Game theory is a lot easier when you know what the other players are going to do.

(In lieu of constantly editing this answer, it is generated by a Stack Snippet based on [the leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5139/43394). I hope this is okay. If not, I'll try to ninja-edit the final version in just before the deadline.)

````js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 224621; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!)qM4PLHIEQza67lA3AlA";

/* App */

var answers = [], answer_page = 1;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  let oreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oreq.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
    if (data.has_more) getAnswers();
    else process();
  });
  oreq.open("GET", answersUrl(answer_page++));
  oreq.send();
}

getAnswers();

function process() {
  let codez = answers.map(a => {
    var body = a.body_markdown;
    
    let x = [];
    let stage = 0;
    body.split("\n").forEach(line => {
      if (line.startsWith("```")) {
        stage += 1;
      } else if (stage == 1) {
        x.push(line);
      }
    });
    if (stage > 0) {
        return x.join("\n");
    }

    x = body.split("\n").filter(
      l => l && l.startsWith("    ")
    );
    return x.join("\n");
  }).map(x => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString("<!DOCTYPE html><body>" + x, "text/html").body.textContent);
  
  document.getElementById("here").innerText = JSON.stringify(codez);
}
````

```html
<code><pre>
{
    name: "Chessmaster",
    pieces: (
        codes => codes.map(
            code => { try {
                return (new Function('return ' + code + ';'))();
            } catch {
                console.log("could not parse", code);
                return undefined;
            }; }
        ).filter(p => p !== undefined)
    )(<span id="here"></span>),
    run(scores) {
        const prediction = this.pieces.map(
            piece => { try {
                return parseInt(piece.run(scores.slice()));
            } catch {
                console.log("could not run", piece.name);
                return NaN;
            }; }
        ).filter(s => 0 <= s && s <= 100);
        const average = prediction.reduce((a,b)=>a+b) / prediction.length;
        return 50 + 0.4*average;
    }
}
</pre></code>
```

Comment: This one doesn't work.. yet?

Answer (score 2):

### Equilibrium

The optimal score is 50 + (0.4 * avg). There is an equilibrium point at approximately 83.333 where the average score is also the optimal score, e.g. avg = 50 + (0.4 * avg).

This bot assumes the average will move towards the equilibrium point, so it picks a point halfway between the equilibrium and the last average. It then chooses the optimal score for that halfway point.

```
{
  name: "Equilibrium",
  equil: 83.333,
  first_round: true,
  run(scores) {
    if (this.first_round) {
      this.first_round = false;
      return this.equil;
    } else {
      let midpoint = (average(scores) + this.equil) / 2;
      return (50 + 0.4*midpoint);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Comment: I think you've got a decent chance of winning with this one.

Answer (score 2):

## SettleDown

Starts off really unpredictably, but over time sets its result closer and closer to the average of the last round

(if this doesn't run, please let me know!)

```javascript
{
    name: "SettleDown",
    rounds: 0,
    lastAverage: 0,
    run(scores) { 
        this.rounds++ 
        this.lastAverage = (sum(scores) - this.lastAverage) /(scores.length - 1)*0.8
        return (this.lastAverage + ( Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 - 50) / (this.rounds/5+1)))%101
    }
}
```

Comment: It should have `run(scores) {` instead of `run() {`

Comment: ah, thanks! I knew I missed something...

Answer (score 1):

## That mean average Joe

```js
{
  name: "That mean average Joe",
  Joe: [],
  run( scores ) {
    this.Joe.push(average(scores)); // like.no.one(ever(did));
    return average(this.Joe)*1.1111111111111111;
  }
}
```

This returns the mean of the averages of the scores of all the turns played so far, multiplied by `1.1111111111111111`.

#### Why 1.111111111111111?

Suppose that the average of every turn is always the same constant and let's take it as the reference unit.

Now knowing that in the next turn the average of the scores will be **1**, our smart move for the Game Theory exam would be to return **0.8**.

However in this way we would score **100%** in Game Theory (impossible to do better) and **80%** in Cybersecurity (relative to the class average) and since the KOTH's final score would be the geometric mean of the two exams, we'd better find a compromise between the two rather than maximise one of them.

The perfect compromise would be scoring **88.88888...%** in both, cause that's **11.11111...%** less than **100%** and more **80%**.

To score **88.88888...%** in Game Theory means being **11.11111...%** away from the average of Cybersecurity scores, doesn't matter if it is 11% more or 11% less.

However if we move to **11.11111...%** more than the average, rather than less, we would get a better score in Cybersecurity, while still scoring the optimal **88.88888...%** in Game Theory.

So returning **11.11111...%** more than the average of the scores is what we want.

In the KOTH challenge the average of the scores is unlikely to be the same every turn, so as a reference unit we take the mean of the averages of the scores of all the turns played so far.

NOTE: This wasn't the actual reasoning that brought me to the constant, my initial reasoning was quite similar but buggy and I tried to fix it till I came up with this. However I wouldn't say that this constant is the result of luck, but rather of intuition. After all it seems that [the purpose of our reasoning has always been to support and explain our intuitions](https://youtu.be/_ArVh3Cj9rw).

Comment: Why don't you just do `*10/9` instead?

Comment: `1.1111111111111111` is harder, better, faster, straighter. `10/9` could be rounded to [1.1111111111111112](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP13D0EDfUtP6/38A "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") which is less accurate.

Comment: Is "harder, better, faster, straighter" a reference to "harder, better, faster, stronger"?

Comment: @leo3065 yes, where straighter is for "more accurate", harder and faster because it's hardcoded, and better as a consequence.

Answer (score 1):

## Golden

This bot was inspired by Self Aware Maximizer, but also takes into account how its own score affects the scores of other players.

Golden uses a golden section search to find which cybersecurity score would have maximized the previous round's score for itself minus the previous round's next best score. It then chooses the average of the optimal cybersecurity scores it has found.

The first cybersecurity score returned was determined by determining the best cybersecurity score for the first round 1000 times in a row, then taking the average.

````js
{
    name: 'Golden',
    previousChoice: 0,
    first: true,
    goldenRatio: (Math.sqrt(5) + 1) / 2,
    weightedBest: 75.28679012885513,
    round: 0,
    goldenSectionSearch(f, min, max, tolerance = 1e-5) {
        while (max - min > tolerance) {
            let leftInterior = max - (max - min) / this.goldenRatio
            let rightInterior = min + (max - min) / this.goldenRatio

            if (f(leftInterior) < f(rightInterior)) {
                max = rightInterior
            } else {
                min = leftInterior
            }
        }
        return (min + max) / 2
    },
    run(choices) {
        if (this.first) {
            this.previousChoice = this.weightedBest
            this.first = false
            return this.weightedBest
        }
        const n = choices.length
        const i = choices.indexOf(this.previousChoice)
        const otherChoices = [...choices.slice(0, i), ...choices.slice(i + 1)]
        const sum = otherChoices.reduce((a, b) => a + b)

        function score(candidate) {
            const average = (sum + candidate) / n
            const gameTheory = 100 - Math.abs(average * 0.8 - candidate)
            const score = Math.sqrt(candidate * gameTheory)
            const otherScores = otherChoices.map(c => {
                const gameTheory = 100 - Math.abs(average * 0.8 - c)
                return Math.sqrt(c * gameTheory)
            })
            const best = Math.max(...otherScores)
            return best - score
        }

        const best = this.goldenSectionSearch(score, 1, 100)
        this.weightedBest = (this.weightedBest * this.round + best) / (this.round + 1)
        this.round++
        this.previousChoice = this.weightedBest
        return this.weightedBest
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## The Skinny

Basically the same as fat, just trying to use less lines of code, by using an approximate constant for average velocity and not using numerical solver.

```
Fat                             78684.97459611233
Skinny                          78684.90970216368 
Overshoot (slightly)            78684.59923852411 
Histogrammer                    78684.24574125063 
ExponentialMovingAverage        78680.78518171726 
Optimise Mean                   78679.65559244195 
Near-stable                     78679.65559244195 
Calculus                        78679.47519324803 
Squidward                       78679.11475381341 
FollowTheLeader                 78677.6890436919 
Smartleton                      78673.66796955772 
Simpleton                       78673.62925366624
```

````javascript
  {
    name: "The Skinny",
    l_a:71.5,
    l_v:2.5,    
    n:0,
    run(s){      
      let a = sum(s)/s.length;
      let va =Math.sqrt(sum(s.map(function(x){return Math.abs(x - a)})));
      let p = 0.3*(((va - this.l_v)>0?1:-1)*4.8 - (a - this.l_a));
      this.l_a = a;this.l_v = va;this.n++;
      return this.n <2 ? 77 : 50+(a+p)*2/5;
    }
},
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## 78

Turns out 78 is much better than 77

```
{
    name: "78",
    run(s){
      return 78;
    }
},
```

Comment: A bit late eh..