# Time bomb (KoTH)

Tags: king-of-the-hill, javascript

In this challenge, players need to tamper with a time bomb as late as possible without getting blasted in the face.

### Mechanics

Let `N` be the number of bots plus one. Each round, each bot receives the following arguments:

- numbers played by all bots last round in ascending order.
- number of points it received last round. Negative if it lost last round.

The bot is asked to play an integer between 1 to `N` inclusive. After all bots played their numbers, a counter is initialized with half of the sum of numbers from all bots. Each bots then subtracts the number it played from the counter. Bots are sorted from the lowest to the highest. Bots with the same number are considered subtracts the counter at the same time. The bomb explodes when the counter hits zero or becomes negative.

### Scoring

After the bomb exploded, the round ends, and the points for this round is calculated as the following:

- Bots that played before the explosion get the number of points equal to **twice** the number it played this round.
- Bots that played when the explosion lose the number of points equal to the number it played this round.
- Bots that played after the explosion do not get nor receive point.

Example rounds:

- Number played: `[1,2,3,4,5]`. The initial counter is 7.5, and the bomb explodes on 4. The bot with 1, 2, and 3 gets 2, 4, and 6 points respectively, the bot with 4 loses 4, and the bot with 5 neither gets not lose points.
- Number played: `[1,1,2,4]`. The initial counter is 4, and the bomb explodes on 2. Bots with 1 gets 2 points, the bot with 2 loses 2, and the bot with 4 neither gets not lose points.
- Number played: `[3,3,3,3]`. The initial counter is 6, and the bomb explodes on 3. All bots lose 3 points.

The point for each round is added to a total score for that run. Each run consist of 1000 rounds, and there will be 10 runs. The final total score is the sum of each run, and the bot with the highest final score the the end wins.

### Specifications

The challenge is in JS.

Your bot must be an object that has a `run` method that takes an array of numbers and a number as input, and returns a integer between 1 and `N` inclusive. The value being outside the valid range will be rounded and clamped. If the value is not a number, a number in the valid range will be selected and the behavior of selecting the number is not specified.

On the first round, the array of numbers given will be initialized with random numbers, and the number for points last round will be 0.

### Other rules

- Storing data in your bot's properties is allowed.
- You can use the `Math.random` method. During scoring, [seedrandom.min.js](http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html) will be used, with a secret string concatenated with the run number as the seed for each run. The md5 of the secret string is `4311868bf10b3f7c1782982e68e6d7ca`, for proving that I didn't change the key after the challenge.
- You can use the helper function `sum`.
- Trying to access any other variables outside your bot's own properties is forbidden.
- [Standard loopholes apply.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

The code for controller can be found [here](https://github.com/leo3065/TIme-bomb-KoTH). Feel free to point out mistakes in my code, thanks.

### Example bots

```js
{
  // Example bot
  // It always play the middle number.
  name: "Middle", 
  run(number) {
    return Math.round((numbers.length+2)/2);
  }
}
```

```js
{
  // Example bot
  // It starts at 1, advances when it got points last round,
  // and resets when it lost points.
  name: "Advance and reset",
  last: 1, // Setting properties is allowed
  run(numbers, points) {
    var own = this.last;
    if(points > 0){
      own = Math.min(this.last+1, numbers.length+1);
    }
    if(points < 0){
      own = 1;
    }
    this.last = own;
    return own;
  }
}
```

Both example bots above will also play in the game.

## Submissions are due by 2021-05-06 12:00 UTC, but might be lenient depending on when I'm online after the said time above.

Comment: This is almost identical to the other KotH, just the numbers you need to optimize are slightly different. I'm not sure if this was sandboxed or not, but it probably could have used a lot more feedback.

Comment: @Redwolf This is sandoxed here, which is posted 2 days ago: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/22233#22233

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of [xkcd 2385 KoTH (Final Exam)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224621/66833). As noted by Redwolf, the strategy is going to be almost identical, just with different numbers, and IMO that makes this essentially the same challenge

Comment: I am closing this challenge for the reasons caird gave. Since both just involve "maximize a number without making it too much larger than everyone else" or equivalently "pick a low number without it being too low", strategies will be very uncreative / identical to the other KoTH.

Comment: I don't see how the two challenges are the same
The old KoTH was in favour of all strategies converging: if everyone played rationally they would arrive at a single point, the only challenge was about finding the variance other players make and take slight advantage of it.
In this challenge if everyone plays the same "optimal" strategy, everyone ends up loosing and can improve their gain. I would almost say there is no Nash equilibrium let alone an optimal equilibrium.

Comment: To support on @IQuick143, [here](https://imgur.com/a/bzgDdwI) is a round history of xkcd KoTH with all the bots included. Each line in the plot represent a 10% percentile e.g. 0%, 10%, ..., 100% percentile for score outputted by the bot for each round. You can see that at least 40% of the score (40% to 80%) quickly converge to the range between 75 and 80 in less then 10 rounds. This with the buffer created by these "simpleton" bots, plus that the point is a single-humped function of the score, means that the optimal play is to converge and make use of deviation caused by more random bots.

Comment: (cont.) In contrast, in this challenge, not only the reward function isn't a single-humped, it's also not continuous since the decision space is discrete, with the decision of maximum possible reward right next to the one with the minimum. That combined with the rule that the bots playing the same number subtract the counter together means that converges with other bots will only cause everyone to lose points together.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Please consider my reasoning and reconsider.

Comment: I agree, the scoring function here is different enough from the one of the other challenge that I would expect the best strategies to be different as well

Comment: @hyper-neutrino: I participated in the xkcd 2385 KoTH, and I want to give my two cents. Yes, on the one hand, my FollowTheLeader bot could be ported over without changing the core concept (i.e. "piggybacking" on the behavior of other bots). But on the other hand, I have an idea for a more conservative bot I would also like to try...which would have made no sense in the last challenge, because there was no sense of "conservative" and "high-risk" as competing strategies where it was unclear which one would succeed. That gives this challenge a very different flavor. I want this to be reopened.

Comment: @MJ713 Even if some slightly different strategies will exist, both challenges are just about finding a high number without going too high and ending up losing as a result. It's a simple modification on an even simpler challenge that won't end up offering anything particularly new or interesting. There's nothing wrong with simple KoTHs but this doesn't add anything. I've discussed with several other users and we agree to keep it closed.

Comment: Reopen voters: This is a half-dupe of two KotHs, the xkcd one and the smallest unique number one. It's not an exact duplicate of either, and answers will still be slightly different from either, but it does not add anything new and it encourages trivial KotHs.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
  name: "Playing It Safe",
  run(numbers) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, this is good

Answer (score 4):

Some "basic" bots to get this started, also to serve as baseline (they will also play in the game):

```
{
  name: "33%",
  run(numbers) {
    return numbers[Math.floor(numbers.length/3)];
  }
}
```

```
{
  name: "Pure random",
  run(numbers) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (numbers.length+1))+1;
  }
}
```

```
{
  name: "Copy random",
  run(numbers) {
    return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
  }
}
```

```
{
  name: "Alternate",
  round: 0,
  run(numbers) {
    this.round++
    return (this.round % 2)? 1 : (numbers.length + 1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Smart Random

```
{
name: "Smart Random", 
  run(numbers) {
    var random_int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 * (numbers.length+1)/4);
    return random_int
  }
}
```

Returns a random integer between 0 and 3/4`N`  inclusive.

I hope this works - this is my first JS and my first KoTH answer.

Comment: You missed a right parenthesis, but I fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks, @leo3065, this is my first JS answer

Answer (score 2):

## Coinflipper

Starts by initialising `x` to half of `N`, then flips `N` coins. If heads, decrement `x` (unless already zero). If tails, increment `x` (unless already equal to `N`).

```javascript
{
  name: "Coinflipper",
  run(numbers) {
    let x = Math.floor(numbers.length/2);
    numbers.forEach(function(){
        let coin = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2)+1)
        if (coin==1) { x--; }
        else if (coin==2) { x++; }
        if (x<0) { x=0; }
        if (x>numbers.length) { x=numbers.length; }
    });
    return x;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `x` and `coin`. I added `let` for you.

Comment: Ah whoops, forgot to do that. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

## Painfully Average

```js
{
    name: "Painfully Average",
    run: (n)=>Math.abs(Math.floor(n.reduce((a,x)=>a+x))/n.length-1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## OnePlus

Plays one plus a random floating point between 0 and a random integer between 0 and 5.

```js
{
  name: "OnePlus",
  run(numbers) {
    return 1 + Math.random() * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  }
}
```

My first King Of The Hill answer, not sure if I am doing things correctly. From my understanding, `numbers` is the list of numbers of the bots? But I am completely ignoring that `numbers`.

Comment: It's correct. Technically you should check if the output is valid, but since we already have more than 6 bots, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

## D8roller

Rolls a 8-sided die, and plays that number.

```js
{
  name: "D8roller",
  run(numbers) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*8)+1;
  }
}
```